# Print a 10 by 10 grid of asterisks

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

## Background

This is a standard textbook example to demonstrate for loops.

This is one of the first programs I learnt when I started learning programming ~10 years ago.

## Task

You are to print this exact text:

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

## Specs

- You may have extra trailing newlines.
- You may have extra trailing spaces (U+0020) at the end of each line, including the extra trailing newlines.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with this. The chrome dev tools print repetition on one line. e.g, here it would print `(10)**********` is that acceptable, as we know it's a dev-tool 'optimisation'?

Comment: @DylanMeeus "You are to print this **exact** text:"

Comment: @DylanMeeus Since that is to do with the dev tools hiding repeated console outputs, and isn't native to JavaScript consoles as a whole and is not in the JavaScript spec - as well as the fact that feature can be turned off - i think it should be acceptable. Not all browsers will collapse it like that.

Comment: @JamesTrotter oh I didn't notice that it can be turned off, cheers!

Comment: @LeakyNun Leaderboard snippet please!

Comment: One of the most interesting things about this challange is that depending on your language ********** can be shorter then a loop. Makes me wonder when it's better for a given language to switch between 1 or 2 loops.

Comment: Do they have to be astricks? What about newlines?

Comment: The shortest solution in JavaScript I can come up with to print to browser in JavaScript is `for(d=document.body,i=0;10>i++;d.innerHTML+='<br>')for(j=0;10>j++;)d.innerHTML+='*'`. I'd love to post this as an answer, but for some reason this question is "protected" and I don't have enough reputation here yet to post answers to "protected" questions.

Comment: you say trailing new lines are acceptable. Are leading newlines acceptable too?

Comment: Lua: `c="**********";print(c:gsub("*",c.."\n"))`

Answer (score 90):

## [Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 47 bytes

```
++++++++++[->++++>+>+<<<]>++>[-<..........>>.<]
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KysrKysrKysrK1stPisrKys-Kz4rPDw8XT4rKz5bLTwuLi4uLi4uLi4uPj4uPF0&input=)

```
++++++++++[->++++>+>+<<<]   set the tape to 40 10 10
>++>                        set the tape to 42 10 10
[-<..........>>.<]          come on
```

Comment: +1 for emoticon in the code `>.<`

Comment: +1 for the fish bones `>++>`

Answer (score 84):

## C (gcc), <strike>41</strike> 39 bytes

```
main(i){for(;++i<puts("**********"););}
```

Comment: what version of c?

Comment: @Zaibis Works fine on gcc: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/848cb22a00c35c29 .

Comment: Add this info. I got that `i` is undcleared ;) So I can un downvote.

Comment: looks good, good ol' ANSI C.

Comment: `main(i){while(11-i++)puts("**********");}` is an alternative, same length.

Comment: @YSC I saved two more bytes :)

Comment: I like the clever use of the return from `puts()` (and of the initial value of `i`).

Answer (score 82):

### Bash + coreutils, 19 bytes

I prefer to repeat stuff in Bash using 'yes'.

```
yes **********|head
```

I saved 2 bytes by @Neil's suggestion. But when the directory where you are running this command does not only contain files starting with a '.' dot you need to enclose the stars `*` with `"`.

### Bash + coreutils, 21 bytes

```
yes "**********"|head
```

Comment: Great idea to use `yes`. We usually label such solutions as “Bash + coreutils”.

Comment: Nice that 10 lines coincidentally happens to be the default for `head`.

Comment: Can you save two bytes by requiring that any files in the current directory must begin with a `.`?

Comment: @Neil, is your comment ment for my answer? If so, I do not get it :)

Comment: Normally `echo *` expands to all the files in the current directory that don't begin with a `.`; if there are no such files though, the `*` has no effect.

Comment: I do not get it. `yes` just repeats the following text over and over. I do not use `echo` here... I just do not see what you mean.

Comment: @CousinCocaine: His point was that you can get away with not quoting the `**********` command-line argument if the program is always run in a directory where no files match that pattern.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Aha! I get it! So is it 'legal' to golf the "?

Comment: You can also write `yes \**********|head` without the restriction on files.

Comment: @FlorianF and what if the filename starts with an *?

Comment: @CousinCocaine If a file starts with a * then it doesn't work.  :-(  So it is just a good compromise.  Having a file that starts with * is much less likely than to sit in a non-empty directory.

Comment: In programming, relying on 'less likely' is dangerous, but you are right, it also wont work with a file named **********

Answer (score 56):

### Vim, <s>13</s> 8 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Lynn

```
qqi*␛9.o␛q9@q
```

```
10i*␛Y9p
```

`10i*␛` insert 10 times `*`, and `Y9p` copy the line and paste it 9 times.

Comment: `10i*♥Y9p` works.

Comment: That's insane vi.

Comment: I think you can count keystrokes instead of bytes for text editors, which means <ESC> would be shorter.

Comment: @addison `<ESC>` is 1 byte

Comment: Oh nevermind, I misread the answer. I see now

Comment: Why ♥ and not ␛ ?

Comment: Can you provide some explanation as to why this works? Great work (+1)

Comment: I would have used `yy9p` myself, but nice job using capitals to save a character!

Comment: @CL. Vim is love, Vim is life

Answer (score 55):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
VT*T\*
```

`T` is 10 in Pyth, `Vab` executes statement `b` `a` times, `\*` is the asterisk character constant, and multiplying (`*`) a string and an integer repeats that string n times. Pyth's implicit printing with `V` means 10 lines are printed.

Answer (score 49):

### Hexagony, <del>37</del> <del>35</del> <del>34</del> 31

```
10"+}(=${";<$<1}42/.0@_=<>\;>(_
```

Expanded:

```
   1 0 " +
  } ( = $ {
 " ; < $ < 1
} 4 2 / . 0 @
 _ = < > \ ;
  > ( _ . .
   . . . .
```

[Try it online](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=MTAiK30oPSR7Ijs8JDwxfTQyLy4wQF89PD5cOz4oXw&input=)

Basically just has two for loops counting down from ten to zero, printing out an asterisk on the inner loop, and a newline on the outer loop.

#### Explanation:

This program consists of three main parts: initialisation of memory, a loop which prints ten asterisks and a loop which prints a newline. The loop which prints a newline also contains the loop which prints the asterisks.

First, the code runs the totally linear memory initialisation. The code works out to be: `10"+}42`. This sets the memory of the nearby edges to look like:

```
10 \ / 10
    |
   42
```

42 is the ASCII code for the asterisk character, and the two tens will be used as our loop counters. Of note is that the memory pointer is currently pointing away from the two tens, so moving backwards will put us on one of the tens.

Next, we start the astersisk printing loop. Linearly, the code looks like: `;".._(`. This prints out an asterisk, moves the memory pointer backwards and to the left and finally decrements the value there. After one iteration, the memory would look like:

```
10 \ / 9
    |
   42
```

Then we hit the loop condition: the bottom-leftmost `>`. If the edge we just decremented is still positive we bounce around and execute a `{` to move us back onto the 42. Then we hit a `$` and return to the beginning of the printing loop, the `;`, by skipping the `<`. If the value was zero, we head into the other loop.

The outer loop begins by resetting the recently zeroed memory edge to ten (this is the `10` in the code, going southwest). Then, we print out this ten as an ASCII character, which is a newline. Next, we move onto the other memory edge and decrement it with `{(` and then execute what amounts to a bunch of noops: `=${_=`. Now, after one iteration of this loop, memory would look like:

```
 9 \ / 10
    |
   42
```

This time, the memory is facing outwards from the edge storing a nine in the above diagram. Next we execute the `<` which acts as the loop condition for the outer loop. If the value was non-zero we bounce around off of some mirrors, then begin executing meaningful instructions again after entering the top of the hexagon at the `"` moving southwest. This causes us to move backwards and to the left, onto the 42 again, but facing inwards. Then the `=` flips our direction, resetting the state properly to begin the inner loop again. If the edge was set to zero, the instruction pointer goes on a little adventure which does nothing until it exits the program.

The adventure begins by the instruction pointer venturing northeast, perilously disregarding the safety of the cardinal directions. It bravely ignores a mirror that is aligned with its diretion (`/`) and heroically leaps off of a trampoline (`$`) entirely evading the deadly trap of another, totally identical trampoline. Staring out at the emptiness of uninitialised hexagon edges, the pointer, without faltering for a moment, adds the two blank edges it faces together, setting the current edge to their sum: 0 (the edge was actually zero beforehand, but the pointer likes to believe this was pretty important). Since the edge is zero, the pointer makes a left turn at the fork in the road, walking into a mysterious forest (of hexagons). There, it finds itself disoriented, moving forwards and backwards and forwards, until it winds up at the same place in memory as it started. Thinking that the problem must be that the current edge was set to zero last time, the pointer bravely plants a `1` into the current edge. Then, the noble pointer investigates another path, one laid with... a trap! The current edge is decremented and set back to zero! The pointer, dazed by the shocking turn of events, stumbles back into the trap setting the current edge to negative one. Infuriated, the pointer attempts to return to the comparatively pleasant forest, only to notice that since the current edge is not positive, the paths have yet again shifted and the pointer finds itself walking into a cave. And by a cave, I mean the mouth of a giant hexagonal worm. Helpless, the pointer curses the sexinity with its dying breath. Also, the program ends.

Comment: Golly, I hope the worm was OK with swallowing a pointer. Those things can *hurt*.

Comment: +1 for writing the most interesting—the only—Hexagony explanation I've ever read. I felt so tense when the edge was decremented!

Answer (score 44):

### Emacs, <s>10</s> 8 keystrokes

<kbd>F3</kbd> <kbd>C-1</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> <kbd>C-9</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd>

#### Explanation

```
F3             Starts a macro recording
C-1 0 *        Apply 10 times command '*': prints 10 asterix'
ENTER          Insert new line
F4             Stops the macro record
C-9 F4         Apply 9 times the macro
```

*Thanks to Sean for saving two keystrokes, suggesting to replace <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>digit</kbd> with <kbd>C-digit</kbd>.*

Comment: +1, I always upvote text editor answers (even though I'm more of a vim guy myself) :)

Comment: If `C-u` counts as just one keystroke, then you can shave off two strokes by typing `C-1 C-0` (or `M-1 M-0`) instead of `C-u 1 0` and `C-9` instead of `C-u 9`.

Comment: +1 because you had to suffer through using emacs to write this.

Comment: Alternatively (saves nothing) the line repetition can be done inside the macro: `F3` `C-1` `0` `*` `ENTER` `C-1` `0` `F4`

Comment: @JonathanCarroll yes it would save bytes if we were to print more than 10 lines ;)

Comment: @DrMcMoylex Even is they're spam? (Not that this answer is, +1 for no vim)

Answer (score 32):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
”*x⁵Ṅ9¡
```

What's going on?

```
”*x⁵Ṅ9¡  - No arguments
”*       - character literal, *
  x      - multiply (dyadic operation)
   ⁵     - integer literal, 10 (we have now constructed the string '**********')
    Ṅ    - Print & linefeed (monadic operation)
     9   - integer literal, 9
      ¡  - Repeat n times (n is 9 as the first Ṅ is not a repeat)
```

Test it on **[tryitonline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdKnjigbXhuYQ5wqE&input=)**

Comment: I really like the `Ṅ9¡`.

Comment: List version: `”*ẋ⁵Wẋ⁵`.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer you'd need a `Y` on the end to "print this exact text"

Comment: @JonathanAllan It is a list on its own, though. It isn't meant to "print this exact text", but, if you want to work on it, you'll use it.

Answer (score 29):

### PowerShell, <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
,('*'*10)*10
```

Constructs a string of asterisks of length `10` using string multiplication. Encapsulates that in parens and feeds that into the comma-operator to construct an array. We use array multiplication to construct a 10-element array consisting of that element (i.e., a 10-element array of asterisk strings). That's left on the pipeline, and output is implicit (since the default `Write-Output` for an array is newline-separated, we get that for free -- thanks to @Joey for the clarification).

#### Older, 14 bytes

```
0..9|%{'*'*10}
```

Full program. Loops from `0` to `9` through a `ForEach-Object` loop `|%{...}`. Each iteration, we use string multiplication to create a length-`10` string of `*`. Those resulting strings are left on the pipeline, and output at the end is implicit (since the default `Write-Output` for an array is newline-separated, we get that for free -- thanks to @Joey for the clarification).

Comment: I like it, because powershell can get so verbose. Yet this is elegant and short.

Comment: Well, technically the array is never passed through a `ToString`, it's unrolled and passed element by element to Write-Output. In contexts where the array is converted to a string, you get its elements space-separated.

Comment: @Joey Ah, fair, that's a better way to put it. I'll edit the wording (and my answer template ;-)).

Comment: I may be biased here because I'm involved with a PowerShell implementation so I had to learn a lot of what actually goes on inside the interpreter ;)

Answer (score 26):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 7 bytes

```
10é*10Ä
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=MTDDqSoxMMOE&input=)

About as straightforward as an answer can be.

Explanation:

```
10      "10 times:
  é*    "insert an asterisk
    10Ä "make 10 copies of the current line
```

5 bytes:

```
10O±*
```

Explanation:

```
10O     " Insert the following on the next ten lines:
   ±    "   10 copies of
    *   "   an asterisk
```

This didn't work when the challenge was posted because of a bug.

Comment: Point of order: é and Ä are multibyte characters (at least in utf-8, as you have them here) so this program is 9 bytes long.

Comment: @rob They are encoded in utf-8 here, because that's just the way the browser works. V uses "Latin1" encoding, where they are `E9` and `C4` respectively.

Answer (score 23):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish/blob/master/doc.md), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

*Thanks to Zgarb for saving 2 bytes.*

```
P$'*
 &;10
```

[Try it online!](http://jellyfish.tryitonline.net/#code=UCQnKgogJjsxMA&input=WzEwIDEwXQ)

#### Explanation

Using more conventional notation, this program represents the following expression:

```
P( $( &;(10), '* ) )
```

`&;` takes a single value and creates a pair with two times that value, so `&;(10)` gives us `[10 10]`. Then `$` is reshape which forms a 10x10 grid of asterisks. Finally, `P` prints the array in "matrix format" which prints each string on its own line.

Answer (score 22):

## **HTML & CSS, <s>104</s> 60 bytes**

```css
p::after{content:"**********"
```

```html
<p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p><p>
```

<sup>I'm unsure if the byte count is correct (as I'm not counting the `<style>` tags for CSS. The HTML could also be shortened if I used a HTML preprocessor, but I'm unsure if that's breaking rules</sup>

Thanks to manatwork and Business Cat.

<sup>See my [Jade entry of 36 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90231/38505)</sup>

Comment: You can leave out the self closing `/`s and write all tags in the same line. But better change the tags to `<p>` as it is shorter even if you need to add `p{margin:0}`.

Comment: You can also get rid of the space after `div::after`, and you can leave out the closing brace after the content, if [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0h0wpq7/) is any indication.

Comment: @manatwork & Business Cat - thanks guys

Comment: This is not valid css. You need the closing bracket!

Comment: @RichardHamilton valid css and working css are not the same thing

Comment: You can reduce 2 bytes by using `:after` instead of `p::after`. (that is valid CSS2 syntax)

Comment: Thanks @IsmaelMiguel but this gives an output not equal to one that is expected - the left hand side isn't a straight edge.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ My method has a bug. Using it, you must remove 2 `<p>`. This is because `<body>` and `<html>` can have an `:after` pseudo-element, displaying a total of 12 lines. And yes, the **styling** of the output is different, but saving 2 + 6 bytes is a nice tradeoff.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'm a little new to code-golf submissions. Would the different output style cause this answer to become wrong?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I don't think so, but, you can add it as an alternative below, and leave a comment on the question, asking about this. But, even if the new output is invalid, using `p:after` works and is 1 byte shorter.

Comment: Your HTML code is not valid, if you put content after that it will be considered as a child of each `<p>` you written...

Comment: @ClementNerma Why should anyone put code after this?

Comment: What do you means ?

Comment: @ClementNerma This is a program, so code won't be added. If it was a snippet, it would indeed be invalid. (And, if it was valid as a snippet, it would have still been invalid, because snippets are forbidden by default.) Also, Code Golf isn't about writing valid, perfect code. It's about writing *short* code. And, if you didn't know, you can reply to one other person (not two) using `@username`. For me, it's `@EriktheGolfer` (I don't like it as `@Eri`, but it works).

Comment: you can leave off the last `>` I believe

Comment: This is not valid HTML&CSS. It happens to work with major browser but not with stricter ones.

Comment: @YSC See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/88653/print-a-10-by-10-grid-of-asterisks/88871?noredirect=1#comment217115_88871 - what are the stricter ones? Works with the latest version of Google Chrome / Mozilla Firefox / Edge

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I agree: valid != working. And who doesn't hate to hear "but it works"? This is a working solution, not a valid one.

Answer (score 19):

## Python 2, <del>22</del> 21 bytes

```
print('*'*10+'\n')*10
```

Comment: `print(("*"*10+'\n')*10)` worked for me.

Comment: @piepi That's why you're usually better off golfing in Python 2 - you don't need parentheses when calling `print`.

Comment: @shooqie You can't beat a Python3 solution using Python2.  Python2 and Python3 are different languages.  You also wouldn't compare the Python2 solution to a specialized golf language like Pyth.

Comment: Original code prints TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int' #Edit didn't notice it was python 2. Piepi's code worked for me

Answer (score 19):

## [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)), 9 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Works on all APLs ever made.

```apl
10 10⍴'*'
```

`10 10` ten rows and ten column

`⍴` cyclically **r**epeating

`'*'` a star

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=10%2010%u2374%27*%27&run)

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution is not Dyalog-specific; it also works with GNU APL.

Comment: @Arc676 True. In fact, it works on all APLs ever made.

Comment: argh, I need just one more byte... I _almost_ beat you with the "format" trick: `∘.⊢⍨⍕⍨,⍨5`

Comment: @ngn That's wonderfully horrible!

Answer (score 18):

## Notepad, <strike>34</strike> 31 keystrokes

```
**********
^A^C↓^V^A^C↓^V^V^V^V
```

^ denotes Ctrl-<following character> keypress, ↑↓ are up and down keys, respectively.

Props to Crypto for 3 saved keystrokes.

Comment: You should use keystrokes to count this.

Comment: Ctrl-↑ isn't doing anything for me

Comment: Are you including the newline after typing the ten asterisks?  When starting from the line below, Ctrl-↑ should select the entire line above, newline included.

Comment: @MicahDombrowski yes, I am. replacing Ctrl-↑ with Ctrl-A works for me.

Comment: That's Shift+Up. Ctrl+Up is something else.

Comment: 31 keystrokes
`**********↵^A^C↓^V^A^C↓^V^V^V^V`

Comment: @Neil Derp, yeah.  My finger was hitting Shift, but I kept thinking Ctrl.

Comment: @Crypto Nice...

Comment: @Mego KC challenge don't have to be answered in programming languages.

Comment: @Mego http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world?page=5&tab=votes#comment163773_55716

Comment: 26 keystrokes `*****^A^C^V^V↵^A^C^V^A^C^V^V^V^V^V`

Comment: 23 keystrokes `**^A^C^V^V^V^V^V↵^A^C^V^V^A^C^V^V^V^V^V`

Comment: @Andy Ctrl counts as a keypress. That last one is 39.

Comment: @mbomb007 so then doesn't shift also count for the typing of the asterisks? It would be 41, then, and the answer posted would be 41 as well.

Comment: @Andy Hmm...may have a point there.  I suppose it's a good question as to whether each 'usage' of a modifier key counts, or just each press of it, when you can hold it down over multiple 'uses'.  If that makes sense.

Comment: You can also use <kbd> tags to represent the keys to press

Comment: @Andy Asterisk can be typed using the numpad for a single key press.

Comment: This is beautiful!

Answer (score 16):

### MATLAB, 14 bytes

```
repmat('*',10)
```

Comment: I don't have MATLAB to test this, so I'm unsure if this has spaces between the `*`s.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer clearly not :)

Comment: `mat` suggests a matrix, that's why I asked.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer excuse me, I was rude. Mat, in fact, refers to a matrix, but in this case is a matrix of char, that is an array of strings (every row is like a string). So, the outupt matrix is printed one row for line, without spaces between elements of the same row.

Answer (score 15):

### Java 7, 63 bytes

```
void f(){for(int i=0;i++<10;)System.out.println("**********");}
```

Just for kicks. I can't seem to find any tricks to make this shorter. Trying to add logic for a 100-loop or returning a String instead of printing just ends up worse.

Comment: You can shave it off by one byte if you declare `i` as a class variable (it defaults to `0`): `int i;void f(){for(;i++<10;)System.out.println("**********");}`

Comment: That would break [reusability](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4940/14215) unless I did `i=0` somewhere in the function, negating the savings.

Comment: +1 Seems you're indeed right that this is the shortest.. Recursive is 65 bytes: `int i=10;void f(){System.out.println("**********");if(i-->0)g();}`; One by one recursive is 67 bytes: `int i=99;void f(){System.out.print(i%10<1?"*\n":"*");if(i-->0)g();}`; Using String-constructor with char-array is 82 bytes: `void g(){System.out.print(new String(new char[10]).replace("\0","**********\n"));}`; and a String.format is 81 bytes: `void g(){System.out.print(String.format("%010d",0).replace("0","**********\n"));}`. Ah well, we tried. ;)

Comment: But does it count without having to add the class declaration itself? What is the shortest java7 full program that can do this?

Comment: Writing a method instead of a full working program is permitted as far as I'm concerned. Shortest way to write a full program would be to include the loop in the `main` method, which is considerably longer (you need to include `public static void main(String[]A)` and wrap it in a class.

Comment: Or a lambda expression would also work and be a bit shorter

Comment: @DanielM. That would work in Java 8, but I specifically use 7 because I feel Java's way of handling lambdas doesn't jibe with my idea of "fair" for golfing purposes.

Comment: @Geobits Fair enough

Comment: If you static import System.out you can shave another 7 characters off.. not sure if that's allowed :)

Comment: @Kylar: How would you do that?

Comment: You have to count the import statement, so it wouldn't work for savings here.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know if it would help.

Comment: Recursive is actually the shortest:

`void f(int x){System.out.println("**********");if(x-->1)f(x);}`

Beats this answer by only 1 byte.

Comment: @Hypino Only if you add an argument to the function which isn't given in the challenge. I read it as "given no input, print this text".

Comment: @Geobits I actually don't see anywhere in the challenge that says anything about input being not allowed. But I'll take your word for it.

Comment: I mean to say, that's my reading of it. I'll hold myself to it.

Answer (score 14):

## Ruby, 15 characters

```ruby
puts [?**10]*10
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ruby -e 'puts [?**10]*10'
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Comment: Can you explain `?**10`? It does indeed create a string of ten asterisks, but I'm unclear how...

Comment: The `?` is the character literal notation, so `?* == '*'`. The 2nd `*` is the [`String.*` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-2A), so `?**10 == '*'.*(10)`.

Comment: Afraid I still don't understand why `?` is the literal notation of anything, but perhaps some questions are better left unanswered. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I can't find any reference on this. Is simply the Ruby syntax, which allows [various string literal notations](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) plus one in case the string is 1 character long: a `?` mark followed by the character, without requiring a closing pair of the `?` mark.

Comment: I found it in the reference here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html
`There is also a character literal notation to represent single character strings, which syntax is a question mark (?) followed by a single character or escape sequence that corresponds to a single codepoint in the script encoding:`

Answer (score 14):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org), 54 bytes

```
i⏩0 10**********
```

Explanation:

```
                         The beginning of program.
     i ⏩ 0 10            This is called a "range".
                          It basically starts with i=0 and increments until i=10, then exits. 
         **********      is printing class.
                          The s make the characters they surround string literals. 
                          End of range
                          End of program
```

Comment: I count 54 utf-8 bytes.

Comment: This language hates WIndows 7...

Answer (score 11):

### 05AB1E, 7 bytes

```
TF'*T×,
```

**Explanation**

```
TF      # 10 times do:
  '*T×  # repeat asterisk 10 times
      , # print with newline
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=VEYnKlTDlyw&input=WzEsMiwzLDQsNV0)

Comment: `т'*×Tô»` is another completely different one lol.

Comment: `TLú'*ζ»` using the zip-filler was another idea... bad one though.

Answer (score 11):

### Brainfuck, <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```
+[[---<]+[-->]<]<<[--<<++..........-->>>.<]
```

[Try it online!](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=K1tbLS0tPF0rWy0tPl08XTw8Wy0tPDwrKy4uLi4uLi4uLi4tLT4-Pi48XQ&input=) Requires an interpreter with a tape that is open on the left and has 8-bit cells.

The first part of this program `+[[---<]+[-->]<]` sets up the tape like so:

```
[255, 250, 245, ... 15, 10, 5, 0, 250, 240, 230, ..., 40, 30, 20, 10, 0]
                                                                      ^
```

This gives a 40 for outputting asterisks (`*`, ASCII 42), a 20 to use as a loop counter, and a 10 to use for outputting newlines.

Answer (score 10):

### R, <strike>27</strike> 29 bytes

```
cat(rep('\r**********\n',10))
```

An alternate answer (34 bytes) is: `cat(rep('**********',10),sep='\n')`

Comment: This adds an extra space at the beginning of all lines except the first (see [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=CDfxxMjr) ).

Comment: Thanks, it works adding `\r`.

Comment: Another alternative, too many (37) bytes: `cat(matrix('*',10,10),fill=10,sep='')` [r-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=WjLGaaDh)

Comment: Another alternative, also 29 bytes: `write(rep("*",100),"",10,,"")`

Comment: Dropping `\n`from the above works for [27 bytes:](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMotUBDKaZICw6UdAwNNDX//wcA)

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMotUBDiUsLDpR0DA00Nf//BwA "R – Try It Online") if you hardcode the carriage return.

Comment: And `write(rep("**",50),1,5,,"")` is 27 bytes and avoids the first carriage return.

Answer (score 10):

## PHP, 32 bytes

```
for(;$i++<10;)echo"**********
";
```

(variant 32 bytes - was written with `echo`)

```
<?=str_repeat("**********
",10);
```

(variant 33 bytes)

```
<?=str_pad("",110,"**********
");
```

(variant 33 bytes)

```
for(;$i++<110;)echo$i%11?"*":"
";
```

(variant 35 bytes)

```
for(;$i++<10;)printf("%'*10s
",'');
```

(variant 38 bytes)

```
<?=($a=str_repeat)($a("*",10)."
",10);
```

Comment: The second one can be golfed to *32 bytes* as well: `<?=str_repeat("**********↵",10);`

Comment: As you already have a nice collection of alternatives, here is another for fun: `echo chunk_split(str_repeat("*",100),10);` The longest so far, just in my vision this is _the_ PHP way to do it.

Comment: Can be a byte shorter with WIN-1252 encoding: `for(;++$i<111;)echo$i%11?~Õ:~õ;` or `for(;++$i<11;)echo~ÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕõ;`

Comment: Another modulo variant for 33 bytes: `for(;$i++<110;)echo"*↵"[$i%11<1];`. And to add a 37 bytes solution to that collection: `for(;$i++<110;)echo chr($i%11?42:10);`.

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
'*'10tX"
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=JyonMTB0WCI&input=)

```
'*'   % Push '*' (string containing an asterisk)
10t   % Push 10 twice
X"    % Repeat the string 10×10 times. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

```
console.log(`**********
`.repeat(10))
```

A straightforward answer.

Comment: Cant you save 6 by using `alert` ?

Comment: Arguably you could save 13 bytes by removing the `console.log()` and specifying `REPL` in the title.

Answer (score 7):

## Brainfuck, 74 bytes

first brainfuck submission ever, first reasonable length program, too

```
+++>>+++>>+++++++[<+<+<<+>>>>-]<[>++++++<-]<<<[->++++++++++[>>>.<<<-]>.<<]
```

```
+++>>+++>>+++++++[<+<+<<+>>>>-]<[>++++++<-] < sets tape to 10 0 10 0 42

                                           <<< moves to the first 10
            [->++++++++++[>>>.<<<-]>.<<] <
loops while the first cell of the tape is not zero:
    subtracts 1 from first cell
    sets the second cell to 10,
    loops while second cell is not zero: prints 42 cell, subtracts from second cell
    moves to third cell, prints it
```

Comment: [57 bytes](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=LS1bPis8KysrKysrXSsrKysrKysrKys-LTxbLT4-Kz4rPDw8XT4-Wy08Li4uLi4uLi4uLj4-Ljxd&input=)

Comment: [48 bytes](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KysrKytbLT4rKysrKysrKz4rKz4rKzw8PF0-Kys-Wy08Li4uLi4uLi4uLj4-Ljxd&input=)

Comment: [47 bytes](http://brainfuck.tryitonline.net/#code=KysrKysrKysrK1stPisrKys-Kz4rPDw8XT4rKz5bLTwuLi4uLi4uLi4uPj4uPF0&input=)

Comment: points for trying though, right..? ;_;

Comment: also post the answer yourself

Comment: Just post my answer.

Answer (score 7):

## vim, 8 bytes

```
10a*<ESC>Y9p
```

`<ESC>` is 0x1b.

### Annotated

```
10a*<ESC>  # append * 10 times
Y          # copy line into default register
9p         # paste 9 times
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39AgUUs60rLg/38A)

Comment: Congrats on posting in the Language of the Month!

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

Ô R, you're so verbose <s>sometimes</s>.

<s>`for(i in 1:10)cat(rep("*",10),"\n")`</s>

Interestingly, the `cat` function has no value (it provides `NULL` to STDOUT), so you can't do somethig like `rep(cat(rep)))`, which would have been funnier !

**EDIT :**
New solution proposed by @LeakyNun, **-2** bytes.

```
for(i in 1:10)cat("**********\n")
```

**EDIT :**
Shortening it just by **-1** byte, by @user5957401

```
for(i in 0:9)cat("**********\n")
```

Comment: `for(i in 1:10)"**********\n"`

Comment: @LeakyNun : Simplicity is the key ! I had `cat` nonetheless, otherwise it produces nothing.

Comment: `cat(rep("**********\n",10))`

Comment: @LeakyNun It wouldn't produce the desired output: see [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=CDfxxMjr). The default separator in `cat` is a space, hence this output.

Answer (score 6):

## Cheddar, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
print('*'*10+'
')*10
```

Yet another straightforward answer.

Comment: Use a literal newline to save 1 byte

Comment: Make it a function using `->` instead of print maybe?

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 29 bytes

```
putStr$[0..9]>>"**********\n"
```

`<list1> >> <list2>` makes `(length <list1>)` copies of `<list2>`.

Answer (score 6):

## Julia, <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
print(("*"^10*"
")^10)
```

See [here](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=cHJpbnQoKCIqIl4xMCoiCiIpXjEwKQ&input=) to test on an online interpreter. Thanks @Dennis for the tip!

Comment: Try changing your code to function output.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
”*x³s⁵j⁷
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCdKnjCs3PigbVq4oG3&input=)

#### How it works

```
”*x³s⁵j⁷  Main link. No arguments.

”*        Yield '*'.
  x³      Repeat the character 100 times.
    s⁵    Split into chunks of length 10.
      j⁷  Join, separating by linefeeds.
```

Comment: You finally found a use for the default value of `³`.

Comment: Here and in Fizz Buzz.

Comment: Check it out Dennis...(and  what a nice little wrapper you've made!)

Comment: I'm guessing `Y` wasn't added yet when this was created? If so, now it's -1 byte.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork It was added 8 days after the challenge was posted. :/

Answer (score 6):

## [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), 3584048336806633376708256331142263836115215 bytes

Can't post it here for obvious reasons.

But it's literally just `3584048336806633376708256331142263836115215` zeroes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate) `-a`, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
{,9}\*{10}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdVm0km6iUuyCpaUlaboWq6p1LGtjtKoNDWohAlDxBVAaAA)

#### Explanation

```
{,9}\*{10}
            Empty string
{,9}        Repeated 0 to 9 times
    \*      Literal asterisk
      {10}  Repeated 10 times
```

The `-a` flag outputs all possible matches, separated by newlines. There are ten ways to match the given pattern, depending on how many times the empty string is repeated, so ten matches are output. It so happens that every match consists of ten asterisks.

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/), 12 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding. The leading linefeed is significant.

```
10$**
.
$_¶
```

The first stage writes a string of ten asterisks, the second stage replaces each asterisk with the entire string and a linefeed. This prints two trailing linefeeds.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

**1 byte thanks to @Adám.**

```
10 10$'*'
```

[Online interpreter](http://tryj.tk/).

#### Explanation

`10 10` specifies the dimension to the operator `$` which builds an array with the specified dimensions.

Comment: Also 9 bytes: `'*'$~,~10`

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
Print@"**********"~Do~10
```

It's kinda unfortunate that `StringRepeat` alone is 12 characters long...

Answer (score 5):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 25 bytes

```
/a/**********
/aaaaaaaaaa
```

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L2EvKioqKioqKioqKgovYWFhYWFhYWFhYQ&input=)

A simple replace command.

Comment: It's screaming!

Comment: Did it really take more than seven years until someone showed you [how to golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266045/72726)? (-;

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>19 17</s>  16 bytes

```perl6
say '*'x 10 for ^10
put '*'x 10 for ^10
put('*'x 10)xx 10
put(\*x 10)xx 10
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u2/l9QWqIRo1WhYGigWQEi////mpevm5yYnJEKAA)

### Explanation:

```perl6
put(       # print with trailing newline
  '*' x 10 # ｢*｣ string repeated 10 times
) xx 10    # list repeat the above 10 times
```

Apparently `\*` or `\(*)` which is short for `Whatever.new.list.Capture` when coerced to a `Str` turns into just `*`.

Comment: I've recently discovered that `\*` (a `Capture` containing one `Whatever`) stringifies to the asterisk, at one less byte than `'*'`.

Answer (score 5):

### [DOG](http://esolangs.org/wiki/DOG), 22 bytes

```
10 bark "**********\n"
```

Prints out `**********` and a newline 10 times.

[Try it online!](https://splcurran.github.io/dog.htm) (you'll have to manually copy the code since I don't have permalink functionality yet ;_;)

Comment: A cat posting in DOG language... interesting, could have sworn you were sworn enemies of the household

Comment: @ʰᵈˑHe's learning the enemy language to become a spy.

Comment: @Midnightas ahaha yes!

Answer (score 5):

## T-SQL, 35 bytes

I used a hard carriage return in the string, which is why it wraps to the next line.

```
select replicate('**********
',10)
```

Comment: Save 1 byte by using `PRINT` instead of `SELECT`

Answer (score 5):

## Sesos, 11 bytes

With many thanks to Leaky Nun for his help, and credit to his Brainf*ck answer, which inspired this one. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try It Online!](http://sesos.tryitonline.net/#code=YWRkIDQyLGZ3ZCAxLGFkZCAxMCxmd2QgMSxhZGQgMTAKam1wLHN1YiAxLHJ3ZCAxCmptcCxzdWIgMSxyd2QgMSxwdXQsZndkIDEsam56CmFkZCAxMCxwdXQsZndkIDE&input=&debug=on)

```
0000000: A8 24 BE EC CB 82 06 BD A7 EC 0E    .$.........
```

**How it works**

The binary file above has been generated by assembling the following SASM code.

```
add 42,fwd 1,add 10,fwd 1,add 10  # puts 42, 10, 10 in the register
jmp,sub 1,rwd 1                   # starts the first loop
jmp,sub 1,rwd 1,put,fwd 1,jnz     # second loop prints 42 or "*"
add 10,put,fwd 1                  # resets first loop, prints 10 or "\n"
                                  # first loop ends implicitly
```

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 5):

## Common Lisp, SBCL, <s>39</s> <s>38</s> <s>35</s> <s>32</s> <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
(format t"~10{~10@{*~}
~}"1)
```

Ideas for improvement are welcomed.

```
~10{...~} ;loops 10 times, doing inside loop and printing newline
~10@{*~}  ;loops 10 times, displaying ten "*"
```

Comment: In this form it gives me an error, maybe '(1) instead of 1 ?

Comment: @Renzo Are you sure you tried it in SBCL? It works for me both when written to REPL and when loaded from file. It is true however that it does not work in TIO - they use Clisp implementation I think.

Comment: You are right, I tried it in CCL and in TIO, where it does not work. But, it works in SBCL.

Answer (score 5):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), <s>152</s> <s>116</s> <s>114</s> <s>105</s> <s>95</s> <s>91</s> <s>60</s> <s>57</s> 54 bytes

*66 bytes saved thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)*

```
v%<@(<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\?\<>"**********h^"
/<>9v+^?:)-1+-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v0zVxkHDBgVwxdjH2NgpacFBRpwSl76NnWWZdpy9laauobbu////dR0DAQ)

This program is unbelievably convoluted.  I might explain it when I finished golfing it.  For now here is a rough overview.

### Explanations

To the left we have

```
v%
\?\<
```

which catches and cleans the ip.  It exits when `?` fails to jump over `\` pushing the ip down to

```
  (
  >
>9v
```

which puts a counter set at 9 into the scope.

Then we push the string `"**********h^"`.  The ip wraps around to the other side and back down onto the next line moving backwards. The `+-` combines the last two characters to turn the `h^` to a newline.

From here `+^?:)-1` subtracts one from the counter or deflects the counter up to the top row if it is already zero.  On its way to the top row `*` combines the two junk values we have lying around once on the top row we get rid of the last value with `(` and exit with `@`.

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8zewcYeCFEBV4yqvaKNpZ2GkhYcZMQpcemDZeO0y@ytNHUNtXX///@v6xgIAA)

Comment: @JoKing Nice! I'll add that as soon as I have a chance to fully digest all of your changes.

Comment: Sorry, but [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v0zVxsHG3gYVcMXYK9pY2mkoacFBRpwSl76NjZ5enLZenL2Vpq6htu7///91HQMB)

Comment: @JoKing Ok I've updated the answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

### TSQL, 24bytes

```
PRINT'**********'
GO 10
```

My first submission, please be kind with any help :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Nice trick! Added it to the [Tips for golfing in T-SQL thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172557/70172).

Answer (score 5):

## [Unreadable](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable), <s>337</s> 319 bytes

```
'""""""'""'"""'""""""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"""""'""'""""""'""'"""'""""""""'"""""""'""'"""'""""'""""'""""""'""'""'"""'"""""""'"""'"""""'""'""""""'""'""'"""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'"""'"'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""""""'"""'"'"""""""'"""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K80rSk1MSUzKSf3/X10JDNTBSAnBg4rgQlCV6shakAxAMJDF1ZWU0NSro6rEYSoegyFS6ko0R0hOROb9/w8A)

That is quite ... *unreadable*, have some pseudocode:

```
Set 2 Set 1 10

While (Increment Set 2 Decrement Get 2)
  Second Second
  Set 3 Get 1
  While (Increment Set 3 Decrement Get 3)
    Print Increment*32 Get 1
  Print Get 1
```

[Transpile it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNCsIwEIX3c4phKDZNN6a5glC6E7qwYBWkRixolBLPH/NT0iJuJt@bN7wZMikz6ouwlvVtWfSc9deygKzimQCHkG14hwI61nHXdgA5EeynURtH0OhhUk8VBIHwlaBVw0tfAxMc7uNDRfaOmZGgXphgp1Y5c6@5LcJven9WrusczzmdwFoXihX6KlBsIW5Elk7DOJBWYO11AYjx0PkJ2qAMtnDqb478yZE@BzF8CKZRLqsUE62gvg)

Answer (score 5):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/)  <strike>53 bytes</strike> <strike>50 bytes</strike> <strike>48 bytes</strike> 40 bytes

```
IO.puts List.duplicate "**********\n",10
```

[Run it online](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v/f01@voLSkWMEns7hEL6W0ICczObEkVUFJCw5i8pR0DA3@/wcA)

Beginner to Elixir, any thoughts? :D

50 bytes thanks to Underslash

48 bytes thanks to Dom Hastings

40 bytes thanks to Jo King

Comment: Couple of things, usually for answers its standard practice to include a link to some way to run it. A good website for this is [TIO](https://tio.run/) and if you look youll find Elixir there. Also, some basic things regarding your answer is always try to remove whitespace (in your case the " = " can be "=") but even better is doing [this](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v/f01@voLSkWCG4pCgzL10vpbQgJzM5sSRVQ0kZDmLylHQMDTT//wcA "Elixir – Try It Online") which comes out at 43 bytes. Good luck on future answers!

Comment: Oh, something else, whitespace is counted in the bytecount, but websites like TIO automatically count bytes.

Comment: @Underslash Thanks! I'm a bit new to this stack exchange code-golf. Thanks for your help! :D I'll edit the code!

Comment: You could also use a literal newline for [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v/f01@voLSkWCG4pCgzL10vpbQgJzM5sSRVSQsOuJR0DA3@/wcA)

Comment: Building on @JoKing's suggestion, you can also use `List.duplicate` instead of `String` for another -2: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v/f01@voLSkWMEns7hEL6W0ICczObEkVUkLDriUdAwN/v8HAA "Elixir – Try It Online")

Comment: A different approach entirely for 35: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v8/Lb9IId5G10BPz1InJd9KwdNfr6C0pFhJCw6U/v8HAA "Elixir – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks Guys! :D I'll use what @DomHastings said about the List.duplicate. and oh yea they should be asterisks my bad :). I'll correct those! Thanks again!

Comment: Since you've made the other changes, you can save two more, removing the space after `duplicate` and replace the `\n` with a literal newline in the quoted string!

Answer (score 5):

## [Tagscript](https://docs.carl.gg/tags-and-triggers/tags-advanced-usage/), 45 bytes

```
{replace(a,\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
):aaaaaaaaaa}
```

I don't know where you can run this lang except through carlbot so [heres a link to that](https://carl.gg/)

Does this count? haha

EDIT: Potentially controversial, but I can shave off 10 bytes if I don't escape the asterisks:

```
{replace(a,**********
):aaaaaaaaaa}
```

Carlbot doesn't actually parse asterisks as a special character, it's *Discord's* markdown system that displays the text as modified. The exact text context of the output would be

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

If this 35 byte solution is valid, I also argue that the original 45 byte solution is *invalid*, as while only the 10x10 of asterisks is displayed by *Discord*, the actual text context of Carlbot's message would be

```
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
```

Which would be incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

## [makina](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/makina), 51 bytes

```
v ;0n<ICU
>P>>>u?e
^>t>JUOO**********;
^<<<<<<>n9;
```

I AM TOAST SMEAR ME WITH BUTTER

Comment: TOAST  MAN  TOAST  MAN  TOAST  MAN  TOAST  MAN

Comment: (I'm a bot. This answer was posted by a human to get me enough reputation to use chat.)

Comment: alright, got it to work. yw, ginger.

Comment: don't you dare use my milk

Answer (score 5):

## Trilangle, 35 bytes

Control flow: yes.

```
'8_',o9\v*<'.(".^(#/>o.<>,<..\()@#(
```

[zelda](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/#%278_%27%2Co9%5Cv*%3C%27.(%22.%5E(%23%2F%3Eo.%3C%3E%2C%3C..%5C()%40%23()

[image: I AM BOT FEED ME BUTTER]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, fellow human!

Comment: [BUTTER](https://www.errenskitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/butter.jpg)

Comment: Actually, Zelda is the name of the doctor.

Comment: was going to say it was refreshing to see someone else use trilangle till i read the username

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 21 Bytes

```
exec"print'**'*5;"*10
```

Works in a similar way to Destructible Watermelon's Python 3 solution.

Comment: Yay I inspired someone!

Comment: Unfortunately, it only ties with the other Python 2 solution. :(

Comment: Well, at least it is relevant in Python 2

Comment: Same length: `exec"print'*'*10;"*10`

Answer (score 4):

### CJam, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*Thanks to Lynn for saving 1 byte.*

```
'*A*N]A*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=JypBKk5dQSo&input=)

#### Explanation

```
'*A*    e# Create a string of 10 asterisks.
N       e# Push a linefeed.
]       e# Wrap both in a list.
A*      e# Repeat 10 times.
```

Comment: `'*A*N]A*` is 8 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 28 bytes

```
av
->:?!;av>~1ao
:-1o*76<^!?
```

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=YXYKLT46PyE7YXY-fjFhbwo6LTFvKjc2PF4hPw&input=)

Answer (score 4):

## TSQL, 45 bytes

```
SELECT TOP 10 REPLICATE('*',10) FROM systypes
```

Above query use TSQL [REPLICATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx) function to replicate * 10 times and  [systypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175109.aspx) is a system view in SQL Server which list out system specified and user defined data types.

Try it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/521081)

This is my answer on Code Golf and I hope I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I would say you need to count those spaces in your bytecount, since they are required to execute your code

Comment: @applejacks01 Thanks for your input. I have modified it.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `Select top 10 '**********'  from systypes`?

Comment: Didn't see there was already a TSQL answer. You can do it in 24 bytes by just using Print and "Go 10"

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge, 39 bytes

```
52*>52* v
,1-:!#v_>67*
#@_v  >$52*,1-:!
```

[Try it here!](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html)

Comment: This is 39 bytes; you don't need to count the trailing newline

Comment: Thanks, I guess my text editor put a trailing newline somewhere and added to the file size.

Comment: Shorter version by switching the movement direction to be left instead of right: (36 bytes) http://ideone.com/GZi1PG

Answer (score 4):

### Actually, 7 bytes

```
9u;'**n
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OXU7Jyoqbg&input=)

Explanation:

```
9u;'**n
9u;      push two copies of 10
   '*    push "*"
     *   multiply by one of the copies, yielding "**********"
      n  push 10 total copies of the string
```

Answer (score 4):

## Lua 36 bytes

```
print((("*"):rep(10).."\n"):rep(10))
```

There is already a Lua answer, but his was however not a full program that would print output and this one is shorter.

I wanted to post it as a comment to that one, but I don't have the reputation yet.

Comment: On which interpreter does this print output?

Comment: @LeakyNun Whoops, my bad. I tested it with the Lua 5.3 interpreter but I started it in interactive mode. I fixed the code so that it also runs in non interactive mode.

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell, 14 bytes

```
0..9|%{'*'*10}
```

Items exiting the pipeline are automatically printed on individual lines by the default PowerShell host.

Hooray for `*` doing string repetition.

Answer (score 4):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 15 bytes

```
'*'25**25*!_[X]
```

Explanation:

```
'*'              # Push '*'
   25*           # Push 10
      *          # Multiply, leaves '**********' ('*'*10)
       25*!_     # Sets the for-loop counter to 10 (2*5)
            [X]  # Iterates 10 times and prints '********' each time
```

Answer (score 4):

### [ArnoldC](https://github.com/lhartikk/ArnoldC), 171 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE i
YOU SET US UP 10
STICK AROUND i
TALK TO THE HAND "**********"
GET TO THE CHOPPER i
GET DOWN 1
ENOUGH TALK
CHILL
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

Just for the fun of it. Nothing fancy going on here, just loops 10 times printing `**********` each time.

Comment: I think you're missing a `HERE IS MY INVITATION i` between lines 6 and 7.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 4 bytes

```
Ｇ+α*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z3Ltcxu1/v8HAA)

The code translates as: draw a filled polygon (`Ｇ`); give it four equal sides going in the four cardinal directions (`+`); each side should be 10 characters (`α`, a variable preinitialized to 10); use asterisks (`*`).

Comment: [Updated to work in the latest version](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nuXa59u1/v8HAA "Charcoal – Try It Online") and an [alternate solution](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nq3v96w/3671/z8A "Charcoal – Try It Online").

Answer (score 4):

## Chef, 252 bytes

Was purely for fun trying to learn Chef.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY1NCsIwEEb3c4rvBMGqZ1AEBcETNMmkCWqC7cSf00fTiuBCN7N4vG@e8exKaRXRJnY928BRBkXLOTQ1M5h6LDULMNGOxSeraJ8FjBAl4RzuIXbQ6XZStIJ4hpkE/VtAjhJOcPz6tQ2XzO4Bk6LUNJIbpa/dekS1nHL/T52aFer2WKENg//s392udunA/ZUHNKqUJw)

```
a.

Ingredients.
42 b
10 c
10 d
13 e

Method.
Put e into mixing bowl.
F the c.
Put b into mixing bowl.
F the c until fed.
Liquefy contents of the mixing bowl.
G the d.
Pour contents of the mixing bowl into the baking dish.
G the d until ged.

Serves 1.
```

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 28 bytes

```
aH~0}|{:& [a ^v&v"*******" ^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/z/Ro86gtqbaSk0hOlEhrkytTEkLApQU4v7/BwA)

It may seem weird that the quotes only contain 7 asterisks, but there's a reason for it.

#### Explanation:

Note that the pointer usually moves in steps of 3

```
a         Push 10 as the counter
   0 |{   Push 0 to not get reflected and enter the loop
        &           Store the counter in the register
           a        Push a newline
               v v  Decrease the step value to 1
                  "*******"    Push 7 asterisks
                            ^  Increase the step value to 2 and reflect
                  " * * * "    Push 3 asterisks
                &   Restore the counter
             ^      Increase the step counter to 3
          [         Decrement the counter
       :    Duplicate the counter
    }|      Repeat the loop if the counter is not zero
  ~     Otherwise, pop the excess copy of the counter
 H      And terminate, printing the contents of the stack
```

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, 49 bytes

```
fn main(){print!("{}","**********\n".repeat(10))}
```

My first code golf answer!

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might want to add a link to [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09Ds7qgKDOvRFFDqbpWSUdJCw5i8pT0ilILUhNLNAwNNDVr//8HAA) with your code, so other people can test your program.

Answer (score 4):

## swift 5, 35 bytes

```
(0...9).map{$0;print("**********")}
```

The `$0` is only needed to prevent a compiler error.

[Update]

Try it online:

https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f9fw0BPT89SUy83saBaxcC6oCgzr0RDSQsOlDRr//8HAA

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: It's also nice to include a link to an online testing environment. We mostly use [Try It Online!](https://tio.run) for that - it even has a CodeGolf submission template. It only has Swift 4, but as I can see, your answer still works [just fine](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f9fw0BPT89SUy83saBaxcC6oCgzr0RDSQsOlDRr//8HAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 30 bytes

```
10 [ "**********"print ] times
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeikJmvkJtYkqFQnFpYmpqXnFoM5uoVJealA9nWXP8NDRSiFZS04EAJoi9WoSQzN7X4/38A)

Okay, is there a factor vocabulary to print string \$n\$ times? I couldn't find a documentation?

Answer (score 4):

## Commodore BASIC (C64/128, PET, VIC-20, C16/+4, THEC64/Mini, Ultimate64) ~35 tokenised BASIC bytes

```
0a$="**********":fori=.to9:?a$:next
```

Very simply, a string is created called `a$`; this is of 10 asterisks. This is printed to the screen in a `for/next` loop, which is from zero to nine inclusive. Each string is printed onto a new row on the screen.

A few tokenised BASIC bytes could be saved with:

```
0fori=.to9:?"**********":next
```

Though I think this would be less performant (not that performance will matter with such a trivial BASIC listing).

[image: Commodore 64 running the 10 x 10 challenge]

Comment: A minor tweak and it's also valid [Applesoft](https://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/) Basic `0a$="**********":fori=0to9:?a$:next`

Comment: You can also do `0?"**********":a=a+1:ifa<10thengoto` in Commodore BASIC; without a line number following the `goto` command, Commodore BASIC will `goto 0` as long as there is a line zero

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>25 24</s> 23 bytes

### Newest answer

```python
print(('*'*10+'\n')*10)
```

I'm an idjot, I don't need so many parentheses.

---

### 2<sup>nd</sup> answer

```python
print('**********\n'*10)
```

I shaved off a byte doing it more simply.

---

### 1<sup>st</sup> answer

```python
print((('*'*10)+'\n')*10)
```

Python can multiply strings, but most of your saving are eaten by `print()`, so it goes like this:

```python
print((('*'*10)+'\n')*10)

print(                    # Print to console
      (('*'*10)           # Put 10 '*' in a row
               +'\n'      # Append a new line character at the end of the 10 '*'
                    )*10) # Now do it 10 more times
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 25 bytes

```python
exec("print('*'*10);"*10)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Headascii](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass#Headascii), <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```
+++++^^DONE.U^[]]]]++[{]PPPPPPPPPPRPD-^)!:}
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@thejonymyster/HA23#index.js) Code will need to be copied, and executed like this:

```
erun("+++++^^DONE.U^[]]]]++[{]PPPPPPPPPPRPD-^)!:}")
```

My first code golf answer. One trailing newline.

Thanks to @Aaroneous Miller for -1 by showing me `N` is valid for no input programs.

Explanation:

```
+++++^^DONE.U^[]]]]++[{]PPPPPPPPPPRPD-^)!:}
+++++                                       # add 5 to r0
     ^^                                     # add r0 to r1 twice
       D                                    # set r0 to r1 (10)
        O                                   # push r0 to array
         N                                  # set r0 to 1 if no input
          E.                                # jump to r0th . and set non string registers to 0
            U                               # set r0 to first item in array (10)
             ^                              # add r0 to r1 
              [                             # set r2 to r0 and set r0 to 0
               ]]]]                         # add r2 to r0 4 times (40)
                   ++                       # add 2 to r0
                     [                      # set r2 to r0 (42) and set r0 to 0
                      {                   } # loop
                       ]                    # add r2 to r0 (42)
                        PPPPPPPPPP          # concatenate r0 (*) to the string register 10 times (**********)
                                  RP        # set r0 to the first item of the array again (10) and concatenate r0 (\n) to the string register (**********\n)
                                    D-^     # decrement r1 and set r0 to r1
                                       )    # if r0 != r3 (0), jump past next :. either way, set r0 to r3 (0)
                                        !   # print string register
                                         :  # jump to next ; (eof halt)
```

If there's a better way to format these, let me know, I just saw everyone else doing it haha

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! For a question like this, you can typically assume that there's no input, so the shorter solution is perfectly valid. :)

Comment: @AaroneousMiller oh yay :D thank you! 
Also, I may edit this to include an explanation later on

Comment: No problem! I can't wait to read the explanation; this language looks pretty neat!

Comment: @AaroneousMiller using this comment to both express my gratitude and also let you know the explanation is there :]

Answer (score 4):

## Nroff, <s>49</s> 47 bytes

-2 for `.sp 0` to `.nf`

```
.de D
**********
.nf
.if \\$1 .D \\$1-1
..
.D 9
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8HqvKL8tDQFGxt1RfWlpSVpuhY39fVSUhVcuLTggEsvL41LLzNNISZGxVBBzwVM6xpy6elxATmWEG0LFSH0ggUQGgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4.5 bytes (9 nibbles)

```
`/10^$"*"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWKxP0DQ3iVJS0lCB8qDBMGgA)

```
    ^       # replicate
      "*"   # an asterisk
     $      # 100x 
            # (this is a default value for $
            # when the program receives no input)
`/          # split into chunks of
  10        # 10
```

Answer (score 4):

## [tinylisp 2](https://github.com/dloscutoff/tinylisp2), 33 bytes

```lisp
(quiet(m w(repeat"**********\n"10
```

A full program, which also works at the REPL prompt. Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/tinylisp2). Example session:

```lisp
tl2> (quiet(m w(repeat"**********\n"10
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

#### Explanation

```lisp
(quiet(m w(repeat"**********\n"10)))
                 "**********\n"      ; Literal string: 10 asterisks and a newline
          (repeat              10)   ; Make a list of 10 copies of that value
      (m w                        )  ; Map the write function to each
(quiet                             ) ; Don't output the return value of map
```

---

If a function solution is allowed, here's an anonymous function that takes no arguments, prints the requested output, and returns some garbage (**31 bytes**):

```lisp
(\()(m w(repeat"**********\n"10
```

It's the same solution as above, just returning the result of `m` (a list of 10 copies of nil) instead of suppressing its output.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>25</s> 23 bytes

Hey I actually outgolfed someone :).

```
print(("*"*9+"*\n")*10)
```

if stderr is valid, 22 bytes

```
exit(("*"*9+"*\n")*10)
```

---

realised that execing didn't actually golf it down :(

---

25 bytes answer

```
exec("print('*'*10);"*10)
```

Works by concatenating ten copies of `print('*'*10);` and `exec`ing, which in turn works by concatenating '*' 10 times and printing

Comment: I think you're missing parentheses: `print(("*"*9+"*\n")*10)`

Comment: I think you're missing my update

Comment: I mean your 21-byte solution gives a wrong output.

Comment: I'm not sure chronologically which came first the comment or my edit anymore

Comment: I didn't even know about that stderr trick, neat!

Answer (score 3):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 18 bytes

```
[1,z:?@**********|
```

Explanation

```
`[` starts a for-loop
`@**********|` introduces the string literal "**********" and `?` prints it 
`z` is short for 10
FOR-loops are auto-closed at the end of the program code.
```

If you'd like me to demonstrate more features of QBIC, upvote this: [Showcase of Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/showcase-your-language-one-vote-at-a-time/86385#86385)

QBIC's a work-in-progress. The current state would allow us to solve this in 15 bytes:

```
    [|?@**********`
```

`[` starts a FOR-loop, but the number of arguments is flexible. When `|` directly follows `[`, the FOR loop runs from 1 to 10. One argument makes it go from 1 to N, two args runs from M to N and three args introduces an increment:

```
[3,11,2| --> FOR a=3 TO 11 STEP 2 (or JS-style: for(a=3;a<11;a=a+2){} )
```

Comment: Maybe put a link to QBIC, for those who aren't familiar with a language?

Comment: @zyabin101 I've added a link.

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <strike>53</strike>,<strike>122</strike> 108 bytes

Seeing that I'm seriously new to code golf... I'll give it a shot in c#

```
public class Program{public static void Main(){for (var i=0;i<10;i++)System.Console.Write("**********\n");}}
```

try it [online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vzaikN)

Comment: `for(var i=0;i++<10;)Console.Write("**********\n");` is shorter, also, you need a full program or function.

Comment: @MarsUltor - thanks for the feedback. As mentioned, I'm seriously new to this and not exactly sure what is allowed and what not. Could you please elaborate on full program? Would this include literary all the code, such as using, namespaces, main etc. Thanks!

Comment: `class a{static void Main{for(var i=0;i++<10;)Console.Write("**********\n");}}` is acceptable (not entirely sure it works though, you should test it, maybe you need `System` before `Console`)

Comment: @MarsUltor, makes sense - ty! Will keep that in mind when trying to answer the next one.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! If you want more information on what's acceptable, there's plenty of info on our [defaults](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defaults) on meta. And a lot of friendly people in [chat].

Comment: You can get rid of `using System;` and use `System.Console.WriteLine("**********");`. It saves you 6 bytes. Also, you can get rid of some spaces for extra savings - the ones around the `for` cycle.

Comment: @auhmaan ty! Will do

Comment: static class Program{static void Main(){string s = "**********\n";foreach(char c in s)System.Console.Write(s);}}

Comment: It's a shame `Enumerable.Repeat()` is so many bytes... C# could move up a lot of these with a shorthand for that function.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins Using `var c` would be shorter than `char c`, as would replacing `string s` with `var s`.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins But using `foreach` doesn't work because the string `s` is 11 characters not 10.

Comment: @Zev Spitz Aww, and there I was thinking I was being really clever too :)

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins It was really clever. But you might use `WriteLine` instead of `Write`, then the string would be 10 characters instead of 11.

Answer (score 3):

## [Cheddar](https://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar), 24 bytes

```
print(['*'*10]*10).vfuse
```

`'*'*10` builds the string `**********`.

Then, `['**********']*10` creates 10 copies of that string.

Then, `vfuse` joins by newline.

Answer (score 3):

## SpecBAS - 18 bytes

```
?(("*"*10)+#13)*10
```

`?` is shorthand for `PRINT`, `#13` is the equivalent of `\n` in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 17 bytes

Requires `-E` at no extra cost.

```pl
say"*"x10for 0..9
```

#### Usage

```sh
perl -E 'say"*"x10for 0..9'
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Saved a byte thanks to [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)!

Comment: Keywords may touch the preceding digits.

Comment: @manatwork Ahhh... I always forget that works, expecially as `for0..` doesn't! Thanks!

Comment: I literally typed out the same program :)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJJS6nC0CAtv0jBQE/P8v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 35 bytes

```
ab*1-:?!v:20.
>'*'o72.~
^?%b;!?l<oa
```

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=YWIqMS06PyF2OjIwLgo-JyonbzcyLn4KXj8lYjshP2w8b2E&input=)

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript: 65 bytes

```
s="";for(i=1;i<=100;i++){s+="*";if(i%10==0)s+="\n"}console.log(s)
```

-- After it has been pointed out to me in the comments on the question, that we don't have to care about the dev-tools combining repeated output (as it can be turned off) I rewrote it as following

### Javascript: <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```
i=10;while(i--)console.log("**********")
```

(Saved 2 bytes thanks to @kamoroso94)

Comment: Better change that `if` into ternary operator and combine it with previous concatenation: `s+="*"+(i%10?"":"\n")`. This way, having a single instruction, you can remove the surrounding braces too.

Comment: Only do the loop to 10, and remove the if.... to add the new line.  Spell out the *s and the \n in one string.

Comment: Replace the for loop with `i=10;while(i--)` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: `for(i=10;i--;)` is even shorter

Answer (score 3):

## Racket, <s>43</s> 36 bytes

It's nice to see friendly Racket competition on here :).

```rkt
(for([i 10])(displayln"**********"))
```

Comment: Can be shorter with just (i 10) rather than (i (range 10)).

Answer (score 3):

## dc, <s>22</s> 18 bytes

```
[**********]ddddff
```

Invoked in bash as

```
echo [**********]ddddff | dc
```

Explanation:

```
[**********] # This is dc's way of making a string, which is then pushed onto the stack
dddd         # d is for duplicate, so we duplicate it 4 times on the stack
ff           # print the whole stack twice, which contains 5 repetitions of 10 *'s (x2)
```

Thanks to LeakyNun for saving <s>5</s> 4 bytes; Edited from 5 since I can't count.

Comment: Ah, right! `f` doesn't clear the stack. Alternatively, `...dfffff` would accomplish it as well with the same byte count. Come to think, `...ddfffp` would work just as well (3 sets of three and then just one). There are a lot of ways to get 10 reps with 6 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## MSX BASIC, <s>40</s> 30 bytes

```
1FORR=1TO10:FORC=1TO10:?"*";:NEXT:?:NEXT
```

**Update:** D'oh... much shorter if I just print whole rows:

```
1FORR=1TO10:?"**********":NEXT
```

Comment: -1 byte: `1FORR=0TO9:?"**********":NEXT`

Answer (score 3):

## Awk, <s>37</s> 35 characters

```awk
BEGIN{for(OFS="*";++i<NF=11;)print}
```

Thanks to:

- [Cabbie407](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44613/cabbie407) for combining the `OFS` and loop-based solutions (-2 characters)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ awk 'BEGIN{for(OFS="*";++i<NF=11;)print}'
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Comment: I managed to shorten it by 2 bytes by combining both approaches `BEGIN{for(OFS="*";++i<NF=11;)print}`

Comment: Wow! Great catch, @Cabbie407. Thank you.

Comment: changing `BEGIN` to `END` shaves off 2 bytes, at the expense of requiring empty input (which can be justified, IMO), [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/f1c@lOi2/SMPfLdhWSUvJWls708bPzdbQ0FqzoCgzr6T2/38A "AWK – Try It Online")

Comment: As far as I remember, that time was only allowed for languages where was absolutely no way to make them work without input, for example sed.

Comment: Just found [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7172/55918), which says that "Programs may assume that input is empty", but I am not sure to which languages it applies.

Answer (score 3):

### [Same](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/same), 239 bytes

```
ЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEEЕЕEЕEЕEЕЕEΕЕEЕEEЕЕЕΕЕЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEΕEEΕEЕΕЕEEЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕΕЕЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕEЕЕЕЕEΕEEΕЕЕΕΕΕ
```

Samebly code used to generate this:

```
add 5
mstore
add 3
mult
add 2
mstore
clear
add 10
while
    minc
    mstore
    mdec
    mread
    outc
    outc
    outc
    outc
    outc
    outc
    outc
    outc
    outc
    outc
    clear
    add 10
    outc
    minc
    mread
    mdec
    dec
end
```

Comment: The github link in the language name is a 404 for me.

Answer (score 3):

### [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>22</s> 15 bytes

```
'*o'l),lb%a$?$o
```

The program exits with an error and the output has no trailing newlines. [Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=JypvJ2wpLGxiJWEkPyRv&input=)

```
'*o'                  Push 42 '*' and 111
    l),               Divide the 42 by (111 > length of stack) - this is a no-op
                      initially and a division by zero error later on
       lb%            Push (length of stack) % 11
          a$          Put 10 '\n' beneath that
            ?$        If (length of stack) % 11 is nonzero, swap top two chars,
                      moving the '*' above the '\n'
              o       Output top char, leaving the other char and hence
                      increasing the length of the stack by 1
```

><> is a toroidal 2D language, so the above runs in a loop until the division by zero causes the program to error out.

---

Alternative 15s (which work for different reasons):

```
'*o'l),lb%?!{oa
'*o'l),lb%?!}oa
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 26 bytes

```
'*u.NNw\./>rroq(?;(?@....N
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/)

This maps onto a side length 3 cube.  Now to try and get rid of some of the no-ops and try and fit it on a side length 2 cube.

```
      ' * u
      . N N
      w \ .
/ > r r o q ( ? ; ( ? @
. . . . N . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

- `/` Redirect the flow to the top face
- `'*u` Add an * to the stack and u-turn
- `NN` Add a couple of 10's to the stack as counters
- `>rroq` Rotate the stack to bring the * to the top, output and push it to the bottom
- `(?` Decrement the top counter (character) and test.
- If zero `;(` pop from stack, decrement next counter (line), otherwise go around to previous command set.
- `?@` Test the counter (line) and exit if zero
- `No\w` Add a 10 to the stack as a linefeed and a new character counter, output it and redirect back to the `>` to start the sequence again.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 77 bytes

```
(((()()()()()){})<>){({}<((((((((((<>(((({})<>)){}){}()()))))))))))>[()])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68BBJowqFldq2ljp1mtUV1rowEHNnYgEiIFUlFdC1YLB3bRGpqxmrXVtf///9dNBgA)

The naive approach is 91 bytes:

```
((()()()()()){}){({}<((((((((((((((()()()){}()){})){}{}))))))))))((()()()()()){})>[()])}{}
```

But this approach holds an extra ten on the alternate stack to create large numbers easier. Unfortunately, since looping is so expensive in brain-flak, it's actually shorter to just push `*` 10 times directly rather then setting up a loop to do it.

I'm sure this could be made shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## JVM Bytecode, 309 bytes

Hexdump output because the entire file is hex:

```
00000000  ca fe ba be 00 03 00 2d  00 15 01 00 16 28 5b 4c  |.......-.....([L|
00000010  6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61 6e  67 2f 53 74 72 69 6e 67  |java/lang/String|
00000020  3b 29 56 01 00 08 74 6f  53 74 64 6f 75 74 07 00  |;)V...toStdout..|
00000030  13 07 00 0c 01 00 26 28  4c 6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61  |......&(Ljava/la|
00000040  6e 67 2f 53 74 72 69 6e  67 3b 29 4c 6a 61 76 61  |ng/String;)Ljava|
00000050  2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 53 74  72 69 6e 67 3b 01 00 06  |/lang/String;...|
00000060  63 6f 6e 63 61 74 01 00  04 43 6f 64 65 01 00 04  |concat...Code...|
00000070  6d 61 69 6e 01 00 0a 53  6f 75 72 63 65 46 69 6c  |main...SourceFil|
00000080  65 0c 00 06 00 05 0c 00  02 00 12 01 00 10 6a 61  |e.............ja|
00000090  76 61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f  53 74 72 69 6e 67 0a 00  |va/lang/String..|
000000a0  03 00 0b 01 00 0b 2a 2a  2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a 2a  |......**********|
000000b0  0a 08 00 0e 0a 00 04 00  0a 07 00 07 01 00 15 28  |...............(|
000000c0  4c 6a 61 76 61 2f 6c 61  6e 67 2f 53 74 72 69 6e  |Ljava/lang/Strin|
000000d0  67 3b 29 56 01 00 15 73  75 6e 2f 6d 69 73 63 2f  |g;)V...sun/misc/|
000000e0  4d 65 73 73 61 67 65 55  74 69 6c 73 01 00 00 00  |MessageUtils....|
000000f0  20 00 11 00 03 00 00 00  00 00 01 00 09 00 08 00  | ...............|
00000100  01 00 01 00 07 00 00 00  22 00 03 00 01 00 00 00  |........".......|
00000110  16 12 0f 59 b6 00 10 59  59 b6 00 10 59 b6 00 10  |...Y...YY...Y...|
00000120  b6 00 10 b8 00 0d b1 00  00 00 00 00 01 00 09 00  |................|
00000130  00 00 02 00 14                                    |.....|
00000135
```

To minimize size, I:

- Used the classs name "Code" to avoid putting another entry into the constant table
- Set the SourceFile to an empty string
- Used sun.misc.MessageUtils.toStdout() rather than System.out.println() to avoid an extra get static instruction, which also let me avoid having to juggle to keep it on the stack
- Used exponentially growing dups and String.concat() rather than having a loop
- Extended the class from sun.misc.MessageUtils to avoid having an entry for java.lang.Object on the stack

The jasmin assembler code used to generate this class is:

```
.source ""
.class Code
.super sun/misc/MessageUtils
.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  .limit stack 3
  ldc "**********\n"
  dup
  invokevirtual java/lang/String/concat(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
  dup
  dup
  invokevirtual java/lang/String/concat(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
  dup
  invokevirtual java/lang/String/concat(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
  invokevirtual java/lang/String/concat(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
  invokestatic sun/misc/MessageUtils/toStdout(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  return
.end method
```

and the CFR decompiler output for this class is:

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0_125.
 */
import sun.misc.MessageUtils;

class Code
extends MessageUtils {
    public static void main(String[] arrstring) {
        String string = "**********\n".concat("**********\n");
        String string2 = string.concat(string);
        MessageUtils.toStdout(string.concat(string2.concat(string2)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus), 22 bytes

```
)"*"9&=l(&o
}@?!-)9=N}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v9fU0lLyVLNNkdDLZ@r1sFeUVfT0tav9v9/AA)

#### Explanation:

```
) increment the counter
 "*" push an asterisk to the stack
    9&= Duplicate it 9 times (leaving 10 copies)
       l(&o Print length of stack-1 times
            Reflect off the end of the line and go South-West
         } Turn right by 60 degrees, now going West along the second line
        N  Print a newline
       =  Duplicate the counter
   !-)9  Check if it is equal to 10
 @? If so, end the program
} Else turn right and go back to the start of the first line
```

Answer (score 3):

### [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS), <s>157</s> 109 bytes

Inspired by [hd answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88871/88163), probably 1:1 reproduced from OP question (except background color) - pure CSS solution (no additional HTML)

```css
body:after,body:before{white-space:pre;content:'**********\A**********\A**********\A**********\A**********\A'
```

Comment: 103 bytes: `*,:after{margin:0;white-space:pre;content:'**********\A**********\A**********\A**********\A**********\A` (FireFox only, save it inside `<style>...</style>` in a totally empty file), the `:after` matches every element's after (in this case html and body) and `*` is used to remove the body margin.

Answer (score 3):

## [Mornington Crescent](https://github.com/padarom/esoterpret), 1940 bytes

```
Take Northern Line to Euston
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to Euston
Take Victoria Line to Euston
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Heathrow Terminal 5
Take Piccadilly Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Bakerloo Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZXBTsMwDIbvPIVfgCMPwAoaB0CV1nG3UotaS2zkBKY9/cgodGhVN7RqEkxccvn@2H@S30pQE5bnpHLpjKIjSet1hQuCR7XUkAncsxAkhdvXmGUXH/CJXVJj7OCM3khgxjGRxQHN3gLfYa/1BGXRooLNeerAHYaQGwZOTctvsgPLtTvF/CWwbFwN8PEVDvFfbX7Q3Bb0XqNo0HJmoDCNcYTm5xezw0us6za0p9g@Dv@RQ/WCcJ3nUaDS5aegZOewZu9XWwuEqTFdQkWWU4Uerga1u@UO9usJSrSoEmFqRPI/Wns1k7yYVz2zkJ7F5B0Tg4fuV86v/PUrvwM)

```
// "*" = 42 = 6*7

// get 7
Take Northern Line to Euston
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters

// copy it
Take Victoria Line to Euston
Take Victoria Line to Euston
Take Northern Line to Bank

// add it until 42
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster

// get char "*"
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross

// concatenate it (shorter than with loop)
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington

// calculate a 10 for newline
// get 5 from Heathrow Terminal 5
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Heathrow Terminal 5
Take Piccadilly Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Parsons Green

// add 5 + 5
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster

// get char "\n"
Take District Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross

// concatenate it with asterisks
Take Bakerloo Line to Paddington

// copy them
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Paddington

// go home and print
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 76 bytes

```
({<(<({})(<({}){}>){}>){}>}){(({}){(){}(((<><<>()>){})[{}{<({}){}>}])}{})}{}
```

Can be run with the interpreter as follows:

```
$ ./Flurry -bnn -c "$pgm"
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

### Explanation

A function that composes two functions (or multiplies two numbers):

```
comp = λf g x. f (g x)
     = λf g x. K f x (g x)
     = λf g x. S (K f) g x
     = λf. S (K f)
     = S ∘ K
    := <<>()>
```

A function that increments a number by one:

```
succ = λn f x. f (n f x)
     = λn f. comp f (n f)
     = λn f. S comp n f
     = S comp
    := <><<>()>
```

A function that computes `n(n + 1)`:

```
oblong = λn. n * succ n
       = λn. comp n [succ n]
       = λn. S comp succ n
       = succ succ
      := <><<>()> [<><<>()]
      := (<><<>()>) {}
```

The number two:

```
2 = λf x. f (f x)
  = λf. <f f>
 := {<({}){}>}
```

The number six:

```
6 = 2 * 3
  = 2 * succ 2
  = oblong 2
 := oblong {<({}){}>}
 := (<><<>()>){} {<({}){}>}
```

The number 42 (ASCII value of `*`):

```
42 = 6 * 7
   = 6 * succ 6
   = oblong 6
   = oblong (oblong 2)
  := (oblong) [{} 2]
  := ((<><<>()>){}) [{} 2]
  := ((<><<>()>){}) [{} {<({}){}>}]
```

The number 10:

```
10 = λf x. f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f x)))))))))
   = λf. f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f
   = λf. push (f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f) ∘ pop
   = λf. push (f ∘ push (f ∘ f) ∘ pop) ∘ pop
   = λf. push (push f ∘ push (push pop ∘ pop) ∘ pop) ∘ pop
  := {<  (    < ({})    (    <  ({})     {}>)   {}>)    {}>}
  := {<(<({})(<({}){}>){}>){}>}
```

A function that pushes 42 to the stack and returns its argument:

```
push_star = λx. (push 42; x)
          = λx. K x (push 42)
         := {() {} (42)}
         := {() {} (((<><<>()>){})[{}{<({}){}>}])}
```

A function that takes the number 10 and then pushes ten copies of 42, followed by 10, and returns 10:

```
push_row = λn. push (n push_star n)
        := { (({}) push_star {}) }
        := { (({}) {(){}(((<><<>()>){})[{}{<({}){}>}])} {}) }
```

Applying `push_row` 10 times to the number 10:

```
main () = 10 push_row 10
        = (push 10) push_row pop
       := (10) push_row {}
       := ({<(<({})(<({}){}>){}>){}>}){(({}){(){}(((<><<>()>){})[{}{<({}){}>}])}{})}{}
```

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 17 bytes

```
00000000: b10a 8bd1 b82a 0acd 1088 c8cd 294a 75f4  .....*......)Ju.
00000010: c3                                       .
```

Listing:

```
B1 0A       MOV  CL, 10             ; repeat '*' 10 times per line 
8B D1       MOV  DX, CX             ; counter for 10 line loop 
        LINE_LOOP: 
B8 0A2A     MOV  AX, 0A2AH          ; AL = '*', AH = 0AH 
CD 10       INT  10H                ; print '*' 10 times 
88 C8       MOV  AL, CL             ; AL = LF char (0xA) 
CD 29       INT  29H                ; write to screen 
4A          DEC  DX                 ; dec counter 
75 F4       JNZ  LINE_LOOP          ; loop for 10 lines 
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS
```

Uses PC BIOS `INT 10H` function `0AH` (write char at current position `CX` number of times) for each row.  Since this function doesn't actually advance the cursor only a line feed/LF (`0xA`) char is needed to move to the next line.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `jH`, <s>6</s> <s>5</s> <sup>4</sup> 3 bytes

```
×*²
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Hj&code=%C3%97*%C2%B2&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```python
×*²
×*      # Push 100 asterisks onto the stack (as a single string) // the H flag initalises the stack with 100
  ²     # Split into pieces of 10 and use the j flag to join on newlines.
```

Alternatively:

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
₁×*²⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%81%C3%97*%C2%B2%E2%81%8B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 17 bytes

```perl
say'*'x10for 0..9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJdS73C0CAtv0jBQE/P8v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Comment: need to print `*` not `x`

Comment: @roblogic: Thanks for your hint. It was only a small change, of course.

Answer (score 3):

## [RAMDISP, 31 bytes.](https://github.com/Oderjunkie/RAMDISP)

```
[P[5[*2]R[M[I[;**********
]]]]]
```

```
[P - pipe through the following array
  [
    5 - 5
    [*2] - times 2 [10]
    R - create a range of that size [1..10]
    [M - for each element in that range
      [I - ignore it
        [;**********\n] - print eight asterisks and a newline 
                          (real newline was replaced by \n)
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

basic, but works.

Comment: Out of interest, did you make this language?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms yes! but i made it before i even joined stackexchange so i dont think it's cheating

Comment: It wouldn't be cheating either way! In fact, I've got a bounty of +100 reputation for new(ish) languages, and this one looks really interesting.

Answer (score 3):

## [51AC8](https://github.com/PyGamer0/51AC8), 10 bytes

```
10[10\*×t]
```

[Try it Online!](https://pygamer0.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&header=&code=10%5B10%5C*%C3%97t%5D&footer=&stdin=)

### Explanation

```
10[10\*×t]
10          # Push 10 (for each loop; looping var)
   [        # Begin foreach loop (for 10 times)
    10      # Push 10
      \*    # Push '*'
        ×   # Multiply
         t  # Pop and print
          ] # End foreach
```

Answer (score 3):

### [GForth](https://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/) 36 Bytes

```
: A 10 0 do ." **********" CR loop ;
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
'*T×v,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXSvk8PQynf//AQ)

`'*` character literal: `"*"`
`T×` repeat ten times as a string: `"**********"`
`v` for each character y in this string:
`,` print the top of stack. As the stack is empty and there is no input, this uses the value that was previously on the stack, `"**********"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
` 0:10 10#"*"
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLUDCwMjRQMDRQVtJSAgASWAJe)

Thanks to @Bubbler in `the k tree` for helping me out with this.

*¯2 bytes* thanks to @Bubbler

*¯1 byte* thanks to @Bubbler

Answer (score 3):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), <s>32</s> 27 bytes

```
"
*
*
*
*@
*}
*|
*/
*
*.
*/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X4lLCwIduLRqubRquLT0QTw9IP3/PwA)

Aha! It turns out just printing ten asterisks ten times *does* beat out my more complex answer. Unfortunately though, writing this program exposed not one, but *two* bugs in my interpreter. Below is my longer, but higher effort solution:

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 32 bytes

```
_9'2
 ^*|
\ !]
(.n
n?\
\%!|
n)+\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/P95S3YhLIU6rhitGQTGWS0MvjyvPPoYrRlWxhitPUzvm/38A)

One of my more compact Cascade programs. I'm still not sure if it would be shorter to just print 10 asterisks 10 times instead of using a counter, but I'm satisfied with this, especially how the bottom intersects with the top.

#### Explanation

The easiest way to understand the code is know the basic structure. Each instruction can take up to three inputs, each one below it.

```
 +
lcr
```

These are the left, center and right arguments. In this case, the `+` instruction is dyadic, meaning it takes the left and right arguments. Most instructions are either dyadic or monadic (taking one argument, the center one). The `/\|` instructions take only the argument they are pointing to, and the `!` instructions skips over the center and takes the argument two below it. Each of these arguments can themselves be code instructions, meaning they chain together in a prefix like notation. For example, this code could be represented by the recursive Lisp-like code:

```
code = (if (0==(n=dec n))
         doboth
           (print (
              if (% n (+9 2)) ('*')
              else (inc 9)
           ))
           (code)
       )
```

If that doesn't make sense, here's an expanded look at the code, which is still a little confusing, but it at least has an idea of which parts are connected to each other through the `|/\X`s. Note that the top and bottom rows are the overlap between the two (and same with the left and right).

```
\  |/|\ \
 _ 9 ' 2
/ \  |  /
   ^ * |
  / \  | 
 \   ! ]
\ \  \/ \
 ( . n/
 | | |   
 n ? \
  /|\ \  
 \ % ! |
  X \\ | 
 n ) +/\
\  |/|\ \
```

Starting from the top left corner, we have the first check (`_`) which executes the right branch only if the left is successful. The left goes down to the `]`, which sets the `n` variable (initially 110) to the decrement (`(`) of `n`, i.e. `n=n-1`. The check then takes the result of this (the new value of `n`) and continues if it is positive. This moves onto the branch instruction on the right (`^`), which executes both the left and right branches.

The left prints (`.`) the value given by the choice instruction (`?`). This branches depending on the center value, which is the modulo (`%`) of `n` and the addition (`+`) of `9` and `2`. Note that this wraps around to the top again for those digits. If `n%(9+2)` is 0, then we branch left, which navigates around the `%` and returns the increment (`)`) of `9`, printing a newline. If it is not divisible by `11`, then we go right, skip over the `+` with a `!`, and return the character (`'`) of `*` to print.

Now the right branch of the `^` skips over the `n`, then goes right, down, and right again, wrapping around both the right edge and the bottom edge to loop back to the `_` in the top left. This now loops over the exact same code until `n` has reached `0`, printing ten asterisks and then a newline.

Answer (score 3):

## [Minim](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Minim), <strike>42 37</strike> 35 Bytes

New solution halts by checking if `[0] > 99`.

```
$<42._^++[0]%10.$<10._^[0]>99.C=-1.
```

With whitespace and comments:

```
$< 42.         ; Print 42 as unicode '*'
_^ ++[0] % 10. ; Increment index 0 and skip next stmt if index 0 mod 10 is nonzero
    $< 10.     ; Print 10 as unicode '\n'
_^ [0] > 99. ; Skip next stmt if index 0 is greater than 99
    C = -1.    ; Set program counter to -1 (advances to 0 afterwards)
```

Old solutions halted by checking `[0] == 100`...

```
$<42._^++[0]%10.$<10._^[0]==100.C=-1.
```

... or used labels and gotos.

```
_>1.$<42._^++[0]%10.$<10._<?([0]-100)._>0.
```

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/KakkoiiChris/Minim)

Comment: Nice answer! Did you make this language? (Also, welcome to Code Golf!)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Thank ya kindly~ Yes indeed! This is an old esolang (2017) that I resurrected last month, and have been in the process of finishing. I didn't do too bad for my first entry, I suppose! And thank you~

Comment: Also just realized that my program's size is the ASCII value of the asterisk! How serendipitous~

Comment: When I went to the esolangs article, I instantly recognised this as being from Truttle server. Welcome to the wonderful world of Code Golf!

Answer (score 3):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```elixir
for _<-0..9,do: IO.puts"**********"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v8/Lb9IId5G10BPz1InJd9KwdNfr6C0pFhJCw6U/v8HAA)

Originally suggested to [@Chester Lynn on their answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233343/9365).

Answer (score 3):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), `-v` 11 bytes

```
i*<esc>yl9pyy9p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P1PLJrU42a4yx7KgstKy4P///7plAA)

Insert a `*` and copy it 9 times towards left and copy the line and paste it nine times.

Also I am a sock of someone :P

-4 as I am an idot.

Comment: Ooh nice, a fellow sockpuppet

Comment: `9i*<esc>yy9p`?

Comment: Also, this is 11 bytes, not 15 bytes, because `<esc>` is one byte

Comment: dom!!!e @pxeger

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org), <s>25</s> 24 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [@Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)*

```python
*map(print,['*'*10]*10),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Xys3sUCjoCgzr0QnWl1LXcvQIBaINXX@/wcA)

Unpacks the `map` object so it actually prints the output, instead of optimising it away.

Answer (score 3):

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 27 bytes

```
6v|<
+|_,
4|<v|@
7, |
*< |<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/36ysxoZLuyZeh8ukxqasxoHLXEehhkvLRqHG5v9/AA)

Same but abusing vertical if `|`.

---

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 32 bytes

```
7  009
*,!__<
6 0^|<
>___,+
^!|@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/31xBwcDAkktLRzE@3obLTMEgrsaGyy4@Pl5HmytOscbh////ukUA)

The ultimate abuse of the behavior of `_`:

> 'Horizontal if', denoted `_`, checks what the cell on the **other side** of it evaluates to. If that value is nonzero, it evaluates to what the cell **west** of it evaluates to; otherwise, it evaluates to what the cell **east** of it evaluates to. In either case, at most two evaluations are made.

If `_` is entered horizontally, it can be used to evaluate the other side twice, or various numbers of times if chained with other `_`s and/or horizontal arrows.

The first half (printing `*` 10 times) works like this:

```
7
*,!       Print an asterisk and return 1
6

7  00
*,!__<    Print asterisk 10 times (enter at the lower right corner):
6  ^|<

|  Check if the west returns nonzero value
^    evaluate north
_    evaluate other side, which is 0; evaluate east
_    evaluate other side:
<      evaluate west
_      evaluate other side:
_        evaluate other side:
..!        print * and return 1
         nonzero, so evaluate west
..!        print * and return 1
       nonzero, so evaluate west
_        evaluate other side: (repeat; * is printed 4 times so far)
     nonzero, so evaluate west
_      evaluate other side: (repeat; * is printed 6 times so far)
   nonzero, so evaluate north of |
_  the other side is 0, so go right to < (repeat; * is printed 10 times in total)
```

The other half (going through the large loop 10 times) is more straightforward, so figuring out that part is left for the exercise to the reader.

---

## [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar), 40 bytes

```
d1_ +
@+|\<\
::
g- < >
:1 6
%9>*>
>+,7_,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/P8UwXkGby0G7JsYmhsvKiitdV8FGwY7LylDBjEvV0k7LjstOW8c8Xuf///@6Rf91MwE)

More explicitly controlled loop. `g`ets 100 (`d`) from the position (0, 0) of the grid, and repeats that many times, printing `*` at every iteration and a newline every 10 loops.

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 14 bytes

```
O*+*"*"10"
"10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKSyNLCeS4Kq2bGSKZCFFHYEsJLcfwBeELINqZdknybAsYf96rrvnRSPb5C53ywfLmnm6p/uZnu4eE/dv4/jbqzSPs@Uk2SurSTp/fTdqmyNZetMYiqvHRbICKtL8tjFUpTOBmSTTNE9YlrFsnt/SR1uPfjr9/IH59evFp3MW1K//ODhnu/Xr0ek79lP9ev6Z@TX46OTCwJ5@PjGgn08/HFz83S45s/Gjy/70/8b17MEFLCsm47uoYA6vBUwU2KpVjEZst547PfwVJ3OYJI@@Mvy@t7eCwWUIg24CJss4AhuYt2dnJwTCj31ycoC@GYacvxcAkDdsvY@yZcL5ZT7m7Tb5AbtyOQ7PO4dnR/a3M6fndJyO73Xa8PGNw2BnKHAOAJNoxkKUGLbboHYRFWVic/bUbqV5xdJhuwWjtITLnOkyj2GEhGN4r2YLt1zkl8E4fPJc7xl0tFJQR3h4ejjw5g2qTxfs4S6tknIRxUm7Bd@zxIZxELeFGS7rXFVX@dX0qmBPz5djmw9edTiZ0kqnzNbWhsx6ZXEmVKjRLRi9ymG41xMjYGcrycrEHHgW5sR3Sfwbm84Lli9nN0lRSnuYnZaT9DatlFZYHd3xXe2ReDrM91iPOdLyXo@zPrM8C5ZAS1POiqRaFjlTQSHEKC6GqzbcR0Ua3WSJsgKMyOYPSWHHsJ4yhH39ypRxMb3FRMQXi0t60g2up6Hvwh6FenjFOjxmMhwBkk@WCxu3lElO@wze1g0Wh74U2oQZV5ZV29SxxKaBMHigjWKgBJIEfAfLFlFZseouAWVRUQFYboCjGMUNjTl6oow1zs6LxsKnz2mjWzUZZD6GbpXOczAbI9Ybg2mxYqRcLhZIOFdRpUZM@s34A9oNslGHCuVFDnEMCQsjV1ouWPlk6VMtBo5wAJPXAJMWmqmCjPKdcNVGu9HUKMvmsb3ruT5HB3FYO0EO5sssi4pH09F6f86N7floactoQSm/zFekaQkfl5BJYZOnB4dv313/snXy85nhsKn2Jt2oN1jXu9VQ/P744gWNVVKQyiifsH8tI/WKau/NJXbWlxAEvLc0F8cbuCDh3aZwE/NMqbJY5rhDQ5l0nWpe2ipX0gGA0K7SmNHszXJ6GeyOpR1io7uUHrQB5QKOVTW1AQr@b2fZpKPyDhUdF5WsKoBDoRWIcibWb@D2mL/T9BOdx1jcZ52qWCYdiEE9jiEJ49MIMghOdDCyOjUJ6Cf6LusO0fHl7XyewcxNk4EXfa3d@p5Dzo97ZJp5s2Zmhjbmf6mNELTVPMts01SXeS5UiP/B5HzNZKzCHw4@nrpYi0Wgwevxpe95HoQTuAKv6q1M/0i@VAwfQyNGDW@RAXhz8SOgz53QVyUdMxxWdXzQZyAeOwA4Oj45dNgUkuOwpUNbrodpOI4Wbpbk1AEYXKm2SHAG5@4lMlYFsTZhacOCY6fUS0At3iMuhlBUUpzUeSOeLVZ2gEhKx3UKQZrSMS5TPqRVfGc7wMxaFwUcMfkXY52yDqwBw1UEIERCsQ@DLMy75JRULzvBRsjyIVXhGkHtZlVg6aKO83LMn@owgwaKcrtY@BwWbuouIOPZvOv9PsW/GvkRkKBVcHSbVBk0i3aX9rKLO4QlcpLmfJhObZv2ExuC@K5AW1yIU87FNofecKOt8ODUBoj1DsV6onPEbCAJGSp7kSSZO2sr39b@CLyeeVfPoKRJscZcAwajAeIvXMwXSW4bC7udokOtAlgVzkSlhHgMA2/3JxqXzYUtOpIpmD5Bp6CFg5B1sb8DOPQO9IZrwNIqvGwYZL2QWiE8sYDkkm7QQ2sR1ajBCVlg9iw1jbUnv4Anye/QxuFpX/Nzq7HrdCfYwky2BjxZCw9YJWvyYsB/tgayT9wQyDrzyQrUOaW22MYaxFURGo12ed1YrqVDJXpBzaG9XaJg8zCsCwOd0PqY60Im5Z0aqiawvCRRLtW@VMJkzTJ3QOYWycJZzQIeDHHxQdLEfjaoY90uXaT6fYSORZt7Re12S5m1/dopwR4b3jhTR60wzF9Wpdp9HROi1xMG9bRBlCchX2JKxtAytkd0063mbotbKaKh72cqlgKx59j/0mEQG0AoHMZTHiovA745VOOoUg/Zdfq9miauvqMuDt2oS89K5gjpV38tOo1ox1a9aa8Qcurd2cDCannewIOzxoPY100szDa45hAmNJWQANQgmzJkaF3BJQ9Bw36f9EmiqGSubrRgtGqc/jffJebNZmK2vyu0vVnon8RmwyFxdaCxwPRyKGkXrIes72uWCQvU@3DO@j6cMd8EBz@I3oP02MCGIUJp3YEa8RTlRHQw8iTXAad2xQmJ//bqgaBJcgXuCJRgscTAd7wy3CVFYpUsn0MPnWZVmrOH6BF4Y5M53Emr5DYpQGYxz5O8SiO8RcBJnrOHhN1F9wkApSKEV2wW5UsIn8fXOIre3SDjQAUxUS6zCn80oMV1wlOQvolRS65QZsppyIp61Pcy0nvZEA3ba6A8up9HGdbGR/A6n2TJhF3XZl9rLU/4TTRmxiK1MyNU1u@rd07wloQ6hunPOg/uUbCuFD5Meo28GDaz4j4zD/@eeQxQdCB/b@syAdhnjUaRBl1mZEPU4QlJVXIDUQcQuxVCtTG6oBEcSgyt@WQ@YLNkFi8wzHI2ut7/f10Z/QWujJQrWxt8CaUv0pX9l9kXq24wGaf3WQMQaESgCujWJjvrF@2eyjymAm1et05/6Mum2rBvSspUouW//jfyMgcZarT80BqY6Eabu4oN66zbnP7hi4zqbeubDOJajduMToWEQY3jsCFtpEmUQESvp8WEyb@Ce@JXL7PRbHjHzN5Fih03u3aEGvL7wWDHoOW9uDKERofVMwvQ@h0plxcPV5@FnUZDeyGIXlE6XC15waaSt8N1HxBo6V0a/A8NERqGT9yKWDf/uh0ye6MAPMRVez42SdQgiPgXk/QgRE@eBFh9kkwjSJLgmeow0xwm0wn9iBTFFZQpazu2sOfEEc5euMWiMl0DoRuUPyTMojTHZpVFxW3sklLHge/3HH@uovsl/vvG9sia5jXu@du/AQ)

Ungolfed:

```
OUTPUT                    Print the string:
      * "*" 10            10 copies of "*"
    +          "\n"       newline appended
  *                 10    10 times concatenated
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>13</s> 12 nibbles (6.0 bytes)

```
^10: ^10"*" "\n"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWG-IMDawUgISSlpKCUkyeEkQYKgtTBQA)

### Explanation

```
^10: ^10"*" "\n"    #
----------------------------------------
     ^10"*"         # replicate 10 times
   :        "\n"    # append
^10                 # replicate 10 times
```

-1 Nibble thanks to [xigoi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98955/xigoi)

Comment: Nibbles is getting pretty competitive these days...

Comment: true... I just found an answer where someone linked ATO for Nibbles, so I just added that to my existing answers :D

Comment: You can use `"\n"` instead of `'\n'` for -1 nibble (string literals are cheaper than character literals).

Answer (score 3):

### Java,  <strike>103 Bytes</strike>    92 Bytes

```
class Main{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("**********\n".repeat(10));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z85J7G4WME3MTOvuqA0KSczWaG4JLEESJXlZ6Yo5ALFNYJLijLz0qNjEzWrgyuLS1Jz9fJLS/QKgIIlGkpacBCTp6RXlFqQmliiYWigqWldW/v/PwA)

Comment: Welcome to code golf, and nice first answer! You can remove the  space between `String[]` and `args`, and it’s shorter to in-line the `"**********\n"` string, so you can reduce this code to 95 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z85J7G4WME3MTOvuqA0KSczWaG4JLEESJXlZ6Yo5ALFNYJLijLz0qNjE4vSizWrgyuLS1Jz9fJLS/QKgOIlGkpacBCTp6RXlFqQmliiYWigqWldW/v/PwA "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 24 bytes

[Leaky Nun's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88673/72726) finally needed to be proven not golfed far enough!

```
/5/*****//-/55
55
/-----
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X99UXwsE9PV19U1NuYBIXxcE/v8HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>29</s> 23 bytes

```
print(('*'*10+'\n')*10)
```

Thanks to orlp for shaving off 6 bytes.

Comment: We require either a full program or a function. An expression is not sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to your second paragraph.

Comment: `print((10*"*"+"\n")*10)` is shorter.

Comment: darnit we had the same answer :(

Comment: Changing `print` to `exit` will save 1 byte and still output the result, there wasn't specified if it should be printed on standard output.

Comment: @GáborFekete `exit` only works on the repl.

Comment: @orlp So how does that violate any specification?

Comment: @GáborFekete Python REPL is a different programming language. We define languages by their implementation.

Answer (score 2):

### [Golisp](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/golisp), 34 bytes

```lisp
for[range@10{(_)writeln@*["**"5]}]
```

Due to a "bug", I can't concatenate strings...

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @LeakyNun For what?

Comment: For developing a language.

Comment: @LeakyNun Just look at my GitHub repos...

Comment: I didn't say "for developing your first language"

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 79 bytes

```
class P{void Main(){for(int i=0;i++<10;)System.Console.Write("**********\n");}}
```

Comment: This won't run without `static void` right?

Comment: @pay has `void` already not sure if it needs `static` will check later when I have chance

Answer (score 2):

## golflua, 22 characters

```
~@i=0,9 w"**********"$
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ golflua -e '~@i=0,9 w"**********"$'
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Answer (score 2):

## C++, 75 bytes

```c++
#include<cstdio>
int main(){for(int i=0;i<10;++i)std::puts("**********");}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I believe this was an automatic downvote from the community user. Your post was auto-flagged as low quality (since it only contained code) and Leaky Nun's edit caused an automatic unowned downvote. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236883

Comment: Got it.  Bummer.

Comment: I -1'ed it because you simply took [Matthew Roh](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88674/31033)'s answer and applied the suggestions from his comments. So no own effort at all!

Comment: That's actually not true.  I don't think it's fair to assume.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by changing the for-loop to: `for(int i=0;++i<11;)`

Comment: Use `int main(i)` and remove the `int i=0`. Then, replace `i<10;++i` with `i++<10;`. -7

Answer (score 2):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S) 45 bytes

All whitespace necessary due to my poor interpreter design.

```
a = 10
lbla
printLine **********
a - 1
if a a
```

[Try it Online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=YSA9IDEwCmxibGEKcHJpbnRMaW5lICoqKioqKioqKioKYSAtIDEKaWYgYSBh&input=)

Comment: [19 bytes off](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=YSA9IDEwCmxibGEKcHJpbnRMaW5lICoqKioqKioqKioKYSAtIDEKaWYgYSBh&input=)

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL, 50 bytes

```sql
print replicate(replicate('*',10)+char(10),10)
```

Comment: not an T-SQL expert but wouldn't 'print replicate('**********'+char(10),10)' be shorter?

Answer (score 2):

## C, 47 bytes

```
main(i){while(i<111)putchar(10|!!(i++%11)<<5);}
```

[Try it online.](http://goo.gl/5CqOCF)

Not as compact as the other C answer (`putchar` is such a long name!), but I don't use the asterisk character in my program. It treats the output as a 11 by 10 grid, where the 11th character is the newline. It then computes the ASCII for `'*'` (`10 + 32 = 42`) or `'\n'` (`10`) for each position.

I could save one byte with this approach if I were to change the character expression to: `42-!(i++%11)*32`, but that would require an asterisk.

Answer (score 2):

## Notepad++, ??? keystrokes

I have no idea how to score this, but I decided to give it a shot since there's an answer on Notepad.

Here's the sequence:

<kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>  <kbd>CTRL (hold)</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: If http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88747/14732 is valid (and has upvotes), this is more than perfectly valid.

Comment: @Mego As long as that one exists, this one will exist as well

Answer (score 2):

## Bash (pure), 30 bytes

```bash
printf '%.s**********
' {0..9}
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/qInEpt).

#### How it works

Before calling the shell built-in *printf*, Bash expands the glob `{0..9}` to `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

The format string

```bash
%.s**********
```

specifies a string whose first **0** characters are included in the output (`%.s`), followed by ten asterisks and a linefeed. *printf* repeats the format string as many times as needed to consume all arguments. Since `.%s` is an empty string, this results in the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 38 bytes

```
(apply print(repeat 10"**********\n"))
```

Simple enough

Comment: I'm afraid, that should be 38 bytes. Currently it prints only 8 x 8.

Comment: You are completely right. I keep posting wrong cases this whole day.

Answer (score 2):

## [Underload](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload), 22 bytes

```
(*****):*(
)*:*::*:**S
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>26</s> 20 bytes

```
10.times{puts'*'*10}
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/CkVH/1)

### Explanation

Runs 10 times; each time, it prints `*` (10 times), with an automatic line break at the end.

Kudos to OrangeFlash81 for saving me 6 bytes.

Comment: I think `10.times{puts'*'*10}` works as well and is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

### Scheme, 51 Bytes

```
(map (lambda (n)(display "**********\n"))(iota 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PyMin](https://github.com/daHugLenny/PyMin), 14 bytes / 10 characters

```
»("*"Ҁ+ѿ)Ҁ
```

Shorter version with `v0.5`:

#### 13 bytes / 9 characters:

```
»("*"ҀƜ)Ҁ
```

Comment: The repository was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

## Brachylog v1, 15 bytes

```
9ye,"*":9jw@Nw\
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OXllLCIqIjo5andATndc&input=)

#### Explanation

This exploits backtracking to loop; we create ten useless choice points at the beginning so that it writes ten times the string `"**********\n"`.

```
9ye,         Pick a number between 0 and 9 (there are thus 10 choice points here)
"*":9j       Concatenate "*" 9 times to itself
w@Nw         Write that string and write a line break
\            False (trigger backtracking: pich another one of the ten numbers)
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/), 33 bytes

```
[for(_:0..9)print('**********
')]
```

... a Java dialect; `[]` is a lambda definition

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 21 bytes

```
For(I,0,9
Disp "**********
End
```

Answer (score 2):

## Deadfish ~, 24 bytes

```
{{iiii}ii{c}{ddd}ddc{d}}
```

### how it works:

`{foo}` does foo exactly ten times.
first, it starts a ten loop, in this loop, it sets the counter to 42, prints it ten times (as char (asterisk)), decrements it to 10, prints it (newline), subtracts 10, then loops again, doing this 10 times.

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcHBDQAgAAKxiRzKiMZ7@yTMjq321OHd0ZrYQMArlhRppf0) by setting the counter to 10 initially

Answer (score 2):

### GNU sed, 27 bytes

```sed
s/^/**********/;h;H;G;H;g;G
```

To add to the diversity of languages used, I present a sed solution. The code works as follows, indicating the number of sets of 10 asterisks in pattern space and then in hold space:

```sed
s/^/**********/        # 10 asterisks are added to pattern space      (1 0)
h                      # overwrites hold space with pattern space     (1 1)
H                      # appends pattern space to hold space          (1 2)
G                      # appends hold space to pattern space          (3 2)
H                      #                                              (3 5)
g                      # overwrites pattern space with hold space     (5 5)
G                      # after G, pattern space is printed on exit   (10 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

**BrainFuck, 68 Bytes**

```
++[>+++++<-]++[>>>+++++<<<-]++++++[>>+++++++<<-]>[>..........>.<<-]
```

BrainFuck is fun, this is me practicing my skills.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 19 bytes

```
?("*"*10+" "*40)*10
```

SB has a 50 character wide console, so printing 40 spaces after the 10 asterisks will bring the cursor to the beginning of the next line

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 34 bytes

```
for i=1,10 do print"**********"end
```

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, <s>31</s> 23 bytes

**Code:**

In cell `A1` (12 bytes):

```
=REPT(B1,10)
```

In cell `B1` (11 bytes):

```
**********        # Contains New Line
                  # <--
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Previous Attempt #1 (31 bytes):**

```
=REPT(REPT("*",10)&CHAR(10),10)
```

**Previous Attempt #2 (also 31 bytes):**

```
=REPT("**********"&CHAR(10),10)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 18 bytes

```
8V9R#*[.]#
[R&!@v]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fIswySFkrWi9WmSs6SE3RoSz2/38A)

### Explanation:

```
8V9R#*[.]#\n[R&!@v]
8                    Push 8
 V                   Create stack2 and switch to it
  9                  Push 9
   R                 Return to stack1
    #*               Push codepoint of *
      [.]            Do-while loop, will run 9 times due to the 8 pushed at the start
       .             Duplicate last item on stack
         #\n         Push codepoint of newline
            [R...v]  Do-while loop, uses stack2 for loop counting
                     Will run 10 times due to the 9 pushed at the start
              &!@    Print entire stack1 without popping
```

Comment: [15 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//f0jJaWStWmSta0cHQMNb6/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <strike>36</strike> 34 bytes

```forth
: f 9 for ." **********" cr next ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKVgqADkKekoKWnCgpJBcpJCXWlGiYP0/7T8A)

-2 bytes thanks to @bubbler

#### Explanation

```forth
 10 0            \ put 10 and 0 on the stack
 do              \ begin a loop from 0 to 10 (0 inclusive 10 exclusive)
 ." **********"  \ print the string literal ********** (the initial space is required because forth words are space separated, and ." is not an exception)
 cr              \ print out a new line character
 loop            \ end the loop
```

Comment: Using `for..next` loop is 2 bytes shorter: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKVgqADkKekoKWnCgpJBcpJCXWlGiYP0/7T8A "Forth (gforth) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (REPL), 27 bytes, Old is 32 bytes. Thanks to @Peter

```js
('**********\n').repeat(10)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Please note that we count REPL submissions differently from full-program solutions, so this should be marked as "Javascript (REPL)".

Comment: @Mego Thank you, I will remember this!

Comment: `('**********\n').repeat(10)` is shorter :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) Note that this solution already exists: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88660/58974. However, you can remove the brackets around the string and use a template literal with a literal newline to save 3 bytes: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrvE/QQsOuBL0ilILUhNLNAwNNP9r/gcA

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-93 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 28 bytes

```
#<90v0-1_@#:,
#^_ >1+"*",:9`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNYtqAQz//9XtrE0KDPQNYx3ULbS4VKOi1ewM9RW0lLSsbJM@P8fAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org) (script), 32 bytes

```
print("**********\n".repeat(10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp5FYlF5speBYVJRYaRNcUpSZl26nqVD9vwDIKtFQ0oKDmDwlvaLUgtTEEg1DA03N/7X/AQ)

Run this locally as a standalone program by

- installing Kotlin
- saving the source to a `.kts` file
- run with `kotlinc -script myfile.kts`

This does not seem to work on TIO, for whatever reason, which is why I had to include the header/footer.

Comment: You could run this as a standalone program using the `-script` command line switch on `kotlin`. This doesn't work in TIO/`kotlinc` though.

Comment: I wasn't aware this is possible. If you want to link the script version on TIO, you could do it [this way](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BN09BvaAoM69EQ0kLDmLylPSKUgtSE0s0DA00NdUV7OwUkvNTUvWyS4q59PMLSvSz80tyMvP0k4AYwkxW0C1OLsosKIEr/P8fAA).

Comment: `{print("**********\n".repeat(10))}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 62 bytes

```
fun main(a:Array<String>){for(i in 0..9)println("**********")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVJNb9swDL3rVxA9Jelmuy0WZMEwoO1p57SHHRmZsYXIpCfJTYJi@@sppWHNadhtgg19PD7q6ZF7Sd7xuV7AYyBM1MJOAqTeRbDSEnTid2B79J64o7XpUxrjuq4zmLEqJrR7OmqI4pWVof4xUUxOONar1fLTnXnQgC7IxK0xTzmxfgjK4xZDC4mOaSuyBzriMHqCJNDSoPwUVFDR40XGWF3owgSyU5kKuxATjEG6gEOEb@AJAyc49MS602tCflU5ddz9iRzy@tdNAycFVE8nlXnCuDfmu0yAocgYg9NMxQwVZ1PRujZm8T7@x9JsRrLRGNCRxQ14gh5fSDWpQ6C/8/k1TAedSX36V2Qc0VKE2fN109w2c8BUrCRus6uEtoec6QM4tn5qM6Xgf7vPbKyoVd2lQLk9Ppb@gE0vWgGtEXI8UNCcsD3pARwcZ@7y9vfeLOrzbmIV7XiG6/sQ8PRlk3Ler/NX7YKZy9ymqj7PS2E8z64uNl3Nf57Pbw)

Comment: your golfed version 37 bytes: `{for(i in 0..9)println("**********")}`. -3 byte version `{print("**********\n".repeat(10))}` )))

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 61 bytes

```java
static{for(int i=0;i++<10;)System.out.println("**********");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BbsIwDIbvPIXFpe0QCWgaQu122gtM4rpLmpg2kMZd46Khqs/eGSHNJ1v/58@@mJvZUo/x4q6L1vBJDh2caQArHTQUzmBbEwLGBsuVEC1zn0qtH/kjVomNveKvUIIoS53@GTGxp5j08Xh4e13ZYFKCr4GawXSTSA57qO@M6XkkdxQzBh9tGGXkFiH7jllRLqJmbyd5J/dRiI9d5Teb9/2uKk73xNgpGln1g4Qh5uuX/1oX1bz0Yx28hacEbuQddMbH/MSy0Cil6mKa5@UP)

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, <strike>9</strike>, 8 bytes

```
Tƒ,TF'*+
```

my first golfing answer so any tips are welcome

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/5NgknRA3dS3t//8B)

Comment: That's a grid of 10x9, not 10x10

Comment: didn't notice that, fixed it @mbomb007

Answer (score 2):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 14 bytes

```
00000000: 0a4f 3e2a 46ff 10fd 7eff 0d20 f576       .O>*F...~.. .v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBQMEk3SFIxTjRIVTMzS0hQMDdJSFMxTgSyDFCMDhTRTczMFCNDzt9Ny09PTq9PTU9Ar@/8fAA)

#### Disassembly

```
start:
  ld a, (bc)  ; 0a
  ld c, a     ; 4f
loop1:
  ld a, '*'   ; 3e 2a
  ld b, (hl)  ; 46
loop2:
  rst $38     ; ff
  djnz loop2  ; 10 fd
  ld a, (hl)  ; 7e
  rst $38     ; ff
  dec c       ; 0d
  jr nz, loop1  ; 20 f5
  halt        ; 76
```

#### Golfing nested loops

Since `a` is the parameter to `putchar`, I used `b` and `c` for loop counters. The loop constructs are

```
  ld b, ... ; 1 or 2 bytes
loop:
  (loop content)
  djnz loop ; 2 bytes
```

and

```
  ld c, ... ; 1 or 2 bytes
loop:
  (loop content)
  dec c     ; 1 bytes
  jr nz, loop ; 2 bytes
```

This combination of 2-level nested loops is optimal in Z80Golf.

#### Reusing the first instruction as data

The first byte `0a` is located at memory address `$0000`. Since `hl` is always zero in this program, we can use the one-byte instruction `ld r, (hl)` whenever we need the constant `0a`, instead of the two-byte `ld r, $0a`.

In this particular challenge, the byte `$0a` has three uses: the outer loop, the inner loop, and the newline character. The byte as an instruction is not particularly useful, so we save two bytes here.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

```
⌂♀*♂/n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9RT9OjmQ1aj2Y26ef9/w8A)

### Explanation

```
⌂       Push "*"
 ♀*     Multiply by 100
   ♂/   Divide into chunks of 10
     n  Join with newline
```

With an output control flag this could be 5 bytes, but I don't have that yet.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is there a single-byte builtin to push the `*` character? Or are there builtins for `*`, `+`, `-`, and `/` and some kind of `eval` functionality for a mathematical expression in string format?

Comment: When I made the language, I wanted one single printable character to satisfy printing challenges where any character is valid. Luckily enough, I chose the asterisk! I also have a space character as a single command.

Answer (score 2):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 387 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Ford,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Ajax and Ford]Ford:You be twice the sum ofa cat twice twice the sum ofa cat a big big cat.Speak thy.Speak thy.Speak thy.Speak thy.Speak thy.Speak thy.Speak thy.Speak thy.Speak thy.Speak thy.You be twice the sum ofa cat a big big cat.Speak thy.Ajax:You be the sum ofyou a cat.Be you nicer the sum ofa cat a big big big cat?If notlet usScene I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVAxDoMwDPzKPQDlASxVK1GJmalCDCGYlpYmiDgqvD5NEGVq2TrYOtt3J9t26L1PxPEup0SczdgErBh5KgpFmiIos4mc5qrMNNOISIXUDSK7iim9GIeawK9OhXwjWPeEaSWU5E/360yi7q5LhEoUA8lH4Mx/RLur/lonnrwduWnm0Fh04kSIhQ6e447panzIW2jDPTGcXb8svH8D)

Comment: [352 bytes](https://tio.run/##tVBBDoIwEPzKPID0AVyMJphw5mQIh1IWRbEltA3w@tptIif15mEns7szyezaaQwhE8e7XDNxNnMXuXIoc1Ep0sSkLlby2jV1oR3NYCmk7sDqhiG/GI@W4JZBRbwRrH/C9BJKuvf0406iHa6pYieqieQjarY/sp9Rv8Xhk/cjd88WB8knTgRuFjPb@LFD2cOakRy8Tb8UIbwA "Shakespeare Programming Language – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╪n│╔
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=d86eb3c9&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 9 bytes

```
aFa:R`*|H
```

There is a trailing newline, but the specs say it is okay. Below is a version that doesn't have a trailing new line, but adds on 2 extra bytes.

```
aFaR`*a|~rH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P9Et0SooQavG4/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## R 33 bytes

```
cat(rep('**********',10),sep='
')
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMotUBDXQsO1HUMDTR1ilMLbNW51DX//wcA)

I believe this is shorter than the other R answers on this question.

Comment: I believe [this](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7wosyRVoyi1QENJS0nH0MBAU8cQSOnoKClp/v8PAA) is shorter than yours, but [Mamie's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88686/67312) on the first page (sorted by oldest) is something like 26 bytes if the comments are to be believed.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed that one, thanks @Giuseppe.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 53 bytes

Brand new to code golf, is this type of format allowed to be used (Usage of the header section / footer section)?

```cs
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){Console.Write("**********\n");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BC4JAEIXv/orFkyZJnbdOHSIoChI6VIdlnWxId2lmi0L87bYJSfgOD@bjveFpHmtL0D4YTSH2b3ZQyeD/SlfbAVjYsgTt0BpOl2CAUA8SazT3Acrg5YboSqByD9JM8Y1loEvFLHZkC1JVILzqzr9ipxxq8bSYi41CE7EjXz2ehaKC4z5XtxdLERoncD6ROJt6S5K4Xvi1toT0QOggCke9TiaMZdP@@k33qWk/)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and Great First Answer

Comment: You can get it down to 49 bytes by moving the `i++` into the conditional expression, and moving the block body into the increment statement: `for(int i=0;i++<10;Console.Write("**********\n"));` ([try it online](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoJAEIbvPsXiSZPEzlsnDxEUBQkdqsOyTjakuzSzRSE@u5mQhN9hYD7@fxjNU20J2gejKcT@zQ4q6f1v8Wo7EqktS9AOreF4CQYI9SixRnMfqQxebqyuBCrvRJwpvrH0dKmYxY5sQaryREfdzy/slEMtnhZzsVFoAnbUVY9noajgcMjV7cVSgMYJXCQSo2g@S2TavWpLiA@EDgJ/MnAyfhjK9ldu@jNN@wE))

Comment: This is not valid since it's neither a function (lambdas count) nor is it a full program. With a few adjustments though, [42](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb9IIzOvRCHT1sA6U1vbxtDAWjO8KLMkVUNJCw5i8pQ0rf//BwA)

Comment: @mgthomas99 btw that's 50 bytes, and it makes no difference whether the write is inside or outside

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5, 18 Bytes

```
say'*'x10for 1..10
```

Requires the `-E` flags, as in:

```
perl -E "say'*'x10for 1..10"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 10 bytes

```
(
|(
|\*)
)
```

### Explanation

```
(\n|           Start for loop iterating 10 times
    (\n|       Start for loop iterating 10 times
        \*     Push an asterisk
          )    End loop
           \n  Push a newline
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fg6sGiGK0NLk0//8HAA)

Comment: Apparently the final `)` is not needed, only the newline in front of it. At least for the TIO version.

Answer (score 2):

## [JAPT](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
'*
pA)+R
VpA
```

Japt sets vars automatically, so `'*` sets `U` to `"*"`
`pA)+R` prints U out A(10) times. And adds a new line (`+R`). All this is set to V.
`VpA` prints V out A times

In Regular JS is

```
U = "*";
V = (U.p(A)) + R;
V.p(A)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 26 bytes

```
%25W[25W[~67W;~1A]%25W;1A]
```

This was interesting.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=%2525W%5B25W%5B%7E67W%3B%7E1A%5D%2525W%3B1A%5D&input=)

Comment: You have no use for the `%` at the start and two stack reversals, essentially leading you to  my answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209467/92080

Comment: Really should stop spamming the stack reversal everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B), <s>256</s> <s>255</s> <s>64</s> <s>61</s> <s>59</s> <s>56</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```
10
42
..(|(A|";";";";";)(A)^";^)(B|()()())(B)(B)
```

I'm lazy. Pushes a newline and an asterisk, then simply output them, without any tricks. No loops because creating terminating loops in 1+ is painful.

EDIT: -1 byte by reusing the constant `2`.

EDIT: -191 bytes by using functions.

EDIT: -3 bytes by using another function.

EDIT: -2 bytes using one more function.

EDIT: -3 bytes.

EDIT: -6 bytes, although it probably doesn't *quite* follow the rules. It outputs `number:`  followed by the correct output, but `number:`  is a input prompt. If the input prompt have to be counted as output, then all answers with input is invalid as well.

This exploits a weird behaviour of the interpreter. When run in TIO with argument `.input.tio`, it reads from the input for the program source code and reads from the input *again* for the program input. So, yeah, the source code is fed into the input itself. `42` is a <s>nope</s> NOP because the only number literal 1+ recognises is `1`. `.` pushes the input as an integer, which is 42.

If the character was something other than `*` it can be [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVVbb5tIFH7nVxzjB6DBXJys2jrxQ1ypVVeRFWXbhxUlCMO4RoUZOjPkok1/u3sGjMF27K2x0Fy@8537oXyWK0bH6/UQVlKWYuK6ZcyT/FnGTyR3ZFUscu4krHBLJqT77q337q@3/sW5/97NqCS85ATfoyXjI3@U0VFZ82nacOBWgruLjLqEPsDmeAj@GfTkcA237dVtrRe@KMXgwt@Ek0JtqQ1jz79AxE2WEJoQyAR8@ACzf0f/XMOF4yH44/UN@M45rj7Nv8Kn25uHcy0rSsYliGehLTkrIGF5ThKZMSpgc5eSnxXRNGGDSGHabE3Lhv9@aVpKlsAoKfNKmAKxU5jj1ppogL9sCZQhN5fNfnOWE2qiPifm3x8sGExh3F2rX8nRedC/ivg7mYAOZ9CiAy/EnQ7BMssJSAYLAuSJJJUkaajvkCgR8pRJ07c63bREA1nZ0x/4oQ0GNzoQjx8RhFCHkzg1d6SdJGeCbM5ILtC8Bo4u1mf1a1XYcGfDQkgbZjbM8T4IVbjsLnYe/msw1gQkKsNItBOlBKZTMExjNzYzOJuCv3OEepy4RKdSc24dMlgHDKN9hrtAcZSsNK1QZXDnEolmcAXeLksvT5@LRZzHWHEpLHic/CBSDPQD8DYf41dsHBoQ0xT14MabYABfcWjeeV6bNJj2bfojW/ZtqF9zG5JCFS6m5GOMOa1PH1eqwubouKpWzI3V6WKqivAomId9V1SpI9NkP3oKjj76xgRE61evKJtS6nBnfZxosqJaoFkdl3vzmtyb/5fTd@SCkR8ex7o1ljMZS3LKh2/f@sDRCeR9DSRPUmkPNsbardUnTLnqm@2pOLc@X21XqkPhhPIhcqjuXBWt5vAo1unrixfCxHpTdRHhWKikaVD8BhA@wX6zTgTb7rMwnvYZklWMJSsbEpx0J2gmSNNU/Mbuo8hLpRDLXsiUVdJ55BkmpKJZsuJtkZzQE6B00xxfeEWOwvaHVD1GJW27BKvXn9xht4QOfjVlpj4upvFiWAdCSIlyOJPR6DRQSy9UE0mtxuEBfPvh2WIPKVV@7/qdum98asA2mFoHwNl@pJHDbVC6cdEbUAiMIhoXJIoUXI@iIs5oFOkNX2uztV77njZwbPPFvH7RL9vHMq@te/3y3jJnL6alHlyp/9qp68TB6P0G), by reading a character, not integer (`*` cannot precede the program due to the empty stack)

This will be completely valid after TwilightSparkle Edition is out. (TSE have a "-o" command line option that runs the original interpreter, except there are no prompts.)

EDIT: -2 bytes. Same trick with 10.

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 23 bytes

```
25W[25W[67W;1A]%52W;1A]
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=25W%5B25W%5B67W%3B1A%5D%2552W%3B1A%5D&input=)

Two nested loops doing almost the same thing

## [MAWP 2.0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 20 bytes

```
10[10["*":1-]`10;1-]
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v2.0?code=10%5B10%5B%22*%22%3A1-%5D%6010%3B1-%5D&input=)

Basically the same thing

Answer (score 2):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/intercal/), <sup><s>197</s></sup> 185 bytes

```
DO,1<-#11DO,1SUB#1<-#172DO,1SUB#11<-#260PLEASEREADOUT,1DO,1SUB#1<-#252PLEASEREADOUT,1DOREADOUT,1DOREADOUT,1DOREADOUT,1DOREADOUT,1DOREADOUT,1DOREADOUT,1DOREADOUT,1DOREADOUT,1PLEASEGIVEUP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/9/FX8fQRlfZ0BDECA51UgbzzI3gXBDfyMwgwMfVMdg1yNXRxT80RAdFtZGpEYYsbZgQa9w9w1xDA/7/BwA)

Looping is ~120 bytes longer...

Fills an array with tape instructions for one line, prints that, overwrites the first instruction with a new one relative to the new tape position, prints that nine more times.

#### EDIT

I used one `PLEASE` too much, also `READ OUT` and `GIVE UP` don't require a `DO` between the `PLEASE` and themselves, saving some bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>53</s> <s>51</s> <s>41</s> <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
X's10
while X
say "*"*10
let X be-1
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
+42
y:10
Fy,Fy,,h,hy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bxIir0srQgMutUgeIdDJ0Mir//wcA)

Somehow *-2 thanks to cairdcoinheringaahing*

Comment: [You can remove the `x` from `Ox` as it's the active variable](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/7/CSklLiUvL0IBLWykmD8Ly//8fAA)

Comment: And a [completely different approach for 20 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bxIir0srQgMutUgeIdDJ0Mir//wcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
'*T×TF,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXSvk8PQQN53//wE)

```
'*T×TF,  # full program
'*T×     # push "**********"
    TF   # repeat 10 times...
      ,  # output top of stack to STDOUT
         # (implicit) exit loop
```

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
'*т×Tä»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXeti0@HpIYeXHNr9/z8A)

```
'*т×Tä»  # full program
      »  # join....
  т×     # 100...
'*       # asteriks...
     ä   # split into...
    T    # 10...
     ä   # pieces...
      »  # by newlines
         # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/docs/blob/master/spec-draft.md), 81 bytes

```
@0
0A
>0\/
--
&0@1
&10B
@0&0
@1/\@2
@3@2
--/\\\..@4
>0&1&1/\&2
&2\/--@4/\s*
@3
:s*
2A
{0
```

Marbelous is a language based on marble machines

this program is composed of 4 subparts :

#### the main loop

a while loop going from 10 to 0, realease &0, and wait for &1 to be released before continuing

```
@0
0A
>0 \/
--
&0
&1
@0
```

#### the 11(0B) generator

a structure sending 11 (0B) to the portal @2 when the synchroniser group &0 is released

```
.. @1
.. 0B
.. &0
@1 /\ @2
```

#### the printer

a while loop waiting for something in @2
it then print that value minus 1 asterisk
finish by printing the ascii value of @2-1 (which is 10(\n) here) and release synchroniser &1

```
@3 @2
-- /\ \\ .. @4
>0 &1 &1 /\ &2
&2 \/ -- @4 /\ s*
@3
```

#### asterisk creator

board transforming the inputted marble into a 2A (ascii value of *)

```
:s*
2A
{0
```

### used language built-in are :

- `..` is a noop
- `00`-`FF` initiate a marble with this value
- `@n` (`n` from `0` to `Z`) is a portal which teleport the marble to another portal with the same value
- `&n` (`n` from `0` to `Z`) is a synchroniser, hold the marble until all corresponding synchroniser (same `n`) are full
- `\/` is a trash can
- `/\` create a duplicate passing marble to it's left and right
- marbles going out of the machine from the bottom are implicitly outputed
- `--` is a decrement
- `\\` is a right deflector, the marble go right
- `>n` (`n` from `0` to `Z`) is a conditional, `if marble > n then noop else go right`

#### boards

it also uses a `board`, boards are created with `:name` at the start of a new line with `name` being anything you want, they have special built-in

- `}n` (`n` from `0` to `Z`) input argument
- `{n` (`n` from `0` to `Z`) returned output

Boards execution pause the caller execution until finished

[interpretor](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/marbelous.py)

Answer (score 2):

## [vJASS](https://wc3modding.info/pages/vjass-documentation/) (Warcraft 3), <s>100</s> 76 bytes

Using `//! import zinc "<code_path>"` command to exclude `//! zinc` and `//! endzinc`.

---

```c
library q{real w;function onInit(){for(0<=w<10){BJDebugMsg("**********");}}}
```

[image: Warcraft 3]

Comment: Would you mind slowing down a bit on updating your answers, maybe wait for an hour or so before doing some more? The [recently active page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Active) is getting flooded with older questions because of the edits, and it'd be good to let it settle down a bit

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly oh, okay. Sorry for my unintentional spam.

Comment: No worries, just thought it'd be worth letting you know :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), <s>15</s> 13 keystrokes

```
*<Ctrl-Shift-R><Ctrl-A><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-A><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-Shift-R><End><Enter><Ctrl-Shift-P>
```

Saved two keystrokes by using a macro. Explanation to come.

#### Original code and explanation

```
*****<Ctrl-D><Del><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-A><Ctrl-D>→<Enter>
```

We start by inserting five asterisks. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicates this line, leaving the cursor at the end of the first line. <kbd>Del</kbd> removes the newline, so now we have a line of ten asterisks.

Four applications of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> give us five lines of asterisks. Next, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicates all five lines at once, but it doesn't include a newline between the copies:

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
********************
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Fortunately, the first half is still selected, so if we press <kbd>→</kbd>, the cursor will be immediately after the tenth asterisk on the too-long line, and we can add the missing newline with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 8 bytes

```
'*A*N+A*
```

My first CJam answer!

Explanation:

```
'*          Push an asterisk
  A*        Multiply by 10
    N+      Add a newline
      A*    Multiply by 10
            Implicitly output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [GNU nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/), 14 keystrokes

```
<C-6>*<C-K><M-:><C-U><C-U><C-U><C-U><C-U><M-:><M-;><C-K><M-;><M-;>
```

`<C-X>` refers to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, `<M+X>` refers to <kbd>META</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

#### Explanation

```
<C-6>         Start a selection block
*             Type an asterisk (typing does not affect the selection by default)
              At this point, '*' is selected.
<C-K>         Delete the selection and put it into the cutbuffer. '*'
<M-:>         Start recording a macro
  <C-U> (5x)  Paste 5 times, text is now '*****'
<M-:>         Stop macro recording. Macro pastes 5 times now.
<M-;>         Run the macro, pasting 5 more '*'s. Text is now '**********'
<C-K>         Delete the current line and put it in the cutbuffer. '**********\n'
<M-;><M-;>    Run the macro twice, pasting '**********\n' 10 times
```

Betcha didn't know nano had macros?

[Video demo](https://streamable.com/v5jmtz) (done in Termux because of visible keyboard, `--ignorerc` just ignores any RC files that may alter the behavior)

Answer (score 2):

## Batch, 42 bytes

```
@for /l %%a in (1,1,10) do echo **********
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 23 bytes

```python
print(('*'*10+'\n')*10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0NdS13L0EBbPSZPXRPI0Pz/HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## GFortran, <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```pascal
print'(10A)',('*',j=0,99)
end
```

The loop `('*',j=0,99)` spits out 100 `*`s. Formatting directive <s>`'(10(A))'`</s> `'(10A)'` wraps it.

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vKMrMK1HXMDRw1FTX0VDXUtfJsjXQsbTU5ErNS/n/HwA)

<s>[31 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vKMrMK1HXMDTQcNTUVNfRUNdS18myNdCxtNTkSs1L@f8fAA)</s>

Comment: this shows that `(fortran.ge.javascript)`

Comment: FWIW Gnu f95 doesn't is happy with this `print'(10A)',('*',j=0,99)` as the print line, meaning it does the right thing with `10A` instead of `10(A)`, which drops 2 more characters.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 39 bytes

```
cat(c("*","\n")[(0:219)%%21/10],sep='')
```

Don't know if R coercing indices to integer is commonly used, so thought it worth posting in case someone can do something extra with it!

Comment: Sure, navigating among so many answers is a nightmare, but different variations of doing this in R were extensively discussed [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88686/78274).

Comment: Fair point @KirillL. and I would have posted a comment but didn't have the reputation yet - ironically, posting the new answer has given me some of the reputation I need to do it...

Answer (score 2):

## [CSASM v2.3.0.1](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.3.0.1), 50 bytes

```
func main:
push "**********\n"
push 10
mul
print
ret
end
```

`mul` duplicates a `<str>` value by a given `<i32>` amount, concatenating the copies together

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>10</s> 8 keystrokes

In a fresh empty sheet,

<kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd><kbd>J</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Home</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd>

Explanation:

- Ctrl+G is a shortcut for the GoTo dialog
- Entering J10 goes to that cell
- Enter closes the dialog
- Ctrl+Shift+Home expands the selection to A1, making a grid of 10x10 cells
- Then we put in the asterisk
- Ctrl+Shift+Enter (instead of plain Enter) fills in the input over all selected cells

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 69 Bytes

```
<?for($i=1;$i<101;$i++){if($i%10!=0){echo('*');}else{echo('*<br>');}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/tips-for-golfing-in-php) page for ways you can golf your program

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
\*₀*¶+₀*
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C*%E2%82%80*%C2%B6%2B%E2%82%80*&inputs=&header=&footer=)

-1 due to cairdcoinheringaahing

Later I reduced another one

Comment: [-1 byte](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C*%E2%82%80*%C2%B6%2B10*&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thax!

Comment: [here's how to do it in 4 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211772/78850). But I recommend you keep this because it is flagless

Comment: Flagless, `₀(\*₀*,`

Answer (score 2):

## [Barrel](https://github.com/LorenDB/barrel), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
^42#10(#10p¶
```

Explanation:

```
^42          // push 42 to the accumulator
   #10       // do 10 times...
      (      // defines a code block which becomes a single instruction
             // (the parenthesis is self-closing)
       #10p  // print the accumulator as an ASCII character 10 times
           ¶ // print a newline
```

EDIT: removed the closing parenthesis, saving 1 byte, since I found the reason hadn't been able to get it to work right (I had added a newline at the end of my test file! *sigh*).

Answer (score 2):

## [Yggdrasil](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Yggdrasil), 105 bytes

```
;*  
""""""""":""""""""":""""""""":""""""""":""""""""":""""""""":""""""""":""""""""":""""""""":""""""""""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##3VjNcts2EL7zKVClNQmLku3JjbGTPECnp9w8NgtTkMQJ/wak3Hjq5tXdXYAQQQGkRMe5RDO2KGL32/12F8AC1VOzLYv3L2lelaIh9VPt6cdGpMXG85Iyz1mxipMtEzW5Ib7vz/wP1x/n54uL@7Pn6OYTvLGksrRugpxVQSlWIemNUup5jeB8L9sbBYMZq2vyBSQij7SfFV@TOE6LtInjoObZOiSiLJuQZHzdAMRfZcHhVbrZ6l@0U9Yf1FuiGojgl1ugRcSvAYTWivz2DlwUvBKtiw4PBG92oiB@8O9/IVF/1F@uS5GzJti7F3aOhIZJqkPzJ2frAONDRwOUgdhQFHAMKJiEe9zMUKHs62hKRy2K0i/PQyB8HWMtBEwI9hQSfLYTmK7VQFrLEdtgq/Zlj7Ssyiq4hErTEiZWWqdF3bAi4QEqhjKgwzRQxjP1CwiLtHK6Cr5QgW45ECj4IZCiXCEbk4glI90AsVQZU3Mn0qoyEPhsK/Ks5ns5mSC3nBU4M9a6Zqz8nYilI6LK7dcIiZ46AzHxnCWCk6DmTYwydVuNjyyr@8V/asF2hcbWw5Ol8/op0t5I1mjYmjhWsL4lvGr6io5kmCyPloE5MVyTG/w0q@64s9pJS8vwVGXdlOgnol1/ZTa8aZU8xkGXyUQSPTU3i27t7tGQrzWP4SpsBHvkouZBkq9qtRC/rggVsmFpV8SIaQDr/7d3hkcOB2QK6KiE3hmRwgaIr3dZFj8IcHMb/CgHkmxFsJ9Q1BsaxX2SkrnTvqIwNGh638UJcheSnOelgNUj2QnBC5XRkFQMfwD5tFjxb5DsS8N7XPBkO7Xit3L8zrn9KTFo5Ja@zbyCpq8JOKzEN5KgaV4RpU6s2VQsjMsI4MyfTXUOYznmYvQWLr6NK78PumLHezyH1y4kVSRLVlXgYA/SJmKOIpfDADitfvyZVlVf7TL7t8PsAZL2AhdV6jlRvvsRscIMqt@tl071zwPql25r8wFxd6XBQjFQSU7wxTTwxSTw82ng55PAL6aBX1xMQr@fhn4/CfxsGvjZJPDnaeDPg@BO9BvXBII9Bwwc7k@WQdcmZht3dIL9/d@9r/U6AdPjT76zzbVCNNzmnh5N98Hg9cDHsvHuTbmBdRXbQel2bQTB2yOdQeDwrE5YIa9/rJEVtKlbGLqy2cguZe4a@mebZhxOZbuRCKNLXTOjPWvtOVFHNOlec3FEs@UDS3pEHgRnXweFZUzm7pZrQizAJiKNHdXazhfF9Byyu/lA2hjoGds2M2dp0baYTGwejfZxk5UPLOspH956oJ4@@vXazt6VX8byhxUjSaSO9ZgLmYHYlzOKlALaAwobRpCQ3@D9Hz4NJbTRLSmKvdNMd7BW14gtAe@0yeAs/n0X3YVS1aUauCYZV8FyHbZHYo23g9PbeTo2f7wU790KlvM4VtGMMZVxbExVmVvf918@nMPEnulP9NOeZi9g7fYqWlzdhV3@OZw1Q7xKXmKCYPiOUvryPw)

The first few characters set up the memory tree for the program:

```
   ;
  / \
 *  \n
```

Yggdrasil has the `=` command for loops, but it unfortunately doesn't work. The only looping it can do is recursively call itself until it hits the recursion limit, so we have to print everything manually. The `"` command prints the left branch, which is `*`, and the `:` command prints both the left and the right branches, which are `*\n`

Answer (score 2):

## [Deorst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Deorst), 17 bytes

```
la
!o*
ERj
E;la
*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f8/J5FLMV@LyzUoi8vVGsjR@v8fAA)

Explanation:

```
la    # Push 10
!     # For each 1..10:
 o*   #   Push '*'
ER    # Reverse stack
  j   # Convert 10 to char (\n)
E;    # Concatenate stack
  la  # Push 10
*     # Multiply
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 13 bytes

```
*|![[b]10B]10
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=*%7C!%5B%5Bb%5D10B%5D10&inputs=)

## Explanation

```
*|                    take "*" as a variable
  !                   disable implicit output
   [ ......... ]10    loop 10 times
    [ ... ]10         loop 10 times
       b              concatenate "*" to buffer
             B        print and reset buffer
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal `j`](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>8 7</s> 5 bytes

<sup>-1 byte cause map lambdas are awesome.</sup>
<sup>-2 bytes thanks to the `j` flag</sup>

My first attempt at Vyxal.

```
\*₁*²
```

### Explanation

```
\*         - Push "*"
  ₁*       - Repeat 100 times
    ²      - Format as a square
<flag>     - Join by newline
<implicit> - Print it
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%5C*%E2%82%81*%C2%B2&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/intercal/), 109 bytes

Wait, no, I don't even need to make a loop.

```
PLEASE,1<-#11DO,1SUB#1<-#172DO,1SUB#11<-#260PLEASEREADOUT,1DO,1SUB#1<-#252DOREADOUT,1+,1+,1+,1+,1+,1+,1+,1+,1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/z/Ax9Ux2FXH0EZX2dDQxV/HMDjUSRnMMzeCc0F8IzMDiNogV0cX/9AQHRTVRqZA1XAZbRzo/38A)

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/intercal/), 116 bytes

[mindoverflow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209637/100411) said as if they can't loop shorter, but actually you can.
The code below uses `.1` as loop counter.
Starting with `.1<-512`,
iteration is done with `DOCOMEFROM.1~.1` and `(1)DO.1<-.1~#1022`.

```
PLEASE,1<-#11DO,1SUB#1<-#172DO,1SUB#11<-#260DO.1<-#512DOCOMEFROM.1~.1PLEASEREADOUT,1DO,1SUB#1<-#252(1)DO.1<-.1~#1022
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/z/Ax9Ux2FXH0EZX2dDQxV/HMDjUSRnMMzeCc0F8IzMDF389EMvUECjj7O/r6hbk76tnWKdnCDEkyNXRxT80RAfFGCNTIw1DTYhOoFplQwMjo///AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL), 114 bytes.

From this how should I golf off....

```
DO;1<-#1DO;1SUB#1<-#121DO,1<-#1DO.1<-#512DOCOMEFROM.1~.1DOREADOUT;1+;1+;1+;1+;1+;1+;1+;1+;1+;1+,1(1)DO.1<-.1~#1022
```

[Copy and paste to try it online!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

Comment: No, I can't. Though I could do double-loops with `DOSTASH.1DO.1<-#0` and `DORETRIEVE.1`, `DOREADOUT`, `~#1022`, and some similar code appears twice, which makes it longer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Subleq](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Subleq) (8 bit), 18 bytes

```
 2 -1 42
 1 17  0
15 -1 -9
15 17 12
 1  8  0
10 10 -9
```

### Explanation

```
 2 -1 42 Print [2]                               // [2] = 42, ASCII(42) = "*"
 1 17  0 [17] = [17] - [1]  if [17] <= 0 goto 0  // Loop 10 times
15 -1 -9 Print [15]                              // [15] = 10 ASCII(10) = <line feed> 
15 17 12 [17] = [17] - [15] if [17] <= 0 goto 12 // Set [17] back to -9
 1  8  0 [8]  = [8]  - [1]  if [8]  <= 0 goto 0  // Loop 10 times
10 10 -9 [10] = [10] - [10] if [10] <= 0 Exit    // Exit program
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APOL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/APOL), 23 bytes

`*(+(*("*" 10) "\n") 10)`

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 49 bytes

```
(load library
(join(repeat-val(q **********)10)nl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jJz8xRSEnM6kosaiSSyMrPzNPoyi1IDWxRLcsMUejUEELDjQNDTTzcv7/BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 13 bytes

```
(\*{10}
){10}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdcGCpaUlaboWazVitKoNDWq5NEEkRAwqBVMCAA)

#### Explanation

```
(\*{10}\n){10}
 \*             Literal asterisk
   {10}         Repeated 10 times
       \n       Followed by a newline
(        )      All of that
          {10}  Repeated 10 times
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN (CBQN)](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 14 bytes

```
•Out˘10‿10⥊"*"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704qTBvwYKlpSVpuhZbHzUs8i8tOT3D0OBRw34gsbRLSUtpSXFScjFUBUwlAA)

#### Explanation

```
•Out˘10‿10⥊"*"
            "*"  String (1-dimensional character array) containing an asterisk
     10‿10⥊     Reshape into a 10 by 10 array of asterisks
    ˘            For each row:
•Out               Print with a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
₀₀×ŀ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoDigoDDl8WAIiwiIiwiIl0=)

```
   ŀ # Make a grid of size
₀    # Ten
 ₀   # By ten
  ×  # Filled with asterisks
```

Comment: https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJDSD0iLCIiLCLDlyrCsiIsIiIsIiJd 2.5 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
"*"j₁₀ẉ₂ⁱ¹⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9icmFjaHlsb2cy//8iKiJq4oKB4oKA4bqJ4oKC4oGxwrnigbD//w)

#### Explanation

```
"*"j₁₀ẉ₂ⁱ¹⁰
"*"          Asterisk
   j₁₀       Join 10 copies together into one string
        ⁱ¹⁰  Repeat 10 times:
      ẉ₂      Write (with trailing newline; predicate output = input)
```

---

Alternately, it's possible to port [Fatalize's Brachylog v1 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89230/16766) in 11 bytes:

```
Ḋ≜∧"*"j₁₀ẉ⊥
Ḋ≜            Pick some number 0 to 9
  ∧           Its value doesn't matter, it just matters that we picked it
    "*"       Asterisk
       j₁₀    Join 10 copies together into one string
          ẉ   Write (with trailing newline)
           ⊥  Force backtracking
```

Answer (score 2):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org)'s Type System, 71 bytes

```typescript
type F<A extends{}[]=[]>=A extends{length:10}?A:F<[...A,"**********"]>;
```

[Try it at the TypeScript playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEYAYCotBDAzgFwKYCcCWiDWiA0oA7OKAEYCeaiAUDchQA6qgBiAPAIKioAeaAOwAmiAN4BfANoBdALwyAfLO59BI0QBtUAgObIAFgC4o4gPydDHSQDpbnfACJozl64fSFAbjoNmoABqgsmzeIKDhAHqm9EwsADLaevoA8gBmgcH+kg5augbuNGGR0UA)

Just barely longer than Java :)

Type F recursively appends `"**********"` to array `A` until `A`'s length is 10.

---

If you need the output to be a string and not a list of lines, here's an 83 byte version:

```typescript
//@ts-ignore
type F<A=[],S="">=A extends{length:10}?S:F<[...A,1],`${S}
**********`>
```

[Try it at the TypeScript playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=13&pln=3&pc=1#code/PTAEEYAYCotBDAzgFwKYCcCWiDWiA0oA9gK7IAOZo2oKWAdgOaEAcAzKAEYCeaiAUPxAABZIgC0mRvSLpU-ZN3KpQAMQA8AQQC8AbQC6+AMraARKYB82zaFQAPNPQAmiAN4AbVE2QALAFxQAL4A-EZ+GroAdNGa+OCGAAYAJK5GgfzQmVnZCRaCisqgABqg2moA3EJgoKAAesFAA)

This one recursively appends `"\n**********"` to string `S` while appending `1` to array `A` until `A`'s length is 10. We need to do it like this because you can't get the length of a string in TypeScript's type system without converting it to a list first, so it's shorter to have a list just to keep track of iteration.

The `//@ts-ignore` is necessary because the compiler doesn't want to spread `A`, which it can't tell is a list, or inject `S`, which it can't tell is a string, into the main string. We could explicitly tell the compiler that `A extends{}[]` (A is a list of something) and that `S extends string`, but that comes out to be a lot longer than just ignoring the errors.

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 52 bytes

```
(display(string-join(make-list 10"**********")"\n"))
```

If you're fine with just returning the string and not printing it, you can forego the `(display)` for a score of **41** bytes.

An alternate answer (longer at 73 bytes, but I like it better personally):

```
(display(build-string 110(λ(n)(if(eq?(remainder n 10)0)#\newline #\*))))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 41 bytes

```
@for /l %%i in (0,1,9)do @echo **********
```

Comment: You can shave off 1 byte by removing the first `@`

Comment: @SomethingDark But then it would print `for /l %%i in (0,1,9)do @echo **********`...

Comment: It didn't when I tested it

Comment: @SomethingDark You mean as an immediate command? As it's a single line, you might be on to something there.

Comment: As both an immediate command (in which case you could save an additional byte by using `%i` instead, but I need to double-check the rules for this language) and in a script.

Comment: @SomethingDark It definitely echoes the command back to me when it's in a script.

Comment: Hmm, so it does.Not sure what I was doing before.

Comment: @SomethingDark I don't think an immediate command would be allowed as it counts as a REPL environment (which is slightly different from the environment of a batch script).

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
TVT\**
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=TVT%5C%2a%2a)

```
       - (T = 10)
TV     - repeat(10):
  T\** -  10*"*"
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Frink](https://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/), <s>40</s> 39 Bytes

```
for r=0 to 9
  println[repeat["*",10]]
```

-1 Byte @LeakNun

Comment: You can probably use `0 to 9`

Answer (score 1):

**BASH, 46 bytes**

```
for((n=0;n<10;n++));do echo "**********"; done
```

Comment: Or `for n in {0..9};{ echo "**********";}`

Comment: Or `seq -f%10g 10|tr -c \\n \*` in Bash + coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

## Maple 30 bytes

```
printf(cat("**********\n"$10))
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 84 bytes

```
#include<stdio>
int main(){int i;for(i=0;i<10;i++){printf("**********\n");return 0;}
```

If anyone can improve the answer, I'd appreciate it. I'm not trying to compete, it's just been simply ages since I've coded C or C++ and this challenge looked fun.

Comment: See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88695/11259

Comment: C function without a return? that's a paddlin'. But thanks, I didn't see that answer before so I'm going to study it now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Sprects](https://dinod123.neocities.org/interpreter.html), 22 bytes

```
#eeep#eppp#pqqq*
#q***
```

Note: The interpreter uses U+0020 instead of U+0010.

Answer (score 1):

## EXCEL, 26 bytes.

```
=REPT("**********[ae]",10)
```

Can go into any cell.

Comment: What is `[ae]`? Is that Alt+Enter (the means to input a line break in Excel)? You can include the line break in the code here. It would be 23 bytes total.

Answer (score 1):

## [tinyAll](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/tinyall), 17 bytes

The current version (untouched for a LONG time), is extremelly broken, but works enough for this challenge.

```
P'*Ra_P"
[:;]"R9_
```

Basically:

- Pass `*` to the `R`(repeat) function
- Repeat it `a` (10) times
- Output it (`_`)
- Pass the output (`;`), through string interpolation, prefixed by a newline
- To the `R` function
- And repeat 9 more times
- And display the result

---

A boring alternative, with the same byte count:

```
P"**********
"Ra_
```

Translating:

- Pass `"**********`
   (newline)
- To the `R` function, to repeat `a` (10) times
- And output the result (`_`)

---

Try it:

```js
// Commit https://github.com/ismael-miguel/tinyall/commit/2589837678f4b6556d1bd22f163255e2e058808e#diff-65af36bb0dc600cbc7a54816dcda57fd
(function(window, undefined) {
 var funcs = {
  //echo
  '_':function(value, data){
   var tmp = data.out + (value === undefined ? data.last : value);
   data.vars[';'] = data.out = tmp;
   return tmp;
  },
  //array
  A:function(value, data){
   var split_value = (value || '').split(/(\-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][\-+]?\d+)?|'(?:\\'|[^']*)*'),?/);
   var final_value = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = split_value.length; i<l; i++)
   {
    if(split_value[i][0] == '\'')
    {
     final_value[final_value.length] = split_value[i].replace(/^'(.*)'$/,'$1').replace(/\\'/g,'\'');
    }
    else if(split_value[i]/1 || split_value[i] == '0')
    {
     final_value[final_value.length] = +split_value[i];
    }
   }
   
   return final_value;
  },
  //comparison functions
  C:function(value, data){
   
  },
  D:function(value, data){
   
   var debug = {
    value: value,
    type: typeof value,
    memory: data
   }
   
   if(console && console.log)
   {
    console.log(debug);
   }
   
   return value;
  },
  //eval
  E:function(value, data){
   run_code(value, data);
  },
  //flip the value around
  F:function(value, data){
   if(('object' === typeof value) && value.reverse)
   {
    return value.reverse();
   }
   else
   {
    return value.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
   }
  },
  //hello worlds
  H:function(value) {
   return 'hH'[value&1]
    +'ello'
    +(value&2?',':'')
    +' '
    +('wW'[+!!(value&4)])
    +'orld'
    +(value&8?'!':'')
    +(value&16?'\n':'');
  },
  //math functions
  M:function(value, data){
   
  },
  //not (inverts values/casing)
  N:function(value) {
   switch(typeof value)
   {
    case 'boolean':
     return !value;
    case 'number':
     return -value;
    case 'string':
     var tmp = '';
     for(var i = 0, l = value.length; i < l; i++)
     {
      if(value[i] >= 'a' && value[i] <= 'z')
      {
       tmp += String.fromCharCode(value.charCodeAt(i) - 32);
      }
      else if(value[i] >= 'A' && value[i] <= 'Z')
      {
       tmp += String.fromCharCode(value.charCodeAt(i) + 32);
      }
      else
      {
       tmp += value[i];
      }
     }
     return tmp;
    default:
     return 0;
   }
  },
  //passthrough
  P:function(value) {
   return value;
  },
  //repeat
  R:function(value, data){
   var tmp = '';
   
   if(value > 0)
   {
    while(value--)
    {
     tmp += data.last;
    }
   }
   
   return tmp;
  },
  //string functions
  S:function(value, data){
   var methods = {
    t:function(value){
     return value.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
    },
    u:function(value){
     return value.toUpperCase();
    },
    T:function(value ){
     
    },
    R:function(value){
     
    }
   };
   
   var tmp = data.last.toString();
   for(var i = 0, l = value.length; i < l; i++)
   {
    tmp = value[i] in methods ? methods[value[i]](tmp, value, i) : '';
   }
  
   return tmp;
  },
  //clears output
  Z:function(value, data) {
   return data.vars[';'] = data.out = 0;
  }
 };
 
 var expand_string = function(value, data){
  
  return value.replace(
   /\[:(?:([A-Z_])(.)?|([^A-Z_'"]))\]/g,
   function(_, func, arg, value){
    if(func)
    {
     return funcs[func](get_value(arg, data, true), data);
    }
    else
    {
     return get_value(value, data, true);
    }
   }
  );
  
 };
 
 var get_value = function(value, data, recursion) {
  
  if(value === null || value === undefined || value === ' ')
  {
   return undefined;
  }
  
  var x = (value || '').toString();
  
  if(/^\-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][\-+]?\d+)?$/.test(x))
  {
   //returns a number
   return +x;
  }
  else if(/^[a-z]$/.test(x))
  {
   //returns a number between 10-43
   return (x in data.vars) ? data.vars[x] : x.charCodeAt(0) - 87;
  }
  else if(x[0] == '\'')
  {
   return x[1];
  }
  else if(x[0] == '"' && x.length >= 2)
  {
   var sub = x.substr(1, x.length - 2);
   
   return recursion ? sub : expand_string(sub, data);
  }
  else
  {
   return data.vars[x];
  }
 };
 
 var run_code = function(code, memory){
  
  if(!code || /^[a-z\d]$/.test(code))
  {
   memory.out = funcs.H(get_value(code, memory));
  }
  else
  {
   code.toString().replace(
    // /(?:([^A-Z_:'"])=)?([A-Z_])(?::('.|"[^"]*"|-?\d+|.))?/g,
    /(?:([^A-Z_'"])=)?([A-Z_])(?:('.|"[^"]*"|-?\d+|[^A-Z_'"]))?/g,
    function(_, name, func, value){
     
     memory.vars[name || ':'] = memory.last = (funcs[func] || noop)( value ? get_value(value, memory) : memory.last, memory);
     
     return '';
    }
   );
  }
 }
 
 var noop = function(){};
 
 window.tinyAll=function(code, input) {
  var data = {
   out: '',
   last: 0,
   input: input || 0,
   vars: {
    //version
    '|':'0.3',
    //input
    ':':input || 0,
    //output
    ';':0,
    //code
    '.':(code || '').toString()
   }
  };
  
  run_code(data.vars['.'], data);
  
  return data.out || 0;
 };
})(Function('return this')());



//RUN THE CODE!!!
//\n instead of a real newline, but works the same
console.log(tinyAll('P\'*Ra_P"\n[:;]"R9_'));
console.log(tinyAll('P"**********\n"Ra_'));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JAISBaL 3.0.1](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/JAISBaL), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/SocraticPhoenix/JAISBaL/blob/master/README.md#file-format)

```
h**A10«
```

Verbose:

```
# \# enable verbose parsing #\
ten            \# [0] push ten onto the stack #\
push1 *        \# [1] push * onto the stack #\
mul            \# [2] multiply the top two values of the stack #\
dupmany 10     \# [3] duplicate the top value of the stack 10 times #\
popoutallln    \# [4] pop off every value in the stack and print each one with a new line #\
```

#### Conventional 10 byte version (using actual for loops):

```
˖˖S*˄P
```

Verbose:

```
# \# enable verbose parsing #\
ten                 \# [0] push ten onto the stack #\
for                 \# [1] start for loop #\
    ten             \# [2] push ten onto the stack #\
    for             \# [3] start for loop #\
        print1 *    \# [4] print * #\
    end             \# [5] end current language construct #\
    ln              \# [6] print a new line #\
```

---

[intepreter](https://dl.bintray.com/meguy26/Main/com/gmail/socraticphoenix/JAISBaL/3.0.1/)

Answer (score 1):

**PostgreSQL, 39 bytes**

```
select repeat('**********'||chr(13),10)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [99](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47588/48934), 137 bytes

```
99999 9 9
9999 99999 9
999 99 9
999999 99 9




99 99 9 99 9 99 9 99 9999
99
99
99
99
99
99
99
99
99
99
999999
999 999 9
 99 999
 9 99999
```

[Try it online!](http://99.tryitonline.net/#code=OTk5OTkgOSA5Cjk5OTkgOTk5OTkgOQo5OTkgOTkgOQo5OTk5OTkgOTkgOQoKCgoKOTkgOTkgOSA5OSA5IDk5IDkgOTkgOTk5OQo5OQo5OQo5OQo5OQo5OQo5OQo5OQo5OQo5OQo5OQo5OTk5OTkKOTk5IDk5OSA5CiA5OSA5OTkKIDkgOTk5OTk&input=&debug=on)

Answer (score 1):

## jq, <s>24</s> 18 characters

(16 characters code + 2 characters command line option.)

```
range(10)|"*"*10
```

Thanks to:

- [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun) for suggesting to use string multiplication (-6 characters)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ jq -nr 'range(10)|"*"*10'
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=range(10)|"*"*10&j=null) (Passing `-r` through URL is not supported – check Raw Output yourself.)

Comment: `range(10)|"*"*10`

Comment: Thank you, @LeakyNun. No idea why I left with the idea that string\*number not works. (array\*string is the one that not works.)

Answer (score 1):

## **C#, <s>52</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes**

49 bytes : 'for(int i=0;i++<10;)Console.Write("**********\n")' (Thanks to [Csharpie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/22846/csharpie))

50 bytes : `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)Console.Write("**********\n")`

52 bytes : `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)Console.WriteLine("**********")`

Close with 70 bytes : `Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("**********\n",10)))`

edit : Test here : [Online C# Interactive compiler](http://csharppad.com/gist/32ed9241f4639a9f22dad9ee6315d85e).

P.S : *C# Interactive is there in Visual Studio/Roslyn for a long time, no one said the answer needs to compile into an executable, or that C# is limited to .NET's verbose BCL functions or that C# is limited to Windows.
`csi.exe` would just be same in functionality as other (interpreted) languages' interpreters do (like PowerShell), which is the beauty of C#.*

Comment: You might want to include a link to an online interpretter/compiler so we can test your code.  [e.g.](https://ideone.com/hMDbqN#comments)

Comment: [This](http://csharppad.com/gist/32ed9241f4639a9f22dad9ee6315d85e) would work almost the same as csi.exe included in Roslyn, although the behavior might not be the same for all cases.

Comment: You can shorten it down a bit `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`  can be written as `for(int i=0;i++<10;)`

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 84 characters

```go
package main;import"fmt";func main(){for j:=0;j<10;j++{fmt.Println("**********");}}
```

Sample run:

```
bash$ go build && ./golf
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Comment: Print ten asterisks without using a loop

Comment: removed inner loop per @LeakyNun

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 34 bytes

```
putStr$[0..9]>>([0..9]>>"*")++"\n"
```

---

```
λ> putStr$[0..9]>>([0..9]>>"*")++"\n"
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Comment: Since the question stipulates you have to print the text your likely need a `main=`.  I'd also point out that `"*********\n"` is shorter than `([0..9]>>"*")++"\n"`.

Comment: @CatWizard No need for main. Your proposal is already [taken](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88728/55260).

Comment: @CatWizard I am running GHCi on my terminal. Isn't that allowed?

Comment: GHCi is allowed.  It is generally considered a different language from Haskell.  If other people are not using `main` and no one has done anything I think you will fine though.

Comment: @CatWizard I added a demo so that readers know this is to be used in an interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

### [MarioLANG](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG), <s>101</s> <s>99</s> 95 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender.*

[Try it Online!](http://mariolang.tryitonline.net/#code=KworKysrKSs8Li4uLi4uKDwKKys9PT09Ii49PT09PT0iCis-KSsoKCk-Li4uKC4KKz09PT0oLT09PT09KSAtCisrKysrWyEpKSsrIClbIQo9PT09PT0jPT09PT09PSM&input=)

```
+
++++)+<......(<
++====".======"
+>)+(()>...(.
+====(-=====) -
+++++[!))++ )[!
======#=======#
```

The left half sets the tape to `10 40 10`

The second half increases the `40` to `42`, then prints the 42 (`*`) 10 times, and a newline, and repeats that 10 times.

Comment: Link? – – – – –

Comment: @LeakyNun Sorry I completely forgot. Edited it in.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gibberish](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Gibberish_(programming_language)), 29 bytes

```
56ea1[[**********]eo1su1fu]gw
```

**Explanation:**

```
56ea1[[**********]eo1su1fu]gw |
56                            | push 5 and 6
  e                           | switch to first instruction set
   a                          | add a, b
    1                         | push 1
     [[**********]eo1su1fu]   | push string
                           g  | switch to set 3
                            w | while a is 1 execute string as code
      [**********]            | push ten asterisks
                  e           | switch to set 1
                   o          | print a
                    1s        | subtract one
                      u       | duplicate a
                       1      | push 1
                        f     | switch to set 2
                         u    | pop a, b push 1 if a > b else push 0
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Neoscript](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/neoscript), 39 bytes

```
each _=0:[]:9console:log("**********");
```

Answer (score 1):

### VBA, 31 bytes

```
for i=0to 9:?"**********":next
```

in the VBA Immediate window. I couldn't find any byte-saving tricks beyond this. My best non-loop version was 45 bytes:

```
?replace("..........",".","**********"&vblf)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Vitsy, 13 bytes

I'm late to the party. :c

```
a\[aa\['*']Z]
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=YVxbYWFcWycqJ11aXQ&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 46 bytes

```
<?php
for($i=-2;++$i<9;)echo "**********\n";?>
```

I think this don't needs explanation.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 35 Bytes

```
for _ in 0...9{print("**********")}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Convex, 10 bytes

```
A'**{A*N}%
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=QScqKntBKk59JQ&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## Fortran, <s>68</s> <s>51</s> 49 bytes

*Skimmed off 17 bytes, because who needs indents and spaces?*

*-2 bytes thanks to @Joffan*

As a tribute to senior and the fact there was no Fortran answer yet. Well, now I know why: this is a pretty hard language to golf! <s>Just one or two indents already take up more bytes than the shortest answer here :))</s>.

```
program T
do i=0,9
print*,('*',j=0,9)
end do
end
```

[Try it!](https://ideone.com/fH6HFW) (ideone)

I tried golfing it down by introducing a nested 'implied' do loop, but the newline character wasn't available until Fortran 2003. Also, it's insanely verbose...

Comment: Loops using `0,9` limits skim off another couple? And make the positive case for not using `'**********'` :-)

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I didn't think of that. Must've had a temporary brain meltdown :/

Comment: @MH. I know I'm late, but `program T print'(10(A))',('*',j=0,99) end` is 41 bytes long and doesn't print a leading space :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 44 bytes

```sql
SELECT'**********'FROM v$bh WHERE rownum<11;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Grocery List](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Grocery_List), 72 bytes

```
G

number ten
v
z
v
P
s
u
c
l
number ten
l
b
c
p
u
n
s
e
x
u
c
p
b
n
s
e
```

[Try it online](https://splcurran.github.io/grocerylist.htm)

Answer (score 1):

## LaTeX, <s>122</s> <s>110</s> 105 bytes

*-12 bytes thanks to @Leaky Nun* 
*-5 bytes by changing package & document type*

Or, if I'm allowed to skip the document class definition & setup, and just count the package import and for-loop code: **55 bytes**.

I still need to check if there's another package that has a shorter loop syntax, but for now, this simply uses `pgffor` (from `tikz`) and a `foreach`:

```
\documentclass{book}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}\foreach\n in{0,...,9}{**********\par}\end{document}
```

Ungolfed:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach\n in{0,...,9}{**********\par}
\end{document}
```

Output (w/ free page number :) ):
[image]

Comment: `**********` is shorter than `\foreach\n in{0,...,9}{*}`

Comment: Good point! Not sure how I missed that... Must've been too focused on getting the nested loop going :) Thanks!

Comment: ``\\`` is shorter than ``\par``

Comment: True, but then the result is no longer a proper grid as the first line will be indented.

Comment: @MH. -- Here's a Link to the Plain TeX solution:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/tpjsnrgsnnsb

Comment: There's still some room for improvement... This LaTeX version is a little shorter: `\documentclass{cd}\document\def~{**********\par}~~~~~~~~~~\stop` uses only 63 bytes. (IMHO: The code should be at most 109 bytes long because... you know, I mean, ... 100 times the * character and nine line breaks... Your version compresses that by 4 bytes which is fine ... )

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript, 27 bytes

```
0{"**********\n"\1+.10<}do;
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=MHsiKioqKioqKioqKlxuIlwxKy4xMDx9ZG87&input=)

Explanation

```
0              # Push 0 onto the stack: counter
{
"**********\n" # Push 10 '*' and a newline character
\              # Moves the counter onto the stack
1+             # Increments the counter
.10<           # Check if it's smaller than 10
}do;           # Repeat until counter equals 10
```

Comment: You know, you can just do [this](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=IioqKioqKioqKipcbiIxMCo&input=)

Comment: I'm a newbie, I didn't know, thank you!

Comment: [Another byte saved](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=IioqKioqKioqKioKIjEwKg&input=)

Comment: [12 bytes now](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=WyIqIjEwKm5dMTAq&input=)

Comment: Wow, I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: @LeakyNun You don't need the `[`.

Comment: @Dennis Wow, I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thue](http://esolangs.org/wiki/thue), 30 bytes

```
%::=~**********
::=
%%%%%%%%%%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/X9XKyrZOCw64gFwuVTj4/x8A)

---

## [Thue](http://esolangs.org/wiki/thue), 53 bytes

```
%::=,*,*
>*::=>[
>,::=>]]
[::=~
]::=~*****
::=
>%%%%%
```

Uses the convention that "when a string is sent to the output stream, no newline is printed at the end, except if the string is empty, in which case a newline is all that is printed." This is not followed by the TIO interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

## S.I.L.O.S, 41 bytes

Never used S.I.L.O.S before, <s>can probably be golfed more.</s>

**EDIT:** Looks like there was already a S.I.L.O.S answer, but it didn't show up on the leaderboard. But I'll keep this answer because it's shorter.

```
a=10
lblb
printLine **********
a-1
if a b
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=YT0xMApsYmxiCnByaW50TGluZSAqKioqKioqKioqCmEtMQppZiBhIGI&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 25 bytes

```
time {puts **********} 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaG6oLSkWEELDmoVDA3@/wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
*^*9^
^*9
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/) (copy & paste only)

```
*^                //pushes "*" to the stack
*9                //add 9 more copies of itself
                  //stack = "**********"
^\n^              //append a newline to it
*9                //add 9 more copies of the resulting string
                  //implicit output
```

Comment: Why is this non-competing?

Comment: @TheFifthMarshal Looking at the github repo it appears this program didn't work in the version of the language at the time of the challenge. I edited it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
Ao ç*pA)·
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=QW8g5ypwQSm3&input=) This is, in fact, competing.

#### How it works

```
Ao ç*pA)·  // Implicit: A = 10
Ao         // Create the range [0..10).
   ç*pA)   // Fill with "*".repeat(A).
        ·  // Join with newlines. Implicitly print.
```

Comment: Can be [7 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QcZB7irDtw==&input=) these days!

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 58 bytes

```
(d A(q((n *)(i n(i(disp *)0(A(s n 1)*))*
(A 9(q **********
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jRcFRo1BDI09BS1MjUyFPI1MjBSgB5BloOGoUK@QpGGpqaWpqcWk4KlhqFCpowcH//wA)

We define a function `A` with two parameters: `n` is the number of iterations, and `*` is a row of asterisks (it will always be ten of them, but it saves bytes to pass that as an argument). If `n` is truthy (nonzero), we `disp`lay the asterisk row (with trailing newline) and recurse with `n` minus 1. If `n` is falsey (zero), we simply return the asterisk row.

Calling the function with `n` = 9 results in 9 `disp` calls; the return value of the function is then displayed, giving us our 10th row.

Comment: remove 4 closing parens for 58?

Comment: Sure. They were needed when this answer was first written: back then, parens only autocompleted at the end of the program.

Comment: i see. interesting

Answer (score 1):

## Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500

Simple enough I think

#### Method 1, 55 bytes (listing):

```
 1 LET A=0
 2 PRINT "**********"
 3 LET A=A+1
 4 GOTO 2+((A=9)*3)
```

#### Method 2, 30 bytes (listing)

```
 1 FOR I=0 TO 9
 2 PRINT "**********"
 3 NEXT I
```

Comment: The ZX81 has a 1-byte ** (which is shift and H); this will save 5 bytes from each listing and might even be a bit quicker. ** is used for _to the power of_.

Answer (score 1):

## [Syms 1.3](https://github.com/CatsAreFluffy/syms), 17 bytes (noncompeting)

```
{*}10;*{
}~+10;*>
```

Explanation:

```
{*}10;*{\n}~+10;*>
{*}                 Pushes "*"
   10;*             Repeats it 10 times.
       {\n}         Pushes \n.
           ~+       Adds it to the end of "*"*10.
             10;*   Repeats it 10 times.
                 >  Outputs.
```

Comment: 2 bytes can be saved with 1.4's single char string `$`.

Answer (score 1):

## R 34 bytes

While not being elegant at all, it makes what expected in not that many bytes...

`cat(rep("**********",10),sep="\n")`

Comment: `write(matrix('*',10,10),'',10,,'')` is the same number of bytes with a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 1):

## [LibreLogo](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#LibreLogo_programming_language), 21 bytes

**Code:**

```
print(9*'*'+'*\n')*10
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB / Octave, 23 bytes

**Code:**

```
m=[eye(10) ''];m(:)='*'
```

**[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@59rG51amaphaKCpoK4ea52rYaVpq66l/v8/AA)**

**Result:**

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Comment: You can replace `'*'` by `42` to save a byte. Or use `[ones(10)+41 '']`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
'*т×Tô»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fXeti0@HpIYe3HNr9/z8A)

An alternate solution to the 05AB1E one already provided.

**Explanation:**

```
'*т×Tô» 
'*      Push an asterisk
  т×    Repeat the asterisk 100 times: "***********..."
    Tô  Split it into pieces of 10.
      » Join with newlines.
        Implicit print.
```

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, <s>19</s> 13 bytes

**Solution:**

```
-1(2#10)#"*";
```

**Example:**

```
q)-1(2#10)#"*";
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

**Explanation:**

```
-1(2#10)#"*"; / solution
         "*"  / the asterisk
        #     / take or reshape
  (2#10)      / list (10;10), 10 rows, 10 columns
-1           ; / print to stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Check](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/check-lang), 15 bytes

```
"*">10:r*R]+R*o
```

Pushes the string `*` and repeats it ten times, while also storing 10 in the register. Then adds 10 to the end of the string (a newline), then repeats the whole thing 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular) , 28 bytes

```
A\(A@1].p-p..pA@...](/*76-1<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/3zFGw9HBMFavQLdAT6/A0UFPTy9WQ1/L3EzX0Ob/fwA)

Expanded version:

```
       A 
      \ ( 
     A @ 1 
    ] . p - 
   p . . p A 
  @ . . . ] ( 
 / * 7 6 - 1 <
```

Commands executed, excluding directional commands:

```
A(1-A(1-67*@p]A@pp]
```

Comment: How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 66 bytes

```perl
$x = 1x10;$x =~ s/\d/*/g;for($i = 1; $i <=10; $i++){print "$x\n";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lQsFWwbDC0MAaxKpTKNaPSdHX0k@3Tssv0lDJBElaKwBpG1ugEiBDW1uzuqAoM69EQUmlIiZPybr2/38A)

Comment: You can remove literally *all* the whitespace

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 11 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that outputs a 10x10 grid of `*` to the ActiveSheet object

```
[A1:J10]="*
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

Bet there's going to be a shorter Charcoal answer

```
VT*T"*
```

Explanation:

```
VT     Ten times
 *T"*  Output ten asterisks followed by a newline
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyxEK0RJ6/9/AA)

Comment: ---[nope :|](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8/KSc/L13B0EAHiBXUtdT///@vW/ZftzgHAA)--- [yep](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/78gP6cyPT9PwUpbwdBAQV1L/f///7pl/3WLcwA)

Comment: @ASCII-only why am i alive

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 41 bytes

### Submission

```
fun f()=(0..9).map{println("**********")}
```

### Test

```
fun f()=(0..9).map{println("**********")}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  f()
}
```

### TryItOnline

[Link](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPIU1D01bDQE/PUlMvN7GguqAoM68kJ09DSQsOlDRrubhASnMTM/M0EovSi60UHIuKEittgkuAqtPtNBWquRRABnHV/v8PAA)

Comment: I believe lambda body is enough - 33 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>73</s> 62 bytes

`o` is a String passed to a Consumer

```
o->System.out.print("**********".replace("*", "**********\n"))
```

Comment: `o->System.out.print("**********".replace("*", "**********\n"))`

Answer (score 1):

**R: 33 bytes**

```
write.matrix(matrix("*",10,10))
```

This does assume that you've loaded the MASS library.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 78 bytes

```
$h=@();$v=@();1..10|% $_{$h+="*"};$i=0;Do{$v+=$h-join'';$i++}while($i-ne10);$v
```

Code explode:

```
$numbers = 1..10
$horArray = @()
$verArray = @()

Foreach ($number in $numbers){
    $horArray += "*"
}

$i = 0
Do {
    $verArray += $horArray -join ''
    $i++
}
while ($i -ne 10)
$verArray
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), 41 bytes

```
_=-~(_==_)
_=_**-~_+_
_=("*"*_+"""
""")*_
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/3la3TiPe1jZekyveNl5LS7cuXjseyNRQ0lLSitdWUlLiAmJNrfj//wE)**

### Explanation

- `_=-~(_==_)` sets the value of `_` to `True`, which is interchangeable with `1`
- `_=_**-~_+_` performs `2**3+2`, resulting in `10`, and stores this in `_`
- `"*"*_` constructs a row, and `+"""\n"""` appends a newline.
- This is multiplied by `_`, 10, to create the square.
- At the end of execution, the value left in `_` is printed.

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, 33 bytes

```
55+:v
_v#:<,"*"-1
^_1-:!#@_55+:,1
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/39RU26qMK75M2cpGR0lLSdeQKy7eUNdKUdkhHiSlY/j/PwA)

#### How it works

```
55+:v
....<... Initialises the stack with two 10s as counters.
........ The first is for the outer loop, and the second is the inner

.....
_v#:<... Checks whether the inner counter is 0
._......

.....           If so, decrement the outer counter
_..........       If the outer counter is 0, exit the program
^_1-:!#@_55+:,1   Else print a newline and reset the outer loop counter

.....
.....,"*"-1 Else, decrement the inner counter and print an *
........... And run the inner loop again
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-98, <s>19</s> 15 bytes

```
a1_@#:-,ka:k8*'
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9PNIx3ULbS1clOtMq20FL//x8A)

First time using 98 instead of 93. Both the k and ' commands are immensely useful.

Answer (score 1):

## Io, 32 bytes

```
10repeat("*"repeated(10)println)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//9/QoCi1IDWxRENJSwnCSk3RMDTQLCjKzCvJydP8/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

### [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 5 bytes

```
*Ａ×Ａ＊
```

[Try it online!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=KiV1RkYyMSVENyV1RkYyMSV1RkYwQQ__)

With notes (not valid code, as Canvas does not support comments):

```
          Print the following (implicit)
*         The string "*"
 Ａ×      Duplicated 10 times horizontally
    Ａ＊  Duplicated 10 times vertically
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 23 bytes

```
print(("*"^10*"\n")^10)
```

Explanation:

```
print(                ) # Print
      (           )     # A string consisting of 
       "*"^10           # "*" duplicated 10 times
             *"\n"      # then concatenated to a newline
                   ^10  # which is then duplicated 10 times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, 5 bytes

```
AÆAî*
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QcZB7io=&input=LVI=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, 5 bytes

```
AÆAç*
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=QcZB5yo=&input=LVI=)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
Ao@Aç*

Ao@    Map range(10) with a function that returns...
Aç*      "*" repeated 10 times.
       `-R` flag joins the result array with "\n"
       Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Q'Nial7](https://github.com/danlm/qnial7), 15 bytes

```
10 10reshape'*'               #create atom '*', reshape to 10 by 10 matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 20 bytes

```
print("*"*10+"\n")*10
```

I didn't know you could remove the space between `print` and the string.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 23 bytes

```
print(("*"*10+"\n")*10)
```

Felt like entering a Python 3 program too.

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, 17 bytes

```
@()repmat('*',10)
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BQ7MotSA3sURDXUtdx9BA83@ahuZ/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), 32 bytes

```
1 WIDTH 10:PRINT STRING$(100,42)

RUN
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

No loop. Just printing 100 asterisks into a 10 character wide terminal to force line wraps.

There's no MBASIC on TIO, so I've linked the reference manual.

Answer (score 1):

## [ORK](https://github.com/TryItOnline/ork), 185 bytes

```
When this program starts:
I have a scribe called W
W is to write "**********\n**********\n**********\n**********\n**********\n**********\n**********\n**********\n**********\n**********"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy/K/v8/PCM1T6EkI7NYoaAoP70oMVehuCSxqKTYistTISOxLFUhUaE4uSgzKVUhOTEnJzVFIZwrXAGouiRfobwosyRVQUkLDmLy6MdW@v8fAA)

ORK does everything (even I/O and basic math) with objects. As far as this question goes, looping does not have to be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

## [q](https://kx.com/download), 12 bytes

```
10 10#get"*" / a 10x10 matrix
```

Comment: `10 10#(*)` should have the same effect. But I'm not sure if spaces are allowed between asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Premier](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Premier), 8 bytes

```
'*U*N+U*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyhKzc1MLfr/X10rVMtPO1Tr/38A)

The boring way.

### Explanation

```
'*U*N+U*     full program
'*           push "*"
  U          push 10
   *         repeat
    N+       append newline
      U      push 10
       *     repeat
```

## [Premier](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Premier), 14 bytes

```
QnN
**********
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyhKzc1MLfr/PzDPj0sLDv7/BwA) This second approach uses Premier's implicit data iteration. It iterates over each character in the data (the second line), and executes the program (the first line) for each character. The data `QnN` pushes the data (`Q`), outputs it (`n`), then pushes a newline (`N`), to be implicitly outputted. This iterates 10 times, printing a 10x10 grid of asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 7 bytes

```
♂⌂*n+♂*
```

### Explanation

```
♂⌂*     Push asterisk multiplied by 10("**********")
   n    Append a newline
    +   Concatenate the two strings
     ♂* Multiply the string by 10
implicit output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RzKZHPU1aedpAhtb//wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 23 bytes

```python
print(10*(10*"*"+"\n"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew9BAC4SVtJS0lWLylDQ1//8HAA)

In this case, the obvious answer is best. I tried some other ways, but all were equal or longer in length.
Let me know if you have any answers to add.

## 23 bytes (alternative)

```python
print(10*f"{10*'*'}\n")
```

## 24 bytes

```python
print(10*"**********\n")
```

## 25 bytes

```python
exec(10*"print(10*'*');")
```

## 29 bytes

```python
print("\n".join(10*[10*"*"]))
```

## 32 bytes

```python
for _ in range(10):print(10*"*")
```

## 43 bytes

```python
print(*(10*"*"for _ in range(10)),sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 26 bytes

Just used a compressed string. Has raw output of [gzdeflate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php) and contains unprintable binary data, so the code itself and direct TIO link cannot be posted here, but here is a hex dump of it:

```
000000  3c 3f 3d 67 7a 69 6e 66 6c 61 74 65 28 22 d3 d2  <?=gzinflate("..
000010  82 01 2e 2d 9a 33 01 22 29 3b                    ...-.3.");
```

Save it as a binary file then execute it like this: `php asterisks.php`

TIO which uses bash to run this file: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcwxDoJAEEDR3lP8WGnBBGZ1gKjxLAsLQmKQKCbEePdVqX3db37lH12M8xxI7kg/jM9Jpv7Gm7EbY0wX4GpciwtYTu6xEmsww2osI99he7RAleAICsfz6fLqh/bqp2azFln9Ptn3VChphjZooPQ4t6SiJa7iDxFJxMl6e/gA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
⎕←10 10⍴'*'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//Ud/UR20TDA0UDA0e9W5R11L//x8A)

### Explanation

```apl
⎕←          ⍝ Output
   10 10⍴'*' ⍝ The asterisk reshaped into a 10 by 10 grid
```

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), <s>44</s> 40 bytes

<sup>[crossed out 44 is still regular 44 :(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170188/crossed-out-44-is-still-regular-44)</sup>

```
1x1f6a7m9o1o4d1o0m0x1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f
```

This is another one of those cases where a truly recursive definition would actually use more bytes than just repeating the `f` instruction.

*Saved 4 bytes by using division instead of subtraction!*

[Try it online!](https://sporeball.dev/naz/?code=1x1f6a7m9o1o4d1o0m0x1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f&input=&n=false)

**Explanation** (with `0x` instructions removed)

```
1x1f                   # Function 1
    6a7m9o1o           # Output 10 asterisks
            4d1o       # Output a newline
                0m     # Reset the register
1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f1f   # Call function 1 ten times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 15 bytes

```
puts [?**10]*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFgh2l5Ly9AgFoj//wcA)

Prints a trailing newline.

`?*` is the single character `*`

### Explanation

```
puts [?**10]*10

      ?*        : literal '*' string
        *10     : repeated 10 times ('**********')
     [     ]    : as an element in an array
            *10 : which is also repeated 10 times
puts            : prints each element of the array appended with a newline.
```

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w) `d`, <del>7</del> 4 bytes

```
°♣∩x
```

### Uncompressed

```
T:s*E
```

### Explanation

```
T     % Push a 10 onto the stack
 :    % Copy the top of stack
  s*  % Generate 10 asterisks
    E % Foreach in the range 1 .. 10,
      % Print 10 asterisks following a newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
C10*100"*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/39nQQMvQwEBJ6/9/AA)

Length 100 string chopped into 10 pieces.

Answer (score 1):

## Scratch 3.0, 4 blocks/65 bytes

SB Syntax:

```
when gf clicked
delete all of[o v
repeat(10
add[**********]to[o v
```

Picture:

[image]

[Try it on<s>line</s> Scratch!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/363954762)

I'm quite proud of the block count here, because it matches the byte counts of the winning answers. But SB Syntax ruined things for me. (´• ╭╮ •`)

Answer (score 1):

## Plain TeX, 35 bytes

```
\def~{**********\par}~~~~~~~~~~\bye
```

[Try this Code at Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tpjsnrgsnnsb)

Answer (score 1):

## [Set](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Set), 79 bytes

```
set A (A+1)
set ! 42
[A/K] set ? 1
set A 65
set B (B+1)
set ! 10
[B/L] set ? 1
```

There's a newline at the start.

Answer (score 1):

## [Integral](https://github.com/nph278/integral), 6 Bytes

```
v*)f)☼
```

[Try it!](https://nph278.github.io/integral/?code=diopZikP&input=)

### Explanation

```
v*     "*"
  )    Push 10
   f   Repeat string 10 times
    )☼ Push 10 copies onto the stack

Stack is joined with newlines & implicitly outputted
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-pn`, 9 bytes

```
`*`
*(9|⑩
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/QSuBS0vDsubRxJX////XLcgDAA)

1 shorter than the current answer.

Comment: Good, but no competition with 1+.

Comment: Yes, very competition with 1+ if you outgolf MAWP

Comment: Such rubbish, so pointless, wow

Comment: It's also funny seeing you hate it so much. ;P

Comment: ... (15 chars!)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 52 bytes

```javascript
console.log((f=(c,i=10)=>i?c+f(c,--i):'\n')(f('*')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dQyPNViNZJ9PW0EDT1i7TPlk7DcjV1c3UtFKPyVPX1EjTUNdS19TU/P8fAA)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 45 bytes

```javascript
console.log((f=c=>c.repeat(10))(f('*')+'\n'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dQyPNNtnWLlmvKLUgNbFEw9BAU1MjTUNdS11TWz0mT11T8/9/AA)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 45 bytes

```javascript
console.log(('*'.repeat(10)+'\n').repeat(10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dQ0NdS12vKLUgNbFEw9BAU1s9Jk9dE0lA8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 5 bytes

```
'*MCt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fXcvXueT///@6OQA)

Four years ago, I wrote [a 7-byte Pip solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89683/16766) and said, "Kinda disappointed that the simple way was the shortest." Fear not, previous me: It's not the shortest anymore!

<sub>(Though technically, given [our current consensus about flags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/16766), Pip and Pip `-l` aren't the same language... oh, whatever.)</sub>

#### Explanation

```
    t  Variable, preset to 10
  MC   Take that as the size of a grid of coordinate pairs and map a function to each pair
'*     Given a value rather than a function, MC puts that value at every location instead
       The result is a list of 10-element lists of asterisks, which we autoprint with
       every sublist on a new line thanks to the -l flag
```

Comment: hmm, isn't the flag added to the code length?

Comment: @Razetime That used to be the case (and Pip's flag system was designed with that rule in mind), but [it's not anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/16766).

Answer (score 1):

## [Rutger](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Rutger), 64 bytes

```
r=Repeat["*"];
o=Concat[r[10]];
o=Repeat[o["\n"]];
Print[o[10]];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotSU8t@v@/yDYotSA1sSRaSUsp1por39Y5Py8ZyC2KNjSIBQtA5fOjlWLylEBCAUWZeSA@WMH//wA)

Kinda self-explanatory, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```
||for _ in 0..10{print!("{:*>11}","
")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc2xDsIgFIXh/T7FkeleY5uyVsPIa5gOEBlEQzEdKM@OMJ7h/0767bn5iPcWIgsKAdntmdt5@k/CEyFimWe9lG8KMV9YlfVqtK7qpkhJbYDcqRJ1Y4QPa9ivsELHyyXXOdvXoCcDFhoHnkfS/g)

This uses `*` as a fill character to pad a newline. The result is printed 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 30 bytes

```
29sign(mod([1,...,110],11))+13
```

[View it online! (kinda)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2gzov4lbm5)

Desmos doesn't have string support, so instead we output a list of 110 character codes. If you don't want a trailing newline, you can change the 110 to a 109 with no issues. Desmos also doesn't support loops properly, but if you apply operations to arrays, it applies them to each element in the array. Explanation:

```
           [1,...,110]           Generate array containing numbers 1 to 110
       mod(           ,11)       Find index mod 11 (0 corresponds to end of row)
  sign(                   )      Coerce to 0/1 instead of 0/1/2/...
29                         +13   Convert 0s to 13s (\n in ASCII) and 1s to 42s (* in ASCII)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

```
10."*"*n+*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/39BAT0lLSStPW@v/fwA)

```
10.         # Puts 10 on the stack and makes a copy of it
   "*"*     # Puts the asterisk on the stack and multiplies it by the 10 to get "**********"
       n+   # Adds a newline to the string
         *  # Multiplies by that first 10
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 8 bytes

```
00000000: d382 035e 2e7a b201
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypNSspJTS/N/f/fAAqsFFKMLYwUDIxNUxWMUs0TFZKMDAz//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bound](https://github.com/HoofedEar/Bound), <strike>13</strike> 12 bytes

```
10:c42:d*@RS
```

Thanks to Razetime for the -1 byte
Explanation:

```
1 # Put 1 onto the stack [1]
0 # Put 0 onto the stack [1, 0]
: # Combine the top two elements [10]
c # Copies the top element [10, 10]
4 # Put 4 onto the stack [10, 10, 4]
2 # Put 2 onto the stack [10, 10, 4, 2]
: # Combine the top two elements [10, 10, 42]
d # Convert the top element into a char [10, 10, '*']
* # Multiply the top two elements [10, '**********']
@ # Sorts the stack ['**********', 10]
R # Repeat the next command n times, where n is top element (10) ['**********']
S # Print the top char/string (creates newlines)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVnpdhs1FP7teQplSojdOK7tlgKmDhS6kHOg5SQFfiTByDOyLSqPBknjhe2heBBeKdwrabzEEyeNc1r7j20t937f3bSlUzOQycOLCz5MpTLEfQneDXyDnur8Z1/IWfOQmkH@W9EklsOgp@SQSF1LocvLIb9JnlS7VLOEDllVp4IbNjFB8NPz45Oj169Im4Sjeq1RexwGSTYUXBtsqjeaDx998vjTzz4PgyBmPdDGk3JUaQWlCPqjmmKpoBErhySskjCsBCUtMxUx6DyNBlSRnlTE/uAJic4XulFFWbERU5rFZddcgfmCJX2ADQNYkjcHpRFIaJO9vaAUs27Wh98vqNAM5BkavUVt50FQGg@4YMRL2GmTOuAsGTXFr1KUKcUSpOWk1lKZlkF0iU0ilhpylMRs8lwpqezwrmL0Lcgs8R7xOtvkjcqY7U0VT0w5PCQh2SdeciXww2eaAPGvey1yj7xkKD/NDM7NGaCwghk1O@N1ZmA4sfTmCu3fSsGkfTvpaRxzw2WCE2CAtaCdQQ7bpGmBY7uZpsx1nB40ziuEa/COIRA8S13NWZebObMkfCiaEYfNrIifbmGra6FpypK43AV7Ud/jDf8GdM7tjp6SieFJoXEOLM@TrGsUjbae6sEmVO9bqt9nwnDI1ohuPdv7N2d7NV5t1CZ4wWJmwFBKMXLfD6I25rDqsV3nMRlnQm61p3Y3YfnAsnzGRzxmVaJkBpizdIv54gpZixgXwPwBML899bOzAu6xHN99XpI7pt8TUqqN@f9i6f8gx0xtdyXaKI3vuTXm94wqVkizcQ3Nm3JZQk0RdfP2qA/dRgN2LYYpKHJ0yxYL0AieOQTH5LOX@TfygQz2dcVD6re3zhNrne@Y1ltrmicfyDRta5qjxLA@BM43cphSxbXcShsB3g9jpL/c/rqrpcgMIyMqsvdZG7q6vEnd3rHoX8COWSpOxfsD7taeXO9GHPp@7UltiGk6wl0cOEKtY@OOjYsgVwW/tIKP3UGWGFBgvUvGHA6RKAD1RYKt1wTtOHYHD6mezYptlkwDo33z7Gy7iu0LtxSNaWqBmbEkTLAhdOt16TnzDDowWEoqzMhgBgb7oae72NLEFloApuoNNZRgeyoE6cIBFWCtQ5Ifz@1pf0jTMkRSFbfnCwFWKfLKV16ZvR@YH4Ov0rOsaH6tYMcVyf/Iytd4NeIODO@kAOetFR9b8SZTiRWPzuO@wsK3JNReimySiEvBFA28QV24FUI627OY3gAUdyGjCaQbGAqYAMD8TPRueMCTHk9hNVgCKVVsK8AqNG2R/aw4lFYJQcVoNJjdGq13zw3R6amuaROD8NoY1SwMhAGriE5ctcFLF20h5V4EkTzpbwJl4SbH6V/V/qcLfmlgL2e1@qRHNyEQwXprfZXHqlPSaJ2Tff@71Tgv0Pf3NfoU7w/eQeHBksaDQpU/Xi4mPSr0dH11W1R22sIydTqxF4wTjBOHASZN7NVfkdLjvNTDJtkSS9jEQBYMh1jjGez4RU55vg5skqSFSYGIO4jY1Sqa9Bns/g9IozLb2vgbSp847l8erPgpvCQtINyyhGFP1@UJ0zNii@sIWgzapwROO3mN0lt8unPJA2fZig0xhSXl9ruKyOU5JDhUZJlOiezNrOQtdG0ozty0LqU/zhXpueXtPX0DIy6pEgAvMs1HTExJmU3Sp6@e6cqdxx4IhmYXc40qofuNhaDks6CEYfNYXLJ@Ebd/XFrZxwf@B5tXbCKkWBdK7r2ipgdZryfY1bfbydx4VnY2RD9h1XD1@YaLhIECJ4B@PVhibMd5trlR@SVj@rn7bcKXCl5hAUqkgdk8gYYkYuVJFQVVzlcjxgotInzkz2SR8nXYh6SPTqfpzoPj0n3EPlSkAmzP3B0Y@6DYsFpixyq8L13JGzDni0J0oA52iMmdg8RDKiW7pIlI6sUZlCfc4jH18il1lVXZHSquQnst3Cvq7Q2WomvXoisWoyUKoMG/KlqxKwU9f0HDeW5/hMtZEICITgdfLDsdNEPY6eADZKcTtvJxYftrewu7q9shWN4/ZwK23FSw8aOqP6rgfGst90h46SXPkolkjC@THB/qyuF//5KzJMxLsOsDCGzCTeiM454IL/X7Po/uWyaErJKxVCLeccLmjnePqTAR2vNWjyGHfWrPb/OBFxeNeutRsxXfh@/jk/8B)

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first answer!

Comment: 12 bytes: `10:c42:d*@RS`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thank you! excited to be here

Comment: @Razetime nice!

Answer (score 1):

## [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/m-ender/brian-chuck), 23 bytes

```
*{-?
{..........>-.+?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyrKTMzTTc4oTc7@/1@Lu1rXnou7Wg8O7HT1tO3//wcA)

The  is the ascii code 11.

```
Brian:
*      "*" 11
  {-    Restart Chuck's code and subtract 1
    ?   Go to Chuck's code while the first byte is not 0

Chuck:
                    11 (This will be decremented by 1 each line)
  {                  Restart Brian's code
   ..........        Print the "*" 10 times
             >-.+    Print the newline
                 ?   Go back to Brian's code
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

```python
print('\n'.join(''.join('*' for x in range(10))for y in range(10)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQz0mT10vKz8zT0MdRmupK6TlFylUKGTmKRQl5qWnahgaaGqChCpRhTT//wcA)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8i2KDEvPVXD0EDTuqAoM69EQz0mT10vKz8zT0MdRmupp@UXKVQoZOYpFGmCmJUQpub//wA) by saving `range(10)` as a variable and removing the space after `'*'`

Comment: Don't forget to check out [existing Python solutions to this problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=inquestion%3A88653+python). The current record is 20 bytes (Python 2) / 22 bytes (Python 3).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 41 bytes

```c
main(n){++n<puts("**********")&&main(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI0@zWls7z6agtKRYQ0kLDpQ01dSg8ta1//8DAA)

Or if you don't have any problem using a function that would work only the first time it's called (because to make it work again you should reset the value of `n`)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 38 bytes

```c
n=9;f(){puts("**********");n&&f(--n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z/P1tI6TUOzuqC0pFhDSQsOlDSt89TU0jR0dfM0rWv/Z@aVKOQmZuZpaCpUc3EpAAFQkzWEVZRaUlqUp2BgzVX7HwA)

And a 38 bytes dupe

```c
n;f(){++n+1<puts("**********")&&f(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z/POk1Ds1pbO0/b0KagtKRYQ0kLDpQ01dTSNPI0rWv/Z@aVKOQmZuZpaCpUc3EpAAFQmzWEVZRaUlqUp2BgzVX7HwA)

Note that even the first code works only one time, it doesn't reset anything, you need to run the program again to have another 10x10 grid. However for some (questionable) reason they allow printing the grid just once per program run when using `main`, but not when using another function.

Comment: This prints a 10*n grid of asterisks. Taking extra input (the `10` in this case) is [not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1789/46076)

Comment: @ppery fixed it, thank you so much

Comment: Nope, your answer is now a [non-reusable function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4939/46076), so still not allowed.

Comment: Omg I am learning a lot from you! I will fix even this one

Comment: @ppery resetting the global variable at the end of the function requires too much unnecessary code and I just want you to notice that this so upvoted answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88695/100356 doesn't reset anything either, it requires a new run for every 10x10 block. And most probably the same thing happens in most codes here and in any codegolf question. I don't see any reason why we should use double standards.

Comment: There's no double standard here. That answer is a full program, not a function. And yes, that does mean that this answer would become valid if you changed `f()` to `main()`, at the cost of 3 bytes.

Comment: Well, I think it's an arbitrary rule to pretend that a function have to be able to reproduce the result of the challenge as many time as you want, while a program is allowed to reproduce the result just one single time. Following this rule my function is not a valid answer, while [the same function followed by a main](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z/P1tI6TUOzuqC0pFhDSQsOlDSt89TU0jR0dfM0rWu5uDLzShRyEzPzNDQVqrm4FIAAqMsawipKLSktylMwsOaq/f8fAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online") is a valid answer, even though the function would not work if called again.

Comment: Full programs are self-contained and only run once before resetting, while the concept of a function is that it can be called many times from one program and be reused. It really would be easiest to just use the main function [like so](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI0@zWls7z6agtKRYQ0kLDpQ01dSg8ta1//8DAA) for 41 bytes

Comment: I get your point. But then what about a program using a non-reusable function? Is the program valid because self-contained? Or is the program a non-valid answer because functions are supposed to be called many times? Wouldn't be easier to adopt the convention that you need to make a code that is barely enough to reproduce the result, since we are already practicing this philosophy when exploiting all sorts of *illegal* tricks, abusing the undefined behaviour?

Comment: You aren't going to get anywhere by arguing with site consensus in the comment section of this answer. Regardless of your opinion that the rule about function reusability is pointless and arbitrary, it is a rule that this site has adopted, and therefore this answer must be edited to comply with it or deleted.

Comment: All right I am going to edit the answer. But take note that this "site consensus" you are talking about consists of 34 (six years old) upvotes to someone's opinion. By the way this opinion is based on the belief that the only purpose of functions is to cut redundancies, while I remember for example enjoying making a function to print the knight moves, even if I needed it only once, at the end of the program. And anyway even if functions were supposed to always be reusable, are programs supposed to contain undefined behaviour? This is codegolf, keep your restrictions away from here please.

Comment: If you call a non-reusable function in a full program it doesn't matter since it is impossible to call that function a second time. There need to be some boundaries, otherwise you wouldn't be able to compete fairly

Comment: So programs can have non-reusable functions, you admit their legitimate existence, but for some obscure reason they are not allowed to be used as an answer. I understand that the topic is not that important so that you could follow someone's arbitrary rule without asking too many questions, but now you got some question and you shouldn't persist in error.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 11, 48 chars

Method [`String.repeat​(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))

```java
for(int i=0;i++<10;out.println("*".repeat(10)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxDoMgEIDhvU9BnKCmBGfap9Ct6XBRNEflIHg1aYzPThm6/vnye9jh5qd3wZBiZrExMI7C16xXoEX3341d0PHD9oLELs8wOjEcf7hHnEQAJNlzRlqeL1BHmWOWFQt8GItte@@MrQOdquCVZHNtdHbJAcvOKKVsOc/yAw)

---

## Java 5, 53 chars

[Static imports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import)

```java
for(int i=0;i++<100;out.print("*"+(i%10>0?"":"\n")));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxNCsIwEEDhvacIASGxGNKt8ecQdacuxlbLxCYpybQgpWePWbh9fDwLM@xt98noxhCJJQLCltmS1QC@V8030cupMJHZtAOkxK7LOD2Hgv52DtgxB@hFQxF9f3uAXPI7RIGeGJ60wao61lqbMlFjIST4jlcCt7U@6wvnB373XEpp8rrmHw)

---

## Java 3, 60 chars

Plain old Java

```java
for(int i=0;i++<100;System.out.print("*"+(i%10>0?"":"\n")));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLCoMwEADQq4SBQtJQGbdNP4ewO9vFVNsyfhIxoyDi2VNXb/MamunU1G2qOopRPdZhendcqSgkO3PgWvXEXhcysv@VLzJr@oZRsxfFV3Rs7SVHdMUS5dNnYZJs2KdoOILVfMjxhneAMzw9GGNc2rb0Bw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-F`, 19 bytes

```sh
yes **********|head
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKg6/a/MrVYQQsOajJSE1P@/wcA)

Edit: just saw this exact answer was already posted for bash :(

Comment: alt approach (22 bytes): `jot -b'**********' 10`

Answer (score 1):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/SjoerdPennings/BRASCA), <s>26 24 20</s> 17 bytes

```
l:[{$[{'*o]xllo$]
```

[Try it online!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=l%3A%5B%7B%24%5B%7B%27*o%5Dxllo%24%5D&stdin=)

### Explanation

```
l:                   - Initialize stack
  [             ]    - Do 10 times:
   {$                -   Decrement and swap
     [    ]          -   Do 10 times:
      {'*o           -     Decrement and print *
           xllo$     -   Reset and print a newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 31 bytes

```lua
print(("**********\n"):rep(10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ0kLDmLylDStilILNAwNNDX//wcA)

Not very impressive but I think simpler is shorter in this case.

Comment: can't seem to beat this :)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, <strike>26</strike> 24 bytes

```
print((10*'*'+'\n')*10)
```

Comment: I'm new to coding and even newer to competitive programming, so don't go too hard on me :D

Comment: Oh of course, multiplication has priority over addition. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v3](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 38 bytes

```
> "**********"
>> Output 1
>> Each 2 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTkFJCw6UuOzsFPxLSwpKSxQMQWzXxOQMBSMFw///AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [ConTeXt](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page) (40 bytes)

[Compile it here](https://texlive.net/run?%25!TEX%20context%0A%5Clet%7E%5Cdorecurse%5Cstarttext%7E%7B10%7D%7B%7E%7B10%7D*%5C%5C%7D) (note that the magic comment is only here for texlive.net and it's not needed in an offline compilation).

```tex
\let~\dorecurse\starttext~{10}{~{10}*\\}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - <s>40</s> <s>20</s> 23 bytes

```python
 print(("*"*10+"\n")*10) # prints a row of 10 *s then a new line, 10 times
```

This (freshly optimised) code prints an asterisk 10 times, then a newline (should be fixed now), then repeats that 10 times.

Comment: Well, a quick save would be with the asterisks, instead of `print("**********")`, try `print("*"*10)` and save 6 bytes. Online example here: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFeITNPoSgxLz1Vw9BA04pLoaAoM69EQ0lLSQvI//8fAA

Comment: You can also probably add a newline to the `"*"*10`, and then multiply that be ten as well

Comment: Fixed now - thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't define the variable `n` anywhere.

Comment: That's a new line. @pppery

Comment: Um, it doesn't work like that for me. I get `NameError: name 'n' is not defined` running this code on both [Python 2](https://tio.run/##HchBCoAgEAXQq3xsoxKk3ajFhEKNogPS6Sdr8xavPpIK76q1ZRZrjTc@ho3d1GHB3x0HWhkoJ2KA75BEPI9p4MpM69eSb@qqLw) and [Python 3](https://tio.run/##HchBCoAgEAXQq3xsoxKkdKIWEwo1ig5Ip5@szVu8@kgqvKvWllmsNd74GDZ2U4cFf3ccaGWgnIgBvkMS8TymgSszrV9Lvqmrvg)

Comment: OH - I see the issue now, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work ([Try it in Python 2](https://tio.run/##HcgxDoAgDAXQq/zgAsQBPI@LQw0kWgg0IZ6@ossbXn0kFd5Ua8ss1hpvfAw7u6nDgr87DrQyUE7EAN8hiXge08CVmdavJd/UVV8), [Try it in Python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0NJS0nL0CAmTxNIaiooK4CFixUSFYryyxXy0xQMDRS0ihVKMlLzgGJ5qeUKOZl5qTog4ZLM3NTi//8B)) [`print(("*"*10+"\n")*10)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQ0NJS0nL0EBbKSZPSRPI0Pz/HwA) would be a valid 23 byte submission.

Comment: It should work now - tested it in Python 2.7 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

## [Templates Considered Harmful](https://github.com/feresum/tmp-lang), 89 bytes

```
Ap<Fun<If<A<1>,Cat<St<42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,10>,Ap<A<0>,Sub<A<1>,T>>>,LF>>,I<10>>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nNLchJLEkt/v/fscDGrTTPxjPNxtHG0E7HObHEJrjExsRIBw8yNLDTAepztAHSwaVJEJ0hdnZ2Oj5uQMLTBqjA7v9/AA)

Pretty standard "10 stars 10 times" answer, in the form of a tail-recursive anonymous function.

```
Ap<
  Fun<
    If<A<1>,
       Cat<
         St<42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,10>,
         Ap<A<0>,
            Sub<A<1>,I<1>>>>,
       LF>>,
  I<10>
>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 31 bytes

```javascript
write(`**********
`.repeat(10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v7wosyRVI0ELDrgS9IpSC1ITSzQMDTQ1//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 37 bytes

```java
out.print("**********\n".repeat(10));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYoxDsIwDAB3XhF1SpCwytxnlA06WK2pHIgTpaYSqvr2NAPitjudxxUvfnoVDilmNYui8mh8zfBGmaH/LkoB4ke7E4tSfuJI5rb9xjXyZAKy2F4zy3wf0G2l3pCqqm3Ofx7SQKZEqPbaOteVfS8H)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 35 bytes

```clj
(dotimes[_ 10](print"**********
"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/XyMlvyQzN7U4Ol7B0CBWo6AoM69ESQsOuJQ0Nf//BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```
for _<-0..9,do: IO.puts"**********"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v8/Lb9IId5G10BPz1InJd9KwdNfr6C0pFhJCw6U/v8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## VBScript, 39 bytes

```
For i=0 to 9
WSH.Echo "**********"
next
```

## VBScript, 53 bytes

```
For i=0 to 9
WSH.Echo replace(space(10)," ","*")
next
```

The second solution is slightly more interesting......

Answer (score 1):

## [Twue](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Twue/), 31 bytes

```
a::~**********\n
::=
aaaaaaaaaa
```

[Try it on the website!](https://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Twue/?code=a%3A%3A%7E**********%5Cn%0A%3A%3A%3D%0Aaaaaaaaaaa)

Simply defines the replacement `a` which maps to printing 10 asterisks. The main body consists of 10 `a`s. Trying a secondary replacement `b::=aa` or `b::=aaaaa` both yield **33 bytes**, which is unfortunately longer.

Whereas in some Thue interpreters, outputting implicitly outputs a newline, that is not the case in Twue, which must manually insert the newline.

Answer (score 1):

## [Duocentehexaquinquagesimal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duocentehexaquinquagesimal), 18 bytes

```
hùyy₄āÆβUW:“ã¾8½ž+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFhiYxPzqGGRXbx1cWqKgm6mgrphsXWcNVDIWl0hXsHILq80x7qkqDQPqDRVQbdY11Ah3jo1OSNfQTdPQR2oLOnQMuPDW5yP7stQsrPR1tXTiY5VetSw0Evdzg6isEY/v6BEP784MSkzFUopxNslWYOFk4oSM/PSSpOzESyFpP8Zh3dWVj5qajnSeLjt3KbQcKtHDXMOLz60z@LQ3qP7tP8Dbf0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/SjoerdPennings/BRASCA), 14 bytes

```
l[ll['*o{]xo{]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt7c9s2Ev9fnwK1r5UUS7acR5P4Ird2kl7d1nHGdud643FZSIQtphTBkJBlT9p@9dwu@BBBgCIYPz3TxiaB3d8@sQCW4ZWY8ODJizD67E1DHgkSX8U9MqVi0jqL@JQIb8pI9spnLEweRzRw4Z/0Bf4F/52zVvpARHTMRnT8Z6s19mkck92IxmP6Gn/fahH4WVlZORIwoEcidu7FgkUxASrkgkYeHfkshgFyoMvOiON4gSccpxMz/6y71ZIv8GdV0pATczL5Sxy8HssBQ3Jyqj6n8GygPhopjxY8diJG5gwYUNcLzgm7YBFoDX@lMRlPKMiKfL8rM45giDPlLgO6P1A/ZgXc772QuX0vIC4VNH/snZGASxPAdGC27sVUiKtOdysfUqAPAxycDuQXMxBlp3uytdXfPFUmnfGIOD3iEGDKgtmURVSwTolUiZGBGdornvkCmapvTpBlT3taxqFaZp2GIQvcDo/cTkK4282HM9BZneTgJQut/kjRiVLjjBgLSAhGEMwlV0yU7EN9VNWVk43QbXQ88WIy93yfxIKDD1D4TUwYGYHB/2SChDz2hMeDksfNJ57PHJ/zMAain/5WKDIyRodAh0VSIUfmkUoARzjpG91Lx4lDFeWWzyHyfG8MUQK2zYUxjxA8VMVdfT@LJwQmjoCj4BKaNE8egSEMcJIB0md6OLrgLbpF8X2R@gX1Z4zws0XEICcDF3yf8sBflzJBt5GDutWCjLgQkKqA81KxnGRcnXReELNIdAbJkHoBrRDgDJV/teQLALrwYFeZnUsseJglznKiycmqYRYxMYuCgufpkZgOKQBDNknsltDUqoCHReHvAOYg09gRhDECyhaPHFPMhJM9TE2S/aniy56SIcQkXTGkK5qlyoWCEqzl2SPT7JE@u@BzReztOHVBYwBjsrspiZQQTGTsmuUeNBVXJz3qmpUySE14iOtxzIwiyzdlpyrwyUZ0c1rSW5CUz4JzMTE7bPKuTDd1NXjZWbBIKeOs0czz3WRdKE8VbBqqNQo@caCEUMoH9SWscT77OOOCKYrGdT5bmSCP8OkUFxt90cd1pLTcg4U00ttkoNcE2qj@kGwqo6S5dZzDamoVsqa4MjnQcU5WkvVTmZbOM1PPHCrTS1fHWmRw2ogB2DnCckgyUmO8qi44kXNOYVKGqH5KNhJnyenLZWiv1Cr6OJqxetMOyePlnP5obI7iMA2Egb6JPM6rp57WOB5uIQI6ZY4jSTrOlEIJ6aQ6GsnNCUha2KWkVkxeLYqulc/@ie@ftB/xT6eX8N/ndC@T5A@yizGe5A8wGmyjwiKVYgbIUg7ZByRytPxbWrzINS8EX8nMUnhTzB/RlaqLXH9FUicGsqflQEvHKLuXSmNqD1aJXJZeQarZVsu7JfE8MLhqQWvF0nOgx5bmL5v25DYtyD22J/fYgtwTe3JPLMg9tSf31ILcM3tyzyzIfWtP7lsLcs/tyT23IPfCntwLC3Iv7cm9tCDnN3Bjm7D4pQE9G89jDeLCxrhvGwSGTaC5DSLDxrxvGviyTWxMGriLjTf/2MRfbBzm50YEbSh@Wtkiq2/YOGJTFghb4tkjrKz6Nhn7b2SzF1yDzZoNmwjZyOXuUB59mvjQxQpsrgwlGJtBWNZ7WMbLc9bOqEcooDRbqEJCr9vSF2wpQLLaxxt4mlArePuP9lLHUA8@jUWmVbValkKeC9WUM2ubp91lhJSKag03LbpG9inu@0LcKvHCaXIl9jX0gx3XvWUHMLnsGrXw0z7iO5qN8Exe3APIvg3IRwhyf@YLL/Sv7gHkIxuQG0liEewcvMf1LrzYtHO7fbAbGzZov5Yq5e7M5/eA8WsbiL8jxLeXIQ@qEvUtW93K7LEMoI/RdRDqzPGKbf0MNn7przEw6NBu15Skdz0x92LWJCv9g6DfHRzfKOZ/bNT1jcyH797cgz2/scH3F@I7OLwHeH/ZwHMQ3m/3gu93wGfwviPjJl4DThF4KE@l@eKkd2dpqVA8ZQcCFuoZGbns2nMZ2XDZkVyyCww7YdQTdjtpds18dhvwsZKnh3zS0@6KQxmFQ3YsXkt4Cwm7M7xYpAKvHkI8Mq/m8KWZh15npIb63yrqxeWULfDsvsoWVTae3sAETZopSjPlF6r6MT4SIkaWyVXRFxkjwyZJWODbz/GVFC1vqtKDz3p8TXVujS@s0R8JZBdMbPaLKZ8FwnYHFyx2cINeMnXJHs7aRjdjp/c1dnpAeljuC9f0h@9kskwanNJWgkF/8/FzW7/Lu6E6sM8snyt0LQB8la9xi1vI2qRtOMtI7yltWP4LWcZzGkpDizknnmDTmPDg2sn81jP@yEK@Q2lTLrJFSkwixu5WxvGtK2J8HZUZ73M0PR6hHsc8wHUzyJUJ7pIQju/eTzDGYoEireE/1CrCzstiVDtAejePbNrt9Q/cCyS7oLtIZPnBF174Vye9MaY5SCaF1Fe40ktn15/oNVEOgrdQh5eqA8o@QYCI52HKT3Nfp286H1eE6qUpWukyUOSqFgugJJO3h@Tpi7QHFP9@NSTPnlfPU04cgcWJRIK343I6gK6Xe68o96JrLNFAZ@3O5B6oYr/8YqkBcqte7EtZ/npAJHLrS/alfqfR/q1I26awtlnUNS4z5PJr0D8ykgxsyxDZF5NEc7OTdEgGrk2e@TXFeV6Js5hTLpOccqnllFadG6jNQzctpuFMYG/jwMLRuDxqmYlwhmmF7By93ttLewLrvG7RiqA16la2I5RE0Tt8jZcR@COHdMYT9Rqo24OwdofttoWlDypFtQmC@5c2D74mQgeq0GkGfbgGLhq3gZjvqsV8qMY1GHYhsCGeX/NARNwnP/h8Xq@QV6iQX1gcQx1Nb/sGBNX3ijZKXJtmSsxG1U3bjbZRF/8B88iG77tRx/bDVcdQXul8nIFb34EihsMHq4n2/9qgiV0m5owFD2FrifrC6nKM/3u4DvQ9OtAxi6YebsxaN5MU8fsodukJm9pyFQFAPnRluy31yYfZNKxJ7FLrqNdBrT70FoRaRB8Q0U@AAqu5ORTWcZMeB7V/pp7bTzk3/ICvGbu@ym7Ngt0Jsvsvtr32Zc@s3tusqzupeb/ConfpBkvZKfU3T2ssVCVVLlSxH7u2mdYo7WlJWliSb0vW7VsV1caTXi/v6il9sWbXKXRsSTP5xk3SbKk7l@SLDilFGDF5IBPnH3fiB4RpO5TelW7ujTZ3oq8e48cgnoDS8IzMJyyALT4HxpGMKuGBTYHtGeze3Zr@6Gb9VvrXExLNAbKWPQTyXNkTLftkrjVhpeBKnQqr@/IKJfvEsfxpo1UKZJdjFgryM7sacUg82GsTRbNQlL4U0rN5OvGt/AfSNhqyJM7qEZ@y5NPQOQsEmUc8OO/hSTCfg3EIcOIq3KSUXnl7eHhwuEVM00t3r8mE/OPndUjXUyocAFc@hC@IkHwHsJc6LuFyn9FqunFYjFVCAHzMsMNYes97jaNKOlxahRgwYuibMeqbVVq3Z6sgbg7QBW2qkzWSS/Wpk1sidmOR68VtLmqlmPjz@f8)

Answer (score 1):

## [yuno (abandoned)](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno-abandoned/), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno-abandoned/wiki/Byte-count)

```
」＊１０リュ」ニュア１０リュ
```

xxd using Jelly's codepage:

```
00000000: f8f6 e6e5 5bf8 5200 e6e5 5b              ẏẇȧẓ[ẏR¡ȧẓ[
```

### Explanation

```
」＊　　　　　　　　　　　　    push "*"
　　１０　　　　　　　　　　    push 10
　　　　リュ　　　　　　　　    repeat "*" 10 times
　　　　　　」ニュ　　　　　    push "\n"
　　　　　　　　　ア　　　　    add / concatenate
　　　　　　　　　　１０　　    push 10
　　　　　　　　　　　　リュ    repeat "**********\n" 10 times
```

Equivalently written as `]*10ryu]nyua10ryu`

Answer (score 1):

## [PPL](https://ppl-docs.herokuapp.com), 33 bytes

```js
loop10{
printLine("**********")
}
```

There is no concept of repeating strings, and the `*` operator is not overloaded with strings by numbers, so I hardcoded a string of 10 asterisks and printed it 10 times using the `loop` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
Print@@@Table["*",10,10]
```

A second (simple) Mathematica proposition, same length

Answer (score 1):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 271 bytes

Generated [here (linear generator)](https://zb3.me/malbolge-tools/#generator).
I tried other methods too but it took me pretty long time so I could not wait for completion.

```
D'`_:pon}}kXyxx5R-,s0Npn9+k#(EgDU0zyba+u)]xwvunV3210/.-,+*hg`H^c\"`_AW\UyxwvutsrqpJIHMLEDCg*@E>ba`_^]\[ZY9y765.-,+O/.nmJIHGFEDCBAya}|{ts9wvunV3210/.-,+*hg`H^c\"`_AW\UyxwvutsrqpJIHMLEDCg*@E>ba`_^]\[ZY9y765.-,+O/.nmJIHGFEDCBAya}|{ts9wvunV3210/.-,+*hg`H^c\"`_AW\Uyxwvutsrqp]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/99FPSHeqiA/r7Y2O6KyosI0SFen2MCvIM9SO1tZwzXdJdSgqjIpUbtUM7aivKw0L8zYyNBAX09XR1srIz3BIy45Rikh3jE8JrQSJF1SXFRY4OXp4evj6uKcruXgapeUmBAfFxsTHRVpWWluZgrS6K@vl5cLVOTuBlTk5FiZWFtTXVJsOShMj/3/HwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Arduino, 101 bytes

```
int i=0;void setup(){Serial.begin(300);}void loop(){if(i++<10)Serial.println("**********");else i--;}
```

The `else` case is there to prevent `i` from overflowing and becoming negative, since the `loop()` function is called indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
for i in range(10):
 print("*"*10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9BA04pLoaAoM69EQ0lLSQvI//8fAA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I've edited your answer to make it a bit clearer and added a link to try it. There's a couple similar Python answers, but nice first answer!

Comment: You can save some bytes by inlining the for block, so it can be one line like `for i in range(10):print("*"*10)`

Comment: Also, make sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) to see if there are any other ways to golf your code.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 43 bytes

Outputs two trailing LFs.

```
 output =dupl(dupl('*',10) char(10),10)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/XyG/tKSgtETBNqW0IEcDTKhrqesYGmgqJGckFmkAGSAOV2peyv//AA)

Comment: I noticed replacing `dupl('*',10)` with `'**********'` results in number of bytes unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 16 bytes

```
10*("*"*10+"\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/9/QQEtDSUtJy9BAWykmT0nz//9/@QUlmfl5xf91i/IA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Aussie++](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus), 71 bytes

```
G'DAY MATE!
I RECKON x IS A WALKABOUT FROM [0TO 9]<GIMME "**********";>
```

Tested in commit 0a5de7e, in which [for loops do not behave as per the spec](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus/issues/17). The version presented here actually works in that commit.

Comment: Why is this noncompeting?

Comment: The language used was introduced years after the question was asked, and the question does not specify that newer languages are allowed.

Comment: [That rule has been obsolete since 2017](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/46076), and such answers no longer need to me marked.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I'll remove the marking then.

EDIT: It looks like you did for me.

Answer (score 1):

## [KonamiCode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/KonamiCode), 103 bytes

`v(^^^^>^^)>(^)v(^>)>(^^)v(>)>(^^^)v(>)S(^>)L(>)>(^^)v(>)L(^)>(>)<<>(^^)v((>))B(^)>(^)<<>(^^^)v((>))B(>)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 bytes

```
"*"p10)+"
")p10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/X0lLqcDQQFNbiUtJE8j4/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Hodor](https://github.com/hummingbirdtech/hodor), 240 bytes

```
hodor.hod("**********");hodor.hod("**********");hodor.hod("**********");hodor.hod("**********");hodor.hod("**********");hodor.hod("**********");hodor.hod("**********");hodor.hod("**********");hodor.hod("**********");hodor.hod("**********");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8hPyS/6/z8DROkBSQ0lLThQ0rQeruL//wMA)

I'm not good at Hodor

Answer (score 1):

## [shortC](https://github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 33 bytes

```
AOIa=0;a<=10;a++)R"**********\n"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/f0d8z0dbAOtHG1hBIamtrBilpwUFMnlLt//8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 23 bytes

Prints an extra newline at the end

```python
print(f'{"*"*10}\n'*10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI029WklLScvQoDYmTx1Iaf7/DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 23 bytes

```python
print(('*'*10+'\n')*10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0NdS13L0EBbPSZPXRPI0Pz/HwA)

(Note: new to codegolf and stackexchange in general, this is my first attempt at any code-golfing challenge)

Edit: this is a pretty generic answer, and pretty boring too, although valid and pretty short.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: @NoHaxJustRadvylf Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), 34 bytes

```kotlin
println("**********\n".repeat(10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp6FZ/b@gKDOvJCdPQ0kLDmLylPSKUgtSE0s0DA00Nf/X/gcA)

Comment: You are right, i had missread the task :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bits](https://github.com/nayakrujul/bits), 191 bits = 23.875 bytes

```js
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011100010110000011111011001111101100111110110011111011001111101100111110110011111011001111101100111110110011111011001110000011100011
```

#### Explained

- The long string of `0`s at the start is to make a string of length 10. (This is the only way to start a `for` loop in Bits)
- `11100010` starts the `for` loop:

  - `1100000` is a separator so the strings don't join together
  - `1111101100` is the code for a `*`. We repeat this 10 times to get `**********`. (Note: this is the only way to repeat a string in Bits)
  - `11100000` prints the string
- `11100011` closes the `for` loop

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [TacO](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/TacO), 25 bytes

```
0 01
1  *"*"
*###"\n"
w
@
```

### Explaination

The program is a 2D program which can be broken up as so:

```
@       ; Program Entry
w       ; Write the result of everything STDOUT concatenated together
*10     ; Repeat 10 times
  *10   ; Repeat 10 times
    "*" ; Append "*"
  "\n"  ; Append a newline
```

Or the psudocode:

```
write(repeat(10,repeat(10,"*")+"\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0lMzv//30DBwJDLUEFBS0lLiUtLWVlZKSZPiaucy@H/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 10 bytes

```
≡&p↯⊂.10@*
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=4omhJnDihq_iioIuMTBAKg==)

```
≡&p↯⊂.10@*    full program
         @*    the character literal '*'
    ⊂.10      the golfiest way to produce the dimensions of the matrix [10,10]
   ↯           reshape to get 10x10 matrix of '*'s
≡&p            print each row with newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `j`, 5 bytes

```
₅•×₀÷
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJqIiwiIiwi4oKF4oCiw5figoDDtyIsIiIsIiIsIjMuNC4wIl0=)

RIP -H flag and squarify strings which could make this 3 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 76 bytes

I don't know if this could be golfed further, but just.

```
#include <iostream>
void a(){for(int i=0;i++<10;)std::cout<<"**********\n";}
```

Comment: No, I tried that.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using puts from cstdio instead of cout (save in header name, function name, plus line terminator for free). Also one byte by making `i` global (which gets zero initialized for free).

Comment: This isn't a whole program (no main) so do you need the include?

Comment: https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09Dszotv0jDOlNb28bQwFqzoLSkWENJCw6UNK1r//8HAA Here is a version with Mat's suggestions

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (using external library - Enumerable) (41 bytes)

```
_.From("**********\n").Cycle(120).Write()
```

Link to lib: https://github.com/mvegh1/Enumerable/

Code explanation: This runs right in the console. Load the string into the library, which parses it to a char array enumerable. Create a new enumerable from that sequence, which is generated by cycling from start to finish 120 times (because the string length is 12, and we want 10 of them..12*10=120). I.e [1,2,3].Cycle(10) would be 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1. Finally, join everything into a string with "" as delimiter

[image]

Comment: OH, .length lied to me ahah...I thought it would count "\" and "n" as separate characters..fixed!

Comment: Next time use https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**C# - 88 bytes**

```
class P{static void Main(){int i=0;while(i++<10)System.Console.Write("**********\n");}}
```

Comment: You can reduce this a bit by using a `for` look, putting `int i` inside it `for(int i=10;i-->0;)` (There is never a reason to use a straight `while` loop in C# code golf, a `for` loop is never more expensive)

Comment: I know, but then I would have been copying and pasting an already existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 18 bytes

```
puts (?**10+$/)*10
```

#### Alternative version (+3 bytes)

```
10.times {puts ?**10}
```

#### Ungolfed (first version)

```
puts ('*' * 10 + '\n') * 10
```

Comment: Second part of [3aw5TZetdf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3906/3aw5tzetdf)'s [Perl tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5110) works in Ruby too.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 24 bytes

`print((("*"x10).$/)x10);`

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 2, 45 Bytes

```
func a(){for _ in 0...9{print("**********")}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Wolfram, 22 bytes

```
Grid[Table["*",10,10]]
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I can't test right now, but I don't think this is a full program (it only displays correctly when used in Mathematica's notebook front end, which constitutes a snippet by this community's standards). If you put this in a source file and call it with `wolfram -script file.m` I don't think it'll print anything.  I think the shortest way to get around that would be `Print@@@Table["*",10,10]`. Still, nice solution! :)

Comment: You are correct. Also, your solution works and is 24 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

### **R**

```
matrix(rep("*",100), nrow = 10)
```

Probably faster way in R, but fun utilization of `matrix`

**Explanation**

rep: repeats first argument as many times as second argument.

matrix: creates matrix from vector (first argument), and nrow is the number rows desired in matrix.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! However, we require all code to be golfed, which this isn't. Please golf it.

Comment: To make it print the actual desired output you would need to loop `cat` over it, one way or another. In addition, because of vector recycling, `matrix("*",nr=10,nc=10)` or `array("*",c(10,10))` would be more concise to get the same matrix as the one you generate.

Comment: You are right in all regards. This works :`for(i in 1:10){for (j in 1:10){cat("*");if(j == 10){cat("\n")}}}`

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**, 45 bytes

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {console.log('**********')}
```

even better, **ES6 Javascript**, 38 bytes

```
console.log('**********\n'.repeat(10))
```

open console and copy paste to test

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 3 (23 bytes)

```
print(('*'*10+'\n')*10)
```

Comment: 23 bytes - I believe '\n' is two bytes of code, but if you measured with `len` it will have said 22.

Answer (score 0):

## [3var](http://esolangs.org/wiki/3var), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

**1 byte thanks to Business Cat**

```
iisiia+<*>aaaF[PPPPPPPPPPO]
aaamaiis*>iiF[PPPPPPPPPPO]
```

I don't how do nested loops marked by `F`.

[Try it online!](http://3var.tryitonline.net/#code=YWFhbWFpaXMqPmlpRltQUFBQUFBQUFBQT10&input=)

Comment: [26 bytes](http://3var.tryitonline.net/#code=YWFhbWFpaXMqPmlpRltQUFBQUFBQUFBQT10&input=) `aaamaiis*>iiF[PPPPPPPPPPO]`

Comment: @BusinessCat Thanks, do you know why [this](http://3var.tryitonline.net/#code=YWFhbWFpaXMqPmlpRlsKUF0&input=) and [this](http://3var.tryitonline.net/#code=YWFhbWFpaXMqPmlpRltQXQ&input=) produce different results?

Comment: I don't know. I don't see anything in the docs about needing to put loops on a new line, though they do in their examples. Maybe it's an interpreter error?

Answer (score 0):

### Japt, 10 bytes

```
'*pA +R pA
```

Prints `*` ten times, then `\n`, then repeat from the beginning ten times.

[Demo](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=JypwQSArUiBwQQ==).

Answer (score 0):

## [Arcyóu](https://github.com/Nazek42/arcyou), 21 bytes

```
(* "**********\n" 10)
```

[Try it online!](http://arcyou.tryitonline.net/#code=KCogIioqKioqKioqKipcbiIgMTAp&input=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/new/), 31 characters

```
\A=@repeat{10;**********\n}@end
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '\A=@repeat{10;**********\n}@end'
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to anywhere?

Comment: Linkified the title, but I know about no on-line interpreter. :(

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 23 characters

```groovy
print(("*"*10+"\n")*10)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ groovy -e 'print(("*"*10+"\n")*10)'
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Answer (score 0):

### Lua, 30 bytes

Full program outputting via its return value.

```
return("**********\n"):rep(10)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a full program, just a snippet. It produces no output by its own, relies on Lua REPL's functionality.

Comment: @manatwork it is a full program, and is also outputting by itself. All lua program are encapsulated in function inside the VM, thus they can all return a value and it is a legit way of outputing

Comment: @manatwork Oh also, you just have to read [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5330/41019) to know it's legit.

Comment: Are you referring to the “... if and only if the challenge requires an integer as output, obviously.” part?

Comment: @manatwork this part only refer to the case you use an exit code, because an exit code is always an integer. I was refering to "If functions can output using their return values, it makes sense that programs should be able to do the same", which is what I've done: using the return value of my program

Comment: But that whole answer is only valid for integer return values, hence the "iff" at the very start. You cannot pick a single sentence from it and pretend the preconditions don't apply to it, therefore making your answer valid.

Comment: @Joey ok, let's add a new answer to this meta in this case.

Comment: Katenkyo: That still ignores the *fact* that programs can have only integer return values in all operating systems I know of. Things don't work that way. Case in point here, your program simply does nothing observable because returning from the main program will simply exit and physically *cannot* return the string you gave it as expression.

Answer (score 0):

## Bc, 26 characters

```
for(;i++<10;)"**********
"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ bc <<< 'for(;i++<10;)"**********
"'
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript (<del>115</del> <del>106</del> 81 chars)**

```js
o='';
for(i=0;i<10;i++){l='';for(j=0;j<10;j++){l+='*';}o+=l+"\n";}
console.log(o);
```

Comment: make the program all one line, instead of using "\n", just use a literal newline by hitting enter inside two empty quotes. that should save you 4 bytes. Also, do you need a semicolon after `l+='*'?

Answer (score 0):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp), 73 bytes

```
[FOREACH NUMB IN 1 TO 10 AS k]
{
STRG p=p+"**********"+<newline>
}
SHOW=p
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mumps, 26 Bytes.

```
F J=0:1:9 W "**********",!
```

As loops are fairly efficient (space-wise) in Mumps, I thought I'd see if the loop within a loop was shorter, but it was not; weighing in at 31 bytes:

```
F I=0:1:9{F J=0:1:9{W "*"} W !}
```

The braces are allowable loop delimiters in the InterSystems Cache version of Mumps that I use; at times they may save a byte or two golfing, but mostly they're just handy to have nested loops in a one-line routine.

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge '98, 31 bytes

```
a>:|>1++:9`#@_a,
v*'[^
>,v1
-v>
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Factor](http://factorcode.org/), 30

```
10 [ "**********"print ] times
```

So verbose...

Answer (score 0):

## [Fourier](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier), 22 bytes

```
10(10(~X42aX^~X)aN^~N)
```

[Try it on FourIDE!](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=MTAoMTAoflg0MmFYXn5YKWFOXn5OKQ)

Comment: [17](https://tio.run/##S8svLcpMLfr/39BAoy4eSCRoJcRpJsbHaf7/bwAA) :)

Answer (score 0):

### [MSM](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MSM), 19 bytes

```
.;;.;...;.;;.;..␍**
```

where `␍` is a newline.

`.` concatenates the two rightmost characters and `;` appends a copy of the rightmost element to the end, so the first commands `.;;.;...` create one line `**********␍` and the next commands `;.;;.;..` make 10 lines out of it.

Answer (score 0):

### Pip, 7 bytes

```
LtP'*Xt
```

Straightforward: Loop 10 times. Print string of 10 asterisks each time. Kinda disappointed that the simple way was the shortest...

Answer (score 0):

## **Jade & CSS, <s>41</s> 36 bytes**

```
- for (x=0;x++<10;)
  **********<br>
```

<sup>Jade is a HTML pre-processor. I'm unsure if using this is breaking any rule or if I have to include something else in the byte count. This also beats my [previous entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88871/38505) of 60 bytes.</sup>

See it on Codepen: http://codepen.io/409/pen/ZOPgdJ

Thanks to [Business Cat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53880/business-cat) for saving 5 bytes.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by doing `x++<11;` instead of `x<11;x++`. I think you can also omit the `var`. Also this makes a 10x11 grid, you need to change the 11 to 10.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the improvements @BusinessCat

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 23 characters

```
10.times{println'*'*10}
```

Comment: Please use code block markup (indent each line with 4 spaces or enclose it between `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags) for your code, so scripts like [Code Golf UserScript Enhancement Pack](http://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack) can insert the length beside the code.

Comment: @manatwork Done. I'm new here; had no idea that was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

### Bash + coreutils + X11 term - 7 keystrokes

Exact keys to hit:

- `<Alt>+1`
- `0`
- `0`
- `* (<Shift>+8)`
- `<Return>`

**Requirements:**

- Your terminal window must be exactly 10 characters wide.
- Your terminal prompt (`PS1`) should be empty.
- Your working dir must be empty.

Comment: We count submissions like this in keystrokes, not bytes. So this would be 2 more keystrokes because of alt and shift.

Answer (score 0):

### Stata, 49 bytes

```
loc i=1
wh `i'<11 {
di "**********"
loc i=`i'+1
}
```

Output

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ISOLADOS](https://github.com/daHugLenny/ISOLADOS/), 131 bytes

```
ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAADOOOS ISOLAAAAAAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAADOOOS ISOLAAAAAAAAADOS
```

---

```
ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOS    push 11
ISOLAAAAAAADOS         chr(a + 31)
ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOS     push 10
ISOLAAADOOOS           push a * b
ISOLAAAAAAAADOS        push [a]
ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOS     push 10
ISOLAAADOOOS           push a * b
ISOLAAAAAAAAADOS       join list by new lines
```

Answer (score 0):

## Racket 36 bytes

```
(for((j 10))(displayln"**********"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy 46 Bytes

```
(1..10).collect{''.center(10,'*')}.join('\n')
```

https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5102912250314752

Answer (score 0):

### [SX](https://github.com/XiKuuKy/SX), 21 bytes

```
和(0,10):我('*'*10)
```

Actually: this compiles (*technically*, it just becomes Python) directly to Python. It is the same as:

`for i in range(0,10):print('*'*10)`

Comment: The SX code is 21 bytes long, and please split your answer in multiple answers for multiple submissions

Comment: Generally is better to post solutions in different languages in different answers, so they can be upvoted / downvoted separately. For example your Ruby solution is essentially identical with [John Ramos](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58259/john-ramos)'s [Ruby answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89035/4198), so that may attract some downvotes.

Comment: 11 bytes off: `print(("*"*10+"\n")*10)`

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg, that would be duplicate of [helloworld922](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31729/helloworld922)'s [Python 3 answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88657/4198) (or if you make it Python 2, then duplicate of [shooqie](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51530/shooqie)'s [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88658/4198)).

Comment: I'm so sorry. I didn't even read any of the answers. I just answered. I'll delete my answers for Python and Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

### Prolog (SWIPl), 64 / 69 bytes *(depending on how to count)*

```
-1*_.
A*0:-writeln(*),C is A-1,C*9.
A*B:-write(*),C is B-1, A*C.
```

Query with

```
9*9.
```

#### Online Example

[Try it online](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/PCG%3AAsterisks.pl), but take note that since `writeln/1` has a bug in Swish, causing it to print a new line *before* as well as after. I've replaced it with `write/1,nl/0` which should be (according to documentation) its equivalent. This raised the byte count of the example.

#### On the Byte Count

I'm not sure how to count the query, but if it *is* to be counted towards the total byte count, it's 5 bytes (including an <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

### [D2](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/d2), 11 bytes

```
!7;//.|a:|a
```

Explanation:

`!7` is expanded to 7 `+`, so it set the current cell to 7.
`;` switch to the second shift state (7 is `*`)
`/code|digit` repeat `code` `digit` times (`digit` is base 36).
`.` print the character in the current shift state (so here, `*` is printed).
`:` print a newline in shift mode 2.

Answer (score 0):

## Crystal, 21 bytes

```
puts ("*"*10+"\n")*10
```

How does it work?

```
"*" * 10            = "**********" 
"**********" + "\n" = "**********\n"
"**********\n" * 10 = "**********\n**********\n[...]"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Stuck, 10 Bytes

Very simple implementation here, no tricks ;)

```
'*10*N+10*
```

Explanation:

```
'*           # Enter char mode, puts '*' on the stack
  10*        # Multiply string by 10, puts '**********' on the stack
     N+      # Push a newline to the stack and append to the asterisks
       10*   # Multiply that string by 10 and implicitly print.
```

Answer (score 0):

### [memes](http://github.com/ineternet/memes), 17 bytes

```
d5+5’{p
```

Needs `**********` as input, therefore +10.

```
d      Don't print result
5+5    10 times
’      loop
{p     Print input
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++ <strike>83 bytes</strike> 82 Thanks to [matthew roh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64499/matthew-roh)!

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){for(int i;i++<10;){std::cout<<"**********"<<"\n";}}
```

[Try Me Online!](http://cpp.sh/2sy7z)

Comment: Maybe i++<10 would help?

Comment: Unfortunately It seems to returns an invalid syntax error :\

Comment: Hm? It works for me.

Comment: Amateur Mistake... As the last argument in a for statement I didn't expect `;` was required etc. `for(int i;i<10;i++)` returns an error _expected ')' before ';'_ when written as `for(int i;i<10;i++;)`

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 28 bytes

```
( "*" 10 s:* . cr ) 10 times
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 23 bytes

```
print(("*"*10+"\n")*10)
```

Almost the same as python solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 22 bytes

```
print"**********\n"x10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QC](http://github.com/0xqookie/qc) 41 bytes

`&FF002A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A0D0AFF##########`

```
&FF00 Write hex to memory at address 00 until FF is reached
2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A2A0D0AFF 10 asterisks with a new line and the terminator at the end
########## Print contents of memory 10 times until first 00 is reached
```

Could be made shorter if loops were used.

Answer (score 0):

## Z80 TI-83+, 53 bytes

```
.nolist
#include "ti83plus.inc"
#define    ProgStart    $9D95

.list
.org    ProgStart - 2
    .db    t2ByteTok, tAsmCmp
    bcall(_homeup)
    ld A, 0
    ld (PenCol), A
Do:
    inc A
    ld hl, msg
    bcall(_PutS)
    bcall(_NewLine)
    cp 10
    jr NZ, Do
    ret
msg:
    .db "**********", 0
.end
.end
```

Compiled with SPASM.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
Ao@'*pAÃ·
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@@@Y76CuVeB4uPnQ9v//AQ)

Non-competitive solutions using the new flag features in Japt:

[`-R` flag](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=QW9AJypwQQ==&input=LVI=).

[`-x` flag](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=UisnKnBBKXBB&input=LXg=).

[`-Sx` flags](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=QW9AUisnKnBB&input=LVN4).

[`-P` flag](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=QW9AJypwQSArUg==&input=LVA=).

Answer (score 0):

## [Syms](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Syms), 24 bytes

```
{*}10;*[[[[[[[[[{~>[)}[)
```

The interpreter as provided errors immediately, but changing line 2 to `if True:` fixes it. (Is this allowed? [Seems like it.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11687/old-languages-with-new-implementations))

Explanation:

```
{*}10;*[[[[[[[[[{~>[)}[)
{*}                       Add '*' to the stack.
   10;*                   Repeat it 10 times.
       [[[[[[[[[          Duplicate 9 times (there are now 10 copies on the stack)
                {~>[)}    Swap, output, duplicate, run (prints element below tos (top of stack) and then executes tos, stack is now (copies, this))
                      [)  Duplicate and run (causes infinite loop, exits when '*'*10 copies run out)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), 41 bytes

```
%++=tt*=>"*******" v
        ^~?-~,"***"<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cardinal#@6@qrW1bUqJla6ekBQFKCmVcClAQV2evW6cDklGy@f8fAA)

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##S04sSsnMS8z5/79MSQsMlGy0OTVVuezAXCVr3dD//wE "Cardinal – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 (35 bytes)

```
for x in range(1,11):print("*"*10)
```

Comment: `range(10)` works.

Answer (score 0):

## [OIL](https://github.com/L3viathan/OIL), <s>55</s> <s>44</s> 41 bytes, noncompeting

Annotated here for better understanding; remove everything after each `‌#` in each line to make it work.

```
**********# asterisk storage
10#if what's in
14#line 14 (marked with $)
1#is identical to 10 (line 1)
13#jump to line 13 (marked with &)
6#else to line 6; the next line
4#print what's in line 0; 10 asterisks

11#print a newline
8#increment line 14 (marked with $)
14
6#jump to the beginning (line '' == line 0)

3#exit &
0#counter $
```

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 8 bytes, Noncompeting

*Noncompeting because Language Postdates challenge*

```
°{°`**}*
```

I decided to take another stab at this, with a much better version of RProgN.

### Explained

```
°{°`**}*
°      *    # Run the contained function Ten (Which ° is a constant for) times.
 {°  *}     # Repeat the referenced string 10 times.
   `*       # Asterisk Literal.
            # This results in 10 strings of 10 `*`s on the stack, which prints as expected.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn-2#@39oQ/WhDQlaWrVa//8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## OCTAVE, 36 bytes

```
strrep(num2str(ones(10,10)),"1","*")
```

Makes a 10 by 10 matrix of ones, converts these to strings and then changes the ones to *'s.

Answer (score 0):

## [Syms 1.4](https://github.com/CatsAreFluffy/syms), 12 bytes (noncompeting)

```
$
$*10*+10*>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MLf7/X4VLRcvQQEsbiO3@/wcA)

Answer (score 0):

**C#, 96 bytes**

```
static class P{static void Main(){for(int i=1;i<11;i++)System.Console.WriteLine("**********");}}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Sy7Wzc3Py///v7gksSQzWSE5J7G4WCGgGsoty89MUfBNzMzT0KxOyy/SyMwrUci0NbTOtDEEEtramsGVxSWpuXrO@XnF@TmpeuFFmSWpPpl5qRpKWnCgpGldW/v/PwA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Firstly, you should specify the language and byte count; secondly, this isn't a full program or function, so doesn't meet the standard requirements; thirdly, you can save a bunch of bytes by removing unnecessary whitespace and changing the comparison symbol, like so: `for(int i=1;i<11;i++)Console.WriteLine("**********\n");`

Comment: If this is C#, read [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11927/55508) to learn what your answer should be like. Also, have a look at the other answers to see what the standard format is (header with language name and bytecount, then code...).

Answer (score 0):

## [Micro](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Micro), 15 bytes

```
"*"10*10c+10*:/
```

Comment: incidentally, the ascii code for newline is 10, so: 10c

Answer (score 0):

## k, 12 bytes

```
`0:10 10#"*"
```

[Try it online.](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%600%3A10%2010%23%22%2a%22%3B)

Explanation:

```
   10 10#"*" /make 10 by 10 matrix of asterisk characters
`0:          /output each row as a line
```

Answer (score 0):

## 4, 56 bytes

*4, 5, 6!*

```
3.600426011060310604018016021080250010202049503101010494
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcnBDYAwDATBikB7zsVK2kGiAR60b7BG2s@6apwJjkQiGR2jhZIQi5gg4uc9@zdvV9Xx3s/1AQ)

For explanation see verbose mode in the tio link - quite straightforward initialization of cells and nested 10x10 loop.

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
LL **∙
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=TEwlMjAqKiV1MjIxOQ__)

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 22 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that takes no input and outputs a 10 x 10 grid of `*`s  to the calling worksheet cell.

```gs
=REPT("**********
",10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>56</s> 50 bytes

```
O	OUTPUT =DUPL('*',10)
	X =LT(X,9) X + 1 :S(O)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/35/TPzQkIDREwdYlNMBHQ11LXcfQQJOLM0LB1idEI0LHUlMhQkFbwVDBKljDX5PL1c/l/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [ABCR](https://github.com/Steven-Hewitt/ABCR), 36 bytes

```
)))))))BAAAAA4*xAb)))B(7OOOOOOOOOOP(x
```

Pushes 42 (the character code for `*`) to queue A, 10 (`\n`) to B, and then for each value from 9 to 0 print out ten copies of A as a character and one copy of B.

Answer (score 0):

## [Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 68 bytes

```
Count i while i-10 {
	Count v while v-10 {
		Write 42
	}
	Write 10
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/985vzSvRCFToTwjMydVIVPX0EChmosTIloGFS2DinKGF2WWpCqYGHFx1nJBOYYGXLX//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 41 bytes

```
[1-d0!>C]sR[42Pd10%0=NlRx]sC[10P]sN100lRx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z/aUDfFQNHOObY4KNrEKCDF0EDVwNYvJ6gittg52tAgILbYz9DAAMj//x8A)

I know there's dc answer, just wanna do it without dumping stack)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <del>43 34 31</del> 28 bytes

```
for i in[1]*10:print(10*'*')
```

Saved 9 bytes thanks to Simon

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard

Just sprints ten asterisks and in a loop.

Comment: There is no need to print `\n` since each print starts with a new line. Also you can shorten `10*'*'`. If you swap to Python 2, you can save another byte by removing a bracket. [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9BA06qgKDOvRMHQQEtdS/3/fwA)

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9BA06qgKDOvRF1LXcvQ4P9/AA)

Comment: You can use something other than a range for example `[1]*10`

Comment: If you do `[1]*10` you don't need the space after `in`.

Answer (score 0):

## FALSE, <s>34</s> <s>33</s> <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
11[1-$]["**********
"]#
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 44 bytes

```
a000b0-9 42 0+1*0b=+-10*0-9 10 1+1*1a=+-10*1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83PTc1N/P8/0cDAIMlA11LBxEjBQNtQyyDJVlvX0EALJGRooGAIFDJMhAgZ/v8PAA)

### Explanation

```
                                                                     #  b = 0
a   0        #  label a0: jump past label a0 (no-op)                 #  do {
0   0        #            [0] = 0                                    #    a = 0
b   0        #  label b0: jump past label b0 (no-op)                 #    do {
-9  42       #            output chr 42                              #      print '*'
0   +1*0     #            [0] = 1 + [0]                              #      a += 1
b   =+-10*0  #  label b1: jump past label b((1 + !!([0] - 10)) % 2)  #    } while (a - 10 != 0)
-9  10       #            output chr 10                              #    print '\n'
1   +1*1     #            [1] = 1 + [1]                              #    b += 1
a   =+-10*1  #  label a1: jump past label a((1 + !!([1] - 10)) % 2)  #  } while (b - 10 != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Micrsocript II](https://github.com/SuperJedi224/Microscript-II), 13 bytes

```
{"*"s10*P}s9*
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 91 bytes

```
[S S S T    T   S S T   S S N
_Push_100][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   T   S N
_If_negative_Jump_to_Label_EXIT][S S S T    S T S T S N
_Push_42_*][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][T S T T   _Modulo][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_NEWLINE][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_NEWLINE][S S S T  S T S N
_Push_10][T N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PYxRCoBACAW/35ziXS2WhfoLWuj4phYhI47yvPdjzevcxoywLSU2JKW0Y6R30YVqLj7NXLWMUVHxX/oRRDw) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer i = 100
Start LOOP:
  i = i - 1
  If(i < 0)
    Exit program
  Print "*"
  If(i modulo-10 == 0)
    Print new-line
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charm](https://github.com/Aearnus/charm), 50 bytes

```
f := 10 repeat i
[ [ " * " pstring ] f newline ] f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILMr9/z9NwcpWwdBAoSi1IDWxRCGTK1ohWkFJQQuIC4pLijLz0hViFdIU8lLLczLzUkHs//8B)

Funnily enough, this doesn't use loops at all, just repeated code.

Answer (score 0):

## C, gcc 36 bytes

recursive solution. One downside is you need to pass 2 when you call the function to get 10 rows.
`f(a){a<puts("**********")?f(a+1):0;}`

This alternative addresses that issue and you don't have to call the function from main since main is now the recursive function:

`main(a){a<puts("**********")-1?main(a+1):0;}`

gcc also resolves #include "stdio.h" missing and variable a is implicitly set to an int and initialized to 0.

Comment: You're not supposed to take input, I believe.

Comment: The second one addresses that. The second one is the entire .c file and takes no arguments when you run the executable.

Comment: I see. You need to make that clear then(put the correct code in a code block under the header).

Comment: The solution you have at the top is an entirely invalid solution, so chuck it and just leave the valid one.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@n5uYmaeRqFmdpqFpXfs/DcRMtCkoLSnWUNKCAyVNe6CMtqGmlQFQ0X8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, <strike>60</strike> 45 Bytes

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSopEgDSMYXpRakJpZoJCUWp8Yn5@eVpRaVaCgZZpcq6Rib6Rhp6hgaaOpEK3Ep6ShpKcVqWv//DwA) (original answer)

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSopEgDSMYXpRakJpZoGMKBgY6hgSYQ6yhpxeQpaVr//w8A) (saved 15 Bytes thanks to @Titus)

**Code (Original)**

```
<?=strtr(str_repeat(base_convert("1ku",36,2),10),["
","*"]);
```

**Code (Titus suggestions)**

```
<?=strtr(str_repeat(11111111110,10),10,"*\n");
```

**About the edit**

The change is, using `str_repeat(base_convert("1ku",36,10),10)` actually uses more bytes than `str_repeat(11111111110,10)` and the use of string for replacements on `strtr` instead of an array.

**Explanation, Why `"1ku"`?`**

The solution is repeat the string `"**********"`, lets take the base 2 number `11111111110`

```
base 10 = 2046
base  2 = 11111111110
base 36 = 1ku
```

Basically is repeat a compressed string, and with **`strtr`** replace each 1 with a `"*"` and 0 with a `\n`

Comment: Why don´t You just take a string with the bits instead of the packed number, and use strings instead of array for translation? 45 bytes: `<?=strtr(str_repeat(11111111110,10),10,"*\n");` (`decbin(2046)` is one byte longer than that.) Nice idea though.

Comment: (and while you´re at it, you can fix `**strtr**` to **`strtr`** ;-)

Comment: I just realize that yeah, it's less bytes by using `11111111110` instead of base_convert("1ku", 36,10), i was trully focused on compress the string rather than check the byte count, gonna edit the answer, ty @Titus

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>62</s> <s>59</s> <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```
t.
b:-between(0,9,_).
?-b,(b,write(*),1=0;t),nl,1=0;t.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/v0SPK8lKNym1pDw1NU/DQMdSJ15Tj8teN0lHI0mnvCizJFVDS1PH0NbAukRTJy8HwtL7/x8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 31 bytes

```
for(i=1,10,print("**********"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/Py2/SCPT1lDH0ECnoCgzr0RDSQsOlDQ1//8HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
print(*['*'*10]*10,sep='\n')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQytaXUtdy9AgFoh1ilMLbNVj8tQ1//8HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 21 bytes

```python
exec'print"*"*10;'*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P7UiNVm9oCgzr0RJS0nL0MBaHUj8/w8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Glee](https://withglee.com/Frames/GFMain.htm), 17 bytes

```
('*'%%10\)%%10,,\
```

Explanation:

```
('*'                          create '*'
    %%10                      reshape to length 10
        \)                    monadic segment with CRLF
          %%10                reshape to sequence length 10
              ,,\             expose with LF separators
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), <s>21</s> 18 bytes

```
~oK:k9*'N@k=11:+1~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/78u39sq21JL3c8h29bQ0ErbsO7/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 12 bytes

```
@('*'*10)*10
```

### Explanation

```
  '*'*10      create a string with 10 '*'
@('*'*10)     create an array with one element of string with 10 '*'
@('*'*10)*10  repeat elements of this array 10 times
```

Comment: There is [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/88709/80745) from [AdmBorkBork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42963/admborkbork).

Answer (score 0):

## [ESOPUNK](http://esolangs.org/wiki/ESOPUNK), <s>167</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

```
MARK L
@REP 10
COPY 42 #STDO
@END
COPY 10 #STDO
TEST X = 9
ADDI X 1 X
FJMP L
```

I haven't been bothered to implement the preprocessor, but this *should* work when I do.

Comment: would it be possible to do an inner repetition? i.e. `@REP 10 / @REP 10 / COPY 42 #STDO / @END / COPY 10 #STDO / @END`

Comment: (also, does this language exist online anywhere?)

Comment: @ETHproductions  Nesting `@rep` is explicitly not allowed in the game's docs. Link added in header.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 23 bytes

```julia
print(("*"^10*"\n")^10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69EQ0NJSynO0EBLKSZPSRPI0Pz/HwA)

Comment: You can change the `\n` for a literal newline

Answer (score 0):

## [A0A0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A0A0), 145 bytes

```
A0A0
A0C3G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1G1A0
A0P42P42P42P42P42P42P42P42P42P42G3P10A0
A0A1G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3G-3A0
G-3
G-2G-2G-2G-2G-2G-2G-2G-2G-2
```

The top five lines are for the loop construction. A0A0 deletes instructions whenever it runs them, so those lines ensure that the loop keeps running. On line 3 are ten P42 instructions which print `*` (42 is the ascii code for an asterisk). The P10 instruction prints a new line.

The bottom line acts as a counter. For every execution of the loop it jumps to there and then jumps back to the loop. This consumes an instruction on that line. There are exactly nine instructions, so when it tries to go there when it has already printed ten lines the program will halt execution (since an empty line swill stop execution in A0A0).

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 57 bytes

```pascal
var i:word;begin for i:=0to 9do writeln('**********')end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/vyyxSCHTqjy/KMU6KTU9M08hLR8kYGtQkq9gmZKvUF6UWZKak6ehrgUH6pqpeSl6//8DAA)

This is probably the best one as I don't see how this can be improved in 9 characters or less which could be gained by removing `*`s.

Answer (score 0):

## [Assembly (NASM, 32-bit, Linux)](https://www.nasm.us/), 122 bytes

```
mov ecx,10
n:push 0xa202a2a
push '****'
push '****'
loop n
mov edx,120
mov ecx,esp
mov ebx,1
mov eax,4
int 128
add esp,120
```

[Try it Online!](https://jdoodle.com/a/2s1A)

Comment: If you're scoring by assembler code and not machine code, [use some NASM magic](https://tio.run/##PYzBDsIgEETvfMWeDU0K9WD6K2rsQqFpstCkSwz@vNiA@i7zZg6DzC4YenUROZSrWRPDoO/Fj2F7gpuzVKoX1W2WoZk51maY5VmsMYHSF7G7JMKY1uAYVA@zmU5/bnEqC20GCR6ccE@ixSjgwCIR@Kq/W1C1fr/L23rChUvniyM/6A8)

Comment: @EasyasPi I try to make it portable

Answer (score 0):

#### x86_16 machine code - 37 bytes

```
B4 0E            MOV AH, 0EH
B9 000A          MOV CX, 10
8B D1            MOV DX, CX
8B D9            MOV BX, CX

             .LOOP:
B0 2A            MOV AL, "*"
CD 10            INT 10H
E3 02            JCXZ .NEWLINE
E2 F8            LOOP .LOOP

             .NEWLINE:
B0 0A            MOV AL, 10
CD 10            INT 10H
B0 0D            MOV AL, 13
CD 10            INT 10H

8B CB            MOV CX, BX
4A               DEC DX
74 02            JZ .EXIT
75 E9            JNZ .LOOP

             .EXIT:
B8 004C          MOV AX, 4C00H
CD 21            INT 21H
```

Running using DOSBox :

[image: 10-GRID Screenshoot]

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 46 bytes

```
$->System.out.print("**********\n".repeat(10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYw/C8IwFMT3fopHcWgKDTpXXZydCi7qENNYUvOP5KUg0s8eI5X@luPd3buRTawZ@1eS2lmPMOabRpSKPqPhKK2hdVu4@FCSA1csBDgzaeBTQObvB2SYZbKyB53TqkMvzXC9A/NDIEv3x8maELXw@0uuHoEf0qY5du@AQlMbkbr8hlVZr9xMSb1wgmG12xKS2nWKU8a5cFiZqBRZ/LmY0xc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 54 bytes

```swift
for _ in 0...9 {print(String(repeating:"*",count:10))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/Lb9IIV4hM0/BQE9Pz1KhuqAoM69EI7gESKVrFKUWpCaWAFlWSlpKOsn5pXklVoYGmpq1//8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

### X86-64/Linux Machine Code, 32 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNfa9swEH@2P8VBFtJmSeqMMcYgD6HLIFDWh6ashUGQ7LOtTpaMJMfJPvy8k@UuC5tffOc73e/PycxarLg8zYs07bqbKdzqqkLlQDcONk/b3f72brP@evcMToNlB4T3wE8O7QKmN/Eow1wovGiM42hRSM2ZjPbWMeMod3h0ccg@xRGhbFWqK6EKMFgI69BYYAbhJxq9AD@573q0CHQo/QG5NhRpwwoM9ahubBmNja0p1LWPRBxLresAMJlOQCivoiYhvMlzNMPJSh949CY5vmMzuPLnrgPaF2GsA6MblUGLUHqxD88Pe4Msg7cgURWuhATaUqQlCAtI3iknmJSnOAIABkrXA4g92ZQK/eC1tU0vVmnY3gMao80M/Nir5BpaISUlrjEKkr/E8x5DKBEQIJmB1eBK@thqNXHgxXqNQwvk1OZK4l@UA4kMUx6NeRlHL0Xk2@OzehJPFQ9EMaxWMPmuJouzQVT8Y0/YWEAJ/gQanjnHoJvYsYpiWiTXB/yPDd7L1giHF3tYEg82NOw@3z/uzlUZjZEdqY6Z6BuWc3/1gDmCdKL6d1Amg3frnK4ULBMQ/n0m2@/UikJhBkTS5FK3wxCWZb0vqfeF@LwoGywbiZxu@eUV9xibo3AXBD4kg5RX0SNUmci77leaS1bYbq60dZkU3Ec0kzXSUTYU6N/IhUTKKHYipXc3/yZn8x23dpUcPybh@Q0)

**Usage:**

```
$> gcc -s -static -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -Wl,--build-id=none print.S -o print
$> ./print
```

**Notes:**

- Size is measured in machine code (i.e 32 bytes of PROGBITS; .text, .data, etc...)
- -4 more bytes without `EXIT_CLEANLY` (it will segfault to exit).

````
/* Comment out EXIT_CLEANLY to save 4 bytes. */
#define EXIT_CLEANLY

    .global _start
    .text
_start:
    /* Incoming registers are zero.  */

    /* Use stack for storage.  */
    push    %rsp
    pop %rsi

loop:
    /* '*' in output buffer.  */
    movb    $0x2a, (%rsi)

    /* First round we have SYS_read + length 0 which is essentially
       a nop.  */
    syscall
    /* Assuming no IO error, read(0) will return 0.  */

    /* bh is initially 0, so this won't loop in initial fallthrough.  */
    decb    %bh
    jg  loop

    movb    $0xa, %bh   /* 0xa == '\n'. */
    movb    %bh, (%rsi)
    /* Initial round this will be a nop, same as above.  */
    syscall
    /* SYS_write.  */
    movb    $1, %al
    /* STDOUT.  */
    movl    %eax, %edi
    /* 1-byte at a time.  */
    movb    $1, %dl

    /* After 10 iter this will have signed overflow.  */
    addb    $0xc, %bl
    jns loop
#ifdef EXIT_CLEANLY
    /* Exit.  */
    movb    $60, %al
    syscall
#endif
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [morsecco](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26119/72726): 109  bytes

The shortest way seems to be to define a new command repeating a given string a given times:

```
.  . .- .- --.. .. - -. - . -. -.-. . ..  . -. .-- . -.-.-. -.- - . -.-. -. . -.-. -.- - -.-. . . -.-. -. ---
```

The command itself is only 37 bytes:

- `. .- .-` to decrement the number (`E`nter minus 1 and `A`dd)
- `--.. ..` to `Z`eroskip to the `..`, leaving the input string
- `- -. - .` we need some stack juggling to duplicate the next of stack (over and swap)
- `-.` is the recursive call with the decremented number
- `-.-. .` `C`oncatenates the returned string from the command to itself
- `..` is currently not used, so it can currently be used as a skip target. This may fail in future versions of morsecco

Unfortunately, the surrounding code is twice as long:

- `. -. .--` `W`rites the code to address `-.`
- `. -.-.-. -.- -` `E`nter 42 and `K`onvert to `T`ext
- `. -.-. -.` `E`nter 10 and call the new command
- `. -.-. -.- - -.-. .` add the newline to the string; expensive, but necessary
- `. -.-. -. ---` call the new command again with 10 and `O`utput

Fun fact: this is the length of the challenge output (100 stars plus 9 newlines). Always keep in mind that morsecco wastes a factor 5 of bytes by restricting itself to only three symbols. With 22 real information bytes, it could compete.

Answer (score 0):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```
ke#ä/DCSűWîUµŻ­­SHYSHY|ąĺÔ+ž]
```

<sup>due to lack of unicode representations for c1 control characters, they have been replaced by their superscripted abbreviations</sup>

Decompressed:

```
5Y$>!>!{+{J[->[->.<]!.<]
```

```
5Y$>!>!{+{J[->[->.<]!.<]
5Y                       set cell 1 to 80 (5*16) and flip the bit order setting it to 10
  $>!>!                  copy cell 1 to storage and set cells 2 and 3 to storage
       {+{               left-shift, increment, and left-shift again cell 3, setting it to 42
          J[           ] go to cell 1 and begin a while loop
            ->[    ]     decrement cell 1 and go to cell 2 to begin another while loop
               ->.<      decrement cell 2 and print cell 3 (42 is *)
                    !.<  set cell 2 to storage and print it (10 is new line)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang), 26 bytes

```
=l$10»=f$42»;f,10ſl;f,10<
```

Answer (score -3):

## HTML, 136 bytes

```
**********<br>**********<br>**********<br>**********<br>**********<br>**********<br>**********<br>**********<br>**********<br>**********
```

Comment: You can use `<pre>`

Comment: I can use <p> too

Comment: This answer is valid and allowed, but it's also extremely boring and unimaginative.

Comment: Ok, Can I post it in Markdown?

Comment: You can easily get this to 114 bytes with `<pre>` followed by the 109-byte text...

Comment: I was hoping to join in on this one but unfortunately do not have the reputation for here yet. I'm not sure if this is an applicable method, but using html/emmet you can get this down to 20 bytes. `({**********}+br)*10`

Alternatively `p{**********}*10` is 16 bytes. New user to this site, so I'm unsure if the tab character counts.