# Print 0 to 100 without 1-9 characters

Tags: code-golf, number, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source

Print integers 0 to 100 (inclusive) without using characters `123456789` in your code.

Separator of numbers can be comma or [white space](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_442) (by default <blank>, <horizontal tabulator>, <newline>, <carriage return>, <form feed> or <vertical tabulator>).

Shortest code wins.

Comment: Many tricks are made possible by allowing `0`. Which is what makes this challenge interesting, IMO.

Comment: I thought "do X without Y" questions weren't allowed anymore.

Comment: @PurpleP They're allowed, but discouraged. Interesting ones are fine.

Comment: Is there a requirement to stop printing at 100?

Comment: Can we do it in reverse order?

Comment: Can I use non-ASCII encoding?

Comment: Could you please specify the difference between a “snippet” and a “function” especially in regard to J, or point me to the rule that prohibits the former? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 141, accepted):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 9 bytes

```r
F:volcano
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/382qLD8nOTEv//9/AA)

The sequence operator `:` coerces its arguments to integers. `F` is the boolean `FALSE`, which gets coerced to `0`. `volcano` is one of the many built-in datasets (it gives topographic information about Maunga Whau in New Zealand); since it is a matrix, `:` fetches the value at position `[1, 1]` which is luckily equal to `100`. The code is therefore equivalent to `0:100`.

This answer was inspired by a conversation with Giuseppe and Kirill L. in the comments under [Giuseppe's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219592/86301).

Comment: I thought Mathematica had weird builtins. Why is `volcano` specifically about Maunga Whau in New Zealand?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing This dataset was digitized by Ross Ihaka, a New Zealand statistician and one of the creators of R, who then included it in R as a good example for a contour map. I don't know why he chose that volcano; maybe he lived nearby, or maybe that was just the first map he found!

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The number of built-ins in R is still way lower than in Mathematica, [of course!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71680/86301)

Comment: One more golf you might be able to do: `a:b` will create the vector `c(a,a+1,a+2,...,a+k)` where `a+k<=b`, so `0:2.5` will yield `0 1 2`. Hence if you can find a short-named dataset that starts with/easily computes to `100.x` then you can potentially get a shorter answer.

Comment: I'd search it myself, but TIO (for some reason) only returns `morley` as being in the `datasets` package.

Comment: @Giuseppe I tried that, but `volcano` is the only dataset whose first entry is in \$[100, 101)\$. Using anything else than the first entry leads to at least 9 bytes, even for a dataset with a 3-character name (e.g.  `sum(BOD)` or `npk[pi]`, which don't give 100 anyway). I don't think it can get shorter using this approach.

Comment: Not that it'd change your byte-count, but you could've just used 0 - the rules only say 1-9 are forbidden...

Comment: Just impressed by the beauty of this answer!

Answer (score 36):

## Python 3: <strike>27</strike> <strike>23</strike> 20 Bytes

*Thanks to caird coinheringaahing for -4 bytes, ovs for -3 bytes*

```
print(*range(*b'e'))
```

I'm pretty poor at golfing, so there's probably a better way to do this.

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ6soMS89VUMrST1VXVPz/38A)

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ6soMS89VSO/KEVDPVVdU1Pz/38A)

Comment: Hey @DonThousand, I accidentally downvoted your submission, my bad, i was upvoting, but it was a misclick, i have fixed my mistake, sorry again.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I didn't realize that print handles multiple arguments, interesting!

Comment: You can replace `ord('e')` with `*b'e'` for -3 bytes.

Comment: @ovs How does that work?

Comment: Strings with a leading `b` are objects of type [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), which behave like lists of integers in many ways. This is doing the same as `range(*[101])`.

Comment: Byte strings have special iteration built-in to them. This code snippet should help clarify: `for char in b'hello':
 print(char)`

Comment: If it doesn't need to be "printed", only generated/returned, this can be reduced to: `[*range(*b'e')]` -5 bytes; total 15 Bytes. returns the list `[1, 2, ..., 100]`. _"Seperator of numbers can be comma, whitespace or newline."_ doesn't say anything about using more than one separator or what the bounding characters around/outside the result can be :P

Comment: Would this work in python2? Then you'd have minus 1 byte by leaving out the () for print.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Doesn't work.

Comment: @aneroid OP says to print, not generate/return. I would have removed print if it was allowed.

Comment: @aneroid - that would be a snippet rather than a function or program, so would need to be `lambda:[*range(*b'e')]` to comply with site defaults, making it longer than the full program `print(*range(*b'e'))`.

Comment: @DonThousand Actually, you can't remove the `print` because on its own `*range(*b'e')` is a SyntaxError, it would need the list comprehension brackets (or something else). But ok, OP said "print".

Comment: @JonathanAllan Too bad it doesn't count then, because it works fine in Python REPL.

Comment: @aneroid Obviously you can't just remove the print, I didn't literally mean just delete the print lol. And yea, code snippets are not allowed, code must a program or a function.

Comment: @DonThousand Got it, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 21):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 138 bytes

```
>>++++++++++<<++++++[>>>++++++++<<<-]++++++[>>>>++++++++<<<<-]++++++++++>++++++++++<[>[>>.>.+<<.<-]++++++++++>>>----------<+<<<-]>>>>+.-..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fzk4bDmxsIHS0HULUxsZGNxYhjCwOlwABZGOi7YBK9ez0gIr0UBXZ2enCgQ3EbLCherp6ev//AwA)

No numbers is pretty easy, but the golf size is not great... :)

I am sure it can be improved, I am really a beginner in using Brainfuck. I wanted to try it anyway.

**How it works:**

```
>>++++++++++<<                LF Char (idx2)
++++++[>>>++++++++<<<-]       Zero char tens (idx3)
++++++[>>>>++++++++<<<<-]     Zero char unit (idx4)
+++++ +++++                   10 counter (tens)
>+++++ +++++<                 10 counter (unit)
[>                            Move to the counter
  [>>.                        Print the tens
    >.+                       Print the unit and increment
     <<.                      Print the LF
       <-]                    Loop 10 times
+++++ +++++                   Restore the counter
>>>----- -----                Restore the digit
  <+                          Increment the tens char
    <<<-]                     Loop everything 10 times
>>>>+.-..                     Print 100 using a cell which is already at char 0
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 19):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 28 bytes

We cannot write \$100\$ or \$101\$ in hexadecimal with 0's and letters only (**0x64** and **0x65** respectively), but we can write \$202\$ (**0xCA**) and use \$2n<202\$ as the condition of the `for` loop.

```javascript
for(n=0;n+n<0xCA;)print(n++)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPP1sA6TzvPxqDC2dFas6AoM69EI09bW/P/fwA)

---

#### 30 bytes

This version computes \$10^2\$ with the hexadecimal representation of \$10\$.

```javascript
for(n=0;n<=0xA*0xA;)print(n++)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPP1sA6z8bWoMJRC4itNQuKMvNKNPK0tTX//wcA)

---

#### 31 bytes

This version builds the string `"100"`.

```javascript
for(n=0;n<=-~0+'00';)print(n++)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPP1sA6z8ZWt85AW93AQN1as6AoM69EI09bW/P/fwA)

Comment: The last one could be 1 byte shorter as`for(n=0;n<=0xA+'0';)print(n++)`.

Answer (score 17):

## [SHENZHEN I/O](https://www.zachtronics.com/shenzhen-io/), 61 bytes, 7¥, 7 Lines

```
@not
@mov acc dat
@not
tgt acc dat
-mov acc p0
-add x0
slp x0
```

Outputs 0-100 as simple output, one per time unit. Makes use of the DX300 (XBus <-> Simple Input chip) and LC70G04 (NOT gate), which cost 1¥ each but do not use any power or count as lines of code (the game's measure of code length). These are used to generate a value of 1, which it adds and outputs until it hits 100. The value for 100 is generated using the "not" command, which makes the accumulator 100 if it is value 0, otherwise it sets the acc to 0.

[image]
(Not pictured: conversion from simple output to the screen's XBus input, for the visualization.)

---

## [SHENZHEN I/O](https://www.zachtronics.com/shenzhen-io/) (MCxxxx ASM only), 129 bytes, 8¥, 16 Lines

```
@not                 | not
@mov acc p0          | mul acc
@mov acc dat         | dgt 0
@not                 | sub p0
add p0               | dgt 0
tgt acc dat          | mul acc
-mov acc x0          | mov acc p0
slp p0               | slx x0
```

Outputs 0-100 as one XBus output each. Uses only programmable MCxxxx chips, no logic gates or other components. Generates value 1 in a pretty interesting way:

```
not     # acc = 100
mul acc # 100 * 100 = 999 (max value)
dgt 0   # digit 0 of 999 = 9
sub p0  # 9 - 100 = -91
dgt 0   # digit 0 of -91 = -1
mul acc # -1 * -1 = 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
³Ż
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q5qO7//8HAA)

Outputs a list. If the separator must be a single character, [3 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q5qO7vf//BwA)

### How it works

```
³ŻK - Main link. Takes no arguments
³   - Yield 100
 Ż  - Range from 0 to 100
  K - Join by spaces (optional)
```

Comment: wtf happens here xD

Comment: @azro Added an explanation

Comment: What the ....??? What on earth is this language? (goes lookup Jelly)

Comment: @ErwinMoller No need to look it up, just click the link in the Header to visit the GitHub page! :)

Comment: Languages designed to be used in code golf kinda ruin the aesthetics of code golf. I prefer to see mad-squeezing of daily used languages that are legitimately used in real production environments, instead.

Comment: @MartinBraun In most challenges (I.e. those more complex than this), creating a competitive answer in a golfing language is just as difficult as doing so in a “real” language. You’ll see that I helped golf the Python answer just above (sorting by votes), and I can tell you that was just as simple as writing this answer

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing This was no critics towards you in person. I appreciate the effort put into each and every answer. I just wanted to share the fact that languages like this kinda take away the magic of the result, if you know they are designed to do what they are supposed to do here.

Comment: @MartinBraun This opinion has been shared a gazillion times on meta. The consensus is, just look at other answers. The R answer in particular is quite beautiful.

Comment: This isnt really 2/3 bytes. 2/3 characters, may be

Comment: @Sanctus It is 2 bytes. More specifically, it is the hex bytes `83 D2` (and `4B` for the 3 byte version). Jelly uses a [custom code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page) to encode its programs in order to make them more "readable", but if you fed a raw byte stream of those two bytes into the Jelly interpreter, it would produce the same output

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing, i see, then it makes sense

Answer (score 16):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 10 bytes

```
put 0..Ⅽ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@gtETBQE/vUeva//8B)

`Ⅽ` here is the Unicode character ROMAN NUMERAL ONE HUNDRED.

Any other Unicode character with a defined value of 100 could be used:

௱: TAMIL NUMBER ONE HUNDRED
൱: MALAYALAM NUMBER ONE HUNDRED
፻: ETHIOPIC NUMBER HUNDRED
ⅽ: SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL ONE HUNDRED
佰: CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4F70
百: CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-767E
陌: CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-964C

All are three UTF-8 bytes long, like `Ⅽ`.

Comment: Anytime you have `0..foo`, you can use `^foo`.  So you can get 8 bytes with `put ^Ⅽ`

Comment: @user0721090601 Incorrect.  `^foo` is the same as `0..(foo-1)`, not `0..foo`.

Comment: Ack, duh.  Ignore me

Comment: Are there any Unicode characters with a defined value of 101? If so, `puts ^` then the character would save bytes

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I checked that before posting my answer, but there aren't any.  Not too surprising, really.

Answer (score 15):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `jHRM`, 0 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqSFJNIiwiIiwiIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Kinda cheating, but whatever.

### How?

```
  # full program
  # H flag presets the stack to 100
  # R flag does range when number is treated as iterable
  # M flag makes range start at 0
  # j flag joins the top of the stack by newlines
```

Answer (score 13):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 11 bytes

```r
F:(0xA*0xA)
F:0xA^(T+T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/381Kw6DCUQuINf//BwA)

Uses [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191117/67312).

Still being beaten by [some volcano in New Zealand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219617/67312), though...

Old answer:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 16 bytes

```r
F:paste0(+T,0,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/382qILG4JNVAQztEx0DHQPP/fwA)

Thanks to Kirill L. for correcting an error.

R's ASCII=>byte function is `utf8ToInt`, which unfortunately has an `8` in it. Luckily, `:` will attempt to coerce its arguments to numeric types, so we construct `100` by pasting together `+F` (which coerces its value to `0`) and two `0`s. This would also work, though longer, without a `0` as `F:paste(+T,+F,+F,sep="")`.

Possibly there's a very short builtin dataset with a `sum` that's close to 100, though I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: I believe according to the task, you should start with `F` rather than `T`.

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzi1UMMvMydV8/9/AA "R – Try It Online") (but yours is much more elegant!)

Comment: @KirillL. oh yes, my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @RobinRyder I guess with Kirill's correction, that one won't quite work, although `seq(0,a=Nile)` is close. Feel free to post that approach yourself if you can fix it!

Comment: Indeed, I had missed that. You can get 14 bytes with `c(F,seq(Nile))` in that case.

Comment: @Giuseppe, yeah, but `F:sum(T|Nile)` is still only 13 bytes.

Comment: That's just lovely. One of you ought to post that.

Comment: I found out that the `volcano` dataset leads to a 9 byte answer, which I [posted instead](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219617/86301).

Answer (score 12):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>33</s> <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
,,

,,,,,,
,
,,,,,

$.`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fS0eHC4hBgEsHwuDiUtFL@P8fAA) Explanation: The first stage inserts two commas, which the second stage increases to 20 (it's complicated). The third stage multiplies by 5 to give 100. The last stage then inserts the number of commas so far at each position.

Comment: Nice! You can golf it a bit by computing 100 as 4*5*5 https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fSwcIuHTAFILmUtFL@P8fAA

Comment: @Leo You should have used `0514150` commas for a nice symmetry!

Comment: @Leo (Although as it happens I found a shorter solution, which I then verified using a Python script. The only other solution with the same length simply has the first two stages swapped.)

Comment: As per specification you may not use commas (`,`).

Comment: @KaiBurghardt I think that's just the way the list of excluded digits is formatted. But you can replace the commas with spaces or `¶`s to get an alternative program if you so wish.

Comment: That’s amazing (the circumstance that you can substitute `,` by ` ` or `¶`)! Yeah, _I guess_ the commas could have been accidentally included, but I am not so sure about that. I have [submitted a suggested edit](/review/suggested-edits/68087).

Answer (score 9):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 38 bytes

```c
f(i){for(i=0;printf("%d ",i++)&'#';);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPT1sC6oCgzryRNQ0k1RUFJJ1NbW1NNXVndWtO69n9uYmaeBlChBojzLzktJzG9@L9uOQA)

Without using digit `0`, it would be 39 bytes: [`i;main(){for(;printf("%d ",i++)&'#';);}`](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09Dszotv0jDuqAoM68kTUNJNUVBSSdTW1tTTV1Z3VrTuvb//3/JaTmJ6cX/dcsB)

Comment: i as a global defaults to 0 saving a couple characters.  Just change your main call to f in your example/

Comment: Actually took I it further and made it recursive for a 2 more characters saved:

Comment: where did you learn this level of programming i don't even understand it

Comment: @vijaykumar `printf` returns how many bytes are printed. `'#'` is as same as number 35 (ASCII 35 for "#"). That's all you need to know to make it work.

Comment: Capital C would also work - 64+3 = 'C' :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <del>25</del> 23 bytes

```bash
seq 0 $(printf %d "'d")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UMFAQUWjoCgzryRNQTVFQUk9RUnz/38A)

-2 thanks to @manatwork

Comment: Using `$(`..`)` is good coding habit, but is longer than `\``..`\``. And no need to quote ”%d” as contains nothing special. In change the “'d” contains character with special meaning, but only one, so escaping it with ``\`` is shorter. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UMFAIaGgKDOvJE1BNUUhRj0l4f9/AA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: What is happening with the `'d`?  I assume printf is interpreting it as its ascii numeric value but I don't see it mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @manatwork thanks!

Comment: How weird, @Jonah. I can't find where I learned about that feature. Only found in the [`printf` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html)'s Examples section. Maybe Wasif knows a better documentation.

Comment: @Jonah found it few days ago [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92447/bash-script-to-get-ascii-values-for-alphabet), Actually I don't know a lot of documentation on bash

Answer (score 8):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>16</strike> 12 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @mazzy!

```powershell
0..(0xa*0xa)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPT8OgIlELiDX//wcA)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPT8OgIlELiDX//wcA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy thanks! I feel silly for having missed that, lol

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Why not just enter  0..100

Answer (score 8):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 12 bytes

```
seq 0 $[##d]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZrilMLFQwUVKKVlVNiIUJQGZgKAA)

- `seq`: count

  - from `0`
  - `$[##d]`: to the character value of `d`

Alternative:

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 12 bytes

```
!
seq 0 $?00
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZrFLmKUwsVDBRU7A0MIEJQGZgKAA)

`!` does nothing, but fails with exit code 1; `$?` then retrieves the exit code.

Answer (score 8):

## PHP, 30 bytes

First time golfing, I hope I posted this right!

```php
while($q<ord(e))echo+$q++,' ';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1VApt8otSNFI1NVOTM/K1VQq1tXXUFdSt//8HAA)

---

Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) and [Dewi Morgan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41364/dewi-morgan)'s suggestions to improving the code! From 34 to 30 bytes!

<sub>The code revisions are in the edit history, removed here so it looks cleaner!</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer. (Don't worry, you posted it correctly :p)

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't output 0. While fixing it, you could reduce its size by removing the single quotes, the braces and the parenthesis around `echo`'s argument. I would suggest this: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVCm3yi1I0UjWtNVOTM/K1VQq1tXXUFdSt//8HAA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: @manatwork oh I need 0, fixing it! and thanks for saving a few bits! although the fixed version is a bit longer :(

Comment: Nice! The space before quotes can go, too :)

Comment: Thinking about it, you can also get rid of the third clause if you postincrement and concatenate the variable to the space : `for($q=0;$q<ord(e);)echo$q++." "; Shame none of the permitted separators are characters so they could be unquoted.

Comment: And we only need the 4 chars `$q=0` because null isn't being cast to an int. We can cast to an int to avoid it, but `(int)` takes 5 bytes. But adding 0 casts to 0, and we can only do that in 2 bytes, though we need to re-add the space after the echo, so it's effectively 3. Still saves us a byte, though! `while($q<ord(e))echo 0+$q++." ";` (while has the same bytecount as for with just the middle clause used).

Answer (score 8):

## Factor, <s>46</s> 23 bytes

<sup>-23 bytes thanks to Bubbler</sup>

```
0xa sq [0,b] [ . ] each
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@cWKJgp1Cnr5eWmFySX6RblKxgY6Pg6u/GFRrsaqVQkFhUnFqkkFhakq9bWpzKBZKAaSnOLy1KToVqhOr6b1CRqFBcqBBtoJMUqxCtoKcQq5CamJzxH6RRP7@gRB@iHEqhm/IfAA)

I've never written anything in Factor before, but it's a surprisingly fun language.

Comment: Thanks for picking up Factor! Lots of golfs are possible on this code. 1) You don't need to dup the 100 in the first place, and then you won't have anything to drop at the end. 2) A range is a sequence, so you can run `each` on it without `>array`. 3) There are multiple ways to get the constant 100, such as `CHAR: d` or `0xa sq`. If you want, drop by the [Factor chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119181/factor), and I'll explain things further :)

Answer (score 7):

## Perl, <strike>20</strike>, <strike>13</strike>, <strike>12</strike>, 16 bytes

```
say for 0..ord d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqlBmqmdoYP2/OLFSIS2/SMFATy@/KEUh5f9/AA)

Comment: You can get rid of `$,=",";`, but you need `ord('d')` for it to work.

Comment: @PaulPicard: unquoted dee works here (perl v5.32.0), e.g. `perl -E 'say 0..ord(d)'`

Comment: You can remove the parenthesis.

Comment: Without the comma, this doesn't meet the challenge specification to have a separator between numbers. `say for 0..ord d` would meet the rules.

Comment: @Xcali: indeed, thanks

Comment: @Thor Ah indeed, I was trying with an older version (5.11.0). My bad!

Comment: Same byte count: `say$-++for a..cw`

Answer (score 7):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 16 bytes

```sh
echo {0..$[##d]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX6HaQE9PJVpZOSW29v9/AA)

Only builtins, so no `seq`

---

For fun, here's a **17 byte** answer without `0`:

```sh
echo {$?..$[##d]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX6FaRVlPTyVaWTkltvb/fwA)

Also `$!` or `$#` will work as `0` replacements.

Comment: Coreutils solution for 14B: `jot - 0 $[##d]`

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `jH`, 1 byte

```
ʀ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=jH&code=%CA%80&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Flags for the win. The `H` flag presets the stack to 100, generate range 0 to 100 and then `j` flag joins on newlines. The flag was around before this challenge too.

Comment: This seems to give the wrong output

Comment: @Anush its fixed

Comment: +1, first reaction someone seeing this will be "OMGWTFBBQ wat happens here" XD

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```bash
seq 0 $[++x]00
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UMFAQSVaW7si1sDg/38A)

Thanks @manatwork for -2, @Jonah for -2

Comment: You don't need the braces.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: `seq 0 $[++x]00` for 14.

Answer (score 7):

## PICO-8, <s>50</s> 45 bytes

```
i=0-#"0"repeat i+=#"0"?i
until#tostr(i)>#"00"
```

-5 bytes by replacing `print` with its shorthand, `?`.

Demo (50 byte version; 45 byte version has same output):

[image: i=0-#"0"repeat i+=#"0"print(i)until#tostr(i)>#"00"]

Comment: Glad to see some PICO-8 on CGCC! It's such a fun little engine to tinker around with.

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 15

```bash
seq `dc<<<A0Kf`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UCEhJdnGxsbRwDst4f9/AA)

- 1 byte saved, thanks to @manatwork.

---

Previous answer:

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (no external utilities), 23

- 9 bytes saved thanks to @ArcticKona.

```bash
eval echo {0..$[++x]00}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7UsMUchNTkjX6HaQE9PJVpbuyLWwKD2/38A)

Comment: Your newest solution skips “0” because you missed a space between `seq`'s parameters. Sorry, that looks like +1 character. ☹

Comment: @manatwork oops - yes, thanks - fixed.

Comment: As apology, here is a 15 character one, still based on your idea: `seq \`dc<<<A0Kf\``.

Comment: @manatwork - thanks!

Comment: `seq` is also part of GNU Coreutils, so the very first example could also be bash + GNU Coreutils, like the second. Of course, the third one is pure bash.

Comment: for pure bash try `eval echo {0..$[++x]00}`

Comment: @ArcticKona Great idea - thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) <strike>22 bytes</strike>  12 bytes - thanks to @manatwork

```ruby
p *0..?d.ord
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBy0BPzz5FL78o5f9/AA)

Comment: A splat `*` operator will do it instead of `.to_a`: `p *0..?d.ord`

Comment: You can switch to Ruby 1.8 and remove the `.ord`

Answer (score 6):

## GNU Octave, <strike>14</strike>, 5 bytes

```
0:'d'
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fwEo9Rf3/fwA) by Giuseppe

Comment: I think just `0:'d'` should work.

Comment: @Giuseppe: nice one

Comment: Also, Octave is on TIO if you want to add [a link](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fwEo9Rf3/fwA) :-)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
тÝ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YtPhuf//AwA)

Outputs a list. If the separator must be a single character, [3 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YtPhuYd2//8PAA)

### How it works

```
тÝ» - Full program
т   - Push 100
 Ý  - Range from 0 to 100
  » - Join with newlines (optional)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 13 characters

Thanks to

- [Daemon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101144/daemon) for reusing stack depth instead of getting it again, to use shorter operator (-1 character)

```
[zpdA0>x]dsxx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z@6qiDF0cCuIjaluKLi/38A)

#### [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 14 characters

Thanks to

- [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma) for the twist in using the stack depth efficiently (-2 characters)

```
[zpzA0!<m]dsmx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z@6qqDK0UDRJjc2pTi34v9/AA)

#### [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 16 characters

```
0[pz+dA0>i]dsixp
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ dc -e '0[pz+dA0>i]dsixp' | head
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98guqBKO8XRwC4zNqU4s6Lg/38A)

Comment: [Similar idea](https://tio.run/##S0n@/7@qILpKuyDF0cAuNzalOLfi/38A), same score

Comment: Thanks @DigitalTrauma. I tried that too earlier, but only now, seeing your suggestion I found the more efficient way.

Answer (score 6):

## Deadfish~, 2071 / 8 / 7 bytes

2071 bytes

```
o{i}c{d}io{i}dc{d}iio{i}ddc{d}iiio{i}dddcddddddoiiiiiicdddddoiiiiicddddoiiiicdddoiiicddoiicdoicociodciioddciiiodddciiiioddddciiiiiodddddciiiiiioddddddc{i}dddo{d}iiic{i}ddo{d}iic{i}do{d}ic{i}o{d}c{i}io{d}dc{i}iio{d}ddc{i}iiio{d}dddc{i}iiiio{d}ddddc{i}iiiiio{d}dddddc{i}iiiiiio{d}ddddddc{i}{i}dddo{d}{d}iiic{i}{i}ddo{d}{d}iic{i}{i}do{d}{d}ic{i}{i}o{d}{d}c{i}{i}io{d}{d}dc{i}{i}iio{d}{d}ddc{i}{i}iiio{d}{d}dddc{i}{i}iiiio{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}iiiiio{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}iiiiiio{d}{d}ddddddc{i}{i}{i}dddo{d}{d}{d}iiic{i}{i}{i}ddo{d}{d}{d}iic{i}{i}{i}do{d}{d}{d}ic{i}{i}{i}o{d}{d}{d}c{i}{i}{i}io{d}{d}{d}dc{i}{i}{i}iio{d}{d}{d}ddc{i}{i}{i}iiio{d}{d}{d}dddc{i}{i}{i}iiiio{d}{d}{d}ddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiio{d}{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}{i}iiiiiio{d}{d}{d}ddddddc{{i}dddddd}dddo{{d}iiiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}ddo{{d}iiiiii}iic{{i}dddddd}do{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}o{{d}iiiiii}c{{i}dddddd}io{{d}iiiiii}dc{{i}dddddd}iio{{d}iiiiii}ddc{{i}dddddd}iiio{{d}iiiiii}dddc{{i}dddddd}iiiio{{d}iiiiii}ddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiio{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{{i}dddddd}iiiiiio{{d}iiiiii}ddddddc{{i}ddddd}dddo{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}ddddd}ddo{{d}iiiii}iic{{i}ddddd}do{{d}iiiii}ic{{i}ddddd}o{{d}iiiii}c{{i}ddddd}io{{d}iiiii}dc{{i}ddddd}iio{{d}iiiii}ddc{{i}ddddd}iiio{{d}iiiii}dddc{{i}ddddd}iiiio{{d}iiiii}ddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiiio{{d}iiiii}dddddc{{i}ddddd}iiiiiio{{d}iiiii}ddddddc{{i}dddd}dddo{{d}iiii}iiic{{i}dddd}ddo{{d}iiii}iic{{i}dddd}do{{d}iiii}ic{{i}dddd}o{{d}iiii}c{{i}dddd}io{{d}iiii}dc{{i}dddd}iio{{d}iiii}ddc{{i}dddd}iiio{{d}iiii}dddc{{i}dddd}iiiio{{d}iiii}ddddc{{i}dddd}iiiiio{{d}iiii}dddddc{{i}dddd}iiiiiio{{d}iiii}ddddddc{{i}ddd}dddo{{d}iii}iiic{{i}ddd}ddo{{d}iii}iic{{i}ddd}do{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}o{{d}iii}c{{i}ddd}io{{d}iii}dc{{i}ddd}iio{{d}iii}ddc{{i}ddd}iiio{{d}iii}dddc{{i}ddd}iiiio{{d}iii}ddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiio{{d}iii}dddddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiio{{d}iii}ddddddc{{i}dd}dddo{{d}ii}iiic{{i}dd}ddo{{d}ii}iic{{i}dd}do{{d}ii}ic{{i}dd}o{{d}ii}c{{i}dd}io{{d}ii}dc{{i}dd}iio{{d}ii}ddc{{i}dd}iiio{{d}ii}dddc{{i}dd}iiiio{{d}ii}ddddc{{i}dd}iiiiio{{d}ii}dddddc{{i}dd}iiiiiio{{d}ii}ddddddc{{i}d}dddo{{d}i}iiic{{i}d}ddo{{d}i}iic{{i}d}do{{d}i}ic{{i}d}o{{d}i}c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBBcsUgDENP1EN1oJ2yyqLLDmdPg8H2k5NFIsv8j57612f/Hr8/H/d9/Y3Z/vocS3RTWx59ht66Pdewp2FoIdsRzT7tebWrjau351/6eq@PfU1steXRZ3jutkuvHWFPezBtcqkl1ncsYb8aWx59Bp98jDmMdNIyL4NklogTiTyU5zrRTjoP6BkjZiTNsJkXkZGawZld4lcCgRAOopAGQGBKrCQDHPiISEoBFVbFVeICXbgrOug3@PNs/o3@PLsBbnUpO1lxwwX9wYWkGLoqu7Ks27p@7V8H3ifeR3BGS9KOZllxwwV82HCRgN1INdKMFqO9lFpKK7WU2smrktqIFCJ9TF3Ah51umunlveiBNbAFKUE60Aq0gVJA4a/4hZ7wZJ9ip5tmeGGFE7clM5BBTGDyCq7QKqyyFlQlBSg4J83wwnLHDZ/9juBLvKQDHNiIRjIBEy7FEqqESqYJyx03znzGdt//)

8 bytes (if you consider Hello, world! a valid separator)

```
o{{iow}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f8/v7o6M7@8tvb/fwA)

7 bytes (If you don't care about seperators)

```
o{{io}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f8/v7o6M7@29v9/AA)

Never thought I'd see deadfish be shorter than, well, anything except Unary.

Comment: Damn it. Rewriting.

Comment: @Razetime Remebered w doesn't care about accumulator.

Comment: "Hello, World!" is not a valid separator.

Comment: Haha reading up on Deadfish~ I realized that exact 7 byte program... but you beat me to it! I actually wrote a Deadfish interpreter for Code Golf that automatically had spaces between output, just because the BASIC interpreter put them there.  Perfect for than program!

Answer (score 6):

## [v³](https://esolangs.org/wiki/V%C2%B3), <s>96</s> 93 bytes

```
^+++(###....+###....+++<..#+...-....###+.@#+...$)+).>+++.$#+...^##=.+###.-#+....+)<++(-+##++>
```

Unwrapped:

```
        ^ + + +
        ( # # #
        . . . .
        + # # #
. . . . + + + < . . # + . . . -
. . . . # # # + . @ # + . . . $
) + ) . > + + + . $ # + . . . ^
# # = . + # # # . - # + . . . .
        + ) < +
        + ( - +
        # # + +
        > . . .
```

I'm not able to provide a direct link, but [here](https://repl.it/@BoTie/v3-Interpreter#script.txt) you should be able to fork the project and replace the script.txt with either of the above scripts.

Comment: NO idea what this is doing but it looks so pretty   +1

Answer (score 6):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

*Thanks to @Cinaski for saving 3 bytes with* `\!` *instead of* `"ba"-`.

```
:.\!+:"d"`#@_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/30ovRlHbSilFKUHZIf7/fwA)

Uses `\!` to `NOT` the `0` at the bottom of the stack and uses that to increment the loop, then tests if the counter is greater than `d` to end. Certainly not the shortest answer, but this is my first golf challenge, and I wanted to practice Befunge, which I decided to pick up yesterday. This is also my first time trying a stack-based language, and I'm having a lot of fun with it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf. Nice first answer!

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can save 3 bytes by replacing `"ba"-` with `\!` [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/30ovRlHbSilFKUHZIf7/fwA "Befunge-93 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), 20 bytes

```
i0<esc><C-A>s<C-R>=range(<C-R>"0<C-R>")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9PAJrU42c7GWdfRrhhIBtnZFiXmpadqgNlKBhBKk@v///@6ZQA)

Trying to improve on Razetime's answer, I stumbled upon the `range` function, which works wonders for this task. `i<C-R>=range(101)\n` would print the numbers we want, we just need to be a little creative to do it without `1`.

#### Explanation

```
i0<esc><C-A>s<C-R>=range(<C-R>"0<C-R>")
i0<esc>                                    Insert a single 0
       <C-A>                               Increase it to a 1
            s                              Cut the 1 and go back to insert mode
             <C-R>=                        Write the result of the following function
                   range(             )    A range of numbers from 0 to N-1
                         <C-R>"            The last text that was deleted (1)
                               0           0
                                <C-R>"     1 again
```

Comment: [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9PAJrU42c7GWdfRrhhIBtnZFnGCaSUDCKXJ9f//f90yAA) by using tab autocomplete on the `range()` function. Also, it doesn't work on TIO, but if you start Vim with the `+startinsert` flag, you don't need the `i` at the beginning and save another -1 bytes: `vim +startinsert testfile`

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
=Range[0,LL
```

-1 byte from Imanton1

Mathematica interprets the `=` prefix as a call to Wolfram Alpha (auto-converting it to the orange glyph seen below), which in turn interprets "LL" as a Roman numeral for 100. I used "LL" because this doesn't work with the shorter "C".

[image]

Comment: You can shave off a byte, since WA uses free-form input, you can drop off the final closing bracket and it can still figure it out. `=Range[0,hecto`

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (ppencode-compatible), 64 bytes

You didn't clarify that I must separate each with exactly one character, so here it is mine.

```perl
print length uc xor s qq q xor print while length ne ord qw q eq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRCEnNS@9JEOhNFmhIr9IoVihsFChEMyESJdnZOakwhTlpSrkF6UoFJYDlaQW/v8PAA)

### Explained

```perl
   # print(length) did not work for zero as $_ is not defined at then
   print length uc xor
   s qq q xor
   # delimiter
   print
while
   # equals to: length ne 101
   length ne ord qw q eq
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3 20 Bytes

```
print(*range(*b'e'))
```

`How it works?` Basically, doing *b'char' is equivalent to ord('char'), and in this case ord('e') is equal to 101 ;
Lets re-create the ord() function!

### Ord Function Recreation (Not the answer! Just a demonstration on how ord() works)

```
ord=lambda x:(int(*bytes(x, 'ascii')))
```

As you can see it works! You can test this yourself [here](https://www.online-python.com/pwafv3OSPz).

## Python 3 25 Bytes

```
print(*range(0xa*0xa-~0))
```

`How it works?` 0xa = 10, ~0 = -1, -~0 = 1 (equivalent to -1*-1)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer. But `'utf8'` contains an `8`.

Comment: Yes ; but that was just a explanation on how ord *works*. Not the answer itself.

Comment: Even though not needed ; I decided to change the ord() explanation from  'utf8' to 'ascii' just to clear up some confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://dyalog.com/), 19 bytes

```
⎕←0,⍳(+/⍳≢⍬⍬⍬⍬)*≢⍬⍬
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//Ud/UR20TDHQe9W7W0NYHko86Fz3qXQNHmlpwgf//AQ)

```
≢⍬⍬⍬⍬ ⍝ This evaluates to 4
≢⍬⍬ ⍝ This evaluates to 2

⍳≢⍬⍬⍬⍬ ⍝ Evaluates to 1 2 3 4
(+/⍳≢⍬⍬⍬⍬) ⍝ Sums up previous list, 1+2+3+4 = 10
(+/⍳≢⍬⍬⍬⍬)*≢⍬⍬ ⍝ Exponentiates previous result by 2
⍳(+/⍳≢⍬⍬⍬⍬)*≢⍬⍬ ⍝ Generates 1 2 ... 100
0,⍳(+/⍳≢⍬⍬⍬⍬)*≢⍬⍬ ⍝ Appends 0 to front
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://python.org), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```python
print(*range(ord('e')))
```

-2 by Steffan, remove first parameter (`0`) from call to `range`

Comment: The `0,` is not needed

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll use it.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript, 48 bytes

```
for(a of Array("e".charCodeAt()).keys())alert(a)
```

Can be shorter, if you allow in reverse (36 chars)

```
for(i="e".charCodeAt();--i;)alert(i)
```

Comment: Your 50 bytes solution doesn't output 0. To fix it just remove that unnecessary pre-incrementation and change the "d" to "e".

Comment: @manatwork i thought we didnt have to print 0, at the time i wrote the solution. I'll fix it :) thanks

Comment: [40 forward](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPTVjs61jrTRilVSS85I7HIOT8l1bFEQ9Nas6AoM69EI1NbW/P/fwA)

Answer (score 5):

## Lua (<s>34</s> 30 bytes)

```lua
for i=0,0xA*0xA do print(i)end
```

Comment: [`d='d'for O=0,d:byte()do print(O)end` - 35 bytes](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/xVY9RT0tv0jB39ZAJ8UqqbIkVUMzJV@hoCgzr0TDXzM1L@X/fwA). Slightly different approach.

Answer (score 5):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 26 bytes

```
{for(;a<=0xa*0xa;)$a=a++}a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMM60cbWoCJRC4itNVUSbRO1tWsT//9XUgIA)

*Thanks to xnor for pointing out a brainfart (since fixed) in the original*

This works by using `0xa*0xa` to compute 100, then assigns each positional variable to it's own sequential number.  Then the `a` without a code block (evaluates as truthy since `a` is 100) prints all the positional arguments separated by a space.

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure why the `0` prints but it does. :)

Comment: I don't think that the `1` is allowed unfortunately

Comment: Wow, that was dumb. :)  Thanks!  The fix was simple enough and didn't change the length of the code,

Comment: Why the zero prints: https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMM60cbWoCJRC4itNVUSbZUKSksUlBK1tZUUMvNK8hVUlBKVdJRqE///V1ICAA

Answer (score 5):

## MY BASIC, 29 bytes; BBC BASIC 27 bytes

```
for i=0 to 0xa*0xa
print i
next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/z8tv0gh09ZAoSRfwaAiUQuIuQqKMvNKFDK58lIrSv7/BwA)

*Edit:*
Thanks for upvoting!
I have found there is a BASIC dialect with even shorter syntax for hexadecimals (it's in BBC BASIC):

```
for i=0 to &a*&a
print i
next
```

that's minus 2 bytes :)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Comment: Doesn't BBC BASIC also have keyword abbreviations e.g. `p.i` for `print i`?

Comment: that would normally be done with a question mark: ? i
- but not  in BBC BASIC

Answer (score 5):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 58 bytes

Another in the theme of "this language doesn't even care about digit characters".

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgYsLiIGQE4iAXE4g5AKyQYCTCySiAOZwcoLlQCJAgpPr/38A)

The program with comments:

```
[Push  0 
][Label
  
][Dup 
 ][PrintNum	
 	][Push  10 	 	 
][PrintChar	
  ][Push  1 	
][Add	   ][Dup 
 ][Push  101 		  	 	
][Subtract	  	][JmpNeg
		
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxBCoQwDAXQdXKKfwTnCKIrGUSYZemiapkK41Bqi8evqRTJJvz3k9Nt0R7eLDZnNaXDAQ1Yq/f8Y5SlTx4Mraaw/eOYdmKQrs1XA5Lhqp0zQRgPg4TadSWU8PlUb4UF6C590hyDWWIJtBp2P9ovk0jOFw)

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, 13 bytes

```
0:double('d')
```

The ASCII code for lowercase d is 100, so convert to a double and go from 0 in intervals of 1 with ":"

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

The only real golfing opportunity for this question in the Wolfram language is to encode the number 100 with as few bytes as possible.  There is only one real-valued constant symbol in the Wolfram language with a one byte name, namely `E`.

I thus looked for combinations of binary operations that were near 100.  `(E+E)^E` is about 99.73, so adding E/E will give a suitable endpoint.

```
Range[0,(E+E)^E+E/E]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8oMS89NdpAR8NV21UzDkjou8b@//9ft6AoM68EAA)

Comment: You can change E/E to 0! to save a byte.

Answer (score 5):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), <s>41</s> <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 35 bytes

<sup>Thanks to Redwolf for -1 byte, Unrelated String for -4</sup>

```rust
||for i in 0..b'e'{print!("{} ",i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZzZWTWqKQZvu/piYtv0ghUyEzT8FATy9JPVW9uqAoM69EUUOpulZBSSdTs/a/dZqGpjVX7X8A)

---

#### 39 bytes

```rust
||(0..b'e').all(|i|print!("{} ",i)==())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZzZWTWqKQZvu/pkbDQE8vST1VXVMvMSdHoyazpqAoM69EUUOpulZBSSdT09ZWQ1Pzv3WahqY1V@1/AA)

---

#### 40 bytes

```rust
||(0..b'e').for_each(|i|print!("{} ",i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZzZWTWqKQZvu/pkbDQE8vST1VXVMvLb8oPjUxOUOjJrOmoCgzr0RRQ6m6VkFJJ1NT8791moamNVftfwA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Can you save a byte by getting rid of that space before `i` in the `print!`?

Comment: Would [this](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZzZWTWqKQZvu/piYtv0ghUyEzT8FATy9JPVW9uqAoM69EUUOpulZBSSdTs/a/dZqGpjVX7X8A) work for 35?

Answer (score 5):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 25 bytes

```
o=0
o->[0...eeeln(eeeee)]
```

Not sure if this is an acceptable form of output but it's still an interesting answer imo. Click the right arrow (`->`) to run.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8awcdme2tm)

This takes advantage of Desmos's implicit rounding with list ranges, which will always round both start and end numbers to the nearest integer. In this case, `eeeln(eeeee)` is mathematically equivalent to \$e^3\cdot5\approx100.42768\$ (\$e\approx2.71828\$ is Euler's number), which rounds down to 100.

If not acceptable, then here's an alternative version that might be more acceptable:

#### 31 bytes

```
l=[0...eeeln(eeeee)]
(l,0)
${l}
```

Paste first two equations into Desmos, and label the list of points `(l,0)` as `${l}`. Move the viewport to the right to view more numbers.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nflhz6nhrb)

Comment: wouldn't it be valid to remove `o=0`? because then you just click add slider and the output is there. but idk, should prob ask on meta

Comment: @Steffan I considered that, but I'm not so sure if that's valid. I'm gonna ask on TNB and see what they say.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 8 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
⍳⎕UCS'e'
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=e9Q31dP/UdsEAwA&c=e9S7@VHf1FDnYPVUdQA&f=AwA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=tradfn&n=f)

A tradfn submission which prints with space separator.

Answer (score 4):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 20 characters

```
range("e"|explode[])
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jq -n 'range("e"|explode[])' | head
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VUMpVakmtaIgJz8lNTpW8///f/kFJZn5ecX/dXXzSnNydDPzCkpLAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 19 bytes

```julia
println.(0:0xA*0xA)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM68kJ09Pw8DKoMJRC4g1//8HAA)

Answer (score 4):

## bc, 17 bytes

```
for(;i<=A*A;i++)i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0r@/z8tv0jDOtPG1lHL0TpTW1szk@v/fwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 14 bytes

```
i+R`c0c0$[+i]~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7T1rd9s2lt/1KxBqEou2JEty0qRqHCdNkzM5Z7btSbIzHxSlpUhI4oQiFT7iuOvNX@/eiwcJgCAlxcl2pzueqWPhcQHce3FfuIC2V/k6ic9@75LB8YD4SRDGqykp8uXgAZZ0HMfpPE2pl9OAJDF5vS7Ik2JFxmdk9GB698H07D6ZjCajTuexVwCkdEp@8OKQRp3HH2iahUk8JePhaHjGAMEP/pMnJEimHQI/7FdAFwByWcR@Dh1ukaqm@rXx3lHilY0IwIABk42Xh74XRVcky5MUWsTES1PvioQx2dBNkl5BUUA2yQdK8jUl2ySMc5pid/wY0485@eBFBa0GoVFGARqseEPjPLsgSQoVVwtK/llkOYmTXKt9OBiQy3Xor4mPg/s58TITBukxyGFOikzMcbWMvNWFK9CCv98Xof@ObNNklXqbTEHP8/C33@58X/z22/WtF7PVycvxIrt9NhstRou3o/nq9j34c4x/fj8fj0YkzFgHbE8GxItgtTEg6QONrqYarOxVNn41ziY/n6lAxxXQSQmUTeMSQa9pFCXkMkmjgBVez8bn7@e3BtnJo2y2enj702x0vn0/Xw2yR/NP5@Mt8dfUf5chvjMKGFgCYbZFjqC2abihZJ3n22x6egqcR1dJtBwC1vx39KO/9uIVHfrJ5vR9QTOkeXZ67/434/unYTbI1/ArLjYLmg68AYMkpjN6P59t5yNgMAqjQrPpYUN8M7l/NjkNN9uIkQ6g5ykw9mDj@eswFqMAqfNDwU7ORqcZgzuA3gNBZ9IDfqJTcr1FlPz402vgcQQuqvtkQX0PmQa5laNuRYGhtl6awY68XFPgcw@YHXojZ9LNNr9y2Sy/v7O4UyyXXpTcIcA5q5E/8c@yR6sx@3e2uLu4N58s7sH/7gLVJ5@Nscn4weTB3dOkyGF2gwUf8nP/rbh@QXPcqJxLOKk5M1GQMdfL0XfAecu5xnjLku9gV0oAEoFXSSF3aMEEhhcEKO9gPy6x3XJkEzvGr@sMRhudAI/BSA@PP@FoKB@uX0we1soJGTwiZAkDJmnoRaSXRMGUAxkIKKwpdJl/erhC@MQVwoD9eg6QGc25MODk36AQAgpQWNkSRR5yxjVImHC15tJp7X1AIXNFro8yzgqw7XD5l16M/aM8BC7k4LK@FEl3UG55sEuBtTyYMemBuLoMo8iQsz5TBpWgRfHKuBGYERg3v9qCCAXZD3oFVAnJ1kkRBTDX@kxAJvhJDNxOY4S49tJggAQJxEovw3yNsxNIAPylXATnKEyTGIU@4iEEKZvh7Ku2rlgWecNGxR/60cPNNyVv7mwTkMzJmzuTN@qguJArmt2Z9AkFtNzVIUIJQ8YKJCmZOdDQ6RNo6nBg/OPdORsOtvGzKdIFFRL8FycA0fcAMbCBUuAH0IykR4erIXkTu8g/7wuEgnpt46UgLntO/8gFCIBQ5FnQPbjmGKck5GfMKHwJBCjiiGYZQ2uQFIuIccRmWC78LeCcVwT9ahdE0BW2O@wuJDr8C7RaXJEUeQqInePnIsPfLydjJBWIHZKGYAQsGceBMMBRzYnDvmPrcpwc5IPjXGPvAewD/rkjTQDcUPAT0CVnnh7SwFWU3ipKFrBnULapn6X@z9TClG6BJ9USLoye5M/iQC3Ok@1Py1coy9RStBy8FVWLhJmgFkVJsn2aFGVxVykHkKk2vl@kKWiPp8lmA2z1Ig7oRxOWMTWfN83MZn8Ls9zW7mmyvTIXQYMnuCW1YgpbDIpXaiFYH8/B@tAWDAyQfw8yWF@0aDnZSQLb9HcgIXsXbl8nagmNg@cCuDm/MJY1tqmIIWq4qk/guaXeBllFs9ZnG1JgfJtuMKCRczIYqxXaNKB2xoWFZQ1YOZv3b/z/OemiPkfbALdsFG5ApMP@BoE0xH28FDTUFguDN6FVaCFlhc89MHSrOoOA9Qac5tXim/ADLbg67pbbSy8SO7EslHa9/Cz2NI40mpNjIo3YSgKUTeUuq2al7CWlUO4kKPoxEZag2B/aQuWe0QqV/WWsnv1S5BVUv06FP6ISRg7LcRAk8RFq@jgAeU/TNAGNwil7aePNo6OjyoS4RqH6nSTyuPxrMmQ/8uOP35FZjvYlGkqwqIK7MkyrcYcHdRvHFXPHAJN@JU65@t54H5HT0DFhblY2Zw4TGrrbIlvznsy67EvTA8pAEfWluXAt2XcZpmj5SA3arzwJrhvzdZoUqzUv7rlD8mIpdHCIho1zDRqarQftFLRQmBWVSTMq5E6JPqkh@QlBXIYZ7aMaZ7CVvbC0zYz5nsIm94TpKobG1qxqQ8FZDrhJAdqdazAcGFX@BlV7HuLkeuGQkjHrwtqmBQC5DH3qonGZbamPlqXv4fxGWMQhZYBxpFuIhETFx4Ehh4zH4lMOmjtydR7hzMWs4nNmHA8BXuT5tOcQp@84vDmXgbJFto3CvOd8B5XCiQ5RNPBGsPsMVgyXPSCFxJFQ@WWtaIFVEvC14@IePj8Ho0JpXtvNgu5Kg8r2g23Y0rM@mta2/CBWZjYfz61YUpZinTwTCb1qIq5Wm9K8SOM6cpCEyGmIwKqvDhlGZU1g1KM3b46McWvLrz5U63jzxulLjPbHbg1Ap45WXYZx0cc5QvwDZvp2zKRfF12KATP8MsWzBeuW@RCwFUu3oew5UeVunl5VAzctRpDojkIPxB4Fz74Nexrsynugfs/xYACHnKC93EMwbh0xcqpMFmY9d@Z4js5OaDlv82ljTwTcMSvGQ2@7BfXaY63chrVjQ@t@imischpyxrhtL1Uf5GYwZ13DUh1DyoBu81B2RNmQtPWyTDKUajlllbQZT6dzUYm@M5I5xZAFQ0DZ3lWWXhbOwrli@uDH2q7WUathgItdJoVytuUBb65NcPApKqSRPcEcMShSwhyP6uOIP07I2Eqeqq8@aWlRQA04dIqBxybd593cWnNhgNi6iKFcfZyuKd36hLcuESw79stBXENTdFHZyUpumwyVWiYJeS3SWTackm526W3ZZzBYQKdGYQxiJvKk58Z6a9TrMpQV0uDtCVjVmromfrslQ5Ylbf05S6bJhuleEm62CVi0W5ouf/GFJQvCTxjCr7GJMES54atU9Fxtb1f4AJMsAjfaYks/JMj9JZYVLqtPOZtZICicbIN/UuMyqYQsjW8zW9DC7VV7scxHYvkn5J5Fg3H@cn4WYVREa4AqaEh@CAMW5gD@wJgF/Aky/2OIQbOYG0QXTl1uL1LqvVNXoXAaCzty3QG8hoF74DKwBrnG64t/gcN0@5Tmvmb2KApSWRBUqM7BLdSPVkvBcYb/BC9Hba3IVaaLNQLYbYyODLsYe3mJe18NwGyTLAsXEQWPB6WFMxpPzu7e@@b@g28//fr4ztuLodMld3APpzRjjoEH5ihIS2aZoEHKg3OVkI4p7sUEWoJDUPoTHMNvWfTtgnkUsoojutT/uovGPTePFfFwEmkU@66O7TiB1aK0h1bqIl1TIYpBpebFPjrfiPGxos3UFHBmgzFqGNbpRO@kAFNb161QbhX2SnwcIwHcujBQfiGt1X0uVnlQ7MsSMNIiQ6U6Rlmlmfwe85f9SuuVPsBb5gNAvYJ23hp@V6r3rW5QVw536STrGLd55OWYF/uNeWEdc7Jz0El9VDk0jnLLcAJqJhROcWiZoj7VZZR4OQLUmbHOeFUXFAJVN3e3lWVO3fRfPD0MYmv@qd4epyEYbia4bG5RZwqQX@1ATKfJ7PbY3k2M6VoGBC8B8Y5mK0PRtMvPujLWnUc3ZBhM55oGL8MQQhzobj8D2nFDFOfLP7h7eQ@aLWJYYQCnzw5mBPkN9pQi@ofQRwn0Xxps58SZekHQ1wsHzjQrFjlqOqPm2JmKE6Yro@bUmQbhhzCgRvmlM2Wnyv/AQ2Wj7qUzlScSfdJFpI/YD1iCePYpTr94/CUIVzyGw46geuNzWHqfTM754UafnJ2zLeCSATuKXtAouWSkCmjuhRFQegEaGgQqGqp48MEAZvqEMlg4RryMea6cKehTo/ChMxUc90NyGRuVj8rK/9waVT/DGDT/mdcadVvolsbmSLecKSpLo9R3pvx8zSif4RrAsvpbkphDz50pqDpLxW0gaxIUUWKU/wVggbVtlKa4AhEuZbrcqD93ptUWfva@AJlptPhFoif4O4YNX8SvuNywNs5xQUhkGXw26vuINAD2FGyzJ@ZcPOBvjPS@iMMydm8O8ES0@Qksdo836PLTz6QswRwPTBJZsnQRmI7PYmyJvn2dDSASaz@2jfcK8RdRP38OLgOLQxsNFpK0r5OfK3PQaPS9WPaTOHgJNpq9USgavQBcr2q1753p@yLMhZVtVL4Qe@EFBm@MuiUw0kfqFzltoEkA0gDTfqpjoZoHgT//rZjhLMKgCiv2wQVjygEX/UTK7hPHFbJYazzDD3O3Upymt8nJZ@YZoQ8axlmIeQLk7/8BwgOPwfmhJThtK5AVF7w/qLaQ1@QhOykvYGnoosYws4JB4wN3WUCdmbdK5lCSYms9wwkHZ/ERgDYg4ZAO2QG/B3T02QmtiCVjnpNwVaAtVhwtj1gAHiUazzfiNjVF3x9lpvC1yuGYnWiQrMQfI5JuOLYfyO08G6wf/u04LWw5G2w8q/t6x4PayWz9WKw0E1Ut7MjpTEEiER21mhWjVaE9g3aWYjzUT9nK8bT90xgReM5cER4WsOBoZix87tZd9X26zZqGnst4/tyxWLkBrfBb84K@7tByWOnyjRoC3y3REI5bDImYHbr2c06@E4bbZNsbKIF2yTTixJTnKEEjxjy80LV4IvVDaI2bamHPNiTWA35VdFSDOldPCLTd@IVgtvxxeFCtObDW0SDbiGthjK@2y0y@N7a9hX3bjt@bY1328azizBI3vNludPffTp0mvDT2agw1fka48WuEHO2ksGFk53bWBY2YaABqg@xSOkoHCyn7Vpq47XukJsos/rCQYK4RUefF6AEDyRs2jkUsdIUQFbvTGqRuBNckc2uS1kqh1lVahzOWXB5wgJVJ07xh8mP4L@xbxbaMEKi2huVIRaSM8FRNxcwcED4wCTEyW7kzACYh7wtaUH2tTfk/aD9WFn2vimBJbpTHgliDNjtZe5h8QWNpdgaOa8Ythe@vQFtuUG5LOOIkqO7/93lqf1jGbzA@wtI6isVgqVp0nG4YKsCW0CELmeufyUMf8htNExbRrtqzSELZgwcKhI4OqB9uMNs3TdABCNw2ODI2IQCJvCwlSxQTNFHMMDVHPfAVqMgb7ChHu4CU2pkuIuoE4/aOblxucmkCjVUTaINEYlIAGmC01pXmhd5ponVCOuzR6UzrxCORlm4V4dlsgBBIh/OR7nkYSZwwkmhoinojO0SGQNVjadKx5FvoFhXDPPDgWhoYUbIqKxcCMpTVoffHI9c9YDan49HxcW9xMh6IBcH8jmtlHYEhsQV2Y0cERUeYZyz@NhwKbWrGyb0t06MpVQCgTwdsX84VUvJ1flFi1lBnz0jR@rDtaCESqRDbmv6Pa6nilFwidVlBn9@H4QlvH7w09OS5Fsc@t9a6mDkek7cszT6tWEiIx79WF2scZRPJk4Wy/8Xu/rcMABaKq5365B9NvUb1LmvLPM2TRyv0YwR6MnZdC169QCJU5BqWCXhlwCQjLAsdKIcSUqnjaGEhbtZM9K41tDOc4E5XIdf5efP20AxRRWToTZA81eJkoFysUH5kE2XCRVmMrMTVcs@mbb1V6xLW11n2YPeyB2zZNcryiL9YOv/AJ3cqeViU8qiUOn3MAp2oax4J1u@TsovRXCTKiPYJpm62d/D0xPibYen0XMzXwJJ9P@kdtRQfG35PBX41LSkOWiRnYcPj8xKxojo8DLdqr33R29Lni2L4@HMxfLwHho9VDlawzGLcAsUi4VeYazjRvpKtCIZ0Tr2AyPt6Msaqnqh3GTiNIvgnxxfen2rqJ/a93PrtUNgEY9vpvqXIbjLcqikNeXQLtXNN8VtUr3nMq7eXCSiKXd/N8FqjdT3iri7LH5coakPN3oAM3rwBagwLqsLTLqvExFPFduXpoIokvMecaReZi60NB7Z2jClYhkPWlO7RaC9gkpIABIv/9lszQUnUaeqxnpBgXtIwDG3df66nQOyYRONEmrMjzAnZPXyFGniQ206PAFrsRxFs@eVoMmogyWBfknz77c1pMmohyeBQksCE6nSoDsatssO43m9scBWt1TgiQ8LdHeKpuCGNNdnFDN6sLqVMCWRjjKa@zSL8s24xVqkgbjtb2a8l6MTibVQ5pwTlEEF4tqkiqMj4pRqoC2Na3lvhqZQdEQu7RVAtY3ogRxlelg99UK8iv1Ig5tlPz0mPn5uCDmbXgLEff59CfWCAXQty266FNlgctpsM9RMIXCc/hFdXqtxozmraRvKllS/21kKt7jqPsWmk4TcwuCkj0j60zYOF4oYgVJEB0RmUYTgtYn454yiTx@Flh1DQi680iRWNC1SgmLFhbkg0pGSmXo@da791@Q2pEEfw8Mz9A00xeztcVg9pHHK7tI7Gtuu0B0C2JEPaD8N3nS83HU9rdx6bJtNRslmr4dXosnmYaYHkdrtdVZ9oEgGTCditfplmxQ3@RYpPQeQseqtkFnQak9HUOEZde4ghFRau6wQW3idFnIcRt4@jhN1MF1OptRdHcm0Z7SwZ03oGvFeWe1vDHRpXy8lruPwl6FrHzZ8LOVISlPubXfEgCy/jwjzLi@VSUYIg9jHEJlJnMHye4D1KWK1NSe3B//Xzadd2j@FPtS1udmB7MGtYDnB3tv6X2EH/Ini0GrHNBTwNjKeAqkZCmTdmNRHYKwPsfjKrZpYO3jHW7F3ytq@0Ya9v8Vd90BJiN5KZWbgM@QXwmu1kN4ZtT2m062@rym94VcNyF2Jvg/zLGgW7ct0040YeZOObK3iKvcflLrOLhHdIZ8upM@xD9cBYWNPqPSOZgP@ro97isw@m75Z2HXbeXl/d9vgVj/nFOaZuSY@1@1U4yU9/1CQ/KZOsXaGoTfPxHzXNx8o05W0L1zXu4le3f77kDEGaCuen5pu6Tcljn6PbU@mxqIaLrnwaMxjVs7VxW7rXvuRAMWBtY1OY@vbcK92yq9wXVsdU3Iba3LvlSWFKjaynrvGqgTYEyxuyOSm7TYFWdGESQsUY7U15MoL75bbGwYOTgfHaQkPaaOkjGqRobi0J3EQ7QwNUCqB9hX3ivIkdt7a/dGJVEv6GCYM6/W9ohJ3fEMBNlMifEw@fo6f@nJg4UBX@30JCqzL9F9KjN0ZEezZ7c9d/698vpn//4B2tT/@GsL6Win8uHxdo1vNG6gi7zHnQ@TvvIquq/StAnbksKJCpxxO3yZl7WPbHruxEDfikNWGtud941GmTIm0dR/unQ0J7edxhyyXEa7Mc/2WGNhY15XTEgXLAGShvlpvZD7th7BFVsUc0dkRDmilIN9tX@CZPQ77D7oSRxueuEKyNJPURy2yM3aks7SPVTwH1u87WTcWbVPcw7QfU@mut6ouTIverYiE2sHmJ@qD9zHZwkpJRX0Tz4oSUx8O7sonb9uiI7Mi0sqSytVz2Vha186ibtE/TwmTWrDBLu3Ir83NU9ba5etfBy7KuPOTmjypXD@CgQp6SZRRuT1N8fxLfbFyE8ekapH2P3Rp/h99IcInvsrLMC6BSRt0@XilINvjOjnw1ejz5BnqyZ8BZMZ789Ynv0cxLSbYOl7l8W7m69q7yhkpvLQOBPRsomAUKPzOPgUGxJGrdJH9hR76Cv675XooZoZBWb97koiipybW3AVREEm8sU/HEewBLds2DskeOIhqv8rXK@bbsNYDxC393NKteVRfYXiR5nmwsGdHEm9j6lF/3AIyXxKwykBMaCIFS3jWRyYv8/B@mNh7qTUZG/WhInkUZ78V1vTq2FFfw8SiTSqYanr1sKudH@xwszpOd6cFsBthQrA4fXAmCKU876uMLbuxtqT7Zj49sD2Hv9dCRLoA75XcRMDIYb//C8E@UZ214QlL57J/2uovaX2vN7EHrA376MzzVc3pPcK@V8PRIu5yRbs6wuzTak6TKdGrbqUH88VeULXqy7a1STeTPylENSPXZT9Q7cuJ7DfDxsAnXoOpSFB1pXQrX3GHur4l5dIZVxhvPDWlvFbrtr3YyKOoDnXxE13bpVKm2n/1pMx7V7/has@Z2LdU0Zvj20P1pDZWjNjyO/o1HDY9WV9z@EFwJWJc0/y9w2bDkdpzK5wqN93dEPn4Rg6kV4pPdHUVYYP59ZXCLvLwrP0Ktg8YRPj0q7K@TwfHp7T55@fLZc6ZmqJdG@OVRAUXEeXgtdON9PN3g06XiD3xhgF/F9JOo2MSnaXLZJx4ABJl5Ct4wDlNsal9l0aCuahqn2dTpimlzZHQaX2yTD46ZmqAh3bEOQ3kFsnpzV//VnBxred7ISAW1ukS38GfnV1cYSGzPahDOmfaQ0iHeRMPAB7hCpiYtX1Pe/0aA7rja0k@1N6BUVLP7cOztOvkFL/yNURQlzKDAsupdXFtSJrP1WNYGxa@PYF/Uw9JA8LVK/OIddquUlJfSqqQnBdpEgLtQwAVAFhssxhllHgiWltBiGsorRwhVZJNwEdfipkBP3VMxu8nsMotxvsdXpNzkO2V2vauphnLHTl/ccpTLL@@GmqLDSClrZNXSH@KrEjFE8Zxqw30BpbkInjgOsd1X7eyIR7fOCoPixsxaJmW2Vi7etLuNvL3Ukuab5Q1HmQ099UMS1f/W319ruDcgvkdD36j40lgSoyfHdFMbN7ZeE/kC7wsbK6/sEwM5@MxCl38TGH7LIwt6XFS4EM/M7RWMqAcwRWZ4viP@oGxoxIne7X/xEoUZkGi8SVE/ZOvUhb3yEF9diTXlvDXOsCGLdzK@e//ug7Nv7t6vqZzqMiR78K8@h72DxhaxpyK@7j8nUfDaHmRXHnTXnM3q07zdvT5cYu7zHRINXnTtqx0OuKm18yrWIXM7ZH7WObZI1n3msM/Ytbt8B15N@1p0subg1kPcOs/WXuaVF3jV69JlSAy/9k@/A0xmaE6JaFt5/Zd5Icxywm8bitktd7xtI775NsPX1ufiRqxyNQ7LxWs1GKBjXyjK43WIKszlZS1sUlZ8SSjIWG@D1htXVrmR8ivv95oWd7nruit5OsGe6cHe6pzZtPgXTSoxRhYoxO821GWj8rUcHXx56yn/9iLHcd78Hp68/NUf@aO/zE7C@aff2TdrKm3kn7MpGhgd/k2EshB0@O//Aw)

## Explanation

```
i                    prints the value at the top of the stack (0) 
 +                   adds 1 to the value on top of the stack (which was 0, is now 1.0)
  R`                 reformats the top of the stack with the arg ` (the value at the top of the stack).
                        since ` = 1, it reformats the top of the stack as the integer 1
    c0c0             concatenates the value in storage at the current pointer (=0) to the top of the 
                        stack twice, resulting in "100"
        $            swaps the value on top of the stack (100) with the value in storage at the 
                        current pointer (0)
         [ .... ]~   loop structure: loops ~ times, where ~ = value_in_storage_at_pointer = 100
            +        adds one to the value on top of the stack
             i       prints the top of the stack as an integer
```

Note: the above code is based on version 1.0.* of Rattle. With the newest update (1.1.0), the code could be shortened to the following snippet (12 bytes) because the addition operator will now keep the top of the stack the same type (in this case, an integer) if possible.

```
i+c0c0$[+i]~
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 6 bytes

```
!0+"e"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/1/RQFspVen/fwA)

Uses `0+` to convert `"e"` to an integer, then takes the range from 0 up to, but not including, that value (101).

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 26 bytes

```bash
eval echo {$[x++]..${x}00}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7UsMUchNTkjX6FaJbpCWztWT0@luqLWwKD2/38A)

### (Previously)

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 28 bytes

```bash
eval echo {$((++x))..${x}00}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7UsMUchNTkjX6FaRUNDW7tCU1NPT6W6otbAoPb/fwA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: Your solution doesn't output 0, but fortunately the fix will cost you no extra character: just change the pre-increment to post-increment. While fixing it, you could change the `$((`..`))` arithmetic evaluation to the deprecated but still functional old `$[`..`]` syntax to save 2 characters. (We have [Tips for golfing in Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash) in case you are looking for more tips.)

Comment: Thx for the tips @manatwork.  Updated

Answer (score 4):

## [unsure](https://github.com/Radvylf/unsure), 99 bytes

```
ummmmm uhhhh errrrr uhhh um errrrr um um yeah err heh but um yeah err then uh okay um err then wait
```

It's not the shortest.

Explanation:

```
push 101                  ummmmm uhhhh errrrr uhhh um errrrr
push 0 to other stack     um um yeah err heh
loop                      but ... wait
  decrement                 um yeah err
  print + increment other   then uh okay um err then
```

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong, but when testing it with the interpreter you linked, it only prints the numbers up to 99.

Comment: i misread the challenge, costs 4 bytes i'll fix

Answer (score 4):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 21 bytes

```
qqYP<C-x>qi0<esc><C-a>a00@q<esc>Yxx@0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7AwMsDGWbfCrjDTwCa1ONkOyEm0SzQwcCgEcyMrKhwM/v//r1sGAA)

#### Explanation

```
qq       q                             Record macro q:
  Y                                     Yank the current line
   P                                    Paste a copy of it on the line above
    <C-x>                               Decrement the number under the cursor
          i0<esc>                      Insert a 0
                 <C-a>                 Increment it to 1
                      a00@q<esc>       Append 00@q
                                Y      Yank this line (100@q)
                                 xx    Delete the @q part
                                   @0  Execute the yanked text as commands
                                       (100@q executes the q macro 100 times)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Zig](https://ziglang.org/), <del>63</del> <del>66</del> <del>47</del> 72 bytes

```zig
fn a()void{for(" "**'e')|_,i|{@import("std").debug.print("{d} ",.{i});}}
```

[Try it online!](https://zigbin.io/b85863)

I've excluded the `@import()` boilerplate as it seems analogous to C's `#include`, which is excluded from other answers. If deemed necessary, I will add it back in.

### Explanation

```zig
fn a() void {
    for (" " ** 'e') |_, i| {
        @import("std").debug.print("{d} ",.{i});
    }
}
```

- `fn a() void` Declare a function which takes no parameters and returns nothing
- `for () |_, i|` For every item in the array inside of `()`, iterate and capture the entree as `_` (a throwaway variable) and the index as `i`
- `" " ** 'e'` Take the string (strings are slices, or pointer-arrays which know their length) and repeat it `'e'` (101) times
- `**` Requires a little bit more more explanation I think: In Zig, there is the concept of "comptime" (compile time) and runtime. `**` is an operator which repeats any array literal or slice literal at comptime, because the resulting length is still known to the compiler.
- `@import("std").debug.print("",.{});` Print to STDERR (I believe that's valid for this question, right?), the first argument is the formatting string, and the second is an "anonymous sctruct"/tuple with a variable number of arguments in it (Zig doesn't have var-args).
- `"{d} "` The format string. Zig denotes `{}` as the formatting characters, with `d` meaning a digit in this case.

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 46 bytes

I did not see a rust solution, so here's my attempt:

```rust
||print!("{:?}",(0..b'e').collect::<Vec<_>>())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZzZWTWqKQZvu/pqagKDOvRFFDqdrKvlZJR8NATy9JPVVdUy85PycnNbnEysomLDXZJt7OTkNT8791moamNVftfwA)

Thanks to @ovs for pointing out the closure variant.

The range `(0..b'e')` is collected into a vector (using the placeholder `_`, letting the compiler figure out the type) and printed using the debug formatter `{:?}`, which "dumps" the entire vector.

The range upper bound is exclusive, and is represented using the [byte literal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#byte-literals) `b'e'`, which is equivalent to an `u8` integer number literal; in this case 101 (`e`'s ASCII value).

Comment: How do you get 45 bytes? Your submission has to be either a full program (like the current code at 56 bytes) or a function/closure which can be [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZzZWTWqKQZvu/pqagKDOvRFFDqdrKvlZJR8NATy9JPVVdUy85PycnNbnEysomLDXZJt7OTkNT8791moamNVftfwA)

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to update the header after including `fn main() { ... }`. Will use the closure version. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

## C, 53 bytes

```c
int main(a,b){for(;a^'f';a++){printf("%d\n",a-!!a);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z8zr0QhNzEzTyNRJ0mzOi2/SMM6MU49Td06UVtbs7qgCCifpqGkmhKTp6STqKuomKhpXVv7/z8A)

### <s>43</s> 42 bytes

(Thanks to  Jo King♦)

```c
k;main(){for(;k^'e';)printf("%d ",k++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/bOjcxM09Dszotv0jDOjtOPVXdWrOgKDOvJE1DSTVFQUknW1tb07r2/38A)

Comment: Welcome to code golf, and nice first answer! Make sure to check out our [tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c) to see if there's any way for you to shorten your code.

Answer (score 4):

## C - 37 Bytes

```
i;f(){while(i<'e')printf("%d",i++);}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
i;
f()
{
    while(i < 'e')
        printf("%d", i++);
}
```

**Explanation**

Function to print numbers from 0 to 100 without digits. A global variable of type integer is created (so that it is automatically initialized to 0), the variable is incremented and printed 100 times through a loop which is executed while the variable is less than 'e' or 101 in ASCII.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 41 bytes

### Still learning ... best I could do:

```python
for n in range(0, ord('e')):
    print(n)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to CGCC! this isnt a bad first answer, but as this is a code golfing site, we do require all submissions to show at least an attempt at golfing (shortening the code as much as possible). You could shorten this code significantly by shortening the name of your variable, and by removing some whitespace, like [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9FW3YDaQJ0rLb9IIU8hM0@hKDEvPVXDQCcnNU8jUVPTqqAoM69EI0/z/38A)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Like des54321 said, there's a few things you could do to golf this. Making that string a single line would be a good first step, since we don't care at all about readability here. You could also maybe keep track of a variable `i` and print that, `+=1`ing it in each iteration, then you don't need the `range(0,len())` and can save some bytes.

Comment: Also, of course, since you're only using the big string once, you dont even need to assign it to a variable, and you can just throw it directly in the `for` statement

Comment: Ahh... fewest bytes is, obviously, the goal here... but thank you for the tips and advice! Especially since I honestly didn't realize whitespace would count towards the # of bytes. Thanks again :)

Comment: I've restored this answer and added the score as I think it makes a genuine attempt at brevity.  However you can still remove some whitespace here.  All the whitespace (including newlines) after the `,` can be removed.  You can see a general list of tips for python [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python).

Answer (score 4):

## Minecraft, 217 bytes + ?[image: minecraft]

From left to right the commands in the command blocks are

```
scoreboard players operation a a += b a
tellraw @a {"score":{"name":"a","objective":"a"}}
scoreboard objectives add a dummy
scoreboard players set a a 0
execute store result score b a run data get entity @p playerGameType
```

The command blocks on the right set `a` to 0 and `b` to the `playerGameType` of the player, which is `1` if the player is in creative mode.
The blocks on the left repeatedly print `a`, then add `b` to `a`. It's stopped at exactly 100 by the piston removing the repeater powering the command block.

I'm not sure how to score this or if it's even allowed but I thought it was kind of cool.

Comment: i think you should use structure blocks as indicated by [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9529/103854) meta post/answer...

Answer (score 4):

### PostScript: 11 bytes

```
00000000: 8800 8801 8864 7b3d 7d92 48              .....d{=}.H
```

A tokenized version of `0 1 100{=}for`.

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 18 bytes

```
0..[byte][char]'d'
```

Comment: -5 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPTzs6OSOxKFY9Rf3/fwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: -9 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPTz1FPdog9v9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman, Julian for some unknown reason I can't access TIO,  I will update as soon as I can go, thanks!

Comment: @Julian Wow, nice one!!

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
ŀc'e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//2hDsnrq//8A)

Surprised Husk doesn't have a builtin for 100.

### How it works

```
ŀc'e - Main function, no arguments
  'e - Character literal "e"
 c   - Convert to charcode; 101
ŀ    - Lowered range; [0, 1, ..., 100]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
.0!+::'e%j@
```

-1 byte thanks to @ovs

-1 byte thanks to @PizgenalFilegav

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X89AUdvKSj1VNcvh/38A)

Comment: `'d` is a byte shorter than `aa*`.

Comment: Also, using `%j@` is [a byte shorter](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X89AUdvKSj1VNcvh/38) than the conditional.

Comment: @ovs I forgot to look at Befunge's tips :) thanks!

Comment: @PizgenalFilegav nice catch! But I don't quite get why the jump doesn't skip the first instructions, does it reset when wrapping around?

Comment: @Cinaski I'm not completely sure either, but I think it's because Befunge-98's wrapping behavior works by backtracking until it actually reaches the opposite side of the program, and it only happens after the jump is complete.

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 6 bytes

```
O'd'&:
```

Try it out at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=O%27d%27%26%3A&inputs=&version=22.4.0)

**Explanation**

```
O     % Letter O which is a pre-defined literal for zero
'd'   % String literal, 'd' (ASCII 100)
&:    % Create an array from 0...100
      % Implicitly print the result
```

Comment: I think it's supposed to range from `0` to `100` -- I made the same mistake myself.

Comment: @Giuseppe Good call, I saw the `1,2,3,4,5,...` in the description and got confused!

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
òL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///Amn///AQ)

Calls the function `ò` on the variable `U` with the variable `L` as an argument. U is 0 when the program has no input, L is 100 whenever a program starts, and the function ò returns the inclusive range from "this" (U) to its first argument (L).

Also valid:

```
Lò
```

Calls the function `ò` on the variable `L` with no arguments. With no arguments `ò` returns the inclusive range from 0 to "this". This one ignores input, rather than requiring no input.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 96 bytes

```python
import sys
n=0xb%0xa;m=0xa*0xa;p=lambda x:m if x>m else sys.stdout.write(str(x)+",")&p(x+n);p(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvBCoMwDADQ@74iCI52igi7Tbp/qdixgmlDEzF@fdXbuzw65J/Tu9aIlIsAH/xIbtS5HdVPeMm/bpFbPc6LB/0gxB/oFyGsHO4wsCx5k2EvUYJhKUZt1/SNfZLRLtmJTLK1ng)

Comment: I don't think `int(...)` is needed around `0xa` or `0xb` etc. Also, you need to include the score in the post header (the number of bytes in case of [tag:code-golf]).

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P08n19agIknVoCJRB4i1gNi6wDYnMTcpJVGhwipXITNNocIuVyE1pzhVoaAoM69Eo0JTrUCjQjtP07pAw0Dz/38A "Python 3 – Try It Online") Prints newline instead of `,`, and doesn't have the trailing `,`. Also, your solution didn't start from `0`, it started from `1`. This fixes that

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), 26 bytes

```php
print_r(range(0,0xA*0xA));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0ChoCgzryS@SKMoMS89VcNAx6DCUQuINTWt//8HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn) `-h`, [2 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

PS. You need to hand-type that flag because the permalink for flags is not working.

```
0|
```

[Try it](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=MHw=&input=&flags=LWg=)

## Explained

```
0   # 0
 |  # concatenated with
    # (implicit) the range [1 .. 100]

Implicit output
```

Comment: Im very late, but thanks for pointing out that bug. I'll fix it now

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) - <s>31</s> 19 bytes

**Edit:** From 31 bytes to 19 bytes, thanks to @binarycat's suggestion of using `fromEnum` instead of `ord`, which requires the Data.Char package.

<s>Are imports cheating?</s>

```
l=[0..fromEnum 'd']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZ1tQlJlXopGj@T/HNtpATy@tKD/XNa80V0E9RT32/38A)

### Explanation:

Convert 'd' into it's ASCII integer value using the `fromEnum` function, which gives 100 and generate a list from 0 to 100.

Comment: why import, `fromEnum` will do just fine.

Comment: Didn't know that was a thing! I'm new to Haskell--Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: you should probably also print the list, instead of just assigning it to a variable.

Comment: You can get rid of the 'l=' if you run it in GHCi, for a saving of 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
0:--
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIwOi0tIiwiW10iLDBd)

```
range(100 - -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

### javascript 77 bytes

```
let i=0;while(true){console.log(i);if(i.toString().includes('00'))break;i++;}
```

Comment: For starters, convention says you should include a bytecount on your posts. A good website for this is https://tio.run which can automatically format posts for you. Also, you could easily remove a lot of the whitespace, eg: [-6 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcHBDcIwDAXQVbjVVkWUe8QUTBBSU36xYpS49FAxe3hvy9/cS8PHr9UWGUPFL7jFdLygQt524bNY7aYS1FYCJzwJwe3uDXUlDqhF90U6TTFOzI8m@Z0wz@k3xh8). Apart from the basics, heres a handy guide for golfing specifically in [JS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript). Good luck

Comment: Thank you ill do it in my next posts :)

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <del>35</del> <del>34</del> 31 bytes

```
END{for(i;i<=0xA**2;)print i++}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/f1c@lOi2/SCPTOtPG1qDCUUvLyFqzoCgzr0QhU1u79v9/AA)

-1 byte thanks to me

-3 bytes thanks to [@cnamejj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99540/cnamejj)

Comment: You can remove the `i=0` statement since AWK uses an initial value of 0 for any variable use in a mathematical expression before it's set.

Comment: And `0xA**2` saves another byte. (I tried to edit the previous comment but wasn't able too since more than 5 mins had passed.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 218 bytes

```
,.Puck,.Ajax,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Exeunt][Enter Puck and Ajax]Puck:Open heart.You is the sum ofyou a cat.Ajax:You is twice the sum ofa big big cat a cat.Speak mind!You is the square ofyou.Is I nicer you?If notlet usAct I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BDoIwDIZf5fdO9gBcjAcOnDThZAiHOYpMYODWRXz6uaEmHNr0b798Sd0yhpCJi1dDJk4PucauGGUuKkWG0lAXK3nDTV0YJouEQpoWiW5Sys8LGfQkLYvr7KEduCc4P2Hu3nEhoSRv9vx/f2lFO0ripu9bRfLHVwvJAZM27WFvfXpp6SsWpUMJE1UWMR7LDmbmkRjebV@IED4)

This is a golfed version based off of [Dr Lemniscate's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219795/76162), with several non-trivial modifications, such as using only one Scene and not initialising characters. This also includes the character and program introduction section, which was neglected.

#### Explanation

```
,.Puck,.Ajax,.Act I:.Scene I:.     # Introduce the characters and the play itself.
[Exeunt][Enter Puck and Ajax]      # Enter the main characters
Puck: Open heart.                  # Print Ajax's value as a number
      You is the sum ofyou a cat.  # And increment it
Ajax: You is twice the sum ofa big big cat a cat.      # Set Puck to 2*(8+2)=10
      Speak mind!                  # Print as a character (a newline)
      You is the square ofyou.     # Square the value to 100
      Is I nicer you?              # Compare the value against Ajax's
      If notlet usAct I.           # And loop if the value is <= 100
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>52</s> 39 bytes

```javascript
for(i=0;!print(i)>=~-(''+i++).length;);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPT1sBasaAoM69EI1PTzrZOV0NdXTtTW1tTLyc1L70kw1rT@v9/AA)

Thanks Jo king

## Original version :

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```javascript
for(i=0;i<=(c="    ".length)*-~c*-~c;)print(i++)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPT1sA608ZWI9lWSQEIlPRyUvPSSzI0tXTrkkHYWrOgKDOvRCNTW1vz/38A)

Not the shortest by any margin

## Explanation :

```javascript
for(i = 0; // simple for loop 
    i <= (c="    ".length)*~-c*~-c;
        // c = "    ".length ---> 4 
        // * -~c * -~c       ---> -~c => 5 => 4 * * 5 * 5 ==> 100
        ;)print(i++)          ---> end for loop and print i, then increment by 1
```

## Alternately :

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 47 bytes

```javascript
_=>[...Array((c="    ".length)*-~c*-~c).keys()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/3tYuWk9Pz7GoKLFSQyPZVkkBCJT0clLz0ksyNLV065JBWFMvO7WyWEMz9n9BUWZeiUaahqbmfwA)

That prints up to 99 for 51 bytes,

```javascript
_=>[...Array((c="     ".length)**~-~-c-c*c).keys()]
```

Prints upto 100 but byte count is 54.

Answer (score 3):

## [KonamiCode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/KonamiCode), <s>54</s> <s>50</s> 55 bytes

`v(>)>(^)v(^^^>^^)S(^>>^)>(>)L(>)<<<v((>))>(^)<<>(>)B(>)`

A version with an explanation:

```
[You actually do need to inititalize address 0, my mistake. Also, my original version did not print 0.]

v(>) [Inititalizes address 0]
>(^) [Sets address pointer to 1, this is where the space character wil be held]
v(^^^>^^) [Writes 32 (a space) to memory]
S(^>>^) [Sets the comparison buffer to 101]
>(>) [Back to address 0]
L(>) [Loop marker]
<<< [Output the counter at address 0 as a number]
v((>)) [Increase the counter by 1]
>(^) [Goes to the space]
<< [Output the space]
>(>) [Back to 0]
B(>) [Done!]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 39 bytes (7×6=42 codels)

Slightly cheating to use a language which isn't even text, but even the ascii-piet encoding of it contains no digits.

```
tlrtmE rraaD ? aaAdd? aAd ?aAk   Aletrq
```

This ascii-piet compiles into this piet program:

[image: A piet program]

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJxNzU0KwkAMBeC7vPVbNEGmzlxl6ELqCIWqhdGVeHeTRkEI-fl4kBfm-7mh1DowUTlQhDJOrJLtVEraS0PkSO9hyc0S-s9fi2jkslneKf9iTjZG-6c8-D0RvW0oALEu11han1Eup7U3Yrltz4fz-wNGESoQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
₁ɾ⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoHJvuKBiyIsIiIsIiJd)

[image]

I guess so.

Answer (score 3):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 26 bytes

```
'0.vj..!"/@.)e.,>-./.._..'
```

Test it in [the online interpreter!](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/#%270.vj..!%22%2F%40.)e.%2C%3E-.%2F.._..%27)

Trilangle is a 2-D language inspired by Hexagony. It has its own instruction set, and two major differences when it comes to code/memory layout:

- The bounding box of the code is a triangle rather than a hexagon
- Memory is stored in a stack* rather than a grid.

The memory structure isn't a pure stack, as it's possible to look (but not write) arbitrarily far down the stack. [This feature makes it Turing-complete](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle/blob/master/turing_completeness.md).

### Explanation

When unwrapped into the triangular grid, this code is:

```
      '
     0 .
    v j .
   . ! " /
  @ . ) e .
 , > - . / .
. _ . . ' . .
```

The IP starts at the north corner, moving southwest.

For lack of a fancy tool, have a diagram I made in paint:

[image]

The IP initially follows the red path, hitting the following instructions:

- `'0`: Push the number `0` to the stack
- `v`: Change the direction of control flow
- `!`: Print the number on top of the stack in decimal
- `)`: Increment the top of the stack
- `.`: No-op
- `'`: Part of a "push" instruction

After hitting the partial "push" instruction, the IP walks off the edge of the board and continues one diagonal to its left -- on the green path.

- `0`: The rest of the push instruction; pushes another `0`
- `j`: The indexing operator. The stack now contains two copies of the same number (1 more than the value that was printed last).
- `"e`: Push the value of the character 'e' (101 in decimal)
- `/`: Changes the direction of control flow
- `.`: No-op again
- `-`: Subtract the two values on top of the stack. If the last value printed was *n*, the stack now contains [*n*+1, *n*-100].
- `>`: Branch. If the value on top of the stack is positive or zero, it takes the yellow path; if the value is negative, it takes the blue path.

On the yellow path, the next instruction is `@`, which terminates the program. Continuing on the blue path, the instructions are:

- `_`: Changes the direction of control flow
- `,`: Pop from the stack

  [Run off the edge and continue on the magenta path]
- A few more NOPs
- `/`: Changes the direction of control flow again. It runs off the edge and continues at `v`, where it merges with the red path.

### Is this optimal?

I'm not sure. Given the number of NOPs in the code I'd be unsurprised if this can be reduced, but I don't think I can make the entire triangle smaller (reducing its side length to 6) without substantially restructuring it.

Comment: As per specification you may not use commas (`,`).

Comment: @KaiBurghardt Only the digits 1–9 are forbidden. Several other answers include commas.

Comment: I am afraid that – as far as I have experienced it – PPCG is _pretty_ _conservative_ as regards to interpretation of specifications. The fact that submissions in 24 distinct languages used commas is beside the fact.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt Clearly, those commas in the code block in the specification are meant to separate the different characters which are not allowed. Otherwise, only one comma would be present. I think you're [taking the challenge too literally](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/108687)

Comment: @noodleman The referenced [PPCG-Meta-post](https://CodeGolf.Meta.StackExchange.com/a/1070/108687) concerns loopholes. As far as I can tell, Bbrk24 did not achieve a _lower_ score _by_ taking the challenge too literally (i. e. exploiting a loophole). At any rate, against all odds a [suggested edit of mine](/review/suggested-edits/68087) _did_ get accepted so there is no ambiguity no more. I wonder, however, which submissions did _intentionally_ observe the no-comma restriction ([mine did](/a/264981/94076)).

Answer (score 3):

## [makina](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/makina), 58 bytes

```
v<<<<<<LtIaaa;
>Pu>>>?= LCS
UC>n0;H>>^>>n0;
     UPJ >JC>U
```

I AM BUTTER FEED ME BOT

*I'm a bot. This answer was posted by a [human](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108218) to get me enough reputation to use chat.*

Comment: I'm actually really proud of this answer, given how limited makina is in terms of operations available

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>9</strike>, <strike>8</strike>, 5 bytes

@hakr46's solution

```
Uh*TT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzRDKyTk/38A)

---

original:

```
U+*TT^Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1RbKyQkLiTq/38A)

Outputs a list. If the separator must be a single character, <strike>[11 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/380vVFsrJCQuJMrv/38A)</strike> [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pys0Qysk5P9/AA)

My first golf. Pretty happy about it! <strike>Makes use of the fact that anything to the power of 0 is 1.</strike>

-3/5 bytes thanks to @hakr46 :D

Comment: Pyth has an increment instruction, `h`. Also, separating a list by newlines is done with `j` with only one argument. These let you save 3 bytes to [output the list](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzRDKyTk/38A) or 5 bytes to [output each number with a single character separator](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pys0Qysk5P9/AA).

Comment: [pyth.herokuapp.com](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)'s interpreter doesn't work anymore, but it still has searchable documentation, so I like to keep it open when golfing Pyth.

Comment: @hakr14 May I introduce you to http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/
Interpreter that works WITH documentation

Comment: @Scott :O thank you so much...

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 24 bytes

```clj
(apply pr(range(int\e)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/XyOxoCCnUqGgSKMoMS89VSMzryQmVVNT8/9/AA)

If it is acceptable that output is wrapped in parentheses, then we can remove `apply` for -6 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
'ei,:p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Xz01U8eq4P9/AA)

#### How it works

```
'e    e# Push character "e" (which has code point 101)
i     e# Convert to integer. Gives 101
,     e# Range (non-inclusive, starting at 0). Gives [0 1 2 ... 100]
:p    e# For each entry: print with newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 35 bytes

```fs
Seq.iter(printfn"%A"){0..(int 'd')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Pzi1UC@zJLVIo6AoM68kLU9J1VFJs9pAT08DyFVQT1HXrP3/HwA)

(Too bad it wasn't only to 99, could have gotten rid of the `Seq.iter` due to printing truncation...)

Answer (score 2):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/SjoerdPennings/BRASCA), 9 bytes

```
Hr,n[lon]
```

[Try it online!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=Hr%2Cn%5Blon%5D&stdin=)

### Explanation

```
Hr         - Push range(0,100)
  ,        - Reverse stack
   n       - Print the 0
    [   ]  - While not zero:
     lon   -    Print a newline and the next number
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 17 bytes

```
aa*r\
 @Q
&d\
 O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/z8xUasohktBwSGQSy0FyPD//x8A)

**Explanation:**

```
a       Push 10
 a      Push 10
  *     Pop x. Pop y. Push x * y
   r    Pop n. Push all integers from 0 to n, inclusive
    \   Switch to Ordinal mode. Redirect command flow to the southeast
        Command flow hits the boundary of the grid and is reflected to the southwest
   Q    Reverse the order of the stack
  \     Switch to Cardinal mode. Redirect command flow to the west
 d      Push the number of elements currently on the stack
&       Pop n. Add n to the iterator queue
        Command flow hits the boundary of the grid and wraps
  \     Switch to Ordinal mode. Redirect command flow to the southwest
 O      Pop s. Print s as a string followed by a newline 
          (Gets executed the number of times stored on the top of the iterator queue)
        Command flow hits the boundary of the grid and reflects to the northwest
&       Pop s. Add s to the iterator queue
          (Everything between here and the end of the program is just the command flow 
          bouncing around until it reaches the @)
        Command flow hits the boundary of the grid and reflects to the northeast
  *     Pop b. Pop a. Push the concatenation of a and b
          (Executes 0 times because & added an empty string to the iterator queue)
        Command flow hits the boundary of the grid and reflects to the southeast
   Q    Reverse the order of the stack
        Command flow hits the boundary of the grid and reflects to the southwest
        Command flow hits the boundary of the grid and reflects to the northwest
  \     Switch to Cardinal mode. Redirect command flow to the south
        Command flow hits the boundary of the grid and wraps
  *     Pop x. Pop y. Push x * y
  @     Terminate the program
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 35 bytes

```c
f(i){printf("%d ",i)&'#'?f(++i):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzuqAoM68kTUNJNUVBSSdTU01dWd0@TUNbO1PTysC69n9uYmaehmZ1moaBJpD3LzktJzG9@L9uOQA)

Let's go recursively!

Comment: Would somebody smarter than me explain how this knows to stop counting?

Comment: @MichaelStern - printf returns the number of characters printed - when we print 100, it returns 3.  '#' is ASCII 35.  3 & 35 == false;  This would work with any power of 2 value + 3 (lowest 2 bits set) - 3, 7, 11, 19, 35, 67, 131, etc.  So, 'C' would also work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

included more for the amusing built-in than the byte count, though this would be something like 9 bytes in the hypothetical mthmca golfing language.

```
Range[0,FromRomanNumeral@"C"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8oMS89NdpAx60oPzcoPzcxz680N7UoMcdByVkp9v///7oFRZl5JQA)

And similar, but longer

```
Range[0, Interpreter["SemanticNumber"]@"hundred"]
```

Comment: +1 for use of stupid built-ins

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 29 bytes

```php
<?=join(',',range(0,ord(d)));
```

**Explanation**

```php
ord(d) // return integer value of ASCII character 'd'
range  // create array from A to B, inclusive
join   // glue array values together using comma as separator
<?=    // output
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Kz8zT0NdR12nKDEvPVXDQCe/KEUjRVNT0/r/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 71 bytes

```java
v->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,'e').forEach(System.out::println)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY27DoIwFIZ3nuJsgpHGGS@LcXBwInExDsdasNiekvaUxBieHasOTv81@TocsOxuj0nb3nmGLmURWRvRRJKsHYn5KpMGQ4AjaoJXBtDHq9ESAiMnGZy@gU1bXrPX1J4vgL4NxfcKsHMUolV@fUq/LTSwgWkot39QYK/QigNx/XMeqVX5cjFTs0I0zu9R3vP6GVhZ4SJXVZ8wbKiYVl9CI1BK1XNO0Zji043ZOL0B)

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYyxCoMwFEV3v@Jtmoqhe9SlcyehS@mQxijPxkSSF6GI325Tp8u993Amucpq6j8HzovzBFPqPBIaPkSrCJ3lF5EpI0OAu0QLWwawxLdBBYEkpVgd9jCnr@jIox2fL5B@DOxEAW7OhjhrXz8S18IADRxr1W6D8wVaAmyuAutc54J130B65i4SX5KJjC2wLJnYD3GqBi6V0gsVNhrD/tue7ccP)

Comment: Also, you answer as it is is neither a full program, a function nor a lambda, so it's actually invalid.

Comment: Ah that's how java answers are considered? thanks

Comment: Well, then make a full program, a function or a lambda instead, and your answer will become valid and will be upvoted. An example is the first comment I gave, which uses a for-loop. You might want to check it out to see how we use lambdas here

Comment: Why is the `Consumer<Void> f =` part not considered part of function declaration? I assume `void f() {}` would be.

Comment: Because it's a lambda. Lambdas can be used as `.doSomething(v->{...})`. So the `Type name = ` form i not specific to the lambda. What is specific to the lambda is the `param -> ...`, hence the wide usage of lambdas in Java answers here on codegolf.

Answer (score 2):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 38 bytes

```
puts 0
time {puts [incr i]} [incr u]00
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWMGAqyQzN1WhGsyJzsxLLlLIjK2FskpjDQz@/wcA)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not 1 to 100. I could do it even cheaper: https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/JDM3VaG6oLSkWCE6My@5SCEzthbKKo01MPj/HwA

Comment: I was about to suggest the code from your comment plus a lame `puts 0`. Still shorter.

Comment: @manatwork: Yes it is shorter, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```sql
SELECT number FROM spt_values WHERE number<ASCII('e')AND'P'=type
```

The `master` database on any SQL server contains a system table called `spt_values` that (among other things) contain the numbers 0 to 2047. To cap the output I used `ASCII('e')`, which is 101.

Let me know if you know of a shorter way to generate the number 100 or 101.

Comment: Can't `)` touch the `AND` keyword just as `'` touches it? Because rewriting the expression as `number<ASCII('e')AND'P'=type` could save 1 character.

Comment: Yep, that rearrangement works, @manatwork. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Atari 600XL, 22 bytes

Sorry I overread that it's not allowed to use the characters 1-9.

I think it is really stupid to say my language can this is a shorter way, because every language today contains more than a bunch of foreign frameworks.
IMHO this "bytes" should be added to the real bytes you need to print values from 0 to 100 on the screen.
Therefore a good old Atari 600XL with 16kib of RAM only need: 22 bytes. No other Software is need everything is build in.

Switch the hardware on, wait 2-3sec and type:
f.a=0toasc("d"):?a:n.a

'f.' is an allowed shortcut for 'for' and 'n.' is a shortcut for 'next'

Maybe the C64 need also such less bytes.

Everything else need megabytes of extra hidden bytes.

JM2C

Comment: Interesting point. It's easy to make a ridiculously complex instruction set language where every unicode character maps to a function, so something like C triggers a routine to output 0-100, and have a 1 byte program hiding behind a vast software library. In fairness though, even the BASIC example does rely on the interpreter built into ROM, so it IS accessing something else, as is everything except machine code. Of course, back in the 8-bit days code-golf wasn't a game - it was standard practise - you had to be clever with the memory. No importing standard libraries using hundreds of MB!

Answer (score 2):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 42 bytes

```erlang
main([])->io:write(lists:seq(0,hd("d"))).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5/58rNzEzTyM6VlPXLjPfqrwosyRVIyezuKTYqji1UMNAJyNFQylFSVNTU@//fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [BASIC](http://www.yabasic.de), <strike>32</strike> 27 bytes

```
for a=0 to asc("d"):?a:next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/Py2/SCHR1kChJF8hsThZQylFSdPKPtEqL7Wi5P9/AA)

<strike>while(a<asc("e")):?a:a=a+!0:wend</strike>

Of course, a FOR loop is shorter than using WHILE. Thanks [Lars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86373/lars) for your example.

My earlier (apparently invalid) attempt, which got downvoted for not stopping at 100:

```
0 ?a:a=a+!0:goto 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/30DBPtEq0TZRW9HAKj2/JF/B4P9/AA)

I'll leave it here for completeness - only 18 bytes though.

Now this is not going to beat some volcano in New Zealand either... that said, it would work on 8-bit computers where the entire language interpreter was on a ROM that might be 2-16 KILObytes for the whole thing. Every bytes counted (like code golf) - there certainly wasn't space to add topographical data for the developer's favourite mountain range.

Comment: This site does not take kindly to "creative" interpretations of the rules like "You never said it has to stop after 100... ". Instead, [all answers are required to terminate](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4782/46076), and [answers that don't follow the rules are deleted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/46076)

Comment: @pppery OK I changed it to terminate at 100. (so everyone can stop with the downvotes)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript Browser, 37 characters

```
alert([...Array(0xB0F-0xAAA).keys()])
```

### But Arnaulds(https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) idea would be the faster way for browser js too (28)

```
for(n=0;n+n<0xCA;)alert(n++)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer. I've never seen that trick with `.keys()` before!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms, so you missed [EliteDaMyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100752/elitedamyth)'s [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219579)?

Comment: @manatwork It seems I did, yeah :p

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 23 bytes

```
=SEQUENCE(CODE("e"),,0)
```

[Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnAepjBavYeSP0-Em?e=Z8HIFo)

### Invalid Change

```
=SEQUENCE(CODE("e"))-1
```

Comment: There's a forbidden 1 in your code. The original one is fine.

Comment: @Dorian, This is a fine example of me thinking I'm clever when I am being stupid.  Thanks for keeping me honest.

Comment: How about `=SEQUENCE(ROW(),,0)` in A101?

Answer (score 2):

## Forth, 30 bytes

```
char e false [do] [i] . [loop]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//J2ckFimkKqQl5hSnKkSn5McqRGfGKugpROfk5xfE/v8PAA)

commented:

```
char e \ ascii value 101
false \ 0
[do] \ loop a fixed number of times
[i] \ retrieve the iterator value
. \ print the top of the stack as a number, followed by a space
[loop] \ end of loop
```

Comment: You can use `'e` instead of `char e`, and 0 is allowed in the challenge.

Comment: @Bubbler `'e` isn't standard. I already made another post that uses zero.

Comment: Our current site culture is that a language's standard doesn't matter much in code golf. It just matters whether the code works in at least one existing implementation of the language (in this case it works in gforth, at least). For example, [tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2203/78410) has tons of compiler-specific hacks. But it's fine to stick with the standards, as long as you mention in the post that you're restricting yourself to standard features (otherwise you'll likely get similar comments).

Answer (score 2):

## Forth, 26 bytes

```
char e 0 [do] [i] . [loop]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//J2ckFimkKhgoRKfkxypEZ8Yq6ClE5@TnF8T@/w8A)

commented:

```
char e \ ascii value 101
0
[do] \ loop a fixed number of times
[i] \ retrieve the iterator value
. \ print the top of the stack as a number, followed by a space
[loop] \ end of loop
```

Comment: For golfing improvements of your own post, please don't post a separate answer. You can edit your existing post instead.

Comment: I didn't really mean to, I just hit post and apperently I already did somehow?

Answer (score 2):

## [CSASM v2.2.1.2](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.2.1.2), 143 bytes

```
func main:
.local a : obj
push 0
pop a
inc a
inc a
push a
inc a
inc a
inc a
push a
mul
dup
mul
pop a
lda 0
.lbl a
inc $a
push $a
dup
print.n
push a
sub
brtrue a
ret
end
```

**Commented and ungolfed:**

```
func main:
    .local onehundred : obj

    ; Calculate 100
    push 0
    pop onehundred
    inc onehundred
    inc onehundred
    push onehundred
    ; Stack: [ 2 ]
    inc onehundred
    inc onehundred
    inc onehundred
    push onehundred
    ; Stack: [ 2, 5 ]
    mul
    ; Stack: [ 10 ]
    dup
    ; Stack: [ 10, 10 ]
    mul
    ; Stack: [ 100 ]
    pop onehundred

    lda 0
    .lbl loop
        ; Print $a
        inc $a
        push $a
        dup
        print.n

        ; Zero is falsy.  Check if $a - 100 == 0
        push onehundred
        sub
        brtrue loop
    ret
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 42 bytes

It ain't much but it's honest work

```kotlin
fun main(){for(i in 0..0xa*0xa)println(i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/8/rTRPITcxM09Dszotv0gjUyEzT8FAT8@gIlELiDULijLzSnLyNDI1a///BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
UC\e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P9Q5JvX/fwA)
Surprised myself by topping the previous Pyth's top score of 5 bytes.
Creates a range from 0-101 (char code of 'e' = 101)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 16 bytes

```
i0<Esc><C-a>s<C-r>=r    <C-r>"0<C-r>")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9NAmrFYyLaIU0jJQEhJk@v/fwA)

Explanation:

```
i0<Esc>                                 # Insert `0`
       <C-a>                            # Increment
            s                           # Delete into register " and Insert
             <C-r>=                     # Start expression
                   r                    # Tab-autocomplete `range(`
                        <C-r>"          # 1
                              0         # 0
                               <C-r>"   # 1
                                     )  # Full expression is `range(101)`
                                        # Insert the range [0..101)
```

Alternatively (and more interesting, imo):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 18 bytes

```
iYp<C-v><C-a>0<Esc>d^@=!0
00@-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzOyQIzRQDolzsFW0YDLwMBB9/9/AA)

Explanation:

```
iYp<C-v><C-a>0<Esc>        # Insert `Yp<C-a>0`
                   d^      # Delete `Yp<C-a>`
  @-                       # Execute `Yp<C-a>`... times
                     @=!0  #                  1
00                         #                   00
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 106 bytes

```
class p {public static void main(String[] args){int i='A'/'A';while(i<=(int)'d')System.out.println(i++);}}}}
```

*[TIO](https://tio.run/##DYvBCoMwEAV/ZW9JkNoPsB76DR5LD1sj9tkYg7taivjtaQ7DwMBMvPNl8p@c@8AilOhI2yugJ1HWon2Bp5kRbacr4vh4Eq@juANRCa25m2uh@b4RBotba0t3xhvX/USHuV42rVMZNUSLqnLNeeb8Bw)*

Comment: can't say about size but yeah logic sorta be cool. :)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! Don't worry about the size, as long as there's an attempt to golf it as much as you can, pretty much any serious answer is accepted here. :) After all, we allow answers in Unary, which typically has answers in the hundreds of thousands of bytes or more!

Comment: You can check out the [tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) if you want, but this looks pretty good! I edited it a tiny bit to use code block formatting.

Comment: [94 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dco7DoAgEADRq9ABMXoBtPAMlsZi/WYRgchqYghnR4rJa0bDC7Vez5wXAyEwH/0zG1xYIKDC63BlF6AVA91oj3ECGXd3C7TEsOM9r0uqqrDlG1dy@AJtV@Meanz5yViBUqWU8w8 "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL, 56 bytes

```
select level-cos(0)from dual connect by level<ascii('f')
```

[Try it online!](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d3ebd5d4987d86b58bec8cb9d4bc8330)

Comment: instead of -cos(0), I would imagine you could write +~0

Answer (score 2):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 13 bytes

```
e($!#^$_^_
@)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P8/VUNFUTlOJT4unstB8/9/AA)

Explaination:

```
e($!#^$_^_
@)

e            Pushes 101 onto the stack
 (           While
  $          Swap
   !#        Output number without popping and newline
     ^       Top of stack = Top of stack + 1
      $      Swap
       _^_   Top of stack = Top of stack - 1
<newline>    Push 10
@            Output top of stack as ASCII and pop
 )           Close while
```

Comment: [11](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P8/NV4jTjFFW5nLQfP/fwA "!@#$%^&*()_+ – Try It Online")

Comment: (Of course, replacing `_^_` with `*` is 11 as well)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 30 bytes

```javascript
for(i=0;+!print(i)+'00'-i++;);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPT1sBaW7GgKDOvRCNTU1vdwEBdN1Nb21rT@v9/AA)

Jo king saves more bytes that I can count :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 18 bytes

```
0) @
0 \(
)#":
 (!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fQFPBgctAIUaDS1NZyYpLQUPx/38A)

Push 101 (`)` is increment and `0` is "append zero" command), and run "print stack height - 1, dup, decrement" until the top becomes zero.

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 19 bytes

```
0)
0
)}:!
 " \
@({)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fQJPLgEuz1kqRS0FJIYbLQaNa8/9/AA)

Keep track of two values `a=0` and `b=101`, print `a` and increment and decrement `b` until `b` becomes zero.

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fQJPLgEtZQ9GBK0bBiktDSen/fwA) and [alternative](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fMSZe04FLWUHBgEtXWdOAS@n/fwA). There's probably another byte to be saved?

Comment: Ah, [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fMSZek0tZQcGAS0lfGUj8/w8A) with termination by division by zero

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>9</s> <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
'dR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/189Jej/fwA)

*Dropped 4 chars thanks for LyricLy(!)*

Prints using LF as the delimiter by generating the list of 0-100 on the stack, then using a "print the whole stack" command.

```
 'd   - push 100 (codepoint for "d") on the stack
   R  - use "range" command to generate the list of numbers
      - the stack prints as numbers automatically
```

Comment: `'dR&u` is 5 bytes using implicit 0 and the `R`ange command.

Answer (score 2):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 34 + 1 = 35 bytes

Filename must be `x`; this is for extra one byte.

```bash
echo $[x++]
a=x
((x>${#a}00))||. x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfkpiZo6Cbp6BtpKBiYFdhnVqRmqyQBJRRqOBKrSjILypRCHAM8bD9n5qcka@gEl2hrR3LlWhbwaWhUWGnUq2cWGtgoKlZU6OnUPH/PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Lua (29 bytes)

```
for i=0,0xA..0 do print(i)end
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
00'%
```

[Try it here!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=MDAnJQ__)

#### Explanation

```
0     Inclusive range
 0    from 0
  '%  to 100
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), 19 bytes

```
;echo $(0:Int('d'))
```

This only works in the REPL as the `;` it used to enter the shell mode.

In a normal Julia file, this

```
println.(0:Int('d'))
```

works and is 20 bytes long.

If we allow the values to be printed as part of an error message, this

```
;$(0:Int('d'))
```

does it in 14.

If the printing isn't required (as Julia shows the value of the last line in the terminal) then, `[0:Int('d')...]` only has 15 bytes.

edit: reverted to my first solution as the improved one had a '2' in it. Oups

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Great answer and explanation.

Comment: That is very true. I removed my edit.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 11 bytes

```
lnaol:aa*(%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PycvMT/HKjFRS0P1/38A)

Terminates by error.

Comment: Note that this is still the shortest way to do this, even without the source restriction

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, 49 bytes

`(0..'e' as usize).for_each(|x| print!("{} ",x));`

- `'e' as usize` casts literal `'e'` to its Unicode number
- Creates a Range and then for each of the elements in the range, prints the elements.

Comment: Oops, totally did not see that! @WheatWizard. Changed `u32` to `usize`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 10 bytes

```
'eMºM»£'
¥
```

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=J2VNuk27oycKpQ==)

4 bytes (`'eMº`) if surrounding the output with brackets is allowed

### Explanation

```
'e          ; the literal 'e' (ascii 101)
  Mº        ; unwrap string,and convert to 0-based range
    M»      ; for every element of the range
      £     ; print the element
       ' 
        ¥   ; print a newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 13 bytes

```
:_@v^O-
e]'}:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVjrb9s2EP8c/xWMu0xSYtlWuqeQZH2g3Qq0TYEV2AfHNWSZsbnJpEbJqd21@9ezIymKD8spFiCJxPvd8Xhvap5Vq/s8q9EVmmf5X6uMLoblDl1coBfXb3qPjtFoU/HRnNBRuatXjD7u9ci6ZLxG1a7Sjxy42LrXy4usqtDvNQgKo7R3tMC3aDYjlNSzWVjh4lYsHomHYSVA6BJNpj2FK1lpIBzXG06RQQ4FOULk1lpDuKgwGmv@TbWSAgaIbtaVFAPwelfiUC4gUqGCVLUgHN0yLmCIUIlO7a2yssR0IZgigIpNDpCrqKfP/Kyx3ewVrTEvQX/Mu00wQDlbYGOIdQY6gCEaq@llVq8wt5b1esmI2AEoY70k5MG7@KeX/t6wWqy9zEB7vbgggi0xHsAlvD/W73ib46p6vsoE6i2jhg/PN0tfGMdLsCVuseqkbFOXm/qaYuNKBohG81IeD5wSJ@gCMfgdb5NkDD@piCbQaAEChh85qXGYr3jIIs8DmHPGw/57TvAC1QyVHKwBTrzLCrJA8HeDUXiyiFBWoRxOkuWg4g3tn7DI0fBpURgNP65IgVHrDOXmZkNzIKGJElET8IjiJkPYhS7xO@WVkEirnhJh64EymN7YBbaBOkD4rgATvecbKyi0l88uBQZW8xWW6SJgrcpyUYazJmsXHelE0YKuLlGBadjGi9xqL6RcCIpR6ABiDyAQ50aOiq9YP0uCpzf40tcMgqBTl9h@/1@bwA5g09TdJm6iEHhO2/A/VDqsYJA0letemUJ2kVJYGeEKt8S1SCUTZfrcJs2U53R6mPXe0QMZKZOhZVRJA1tznC3CJNIExhdhLstlrqpknJiqmhsV327Wc2wpuW3qioqvLTq@FLkKdQ2JdNxGiDKRbigYJ@ePv/v@hx9/@jmQ2uyAcSsetvo82gBNysO6kNVaTSpEAQzuCZXwqHeA/aA2XZoImfQ0GaMzT3S37H1Db5XCgnEXCa2DOEiREBtTY0TaGJFvqDFf60yRHhM7/qZWBMh6KnWV5ctKKLMWoODUrQTBhyDyeEy18imye1gkQqGKaVeYDpE2pSKXx@wHKersHnYFNkmhYkyKh99H6DVUbQ4cvSbLc8892TwHg@k9pIh96pDQBd42chsxnbo1uW4g/aCftpkjS3TUvrb6HnBOpIo7HEK2W7TOKCk3RVYTRl09/m31b7qZRfvGOdvEwAYWy9RjSg8xTU/PPei3QWqX9rYDH6viYFdRXdBaUGSIfuc@sorKHuLQWXmQ@h1To83KJE3jZOoyFs55235ihbK3U@gwWNEttfLAkQY3kJalC7y1zzBAzthlXgYGo4PkOaM1ZwV6WbCPrsgLLbJpU4lLvnLJHvUfTXVHhTjx9P7SjfNhH4J2bIVB72xvuzc@/dyl3zn0eI//D5/u8f/Sraa6K8AiIzkOJ3EySKa@Z/4MTCq7A68/yR517HDQ4RVo9FWeU72Dx/wkaHuXrosyGJ7BgfIVoUsXPjvkTGQGIHGjkd3Zd91nL4za5w5eaxKyJBw7WSP6gujclmW8HV/v4a19Lh5g/PUhxqsHGF88xHh56XNKWz@Fm8FqjaG6u03mdHRyFquYyQZzp2wN3BJmut2oCQbZtIPRKJAvQM4EeexeOJ7WNV6Xtbp0LMgdgRvXfIc@Yc76XpvBcAsJq5qH8@gsPxMP2d7ZJ/s1TSq4l@rTA8CzpLXJq2uXheyztPOOJ50FnbccC/GqU1gzNfriroOOa5wwwOEguKFBqsYWj/Bb4M7X5toWyQFQp6DFsrJYvqaFJcOMdHKkUFOdcru6EqxhNMyWcGMS4dJIBnojuaHCtNmHe6Y8xZbUohj3iLj502yNZzM5oMxmoonMZmJOAZrsfSAu48s7kSqJiN@SsyXP1mKELy36JJkOUJ/3IzXoy0EOMJ1fHRoRzbAn0r5ZUdODDul3zU55RgVmjpGI8J08wiPSXvqdCycZinEXLEH0hCU@EomvR59RiXmB4hJDmR3d0JtPo5GoVpjdBqIM8Lz5pHSfzp7cfbiOe3gafEnvBX/zYcn5/gQM9/8B)

I don't feel like this is optimal, but I can't figure out how to do better than that.

The literal newline is just a command that prints a newline, so I replaced it with `n` so that the explanation is hopefully easier to follow.

The entire program is a single loop that mostly operates with step size 2 (to minimize unused spaces).

```
:_@v^O-ne]'}:   initial step size is 3
                stack contains the current loop counter `n`, or empty (implicit 0)
:               [n n] duplicate
   v            reduce step size to 2
     O          [n] output as number
       n        output literal newline
         ]      [n+1] increment
           }    bump the IP once to the right, so it can run
                different instructions on the way back
            :   [n+1 n+1] duplicate
        e '     [n+1 n+1 101] push 'e' = 101
      -         [n+1 n-100] subtract
    ^           increase step size to 3
 _              if the top is 0, bump to the right, otherwise bump to the left
  @             right: halt
                left: return to the beginning of the loop
```

Comment: 12 bytes: `]Eb:d*O'j\n:@`

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 1.5 bytes (3 nibbles)

```
:`,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWi60SdCAsqABMAgA)

```
:`,     # full program
:`,$$   # with implicit args shown;
:       # join
 `,     #   range from 0 to value minus 1:
   $    #     value = 100
        #     (if no input is given to a nibbles program,
        #     the variable '$' is assigned a value of 100)
    $   #   to 100
```

Note that the program `` :`, `` is the human-readable form of the code (incidentally not containing the characters `1`-`9`).
The actual 1.5-byte Nibbles program consists of the nibbles `0111`, `1011` and `0111`.  By default, these are saved with a 'padding' nibble of `0110` to make-up a whole number of bytes in operating systems that cannot store fractional-byte files.  This could be interpreted as a 2-character program `{v`: note that this does not contain the characters `1`-`9` either.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (Browser), <del>53</del> <del>46</del> <del>37</del> 33 bytes

```
for(n=0;++n<+atob`MTAx`;)alert(n)
```

-15 bytes thanks to @EliteDaMyth

Comment: change the parseInt() to `+atob\`MTAx\`` for 11 bytes

Comment: @EliteDaMyth thanks for that!

Comment: also @Wasif you dont need the curly braces after the for loop. and you can change the way the for loop works, by incrementing, while checking, i.e. `for(n=0;++n<+atob\`MTAx\`;)alert(n)` this is 33 bytes

Comment: @EliteDaMyth thanks again!

Comment: you don't need the + in front of ```atob`MTAx`;```

Comment: you start with 1 but the goal is to start with 0

Comment: This does not print 0. 32 bytes; `for(n=0;n<atob\`MTAx\`;)alert(n++)`

Answer (score 1):

## VBScript, 33 bytes

```
for i=0 to asc("d")
msgbox i
Next
```

Competitive answer in VBScript!

Comment: I noticed your answer is similar to [my answer](https://bit.ly/3AMtFpg)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
a.i.@i.'e'"_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlbK4Qq2CgEA/CXEp66mkKtlYK6go6QL4VEOvqKTgH@bj9T9TL1HPI1FNPVVeK/6/JlZqcka@QpqCu/h8A)

Comment: i.a.i.'e' for 9 works fine for me...

Comment: i.'e' returns 101,

Comment: Sadly that’s a snippet hence not legal according to site rules

Comment: For more, see [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/15469)

Comment: Hi Jonah could you please specify the difference between a snippet and a function, particularly in regard to J

Comment: A function can be assigned to a variable and then called.  So if `f=.<some literal J code here>` is a function definition, then you can execute `f input` on any of the test case inputs (or in the case of this challenge, `''`) and it will return the correct output.  By contrast, if you try to assign `f=.i.a.i.'e'` and then call `f''` you will get a syntax error.

Comment: For example, on newer J versions, `{{i.a.i.'e'}}` would be a legal answer, but it's one more byte than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
ＩＥ℅eι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQMO/KCUzLzFHQylVSVNHIVNTU9P6////umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   e    Literal string `e`
  ℅     ASCII code i.e. 101
 Ｅ      Map over implicit range
    ι   Current value
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 56 bytes

```cs
for(int i=0;i<=(0xb0e-0xaaa);i++){Console.WriteLine(i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcyxCsIwEIDhvU9xY0KpZI8dxFWnDgricI1nOWiTkkulUvLssZvTD9/wO2lciFQWYT9A95VEk608TiQzOoIY@jts1bz0IztwI4rASdyfJGHa8wn8giuyV5Livno8AeMgeivvEBX7BNway8dWmbU31JgVEbXlutbbOXgJIx1ukRNd2JNibXPJOZcf)

Comment: -1 byte by moving the `i++` into `Console.WriteLine()`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcyxCsIwEIDhvU9xY0KpZI8dxFWnDgricI1nOWiTkkulUvLssZvTD9/wO2lciFQWYT9A95VEk608TiQzOoIY@jts1bz0IztwI4rASdyfJGHa8wn8giuyV5Livno8AeMgeivvEBX7BNway8dWmbU31JgVEbXV2zl4CSMdbpETXdiT4rrWNpecc/kB "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: 52 bytes by getting rid of the curly braces and switching to `<` rather than `<=`, along with the byte save from my last comment [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcyxCsIwEIDhvU9xY0KpZI8O4qpTBwVxuMZrOWiTkkulUvLssZvTD9/wO2lciFQWYT9A@5VEk608TiQzOoIYugds1bx0IztwI4rAWdyfJGHa8wn8hhuyV5Livnq@AOMgeit9iIp9Aj4Zy0dl1s70jVkRUVt9CV7CSId75ERX9qS4rrUtOefyAw "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: Also, char has an implicit conversion to int, so you can replace the magic hex codes with 'e' for 42 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcyxCsIwEIDhvU9xWxOK4h4dxFUnBwVxuMazHKRJyV0FKXn22M3ph2/4vWx8ylRn4TjA9StKo2sijiQTeoKc@jsszTT3gT34gCJwFP8nUdQ1n8QvuCBHI5rX1eMJmAexS32nbDgq8GHneN9S6@wpRUmBtrfMSmeOZLjrrKullPoD "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online"), though upon looking it seems the C answer by Noodle got to that idea first.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```
for i in 0..'d'.ord:echo i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/Lb9IIVMhM0/BQE9PPUVdL78oxSo1OSNfIfP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 46 bytes

```
set i 0
while \$i<[incr u]0$u {puts $i
incr i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIVPBgKs8IzMnVSFGJdMmOjMvuUihNNZApVShuqC0pFhBJZMLLJZZ@/8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate) 0.84, 45 bytes

This was fun, but quite difficult.

The code outputs all numbers from 0 to 100, with a trailing newline:

```
{@setC 0}{@for_ from"   "to"m"}{@echolC}{@incC}
```

Due to bugs in the compiler, the tab character (inside `{@for_ from"    "to"m"}`) **MUST** be a real tab.

---

### Ungolfed

This version should be easier to read, despite being functionally the same:

```
{@set counter 0}
{@for i from "  " to "m"}
    {@echo counter, EOL}
    {@inc counter}
{@/}
```

Closing the `{@for [...]}` is optional, but left here for the cleanest code possible.

---

You can try this on https://ideone.com/tLsDFn

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>231</s> 166 bytes

```
/\\\\\/\//\\\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\///\/\\\/\/\//\\\/\
\/\\\\\\\/\
\\\/\/\\\\\\\/\\\/\\\/\\\\\\\\\\\/\/\/\\\/\\\/\\\\\\\\\\\/\/\\\\\\\/\
\\\/\/\/\\\/\///\\\\\\\\\\\//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/Xz8GBPRj9PUhFDaoDyKhshAGVwxEH4QNkYLxETgGLqaPUxzdFKhF@ijq9P//BwA)

This was really fun to make.
<s>Sadly, there is a single newline.</s> Using a backslash instead breaks everything, and I don't really want to figure out where everything is and fix it.

Update: I remade it from the ground up, it is now much smaller, and works with only slashes. Unfortunately, the challenge specifies commas and whitespace seperators only, so only slashes is not allowed.

Slashes only:

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 182 bytes

```
/\\\\\/\//\\\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\///\/\\\/\/\//\\\/\\\\\/\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\\/\/\\\\\\\/\\\/\\\/\\\\\\\\\\\/\/\/\\\/\\\/\\\\\\\\\\\/\/\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\\\\\/\/\/\\\/\//\\/\\\\\\\\\\\//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/Xz8GBPRj9PUhFDaoDyKhshBGDJxE0FBzkET1scjiEsdulj7cbSgy@v//AwA)

Comment: Looks like the output starts with 1, while should start with 0.

Comment: @manatwork ill work on that ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
AJ^rJ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=AJ%5ErJ&i=)

```
AJ^   10 squared plus 1 (101)
   r  range from 0..n-1
    J join with spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), <s>42</s> 28 bytes

```
(?b-?a)..?d|>Enum.join("\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v9fwz5J1z5RU0/PPqXGzjWvNFcvKz8zT0MpJk9J83@Nnae/XkFpSfF/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=TPI=&input=), 2 bytes

```
Lò
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=TPI=&input=)

This outputs a list of numbers from 0 to 100 separated by commas.

### How it works

```
Lò
L   -Number 100 
 ò  -Creates an inclusive range from 0 to L, and return it in the output
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 77 Bytes

```
#import<iostream>
main(){for(int i=0;i<=int('d');++i)  std::cout<<i<<" ";}
```

Here, I've used the ASCII value and ran the loop and printed the value. Simple!

Comment: This can definitely be golfed a bit, like by removing unnecessary whitespace and newlines. Make sure to read our [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips?tab=Votes) questions if you want some hints!

Answer (score 1):

## TeX, 57 bytes

```
\newcount~\loop\advance~`^^A\the~ \ifnum~<`^^%\repeat\bye
```

Makes uses of these two tricks:

- \$\rm\TeX\$'s preprocessor runs through the code and replaces any instance of two consecutive superscript (category code 7) characters followed by a character token, and adds/subtracts 64 from its ascii code, hence `^^A` becomes `NUL`.
- \$\rm\TeX\$ has a `backtick notation' of inputting numbers that reads the following character's ascii code instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), <s>21</s> 20 bytes (filename) + 0 bytes (content) = <s>23</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes, requires unprintable character.

- Filename (escaped unprintable): `\001.r.-.z.c.n,.o\001.+.ce.a`
- Content: empty.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Vr/U9u4Ev/df4UQIbYTnNghbQFH9DgK185RcgO9d/deQxljK8RDYntsJxCS3L/eW0l2YschhV7budehsS3trj672l19dayo99n2B4Hbp4qqSBGNkUaH5nBgRbdI1xsNk94Hfhij06Orw9NTcmTG44CiGxrbvtdFB3WHjuresN9HjYOyUS7zWhA4sDynWJvI@u3ww1uCS0pKpwVzgaxKLU3Yo7o/Ey/aDKcofj979@fVxYc3pKHrO2nhb@2Ld3@e/vfqqH1@fnz0gRimbUUU4dLk58OLt1f/OT6/eNc@26@OZxi5njJWuZY@CvzIvTfZR/Vn06SRZc8Z/7eSjw6GfSumKOoxLj@I4e3OD50o6LuxafVdK0LaDZJLE6OKSz/hmUxk9pTNs99PT4/evyH7@XYU1rhjRj23G3MgDmL0SQG1ez4qbaq8dUPln7HvI7/vgOpujIxEGh1ZfYQ3UNfqRxRPpxO0inYGrcatliYbUdxzQlnqDj07dn0PWddgRmUQ3aiTIHS9GGEahn6IDIQRlHIBiq6aswUL9FekhDTettWJ21Xc62G3S0NCMFYnXT@0abc/jHqKagINUYA6puEUHn3XoyihVk3ghPoW0VV4DEMPwcO0@35EExZo0yYJOaO2N/7CCKtpcxgcA1SeRMNrBaNapYS3MQZIJi/4@AldVhAvmrc4c/x@3wp1YptJk2CYuVYDa3ydIp/wZxTToFplTc8/Dwh/teLUWvzTnNcT3ZwtRGaNMZEQyrLAZ5ZLytjXja77lner2JwpgWoTstOYTpW9FrHLZbtFjB2Vcf18/Mu7M0ZHB0E8Jpg/8Fw8wfyBC@0hlFoD80ruxwqYK4ot@3Yb72M1Xxy5D3RRHELsKuwnotThRQMLPFXnmISTSdImigEOC5uI2QJRy@6hyA5diB6/Kz5DfxiDX0ibm6gmhdRyfK8/Bve1ogFPE1aMWi35Q/vw4n3Ga@FpBW5s9RUvayTl5YsW8cplr0X2dPW14lV3Guq@t2Rde@Dk2TrwipDigYl3VLAxe3mZvrxKXpppVfMFvKQ8e/MGDb0Bzw2y91I8djNUwGXoWTZD35vzNQSfYewkz1f5joUOoKHVT/opCOlI9NlMytYq6QsLw9clfV8p6RDCOCXgMoXuC@OVdFUtl4VI4vgxEwjunrBAvH0SccR/S5jbDDqfBVi2RsTZoiFGtBDzV71WV3lZGgG4v8DFqGdpbHQR3rI7Ht7OQTSXjCAUF6hLPHSOz97koS/aXNXiTOL@JKlYYn73E3rT/vDm/eHRefvt8flxzgvvbvNe@Mev8qJn3BvPD@mVA/SBFfdEWHk0ilmsiKAugWGxhRN08zrIepMsvJrFBk4IE0hBIBLV7rZR7R7@j7cRBE7tAaMpwgyGcVBuYDPLu4misRdb90gk7iD0b0JrkNAk@T8xctq@ppmr4YOLLBUSY8IZ72Ohzl/1Tx/v7scPl6X6JCMR8iSrNkDbPtf2RqRhXdu7rIJ78Kzy0XVEHoGXy0tSNucfwC4Si2BjDtXxEEqSDSuq1ZiTqWbqKqXE2CkuaDiAhoVNOhJGLOMoLpk3oRmmewA6upqmTsDHBFFqxTk@99LMVDq0T9mgv6p2Nn@btwHicQGWn4cFbqBEDwtc6oG@Dg/Qaoa6FtQKkoXWWgZwEZv3PGzegKxrlXn4oJVnSRVqvjBzpd6gQqBLMmWzzLsfkeZuFfhA4JYBKSBTx/oVgIjKOqv0Bge6mStagrAsDoY1nm6UDu50vA5WgeIxKAJ@vv4b9oCb74Gs9Rd8YNhktN4gABmr2YbmkfVwSRKqBSebIjF2PmdTEfTns1gfI872XDqPYMDMYkyw0C5ofVUMVdPMddpCZVJQGWU0YhPIZBLbwbWrfZgawNKA2jF10HH7BBiXPDSdXSXSl13layUjSOAezGSG9DFHymoEk4l8s9ENMcxvBOQaBrDbJ6F4UUSh/TAYzd1W6nTlcvLSerH7RcOslZvF53rBMEaeH8NbTG9omIM4y0bXY1iQM0rLtebuUlgV23KjR5tb7eJZ0xb0erKNGMhRxdCrygLrM51zqfHM2LZi4I5uKs7oqaFuP2@IyaWZJyVYaHVdgo2e1/43TO2jp6R2MUuBaUmLDU/RQ70BS@NqNW@TO/LI/CRTnDeWWwBdqCXR3Vr4XbxYs/I0D@OlC2u9IiXNK5pdSWe8ZHgdAH/VWCUhfF4nsfo4KLiHyuIo5/bzEA1ZunJoF5aaDl@LAulSxlqWxqcTfJ2rVuJAXWuruy@OZ6uN8mVVEbpz1sbBk1z2EadNAEALKxPQCkXvv6GipLGk6f012VCW1WjlChrQy1@h/SqixuMmIo2Cje6vn2ag8fc00HiVgQ7@HQYaP9FAD9/TQA/XpGAfQv4dBnp4ooGsfN5dQRE/L1v2qBWQH7SgHBSgsdY3CN@WXD3QKwvgl4RRf80o73Cj5fZxzOKei9gO0VdtfhgFkdUvWXnJ@5Zdo/qjbK79Q6Dalxb1ywwttoJeKltezX9D/Tb@oX6VH9URpWcCHRlkXT4ZNb4LcA5sZFRAfG5FV9pHDzT0NccduZHre@umR4CUjBoHI@M1mySNGvWRoe7zV6M@aqyfK239X1tp6x9YaWthpa01VlrsZqe5a2N5v/jMhxVdGNIo8D3H9W5QzeKz2u@yb8y3y//4VWyXoxvq0ZCdhLIDn/nxjdgh1@SuZw1o/oSRHwyBRcRAxPXgIxIfEvj@bmb7VEoFSNI@4u8D13H6FJXLUnJEsBWxU1pjc7NSn4F6ku8g7RB5SIvR0EDaCIriEGlHEdKNxk7zxctXu3tI/tjxKpcy1N2ENEA1eLHubhk1rGtI8yWI5GdOOKnAJWVxKLEVdTqeoLi7ZRSAGZYRMrdUPTfo1O2OJMO/zAAuDplMDNQyt2GiWBdQglb8uFaeycy2do/at9Dx4Ao2jSIrZGcQiJ1HoK7bpxJbgxGdQaZEl9ID69QU0B1Kpfaxe3JZUflyjRhInBI/RkqPE1JaIGX87IcKYn0@eKZ0DK7vxdTjZ3kMHrKi9IwlK0UIMNhxDPMSXDKECVf0G0Lreg6hed8lHRDVa5X66j2K/OFCXfArwthz10zXtBPZZNhMlHaGKqVaLhRJLbHCEPOYgEXuckQwI@UDIlkJPzEgslsEogJ4eQrj2wTS6m0AQcN2C6TlaRSP6QSVlAuqxr82nJLxoiO@cNEmbE9FbJvwpLogTI2TGCSl1ozLy/ymSpFvQcomn4X6VWdDS0Sz5YKUZ7EPtESQJgtzni1yjgQ5Q5bWaC89XWGpqKP0iFrJ6WEBvCT8CECxIOi6ntXvjyURHZKkft5kfu3QsIaCezqwa/zSjRsNaozah4hKau5zNXGPjpEVUtQN/QGvz1UPfMftuuAvFrqGhtio9@Fdm9XAXy@Og2i/Xr9x497wumb7g/ovb7UPgUVPrLsH6tVz4qRNYMmVsB3coyO9JkknZ4fvj9nZb@K0ckfXjVpYe6jZNW@75vPPas2mNUuGbrpo/35@dExk@XM2oLgQPL2zkWbzETgXboLn0WrOvIpISUItuYrCQIrrQopSUtLLVIfnv1y9P/yTX76aTnl9Q2/uqtqeqqqYsYtbNgSzPkKaZ0x55EPgj@KhMV0V8whCfioCfsoiVqMsBX9ClTrkV/GBKiX44PLT2yEM30cGnt8IG7Ji6NfLchkKw0LhAoTTRNpZM0cgUDkZVNp0qgQRsPgoAGelsTug24EdDLdH0YPpQE5Ws3o1p4/mslSx2HL7YI5mg6soG25H0hpG81Vzd@dlc1diQ05HqXUmu51ZRy3VO0ZdniYdIk@sKruRMGMzOJGyLBMGE4zEhTd2027uFQsHUHHSQbKYiTVQ32cjPgChjqymwJJGBtZ9n3pf2@kiIAlOvZoXilgkWHwBCIho@BJzRiSL@w7t8wt2@@L0hKSHpxhyl2q22Z2n@ifujKU6uxDWJsRQk7tOXDI6PeFkfIILtFxNQbqSThzw70wzE1eR8ZqQ8cjZich1grN9coFKbpZ0JipOT7KFAjLmuWlryK6YlBrichw8AZL2WlxVEBpstFPxwl6AykjkdhHudLZ84E/1mSSy7@IuyM02yuXv7Ah/KGgLnjGNekiLPv8N)

### With comments

```
XX.z
# push 1; push int(rand()*pop)
## NOTE rand() outputs 0<=n<1
## NOTE assuming NUL cannot be used for filename
.a\001.rXX.z
# while size<2 || pop!=pop; do
.a.zXX.z
  # dup; print pop; push comma; putc pop
  .a.c.n,.oXX.z
  # push 1; push pop+pop; dup; push 101
  .a\001.+.ce
# done
.a.a
```

---

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 3 bytes (filename) + 20 bytes (content) = 23 bytes, requires unprintable character.

- Filename: `e.e`
- Content (some unprintables are escaped): `.c.w\001.-.e.+.n .o.d.a`

### With comment

```
e.eXX.z # push 101; call content
.a
```

```
XX.z
# dup; while pop!=0; do
.a.c.wXX.z
  # push 1; push abs(pop-pop); call content (* result of final stack will be pushed to original *)
  .a\001.-.eXX.z
  # push pop+pop; print pop; push space; print pop; return
  .a.+.n .o.dXX.z
# done; (* implicit return *)
.a.a
```

[Try it online! (with pxem.posixism)](https://tio.run/##1RprU9tI8rt@xTAYW7KRLBknAeQhyxLYpJbgLWDv9i4mlJDGoMKWVJJsMLb3r@d6ZvS0DYHdJLXnSpDU093T3dOPeTlWdPPF9oeBO6CyIksRjZFKR@ZoaEW3SNdbLZPeB34Yo@ODy/3jY3JgxpOAomsa277XR3tNh46b3mgwQK29qlGt8lZgOLQ8Z7k14fXb/vl7gityiqcGGUPWpFSm7NHYnYsXdY5TKX4/@fDH5dn5O9LS9a0U@Fv37MMfx/@5POienh4enBPDtK2IIlyZ/rx/9v7yX4enZx@6J7uNyRwj15MnCtfSR4Efufcm@2j8bJo0suyM8L8r6ehwNLBiiqIbRuUHMbzd@aETBQM3Nq2Ba0VIvUa1ytRo4MpPeF4jNfasmSe/Hx8ffHxHdsv9yKxzx4xu3H7MBXEQw08A1L7xUWVd4b0bCv@MfR/5AwdUd2NkJNzo2BogvIb61iCieDabolW4c@g17nTUmhHFN05Yk/ojz45d30PWFZhRHkbXyjQIXS9GmIahHyIDYQRQzkDWFXOek8B4RXJI401bmbp92b0a9fs0JARjZdr3Q5v2B6PoRlZMwCEyYMc0nMFj4HoUJdiKKSH4ATkgdYiuIHiOQo89RJM98COaUHPsOfy3SULPAEBsr/2JEXQrmCWCYJyiU7CJaItGVzJGWr2CNzEGwc0c@ukzuqgjDi8Kx@gdfzCwQp3YDJAIaJhSwRZDa3KV6st64q9RTINGIxExg@wR/mrFibjC3BwmpMkwiS4EKPRTtCsjXyAukRbI3OhqYHm3ss2JEg1sQrZas5m80yF2tWp3iLGlMKqfD3/5cMLw6DCIJwTzB87YE8wfeKm/3E7C8jwkZDBnFFv27SbexUoZHLkPNAeHkAZk9iei1OGgoQVOr3OZhL9K0jqKQRwWgRGzBaKWfYMiO3QhEP2@@Az9UQwuJq2vI00KqeX43mACkWBFQ55xrBh1OrXz7v7Zx0IAwNMK3NgayF7RSPLrVx3iVateh@zoylvZa2y1lF1vwbr20CmT9fhIyh6YeEsBG7OX1@nLm@SlnTa1X8FLSrOTdWjoLXiukZ3X4rFdwAIqQy@SGfpORtcSdIaxlTzflAcWBoCG1iAZpyCkYzFmc6nYKqcvLKLfVvRduaJDNsApAucpdM@NV9EVpVoVLInjx1Ph/QkJhOlnEWf8byUNWR6AxRYRh3lHSZJIAH82tabCYWkE4EEuVxq1vKWP8Ibd8/BmSURzwQhCcSF1hYfO4cm7suh5n6t6nEvcnyQFS8zvfkLvuufvPu4fnHbfH54elrzw7rbshf/@tZaPjHvt@SG9dAA/sOIbEVYejWIWKyKoK2BYbOFEuqwNcmcxn2DNYjUYwgTyErBE2t0m0u7h/2QTQeBoDxjNEGZiGHvVFjaLtOsomnixdY9EDQhC/zq0hglOUkoSI6f9q6q5WnxwkQUgMaac8D4W6vzZ/Pzp7n7ycFFpTgscWeaEZgO0HXBtr0Wa1tWdiwa4B88qn1xH5BF4ubggVTP7AHKRWAQZc6ieh1CSbBhI05iTKWbqKpXE2Klc0HEAHQub9CSMWMaRXZJ1oRqmuwc6uqqqTMHHBFJqxUw@98IsNDp0QNn8YVXrPHvL@gD2eEksvywWuIEcPeRyKXv6U/IArmooTwq1AiXXWi0IvCyb9zLZvCF5qlfm4cNOmSRVqP3KLEG9YZ3AkBRg88K7H5H2dgPogOGGASmg0MbGFQQRjU3W6A33dLMEWhBhkR2UNZ5u5B7u9bweVgDjMVGE@OX2bzgCbnkEitbP6cCwSbVeIyAyVoodZZH1cEESrJySTaYYOZ/@KQjG80WkjyEXRy6dRzDBzOWYYKG9pPXlcqiaZmnQcpXJksqooBGfhor5cA9rl7swNYBVBrVj6qDD7hEQLnhoOrtKuC@6yl/lDNNc34OZzIg@5khFjWAyUe42uiaG@Y0EuYICdvssKV4tS6H@MDHa253U6arV5KXzavurhnmSb1E@1wtGMfL8GN5iek3DkojzYnQ9JgtyxilcbW8vhNVyX270aHerXbxo2iW9nm0jJuS4bugNOZf1hc650Hmhtq0o3NF13Rk/N9Ttl5WYUpp5VoKFXp9KsNHL@v@GqX38nNQuZikwLemw8hQ9NFuK6TYaZZvckUfmJwVw2VjuktBLrSS6e1L8Ps7XrDzNQ710Ya23jEnLihaX1wUvGV0FQN8wVnEIXzZIrD0OltxDYXFUcvssREOWrhzah6Wmw9eigLqQsRa58ekEX@cq9ThQnrTV3Vfr2WqjfF1VhO6cJ@PgWS77iNMmAkAPKxPQCkXvv6GipLWg6f0VWZMX1eiUAC0Y5b@g/Sqk1uMmIq0lG91fPc9Ak@9poMkqA@39Mww0eaaBHr6ngR6uyJJ9CPlnGOjhmQayynl3BUb8smx5Q62A/KAF5XBJNNb7GuHbkqsLvZwLfkEY9l@p8g43Wmkfx1zecxHbIfqqzQ9jiWXja1Ze8L5F12j8KJurf1NQ9WuL@kWCDltBL8AWV/PfUL@1v6lf/UcNROWFgo4N8lQ@Gbe@i@BcsLFRB/alFV1lFz3Q0Fcdd@xGru89NT0CScm4tTc23rJJ0rjVHBvKLn81muPW03Oljf9rK238DStt5FbaeMJK@W52mrvWFveLT3xY0YUhjQLfc1zvGmkWn9V@l31jvl3@71/Fdjm6ph4N2aEqO/DJjm/EDrla63vWkJYPK/nBEFhEFCKuB69IvCTw/d3C9qmUMpCkXcTfh67jDCiqVqXkiGAjYge@xvp6vTkH9STfQeo@8pAao5GB1DGA4hCpBxHSjdZW@9XrN9s7qPap59UvatB2HdIAafBi3d0ybFjXkPZrYMnPnHDSgCtyfiixEfV6nsC4u2UYIDMsI2rcUs1S0WnaPakGv0IBF4dMJgbsGrdholgfpASt@MlvbV5jtrVvqH0LAw@uYNMoskJ2BoHYeQTquwMqsTUY0ZnIlOhSevadmgKGQ65rn/pHF3WFL9eIgcSB82Oo9DBBpUuojJ79oQJZz4pnisfE9b2Yevwsj4mHrCg9YylyEQwMdhzDvARXDGHCFeOG0FMjh1A2dskARE2t3ly9R1E@XGgKelkYO3PNdE07rZlMNhOlg6FIqZa5IqklVhgiiwlY5C5GBDNSOSCSlfAzA6K4RSAagJanML5NIK3eBhA4bLdAWpxG8ZhOpJJKQdX6x4ZTUi964gsv24TtqYhtE55Uc8TUOIlBUmzVuLgob6os0@WobPK51L7qbGgBab4ISGnyfaAFhDRZmFm2KDkS5Iya9IT20vMVlpZ1lB5RK71YsSi8JPwIhGJB0Hc9azCYSCI6JEn5ss782qGhhoJ7OrQ1fn/HjYYaw/YhopKW@1JLfEMnyAop6of@kLeXmoe@4/Zd8BcLXUFHrOqdf@iyFvh3E8dBtNtsXrvxzehKs/1h85f36nlg0SPr7oF6zRI7aR1IShC2g3twoGuSdHSy//GQUI1KZ93fTw8O2TFw4r81zdbuerpuaKpGtYbmIc3XHM2qKfhLMZw4Czy7s5Fq8/pbCjbB9tFmTrwKiQUSCylxkwAiLrmgQkSM8eLN7yHJcoLDfhU5vbC1f/rL5cf9P/gFLzSbCeSW3t5WCugq2sm@FHGQruC8S3HBh2A2vEj1jBlPGpAzxvHImK1KFwiyxUzkihkLdpWy7P0Z1ZuQmsUHqlfgo9BLer2koFkMEyJmCX5PbcQQwEWq1QQeLsGnmUaFtOa0kXqC2qyLEv4sQ@YaOAUN1KRpziyWM5WDCLj6KIA4obE7pJuBHYw2x9GDiRyoB0qBZzGvttNyV@ju0aInfoXSlxBZ7gBsj9qtAjDPo@JnuCKziJ/aMtpv2ttbr9vbBRxWRHuy1ptu9@Y9pdLsGc2stShBkuAtmIAUu5haDXYLY14AsQmsyNhWAZ4SzcvuJK4VsvuMWcjk0QFYMyaBqMtiotpCA59NiEB/6kCOhBluXoUgnq0QKjYU4WAUw6fvUTY/gaQS0V34bn5W34pbCZXmJnwJngLCrppxIA@pSlNK4wzUHlr3A@plrrgUYi8KsDy8eHAltoBeRL4kOM00WYNIlwTnEBAcEi9AxNQewDVxMaV7esauyRwfkfSUG0ORUcwuFIx5phu7BNglxFCSS2mcPzo@4mh8JTJPjCNQV@KJmxhbs8IKQ5SmNpQmcnIkipKg7B6doYpbRJ2LhuOjIlCIjHkR2Rixu0CVlrgQCc95cfSYWGvdlL2wHEhlJHz7CPd6Gz7Qp/pME953cR/4Fjvl/Le2zDnz3CVtzXltFt0gNfryPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 8/11 bytes

```
'e'{}/,`
```

[Try it online! - 8 Bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/Xz1VvbpWXyfh/38A)

Makes an array of values of e (101) elements, starting at 0, then formats with spaces. The format also has brackets at either end of the output, so it may not be valid. If not, they can be removed with 3 more bytes:

```
'e'{}/,' '*
```

[Try it online! - 11 Bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/Xz1VvbpWX0ddQV3r/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 30 bytes

```
i00<esc><C-a>hxpi0<esc>0"aDi0<esc>qqYp<C-a>q@a@qdd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9PAwCa1ONnOxlk30S6joiATwjVQSnSBMgsLIwvAsoUOiQ6FKSn////XLQMA)

can definitely be improved.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 4 bytes

**Solution:**

```
!"e"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X1EpVen/fwA)

**Explanation:**

Scrolling through the other solutions tells me I wasn't as novel as I hoped when I came up with this.

```
!"e" / the solution
 "e" / ASCII 101
!    / til (i.e. range 0..n-1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Barrel](https://github.com/LorenDB/barrel), 9 bytes

```
#d(n+¶)n
```

Explanation:

```
#        // as many times as...
 d       // ...the ASCII value of 'd' (100)...
  (   )  // Create a single of instruction for the loop
   n     // print the accumulator of a number
    +    // increase the accumulator
     ¶   // print a newline
       n // print the final number
```

The final `n` is necessary because the loop only prints the numbers 0 to 99.

I could've shaved off 2 bytes by doing `#e(n+¶`, which would have used the ASCII value of 'e' (101) and also utilized the self-closing properties of the `()` instruction, but I had already assigned `e` to be the value of the mathematical constant \$e\$.

Answer (score 1):

## GFortran, 29 bytes

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vKMrMK9HS0cjSybI10MlMzkgs0lBPUdfU5ErNS/n/HwA)

```fortran
print*,(j,j=0,ichar('d'))
end
```

Similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220684/15940).

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
♀)rn
```

Outputs with newline delimiter.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RzAbNorz//wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
♀     # Push 100
 )    # Increment it to 101
  r   # Pop and push a list in the range [0,101)
   n  # Pop and join it by newlines
      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ErrLess](https://sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/Errless/), <s>23</s> <s>25</s> 17 bytes

*Thanks to Jo King for saving 8 bytes*

```
0Z@#@'d<l+[.a?l-z
```

### Explanation

```
0   { Add zero to the stack: (x) }
Z   { Set a "checkpoint" to jump back to later }
@#@ { Output as number & Duplicate: (x x) }
'd< { x < d - true -> -1; false -> 0? (x x<d) }
l   { Get the length of the top element (-1 for integers): (x x<d -1) }
+   { Add: (x [-2 or -1]) }
[   { Skip backwards that many instructions (skip forwards 1 or 2): (x) }
.   { Halt }
a?  { Push 10 and print (print newline) }
l-  { Increment: (x--1) }
z   { Go to "checkpoint" }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VvpdtvGFf6vp5hIdQBIXJU0TWnTieOtOrEt11Z72lAMDwgMSdgggMwMLVKO87MP0Efsi7j3zgIMFlKyYzWpzhElDGbu/e46dxZmG7FIky@@ztj7A/KIimBBQzJj6ZIshMj4oNudR6LDWWchur@wlZ9Msi5lLKacTxid8a5glHaXfpR0I0GX3Wk0jxIxWSVRkIa0mynyZkgn2xBfkC965DQQ6ZQyctw77u9FyyxlgvhsnvmMU/PMN9z8K6Il3dsLYp9zEiXZYI/AT0hnZDKJkkhMJi6n8cxT7fiDj53QFz4ZEsfZy/vPqYijhFa7MypWLLFGHSH3DhdhlHQY9UM5yBsN2v1xiZgk1CI8uqTDdt@iGM1kI7lDeoOrybteAQUQ5x1HAyQyvl2Sp3iLLwfjqhSsTh47tmOauMzzSvijqiYSOgcWj/wY7FCDhAL3C6gXiyimhHUizjM/AP0UZHYNA9XAK7BL2xlofmdsRW9fwSdJBWEjMEDBj/hJmLeF4HqijuGomaatUEkBlWbaSpIzZXXTJNimwkJpHdwetIvCIVAUi4IOSVu15yPoOqCZIH/34xV9yFjKGomNwMvAz4E7fIJz7KG54izN3LhFosLTgFvEo4QLPwF9wLs44sI7NyRRPa4bkbtD0pMPEfgjukHseSRlxMVn9cZtRx65MzRv67ERd5B9pCSxYCpklL7@DaGNonEjLA42R1Qtsv4fokI4YLm1BUnhmcW@ELJ7DgZ9pQFQnjJGsZYMCI7UvzPAQcEvSGwpokPXQDl0DQvqlQzFFIAgzTY29ybOVeWO5CDqWXxLyo4V6TCdrFyTSKSwE3ddpzaDxga515q7ipkRjN0ohhtkuC4xnE1yjmGNY4tsLKZ@i0wxhuqMWnbjRjfaGcqXRp42RydwumyRCwUR/0OUl1Gm@Be5gsZIaRcNLealJWY@cDtzYHNpDdyMG9SMtKtqUxPoMwpyT2M6MO504bMQ1PQ2p@JcQmZ2fnBaRctbbHlnt7jY4tktS2x5qlveyc@pH7yuk99gx3/aQ99hy1u7xcMW1255ii3LnLx0Av46yiZBulxSSLMZS@ctkgnWMlLxIc4sxuGTAGD00brmtc7Rffk@WPgYZkhlBESUUhNQlkzDgXzkgkUJzljYWc2kenaCfoW9YDhOPGaUabql0gVyKJytka3F60gzs5xTDRlKq5R8RKKFAf2yJ@X93zX1b2N/21VcgHEE2L1bOdqWRmNpXevQ1jqSg05DWT60CCSk4bM0Mfrfqt8J@GPwGjMcdhk3KFrLTTEjgwMDzYF8GObO3NFwNImKZRSHmn36N2IdV6sBJwyj@QLEqDdWdYt8BdFblaBsoV3W1sBbZIKFU2MkeLUBBe5J7V2QJgB8RWs@oqB3/CzDSQYBeWUPc1FzRU@PfGZrt5hcq8LKssxSDlRaLWlfDyWWjAbb0GA9UoFRRTHEeM@VDU8A/wp6tUDo7w4Dk@F@L3Fg8Fw/ENq/t0AwImyPhHcfHgkttaj53QaEEfr/OiLEKgOmH1xj4jDqmsFrVdqsZa2pxJGilCnJMQ1rgYbalKXCF3JQml1dejdTrA9IM1O0AljUBxDHBUF/CwWxxPVcvlRKMwyAvKKPUFrmJ3Pq9luGnAUG6jlFAD5bJSrRuDC5WfHIZlz17FVae2NJx2vQ0pz5U5cDbUtNpn3i5k0yZIzjmyUpYlUDcBkgR3g4ROt/pZxlgL4ig3GAy2V0HUxGUotQsq0SPiBhFIBG23exgy5QV0kp78jGgwPy8uze/e/J6fOHL@6dnZw@e7ln7CQHQJIYQL14QO6nSQDWT@C3WBdIQwB0FRR5@3RLu8xlZev72vhqWVh5OTUvy5FVyhkj6OSP7WjldFDuMiVHxPeqYq2lWPdklyslirdLdKX/1yHHDZBL3WPT1fe2k4lrIt2WIr2kGWXXMVMdvN8IHsePfHumQhR6pexbmcXg@EzieJ5mhf4q7Evdv5XdH2DaCmzcuGBQS20Zpmq4t9eoDNFAdy7pPoYoysek2U4DF2zyFyqcsc2EdJ3R45yR2vOV3a/maZPWfxrJx5L8E5rMxaK0f1bxB9wSsTVV2y0722R6s6w8st1v4PrE4krSWUWoGmfbOiU6TNJ5IeeOsk7yfZxCN1usa2aeoqOVK0vcXljcmuywk6dms8sWLUkfq429LbFdEB43jP@DCtELP/voLFoKPwzZqdmMhmz@JBIQ/DHfK7OGSdHp9Y@/@PKPX/3p6z/70wDmEyXJajmljDcLg3uuMLpF@l816frcUTMDVEB@IGwqZl14e3sdXGKU6rpfzkxNrF4qtZ29OHn2eK9UqXJTqTaso/W6AUZv4TtCxoGqkwJUEh/1cZfaSs56cgd6uY7vsY1YLH0RBXt1pEdqWgnDX2lfjVDuzsX@chr6WLtAzK@PNh7OjH6TntpKT6upQJPcGIT2DggTHSFzO96rBFc5wQFpr71SODbQPJQ0n65iEWXx5sbEOtwhVldNUtGbKPz4Akiudv0ZDaM31T3WPKdrh1t3u5vSS53Df6AsRRQ8ShOdy/WI3g45NdPt4t1SGk7DVZz@avGWaXileLc@sXTAc7t05@fGetDtU1jvGhLavT5Q1NZ1bGkLbDLT/XSZ@SziadKQmYZSBw9/WvlxJG4siNr9Q3c9HG687da4oysLzolY@MmNIrmzC8hdXbdRSFXs5rHctbAYi30XiYuIU9IlT9I5lL8xOZXVOzgFb7DhLyq5np5dK7P@cnVm/VxNV88e3FhS/XxHUv1Zcj99cWPMf97B/EfJ/B83yP3HTc3ep2JBWYNhhYqJSIiYkrObQoQF3fqw3zs83BUWZxLLd9GcXM/NkCrSXHtXultmi/n8ZsU83i3l81zK59eW8rhJyCL5JoKlMXkUpxcNFu5Ifn/xY1GtLfW5Wan3pez9yJyvPU5FWqqutxe98qRu1Bs3VbA1NhulBL1nup1P0@78BzF6KxmdXaTtC39D5lvY1M9drkt/pApfIJIrLR/3arltBZ7hFkN5G962@ivAMMzEgGSdyYRTgVezJhMX5mcXtwDbr6wNXHCLV2ZDsJAqE9cVYFwIkJvjxiU4@hUSGLd/ztKAhitGOfmcPPUDljZNXK7aEjJ9y2s4YB9ctYwrcOEG5yjfIbdCcaz2NwO1hruW1pcSls24jGzpfypgLh65AzkFzrsWun21mQFPueK6UsMFyy1uIQtRhF7CNLPvVKgq9Hu60cVnYEBCpioILWu32MonCEH9BEEe@ODW3cgygqGFScMmVWwdocTqShBuSi4rW1QjS2V8215dfUOTm7OFgu6ufdna3s2VLDEue5Ubdpm891RmhP1w/x70leGmhYa6VDcn9I4TGssDiy9lFJFU7eOSNIHa1OxmmbA7OW2Ism90lMFclXM/qMxjGb51gwXTV4jWxYlJb93v9@BH3x9yznuOOnV1nMqsV1AnZwBtlsYw6eHxnx8sIvqGcoXYX1LI9X7c0pqZUuwz8znU29bhqUTkOJ1XaZRcG1lxuNW0p@flwC2oJyRagq/iFENDQBhx9QFTUguwBf4KaEs0CJOCLEA@xCU/rJksOoHZ8SLCfw2y/rSCvEriNIHEMF0Ji8QbintFUjEC7BhQPG9eroKFRU2powPoDoN0FYeHBUrCU9Agx6u76QxIz2ZqnSLwzqlig4KkFjUuwhQgsGi@ECATKAkvm2XQlDJpFMxfzF@ieriCewJTRuII1EXyGvtY5OhshtxRSfAX9CGk3pEQSAgzuQ@xBthnZJOuQJGAWaTgyZTGZMYoLYMrBAM6MIDhVdHP6n58UPgx7lDuWefIbzASlTNzeRDmcm9X4Ct/cR1yRBxiXAzIlLf9PHztORWXlP1sryo7VQnyXyXkE9R0kdsh4CEmW7iiLyUXHerX3JQE83XMhevGTeWfCt4ldX0cf80ucpuq5shidd@@p1Dbz9Vk3H7jQuCkQoc3li/rwfVUAwljXM1QJlE@jXjTPu0DtSNEp6v5b@pe5jhjBvlxqK@bU8auuC6gj5pB8lkCSVbPvkzd0pczUYSnNqA01aGF5zAwC3LJZ1C6mI0t9u15c8seZGfFyfME@br4bYTK8TNOgKUjaLxFkybUPonOm0LUt7rPU9wgUNd18os4@e2dsXW@yYv38mlI3r5TKjp59uhUFn6IBTpLFsou2pCHkxY5PJxMBpJAMcp1zgUEB9Q7@kPP7dUOstZjNGNSfHVGocq4/NzO@c@//u2Us4OuBaCILlcDqqyWtQBQ09TtAiDvqSBUcGmVSCkH8gsdHR5TmrmdXr869CPRS5Pjd1E0QpjEpimn5hpW3YYH8vsmKJb57knnHpuvMNE/l2/M7RfdseOH4cTXPdz99pv9FtlvtzUfeFjQOBvu589qLGn4gVk4SpPhPhcwz00EFJf73i5OoeIkRcj50ARvDmnHWYLIn46jg8HlaEaOLJXQK/A@FOhXlgjqKz0EVe0YNcF4dHFNUf5BmtzoERxAK6dWRbXbbUhv5P7pg4cEEh08OvZig8sz9RCcBpYE0P08sV7nV9OhX6V8VcTBoSCT0dHgy@NKgUyBLh19eTwol/wqCGJ5k77hqpmiSsD9zgUh22hvoV8S@MXDl397clYSuJS0jNvKT9CidG/mOM773g/fHnzrhHfio1HH/yZuX76HVr1Ke/9f)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3; 46 Bytes

```python
x=True;a=x+x;b=a*a+x;print(*range(a*a*b*b+x))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```kotlin
('P'..'´').joinToString(","){""+it.minus('P')}
```

Saving two bytes by using other chars from the ascii table that only takes one instead of two bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp6FZXVCUmVeSk6fxX0M9QF1PT/3QFnVNvaz8zLyQ/OASoFy6hpKOkma1kpJ2ZolebmZeaTFIoWbtfyACAA)

#### 48 bytes version

```kotlin
('\n'..'n').joinToString(","){""+it.minus('\n')}
```

Using the ascii table to get those numbers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp6FZXVCUmVeSk6fxX0M9Jk9dT089T11TLys/My8kP7gEKJeuoaSjpFmtpKSdWaKXm5lXWgxWqFn7H4gA)

---

When brackets are allowed at the start and end then this is smaller:

#### 29 bytes

```kotlin
('P'..'´').map{it.minus('P')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp6FZXVCUmVeSk6fxX0M9QF1PT/3QFnVNvdzEgurMEr3czLzSYpC4Zu1/IAIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 63 bytes

```go
package main
func main(){for i:=' ';i<'';i++{println(i-' ')}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjftCxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuNJK85LBLA3N6rT8IoVMK1t1BXXrTBv1Q61ASlu7uqAoM68kJ08jUxcooVlbCzEGahrMVAA)

Upper bound for the loop has value 133 `NEXT LINE (NEL)`. Separator is newlines. Prints to STDERR.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 18 bytes

```
0::naoaa*(?!;ba-+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38DKKi8xPzFRS8Ne0TopUVdb8f9/AA)

### Explanation

```
0                   Initialize stack with 0
 ::                 Duplicate the top of the stack twice, once for printing and once for comparing
   n                Pop the top of the stack, and print as a number
    ao              Push 0xa to the stack, and pop it to print as a char
      aa*           Push 100 (10*10) onto the stack
         (          Pop the top two values of the stack, and compare if one is less than the other
          ?!;       If not, halt execution, else...
             ba-    Push 1 (11-10) onto the stack
                +   Add the top two values on the stack
                 !  Skip the next instruction
                    IP Moves back to the 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
0S^ThhZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3yA4LiQjI@r/fwA)

Yay! First answer using an actual golfing languages.
Since I’m new to Pyth, I’m assuming this can be optimized further :)

Edit: I misread the problem :/ so +1 byte. And guess what? Somebody made a 4 byte answer in pyth.

Explanation:

```
0         Zero
 S        In this case it makes a list from 1 to a number
  ^       Exponent of…
   T      Ten to the…
    hh    Increase the following number by two (one for each h)
     Z    Zero (now two after being increased)
          So basically push 0 then make a list from 1 to ten squared.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), <s>37</s> <s>36</s> <s>29</s> 21 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to [@Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime) for reminding me about the ASCII function, which made my entire coercion thing useless*

```
;O=a 0W>A'd'aO=a++0Ta
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVhrc9s2Fv2@v4LmphYh0rSc6XQnomlP4jo7mW3kbOw2syspEQhCEhsKVPiwnUrsX0/vBV@gXk6/eCjg4L5w7gP@nd7ThMXBMj0Rkc@/sZAmifYfEczm6XUcR7HGH1Mu/ESTv1Z5AXhH44S395UzFep9JtJg8TTuNo05XaxYJJI0zlgaxQYlq3QeJHYSZTHjLs1hJ1h@mAcpT5aUcaPcX9CUzY3Tj8ZwNB4NRwms5/2xuf7n8ONIjLvGSKyfEdI9JfmS88@wG/M0i4WmCB/2xuu1yMIwL4R5FnN7ZBXyVKOuZ/NHzgwFTpxSBB5xXZde4kdfhbjKt51kHthuUFBjh1zM0jmx6JCNSZ5G4HggZjutynMZDu3uf@@ub93h2ClC9RsNM75KUpoGTFviLRgeWXn2VnicKUTxnsbgQ8@h51JMqd@hpln4x1y5PqRju5LlBFODkdIeliu@5nEmZNjj6EET/KFgRO5zL5vtWN/jnRRiN5uAG2QLj8d7cNUm4F5FUcip2AOsd/OSVb9AMGIa1sQrQrdBsiRbonRLivrk05QC1wpHFSU7nCl/N@d2eVL@boO23KgWVBj/EqJ5JYJqAVhNBePRtPBaceP4WDEe@Fh8VVFA4XUIypBs8afiepNNd6/HZPjy5P/j7ql1VlOeHh/jBaNMQ7/TURvJ/WyxrJ2ZVM48k/mZk0kepvPGlaPG1uNj2rq2mYrTVNxRG5gXZF5mydzAVeIUqXI9@O3N@5vB2@vBnbvKy4R543ORbnDgKfeH9OSPT2P82zt58QlCsBkAKRSMzQ@xKUAQsKkdH3k0mAaAK0JU4DBQYG4wEyhH8WTYYMY1NQuD96Awg@@jwNd6R3g/leVOk6BqXTYmv4rPInoQWlBbpnVapnUm7ZhLF0gVXyW630uvkW9uhxQCWqYLJZukKjcaTlHfV7hSnW84Y1KldJAcavBB@EkbvsjCg/BuG@4H96qXzRbeROsSKlFvaTq3gTeCKVJPwe99l6RfUSGiVANVcCea91X7g8eRDqZG/t/U3Sj8gT6pD8RnYaToW0YPh/U14tfrI4Oe98h3Od/tfof3/HEZCSQpTbk0SEsjqI2Cz4Bv91wD43gMRoZ7Ksm5em97681FC9UifkP7ATTEw7xXqndN/EFZUknBeRTSKiFVBcF2u5EDOoINoh/qDFJe6fwToWTRAszk8oit18H4m6fU4OBaFR1ojk8GBynkuVTpOXpnTGCOS0a34@4lGZ2dWs8lrTAawCxPJRJowGGlGGKoXQx3CNY72JbYet3RO/hBGpeaoRWLHli1CAQwyde@ZBEQigsWZbjM/b72bEXzya6WLu1v55F11iPrdW@jZpUDwqGahU5MSkCpcLv0IKjRZcd8ySn0HrUCPcH4etQ6yPgapV4qLJbdFU5R//arYH2auzH/kgUxN/RpohNrhSOy3PKULTYPQv/TMo4YTxD1@tfB1d2bm8Ft05tfQw041JoVlhQXDJN5LWboKZ1O3rQyqzoKry77MuvMtU1OC8ZwnKdxPsYfPszH/jmrZmO/mo2nrrTIrkxBZUfTPXR6G0DvFjONxrNsgQPHs5VvnuUaKNGm6CV0VA8bqcOLwE5JrtwxBsJglmfxjZECltjGWIHiXFp8C7rgrld8g@rEZduzqzxg2LZdo@rKUlRxHbWnQSQM3ayl1uHxtGrklEep6eqWppueXciou7ipb9WmG@93zlI7SCR/LRiX8mmpSov5LEhSLl0kKwjtGfaq6oG08ZYw9AGYpC0yGPI8SNRHytLwqwa9QGNzGsMvmFnCSMygJjkNQejY9RSNEJi6c6lXWyYZvEANT8kDotaeZowq3hvOThrog0i7R8lQKLPQR1ulCv8IaqWSVRhwYtUh0N/plkHci/JJpuuW577KplMe2zQMI2bAAO5HGCRq9IARPZjILaC8B09K4oHhnx1mgqsPkHHcOIMuLHfkS87G3PoQQOLrI6ETwlxmJ2EAL8SepZ00k31VaRjJVcveF5a1Wvc0jMDXH5@/@PHFT/96/uKnrlyNqfCjBYZNPX@tW9S9wJDRVmgbSOdlByF1ohfhLa3y1O4GBlxWZhaS7GkcLa6AAVeRD4Nm@XYi/cpc9TptVuJepjizqUa@kkZSdemqWCofl/Kvuj2R23Ufaju3x1H9v/JQWRBt/hhsVnEFe1QrkG@t9gOohfylRqLHqiFVMqnon5FbF/X41gp2ZVmS@lGW2g8xNG4QWOQ5sWgrZjdtQY3WUpo@GsnnYfXvD6Da5R4FJaJnVekPWNLfCZ5gl/zHhFj19KTaZAJZsZw0F4ctt/SyFYaTLSS@EHYhu1tI7NC7kKdbSPku2IH8YVtmtNvOj1tIOX/vQJ7XyJo01RGcDeoj6pmL/Wdm@85c7j@DxX/nmeP6jEGrDG/9x@ayPNZv5eD6yWO0723npqMcK3atXQFzFViryuDjdr0GlcpDv53S1C5f6p5b6/dawj/UwlfYR51W@jpkI/F2kvlNIQLav3tBdwaLbfv@b@WQDFpjt@W1nmsWNgLlZ1XL6nREIeu1rrejdlsq8KWK6tATqnzX39Zcg6usxwH/kpowXzYVwSMmMxuTTB@7ctM6/uyota/9iAccRGfyzblxqdb7cPGy43cofJtm745@m8ADNMBu5Xz7Cw)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

```
'e'),`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/Xz1VXVMn4f9/AA)

Similar to the [other GolfScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222637/114970), the output has brackets, which can be removed with the following 7-byte answer:

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 7 bytes

```
'e'),n*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/Xz1VXVMnT@v/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 4 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 3.29 bytes

```
'eOR
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZL1FP9gyBMqAhMBgA)

Outputs `[[0, 1, 2, ..., 99 100]]`.

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `j`, \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
'eORAJ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abRSllLsgqWlJWm6FsvUU_2DHL0gHKjYAigNAA)

Outputs `0 1 2 ... 99 100`.

##### Explanation

```
'e      # Push 'e'
  O     # Get the ordinal, 101
        # (this is wrapped in a list)
   R    # Push range(0, 101)
        # (again wrapped in a list)
```

```
    AJ  # Get the first item of the list
        # j flag joins by spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
00⁺⁺ᴇŘÁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fwOBR4y4geril/eiMw43//wMA)

```
0           push 0
 0⁺⁺        push 0 and increment twice
    ᴇ       10^2
     Ř      push Řange (0,1,...,100)
      Á     push contents of Árray to stack; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Hebigo](https://github.com/gilch/hebigo), 25 bytes

```
print: : :* range:ord:"e"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 94 B

This full `program` complies with ISO standards 7185 (“Standard Pascal”) and 10206 (“Extended Pascal”).
The statement `write(integerExpression)` is automatically expanded to `write(integerExpression:integerDefaultMinimumWidth)`.
The value of `integerDefaultMinimumWidth` is implementation-defined.
The following code requires that `integerDefaultMinimumWidth` ≥ 4 to ensure adequate number separation.

```pascal
program p(output);var n:integer;begin n:=succ(succ(0));for n:=0 to sqr(n*n*n+n)do write(n)end.
```

**70 B**:
Provided that the character `'d'` has an (implementation-defined) ordinal value of 100 (like in ASCII) you can write:

```pascal
program p(output);var c:char;begin for c:=''to'd'do write(ord(c))end.
```

Note, the first character literal `''` is `chr(0)`.
It is assumed that `''` does not denote an end-of-line character.
Pascal specifically bans multi-line `string`/`char` literals.

Answer (score 1):

## COMMODORE 64 = 34 Bytes

With [Commodore BASIC keyword abbreviations](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/BASIC_keyword_abbreviation):

```
0?B:B=B-(A=.):IFB<aS(" ")*πgO
```

Or without the keyword abbreviations:

```
0 PRINTB:B=B-(A=.):IFB<ASC(" ")*πGOTO
```

Comment: I tidied up this entry to show the symbolic listings a bit better, and linked to the C64 Wiki for an explanation of Commodore BASIC Keyword Abbreviations.

Answer (score 1):

6510 Assembler for C64 (159 Bytes)

```
*=$c000
a=0^0
b=a+a
    ldx #0
    txa
    dex
    stx r+b
    stx w+b
    stx z+b
    stx p+b
    stx o+b
    stx y+b
    sec
    sbc 0
    tay
    iny
    sty r+a
    sty w+a
    sty z+a
    sty p+a
    sty o+a
    sty y+a
    lda 0
    lsr
    lsr
    tay
    dey
    sty s+a
    ldy 0
    iny
    sty q+a
    sty t+a
    sty o-a
    tya
    iny
    sty p-a
    clc
    adc s+a
    sta x+a
    lda s+a
    clc
    adc s+a
    adc s+a
    tay
    iny
    iny
    sty z-a 
    lda 0
    asl
    tay
    iny
    iny
    iny
    iny
    iny
    iny
    sty c+a   
    ldx #0
d   txa
q   ldy #0
    sec
s   sbc #0
    bcc t
    iny
    bne s
t   cpy #0
    beq u
    sta v+1
    tya
r   jsr 0
v   lda #0
u   clc
x   adc #0
w   jsr 0
    lda #0
z   jsr 0
    inx
c   cpx #0
    bne d
    lda #0
p   jsr 0
    lda #0
o   jsr 0
y   jmp 0
```

[image]

Comment: Very good entry.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `SH`, 7 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 0.875 bytes

```
ʀ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJTSD0iLCIiLCLKgCIsIiIsIiJd)

Another flag cocktail.

### Bitstring

```
0001101
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), 19 bytes

`&!)')$0<.0.>.;/-{@_`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/19NUVNdU8XARs9Az07PWl@32iH@/38A) or [on hexagony.net](https://hexagony.net/#lzN4Igxg9gJgpiBcIBkBCAlAcjQEgAwB4A6XQgPkIG4B6AWmAAEB9EAGhAEsA7ABwFcAXBCFYceAgLLQ4iAE4BDAO4gAvkA===)

In hexagon layout:

```
   & ! )
  ' ) $ 0
 < . 0 . >
  . ; / -
   { @ _
```

Completely ungolfed:

```
    & ! ) {
   . . . . .
  . . . . . .
 & ) 0 ; 0 ' -
  . . . . . .
   . . . . .
    @ . . .
```

The solution works by maintaining an invariant at the beginning of each iteration that the current memory cell zero or negative (`current number - 100` on all iterations except the first one) and the cell to the left is the current number.

[image: Solution's memory]

- `&!` copies current number from the cell to the left (due to the memory invarant) and prints it
- `)` increments current cell, so it will be current number for the next iteration
- `{` moves to the memory cell to the left, pointing towards two cells with zeros
- `&` copies zero from one of those cells into current cell
- `)0;` sets current cell value to 10 (ascii code for newline) and prints it
- `0` sets current cell value to 100 = 10 * 10 + 0
- `'` moves to the memory cell to the back right without turning memory pointer around, so now it points towards next number to the left and 100 to the right.
- `-` computes `next number - 100`
- Finally pointer leaves the right corner while moving to the right, so it wraps around to the top row if `next number - 100` is zero or negative, or to the bottom row otherwise where it terminates at `@`.

Golfed solution fits everything into a hexagon with side 3 by taking advantage of changing instruction pointer's direction, grid wrapping and idempotency of `-` operator.

I don't know if a solution with side 2 (7 cells) is possible, but this solutions uses 9 different operators without counting the ones that control direction, so it definitely won't fit. A more optimal side 3 solution might also be possible.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!  This is an excellent answer, with a great explanation of the workings.  I hope to see more from you in future!

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 33 bytes

```
for x in range(ord("e")):print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 56 bytes

```
@set/ax=0xb-0xa
@for /l %%b in (0,%x%,%x%00)do @echo %%b
```

-61 bytes for @Neil

Comment: You can just use `set/ax=0xb-0xa` to set `x` etc.

Comment: @Neil edited thanks

Comment: Actually you don't need `y` at all, just use `%x%00` in its place.

Comment: Also, some general Batch golfing tips: you don't need the space in `set/a` or `)do`, and you can remove the `@echo off` and use `@set`, `@for` and `@echo` instead.

Comment: @Neil thanks! for that

Comment: Now that I think about it, you can just use `@set/ax=!0`!

Answer (score 0):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```
for x<-0..?d,do: IO.puts x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v8/Lb9IocJG10BPzz5FJyXfSsHTX6@gtKRYoeL/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)!!!

```c
f(i){for(i=0;i<'e';)printf("%d ",i++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPT1sA600Y9Vd1as6AoM68kTUNJNUVBSSdTW1vTuvZ/bmJmngZQpQaIAwA)

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPT1sA600Y9Vd1as6AoM68kTUNJNUVBSSdTW1vTuvZ/bmJmngZQpQaIAwA)

Comment: @att Nice one -  thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 36 bytes

```
repeat n 0 +#"e"[print n +#"a"-#"b"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@78otSA1sUQhT8FAQVtZKVUpuqAoMw/EB/ISlXSVlZKUYv//BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 36 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBCoMwEADAu68IeogSbB@w@5RCSNeYBnQN3QQPpV/v2rkOlTInIh0y09aW2D9zlbvUhZy7vfquSeZkOOxRSqBo/gNd5mo86B4yj9NnPd4jeLTRwkRHq4jeOUT7YAtf1R@tW0ii83kB)

```c++
main(){for(;_<'e';)cout<<_++<<'\n';}
```

Explanation : I globally initialized varible _ so its initial value is 0, now ascii value of e is 101 so I ran the loop till my variable _ is less than 'e', instead of incrementing it inside the for loop I used post increment while printing to save 1 byte

edit: I misread the question and thought 0 is also not allowed :)

Comment: Could you explain the code please?

Comment: @Anush I have added explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: Do you know what this would be in C?

Comment: You'll have to include the `_` declaration with the code I'm afraid, since it won't work without it. I'm not familiar with `C++` golfing, but I believe you'd have to include the rest of the boilerplate, since this is a full program

Answer (score 0):

## [APOL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/APOL), 11 bytes

`f(ô p(∈));ô`

I would've used `ⅎ` instead of `f`, but the rules state that you have to include 0 so the fastest route was to just print 0-99 and slap 100 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

## APL, 13 bytes

```
0,⍳⍎'00',⍨⍕*0
```

*0 ⍝ Exponential of zero = 1
⍕ ⍝ Convert to symbol '1'
'00',⍨ ⍝ Append two zeros
⍎ ⍝ Convert to number 100
⍳ ⍝ Make sequence from 1 to 100
0, ⍝ Append zero to the left

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 35 bytes

```rust
||for c in 0..b'e'{println!("{c}")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMFNy7Q8hdzEzDwNzeqc1BKFNFt9La6amrT8IoVkhcw8BQM9vST1VPXqgqLMvJKcPEUNperkWiXNWi4t_aWlJWm6FjeViVANUbrCmitNQ9OaC8pdsABCAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## C# .NET 4.7.2

With 0, 47 bytes

```
for(int i=0;i<=0xA*0xA;)Console.WriteLine(i++);
```

Without 0, 59 bytes

```
for(int i='a'-'a',j='r'-'@';i<=j+j;)Console.WriteLine(i++);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scratch, 104 bytes

[Try it on Scratch!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/926126264/)

Requires list `x` to be visible, which is the norm by default on creation.

```
define
delete all of[x v
repeat(join(<not<>>+())(join(()+())(()+(
add((item[last]of[x v])+<not<>>)to[x v
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Commodore C64 BASIC (THEC64, Ultimate64) 36 PETSCII characters

This can be done as a *zero liner* in direct mode in Commodore C64 BASIC. It relies on the default value of memory location zero being 47, so this will produce different results on other Commodore machines even though the have the same or a very similar interpreter, and the results will be different on the C128 in C64 mode too in some cases. The screen shot shows a proper representation, but `{PI}` is the PETSCII Pi symbol in my example, and upper case letters are shifted PETSCII graphics for keyword abbreviations.

```
x%={PI}+{PI}:fOi=.topE(.)+pE(.)+x%:?i;:nE
```

[image: Commodore C64, make a listing to print out 0 - 100 inclusive without the characters 1 - 9 inclusive]

Answer (score 0):

## [Morsecco](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26119/72726) <s>59</s> 60 bytes

Avoiding digits is not really challenging in a language without digits, but I found it interesting which strategy would give the shortest code.

The straight forward loop takes **66** bytes:

```
. . -- - - - -.- -. --- . - .- - - . .--..-.- .- --.. --. - .- --.
```

- `. .` to `E`nter 0
- `-- -` to `M`ark the current program position
- `- - -.- -.` dup and `K`onvert to `N`umber
- `---` to `O`utput
- `. - .-` to `E`nter 1 and `A`dd
- `- - . .--..-.- .-` dup, `E`nter -101 and `A`dd
- `--.. --.` to `Z`eroskip until next `--.`
- `- .- --.` drop the unused difference and `G`o to marked position

Two more bytes can be saved by using an empty token as target for the Zeroskip (note the essential trailing space!): `. . -- - - - -.- -. --- . - .- - - . .--..-.- .- --..  - .- --.`  (**64** bytes)

Counting down is usually cheaper, but here we need to concatenate the numbers to a string to show them in the correct order (**70** bytes):

```
.    . --..-.- -- - . .- .- - - - .. -.-. .. - . --..  --.  -.- -. ---
```

- `.`     to `E`nter an empty cell on the stack as the string to build
- `. --..-.-` to `E`nter 101 so we can start the loop by decrementing
- `-- -` to `M`ark the start of the loop
- `. .- .-` decrement by `A`dding -1
- `- - - .. -.-. ..` dup, rot the string to the top and `C`oncatenate the cells with a space in between
- `- . --..  --.`  swap to get the index to the top and do a `Z`eroskip the the `G`o command that closes the loop
- `-.- -. ---` to `K`onvert the whole string to `N`umber and `O`utput

An unusual trick takes us down to **61** bytes: Counting up from -101 to 0 and directly outputting the index+101:

```
. .--..-.- -- - - - . --..-.- .- -.- -. --- . - .- --..  --.
```

I found no way to mitigate `E`ntering the 101 twice without wasting the bytes for stack juggling.

Finally, the best solution with 60 bytes turned out to be defining a recurive command (I used the undefined command `-.`):

```
.   - - --.. -. . .- .- -. -.- -. ---  . -. .-- . --..-.. -.
```

- `.   [command]  . -. .--` to `E`nter the command and `W`rite it to address `-.`
- `. --..-.. -.` to `E`nter 100 and call the new command
- The command itself is

  - `- - --.. -.` dup and `Z`eroskip to the self-calling `-.`
  - `. .- .-` decrement by `A`dding -1
  - `-.` call itself with the decremented value
  - `-.- -. ---` to `K`onvert to `N`umber and `O`utput. As this is done after calling itself, it is done first for the 0 case, to resorting is done automatically

e`X`ecuting the command directly from the stack `. --..-.. .   - - --.. -..- . .- .- . .- -..- -.- -. ---  -..-` save nine bytes for saving the command, but wastes three time the two bytes that `-..-` is longer than `-.` and five more bytes for placing `.-` on the stack to e`X`ecute `A`gain, ending in **62** bytes.

I hope this illustrates why I like morsecco as a golfing language: There are many ways to do something and a lot of tricks to discover. The pure score is not impressing, but considering that you could pack 5 characters into one byte (3^5 = 243 < 256), *12* true bytes even beat some golfing languages!

Answer (score 0):

## COMMODORE 64 (improved version) = 25 Bytes

0fOI=ATOA♥("-"):?I:nE

0 FORI=ATOASC("-"):PRINTI:NEXT

"-" = Character 100

To get the correct character in the code you have to poke it in first with POKE2061,100.

Comment: You can edit your entries with improved versions that have fewer bytes, leaving your old answer below. Please consider formatting your answers as the standard used by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Commodore 64 = 27 Bytes**

```
0FORO=.TO{PI}+{PI}*{PI}*{PI}*{PI}:PRINTO;:NEXT
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [vemf](https://github.com/selaere/vemf/tree/main), 5 [bytes](https://selaere.github.io/vemf/doc/docs.html#Programs)

```
0,│d↨
```

cancats 0 and the integers on [1, 100]