# Storing a band matrix

Tags: code-golf, matrix

[Related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243441/bandwidth-of-a-matrix)

A [band matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix) is a matrix whose non-zero entries fall within a diagonal *band*, consisting of the main diagonal and zero or more diagonals on either side of it. (The [main diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal) of a matrix \$A\$ consists of all entries \$A_{i,j}\$ for which \$i=j\$.) For this challenge, we will only be considering square matrices.

For example, given this matrix:

```
1 2 0 0 0
3 4 5 0 0
0 6 0 7 0
0 0 8 9 1
0 0 0 2 3
```

this is the band:

```
1 2
3 4 5
  6 0 7
    8 9 1
      2 3
```

The main diagonal (`1 4 0 9 3`) and the diagonals above it (`2 5 7 1`) and below it (`3 6 8 2`) are the only places non-zero elements are found; all other elements are zero. (Some of the elements in the band may also be zero.)

One nice feature of band matrices is that they can be stored more efficiently: only the elements in the band need to be stored. For example, our 5-by-5 matrix above can instead be stored as a 5-by-3 matrix, where each column represents one diagonal of the original matrix:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 0 7
8 9 1
2 3 0
```

Note how the shorter diagonals are padded with zeros: diagonals below the main diagonal are padded at the beginning, while diagonals above the main diagonal are padded at the end.

In this challenge, the band to be stored must be symmetrical about the main diagonal. For example, this matrix:

```
2 3 4 0 0 0
1 2 3 4 0 0
0 1 2 3 4 0
0 0 1 2 3 4
0 0 0 1 2 3
0 0 0 0 1 2
```

has this band:

```
2 3 4
1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
  0 1 2 3 4
    0 1 2 3
      0 1 2
```

and so it is stored as:

```
0 0 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 0
0 1 2 0 0
```

In this case, one of the diagonals to be stored consists entirely of `0`s, but that diagonal must be included because it is symmetric to the nonzero diagonal consisting of `4`s. (This rule means the output matrix will always have an odd number of columns.)

### Challenge

Given an \$N\$-by-\$N\$ band matrix containing nonnegative integers, output/return its rearranged version.

If \$B\$ is the number of diagonals in the band, the resulting matrix will be \$N\$ rows by \$B\$ columns. If you prefer, you may output the result matrix transposed (that is, a matrix of \$B\$ rows by \$N\$ columns).

You may assume that \$B < N\$. In other words, no input that would generate output the same size or larger needs to be handled.

The matrix will always have at least one nonzero entry.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): the goal is to make your code (measured in bytes) as short as possible.

### Test cases

```
1 0
0 1
=>
1
1

1 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 3
=>
1
2
3

0  0  0
0  0  0
0  0 42
=>
 0
 0
42

1 2 0 0
3 4 5 0
0 6 0 7
0 0 8 9
=>
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 0 7
8 9 0

1 2 0 0 0
3 4 5 0 0
0 6 0 7 0
0 0 8 9 1
0 0 0 2 3
=>
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 0 7
8 9 1
2 3 0

0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
=>
0 0 1
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

2 3 4 0 0 0
1 2 3 4 0 0
0 1 2 3 4 0
0 0 1 2 3 4
0 0 0 1 2 3
0 0 0 0 1 2
=>
0 0 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 0
0 1 2 0 0
```

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>94</s> <s>84</s> <s>83</s> 78 bytes

*Edit: -5 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(m,b=max(abs(row(m)-col(m))*!!m))matrix(c(!1:b,m),dim(m)+1)[-b:b+b+1,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RCsIwDEXf@xd7a2wGrXNTB/sS8WGtFApmgzlxf1/j2qkUmntIctop@i765@DmMA6S0HbUL7K3DzmNL0lQuvHOBXZFwTf18xQW6WRhWosEeAvEXWXgUtrWKqsMXiN13zmDe9TrERUesE5RY8PlmKLGE57RpKh5vgKeq0F4NgvxJ@MWO7LuY96QV3@4ejbM0oQZVgT@QpPfiG8)

(of which 38 bytes are shamefully copied from [Giuseppe's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243509/95126) to calculate the bandwidth: upvote that!)

As noticed by @pajonk, there are 2 'rearranged versions' of any square 'band matrix', depending on how 'rows' and 'columns' are assigned: add [+3 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwEEX3uYW7pP5AUqu2Um/RXenCCILQJGAt9fbpaNSWQOY/ZuYlQ@jq0L1dO/becQtT22bijXnxwX@4FbL1TyrikCR022Yc@om3PNGVwTg34K7SxdlUi7s0lUlNqiHdI9h6X9A4Qi2HZTghj1GhoFLGqHDGBTpGRfOZoLkcN8E6sjP2p6MmWVbh7N6Qln@4mDZctRFXWFDQJ4r9lfAF) (corresponding to `t`ransposing the input matrix) to flip this.

**How?**

For an `n`x`n` matrix, we first calculate the bandwidth `b` and prepend `b` zeros to the front of the matrix elements as a 1d-vector.  We then split this up again into a matrix with `n+1` rows: this aligns the diagonals, placing the 'bands' in the first `2b+1` rows.  The 'rearranged version' is now just the `2b+1`x`n` submatrix of this.

Comment: I guess you take your input transposed, so the results are weird after correcting this [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7RCoIwFIbv9xbenZNnsGVaSXuL7qILJwhCm2BGvv06uZkx2Pk/9u/bxtCZ0L18O/WDB0fWuGaGxj5hHN7gULbDgwfusox310xjP0MLma4tOSR/kT4Wc403aWub21yT9PcAzvzqmvakliUKOlAZo6KKxzFGRSc6k45Rcb9A7pV0RRQd@4X4F/Ixe5Lya1@Rr2@4uFZM4ogJFkT@RrW9Ez4 "R – Try It Online")  I hope this is fine, but I think a fix would just require some work on indices.

Comment: @Arnauld - I *think* that your example has B>N, which isn't an allowed input, right?

Comment: Oh I see. I overlooked that part of the spec.

Comment: @pajonk - I'm kind-of assuming that what we call 'rows' and 'columns' of a square matrix are only distinguished by our naming convention (or how it's printed by the software used).  The results you link don't look wierd to me (I think): they're the expected output when 'row' and 'column' labels are swapped.  I think...

Comment: @pajonk - ...but updated to make this explicit now, anyway.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yeah, that's what I meant with "I hope this is fine". My point was just to avoid confusion when someone goes with the standard representation (printing the matrix vs test-cases in question).

Comment: what is the `[...,-n]` for? \$b\$ is at most \$n-1\$ since \$M\$ is square, so you'll have at most \$n^2+n-1\$ elements in your matrix (before recycling), hence when you add a row you will still be short of it being an \$(n+1)\times (n+1)\$ matrix? Or is there some other consideration I'm missing.

Comment: @Giuseppe - You're absolutely right.  It's a left-over from the original version (see the edits) when I appended as well as prepended zeros, before I realised that the recycled first elements don't interfere with the output.  Thanks and well-spotted!

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>66</sup> 53 bytes

```
#{.#|.-@$(#"1~0{](]#~[-:"2*"2)#\>/#\|@-/#\)@|.]{.~3*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY47b8IwFIV3/4qrGJHYai6OQ19uiKwidao6dA0RAwJVXTqULVH@enp9cYtCByS/jv2d4/M5JpgeYOUghRsw4GjmCOv315dRdih7zP0sk0kxmK7NWjk0uUusTqySm3ohN73PaVW@x7bDodSzUYm3Z4TGZaTndda4GhdyXittK@e1rKwmvq38tUxx3H8fVyEJ9ruPL5@mv8ewHyDBJ9xawVgobkQBRhgohLq45GvLq4Fy@mwAwpjuSxugSYjlmBKWcMvUHel7DnyAx8sfGT7jZ0PsQBaqyQyx/xoV0X4Crp8mdsqjX08PoUlUHBsVW6OKMaz@IkkJNf4A)

#### Basic Strategy

We want to avoid special casing the "pad the partial top rows
on the left", and "pad the partial bottom rows on the right".  If we extend
the input "offscreen" in both directions, a solution which automatically
handles these cases falls out for free.

#### Explanation

Consider:

```
1 2 0 0
3 4 5 0
0 6 0 7
0 0 8 9
```

- `]{.~3*$` Extend the input so its shape is 3 times its original shape:

  ```
  1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 6 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `-@$(...)@|.` And rotate it so the original is centered:

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 6 0 7 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 8 9 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  ```
- `#\>/#\|@-/#\` Generate all possible bands:

  ```
  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1

  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1

  ... etc
  ```
- `](]#~[-:"2*"2)` Filter only those that, when multiplied elementwise with the extended input, return the input unchanged:

  ```
  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1

  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1

  ...etc
  ```
- `0{` Take the first:

  ```
  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
  ```
- `#"1~` Use these masks to filter the extended input, row-wise:

  ```
  0 0 0
  0 0 0
  0 0 0
  0 0 0
  0 1 2
  3 4 5
  6 0 7
  8 9 0
  0 0 0
  0 0 0
  0 0 0
  0 0 0
  ```
- `#{.#|.` To extract only the middle portion that is our final answer, rotate
  left the length of the original input, and then take the length of the original
  input:

  ```
  0 1 2
  3 4 5
  6 0 7
  8 9 0
  ```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 28 bytes

```
≔⌈Ｅθ⌈Ｅι∧λ↔⁻μκηＩＥθＥ⁺κ…·±ηη§ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU3LCoMwELz7FXuMsIW@H3iSnjxYpFfJIbVBgzFaE8W/T7cWbJdhZ4fZnS0q0Ret0N7H1qrSsFRMqhka4o69EP6lQojNk2mih2314CRLlRksaxDq8FsIVRgFWa@MY1dh3S@nY5mm3RohMQVNapR3YUrJbrIUFFXNt9Ril5innD7v9JwZeZ/n@QZhi7AmcAwA8h3CHuGwaHKOs39aNOGMcOGc@9Wo3w) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⌈Ｅθ⌈Ｅι∧λ↔⁻μκη
```

Calculate the width of the band.

```
ＩＥθＥ⁺κ…·±ηη§ιλ
```

Output the relevant cyclic diagonals.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>24</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ĀDƶsøƶøαàUεNX-._X·>£
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SIPLsW3Fh3cc23Z4x7mNhxeEntvqF6GrFx9xaLvdocX//0dHG@oY6RiAYKxOtLGOiY4plG2gYwZkmUPZBjoWOpY6hlC2AVCPcWwsAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaCkU6nDpRRQlFpSUqlbUJSZV5KaopAJlzu0PCr93JasQ7uBivxLS2DCLv@PNLgc21Z8eMexbYd3nNt4eEHoua1@Ebp68RGHttsdWvy/1hbD0Hy4doShh7bZ/4@OjjbUMYjViTbQMYyN1VEAc6ECRlDaQMcYImUAl0LQJkYwbUZQUWMdEx1TqLwZUMwcqtJCxxJFKbJiZOVwo4EagI6CWgfUA3eFoQ6KS4hmg7UDzQHaCZMEuQXKhwQCjA/VCOXDjQHzkQwF8mNjYwE).

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Get the bandwidth of the input-matrix, using the same exact code as [my answer in the related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243498/52210):

```python
Ā        # Transform each non-0 integer in the (implicit) input-matrix to a 1
 D       # Duplicate this matrix of 0s/1s
  ƶ      # Multiply each inner value by its 1-based row-index
 s       # Swap so the matrix of 0s/1s is at the top again
  øƶø    # Do the same for the columns
         # (where `ø` is a zip/transpose, to swap rows/columns)
     α   # Take the absolute difference of the values at the same positions
      à  # Pop and push the flattened maximum
```

Step 2: Leave the actual diagonal band matrix using the \$bandwidth\times2+1\$, and output it as result:

```python
       U # Pop and store the bandwidth in variable `X`
ε        # Map over the rows of the (implicit) input-matrix
 NX-     #  Push N-X, where `N` is the 0-based map-index
    ._   #  Rotate the current row that many times towards the left,
         #  where negative values will rotate towards the right instead
 X·>     #  Push 2X+1, where `X` is still the bandwidth
    £    #  Leave that many leading items from the current rotated row
         # (after which the mapped matrix is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: `εXÅ0.øN._X·>£` saves a byte.

Comment: Actually, since `B<N`, you can use `εNX-._X·>£` to save four bytes.

Comment: @Neil Smart! Thanks for -4. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>37</s> <s>26</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
vT:ẏεfG£¨2Ǔ¥ǔ¥d›Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJ2VDrhuo/OtWZHwqPCqDLHk8Klx5TCpWTigLrhuo4iLCIiLCJbWzEsMiwwLDAsMF0sWzMsNCw1LDAsMF0sWzAsNiwwLDcsMF0sWzAsMCw4LDksMV0sWzAsMCwwLDIsM11dIl0=)

### How?

```
vT:ẏεfG£¨2Ǔ¥ǔ¥d›Ẏ
vT                  # For each row, get the indices of truthy elements
  :ẏ                # Duplicate and push a range in [0..length of list)
    ε               # Vectorizing absolute difference
     fG             # Get the flattened maximum difference
       £            # Store in the register
        ¨2          # Open dyadic map lambda on (implicit) input, pushing both item and index
          Ǔ         # Rotate row left by index
           ¥ǔ       # Rotate row right by the contents of the register
             ¥d›    # Push 2*register+1
                Ẏ   # Leave that many leading items in the current rotated row
```

*-10 bytes thanks to Neil, and another -9 from myself*

Comment: `¨2$¥0ẋ:∇pp$Ǔ¥d1+Ẏ` saves three bytes.

Comment: Actually, since `B<N`, you can use `¨2Ǔ¥ǔ¥d1+Ẏ` to save ten bytes.

Comment: Oh, I see now, that's a `›`... and here was me thinking it was a `>` and wondering why it wasn't incrementing...

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>118</s>  116 bytes

```javascript
f=(m,k,q=m.map(_=>0),M=m.map((r,y)=>q.concat(r,q[S='slice'](~y),0)[S](y+k,~k)))=>M.some(r=>r[0]|r[S](-1))?M:f(m,-~k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9Nc4IwEIbv@RU7XsiOGEHtpwM9tTd74ShOh2KwKARJsDNMW/@6XSKt01MzTHbf3efdDdvkPTGpzvfNSFVreTplAS/dnVsHpSiTPX8JQg/dRa@4dlsMwlqklUqThmS9jALHFHkqnRU/tuh6uIxWvB3u3OMOkeCFMFUpuQ5CvfRWn7prj3zEh8V9RqtGhJ20rA@5ltzJjINCy2T9lBcyalXKPRRNFTU6VxuOwuyLvOGDWMVqgCKr9GOSvnEDQQgfDKCQDZQQgLmAhHUvt8hPeRyb4fhcfz6Ur1IjuuTujpZEAj0M54xK9J@mKqQoqg2nlrXobpQW2ypX3AEHsU9j5SAMwcY5@8KTDx7zwGeMEptO7O3BlFGA7vsbZ5OOnVh6CjO4so1r0jfWdwt3v8AFuUD9eMJoq2WItcv83nIu/p8x8tH0s@g29sqO6pXFe9VbrfodQ@ob)

#### How?

Given a matrix \$m\$ of size \$N\times N\$, we build a vector \$q\$ of size \$N\$ filled with \$0\$'s:

```javascript
q = m.map(_ => 0)
```

For each row \$r\$ at position \$y\$ (0-indexed) in \$m\$, we use \$q\$ to append \$N\$ leading \$0\$'s and \$y+2\$ trailing \$0\$'s:

```javascript
q.concat(r, q.slice(~y), 0)
```

For instance:

```javascript
[ 1 2 3 ] --> [ 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 ]
[ 4 5 6 ] --> [ 0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0 ]
[ 7 8 9 ] --> [ 0 0 0 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 ]
```

Starting with \$k=0\$, we then remove \$y+k\$ leading \$0\$'s and \$k+1\$ trailing \$0\$'s:

```javascript
.slice(y + k, ~k)
```

Which gives a new matrix \$M_k\$ of width \$2(N-k)+1\$:

```javascript
[ 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 ]     --> [ 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0 ]   --> [ 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 ] --> [ 0 7 8 9 0 0 0 ]
```

We increment \$k\$ and repeat the whole process on the original matrix until there's at least one non-zero value in either the first or the last column of \$M_k\$:

```javascript
M.some(r => r[0] | r.slice(-1))
```

NB: `r.slice(-1)` returns an atomic array which is coerced to an integer by the bitwise operator.

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 89 bytes

```
m->a=0;matrix(#m,,i,j,m[i,j]&&a=max(a,abs(i-j)));matrix(#m,2*a+1,i,j,m[i,(i+j-a-2)%#m+1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZBRSgMxEIbxJqGlJXEnmKTVtpTtPWQJMj6sZDES1i3Us_iyIOKZ9DTOJtl23_oymf_PN_OTfP4EbN3TS-i_alZ-H7tabn8fvTxgqfYeu9ad-NwDOGjAV1TtcomlxxNHwOd37mQjhJiQ5hYLfca5KxqJ0ojF3BfaihTwd3OHIbx-cM_kgYXWvXXUzgYxYzX3QgCrKg1qr0Bb6qmNwsSqYDWYKptjXZuEmuisYA338eaB9CYSW9hNkAt0wfIqAkGn1cTmNA2TxOudhYpGKSD5Q2hWw6tGFfms8mxU5z2k7PhvfZ_Ofw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) NumPy, 126 bytes

```
def f(*a):x=triu(tri(l:=len(a),2*l-1,l-1))[::-1];x[x>0]=r_[a];j=min(where(x+x[:,::-1])[1]);return x[:,j:-j]
from numpy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVFLboMwFFS3PsUTKzsliE_apiBH6jlIVKEGFCJjLIeoZNOLdJNNe4kue4r2NH22SVClVoow5o3fvJkBXt_Vodu08nh823fVdP71si4rqOikYGnPO13vKW5UpFyUkhbMjydiGvl4M5an6TRaZX3eL8IV1495scq2vKklfd6UuqT9dZ-nviWxHO9Ml91eSzCn23S6XZFKtw3IfaMOUDeq1d1kSPHp4NArdiAVIVWrQUAtoVWYJWSBLos1ZcFOibqj3lIupcdSAgC13wIHEewwuxoZfOGxsU2lCpqio_2ZpksliqfSSHm-l3mMBQ9gXHvjSnGM2Xmla9khpPidasZ5y4JCCMoAqe7MMN2rHL-vPiIISQgR4QsS4UUQ25PY7iEkrhOThCAGs34_Z7FhIMKFNQrEViKBGdxY0i3iOys2h3tDRj-IHYG4JjaQepodp8f5IY4hRrYyEZP_1TAyJEbTtMNBKbyosprhyeaP3UrPBrbJPCAXxSEn4dCgbdHZx4QenE6k6ILqZIJz7if-AA)

Rather opportunistically takes the splatted array (this saves three bytes) as input.

##### How?

Uses the properties of masked assignment to map *all* diagonals by the deceptively short statement `x[x>0]=r_[a]`. The actual work is in setting up the initial mask `x`. And in trimming excess columns afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>203</s> 193 bytes

*-10 bytes thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)*

```
def f(m):R=range;n=len(m);r=R(n);d=[*map(any,c:=[[m[i][i+d]if i+d in r else 0for i in r]for d in R(-n,n+1)])];k=min(d.index(1),d[::-1].index(1));return[[c[i][j]for i in R(k,n+n-k+1)]for j in r]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVJBTsMwEJQ4-hWrnGzaVElboCTyJ9qj60PVOOA23kROKrVv4dIL_INnwGuwnbSCG0IkUTw7u-Nde_flrTl1zzWez6-HrowXH--FKqGkhmVLbjf4pHLklUJH5JYvKbK84OLWbBq6wdN4m3EhjNBS6FEhdQluAY1gQVWtgqSsLehASA-Db0ljHOMoZZLJfM-NRlpMNBbqSFM2LkSWxam8Ei6t6g4Whdj6NDt53XJJ924bjPd-K8_u-kT9QT5voLS1gaaxGjvQpqltN1iErHgURSSFKST-JTOYw11ACdy79SGgBBbwCGlAiYudEeJ-LrQXeflguZCrFcIHa5AGa8DBIk4cRAEEOB2ULkkC4L-f6zyIpt_LvRR7KZX85US-nmQITH6F_u0SfA-IaYGDEML1hR4Z-EYeQyMnbVPpjjIZOOu5tucqjaqlDNy82d7beu9qUERrXGPEJCHeZbzLtBkB9_T9p36-GekH5TL5Xw)

Comment: [193 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVJBTsMwEJQ4-hWrnGzaVElboCTyJ9qj60PVOOA23kROKrVv4dIL_INnwGuwnbSCG0IkUTw7u-Nde_flrTl1zzWez6-HrowXH--FKqGkhmVLbjf4pHLklUJH5JYvKbK84OLWbBq6wdN4m3EhjNBS6FEhdQluAY1gQVWtgqSsLehASA-Db0ljHOMoZZLJfM-NRlpMNBbqSFM2LkSWxam8Ei6t6g4Whdj6NDt53XJJ924bjPd-K8_u-kT9QT5voLS1gaaxGjvQpqltN1iErHgURSSFKST-JTOYw11ACdy79SGgBBbwCGlAiYudEeJ-LrQXeflguZCrFcIHa5AGa8DBIk4cRAEEOB2ULkkC4L-f6zyIpt_LvRR7KZX85US-nmQITH6F_u0SfA-IaYGDEML1hR4Z-EYeQyMnbVPpjjIZOOu5tucqjaqlDNy82d7beu9qUERrXGPEJCHeZbzLtBkB9_T9p36-GekH5TL5Xw)

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 64 bytes

Prompts for input matrix. Index origin = 0

```
b←⌈/⌈/¨+/¨^\¨b(⌽b←×0 1↓a←(⍳n←¯1↑r←↑⍴m)⌽m←⎕)⋄((r,-b)↑a),(r,1+b)↑a
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##lU7BasJAEL3vV8zNBA3d7Cax/YSC4g@UwkaJCNEWPfVeoqAGpUh/wVsP9eol/sn8SJzdhJjclGGY9@a9x4z6jJ3Rl4o/xs4wVovFZJhjeuj3MNlJRuh1QIgzXC2jPCSIm9WT7uzYpn5/y46hhZuzli6/HFxMfhRhC7f/M5rZH232cx1M9rg9TW0yTzVNDzauvy1r3nFCm0Rldwi77YLkdJDlERMgKOUCp3JZC1osYhJkteMgyikbKodmeaKUPfBMuIhJ8MA3KKDuGvQML6XXB7/mrbvrfpOA2zuykeaVcmeV6QACSgtzs1D0H48wfmNX)