# Return the highest possible placement value based on the input

Tags: code-golf, math, number

### Introduction

The challenge itself was something I came across and had to try and figure out for a personal of project of mine. I ended up branching out and asking family members if they could provide an equation to meet the requirements.

**Note:** I have (with the help of others) found a solution for this but now I'm just trying to see how others would approach this.

### Challenge

Take the following scenario where the left hand side number is N (the input):

```
N    Output
0 -> 9
1 -> 99
2 -> 999
3 -> 9999
4 -> 99,999
5 -> 999,999
...
15 -> 9,999,999,999,999,999
```

So, essentially, for an input number **N**, your program must provide the highest integer with **N + 1** decimal places.

**Note:** Commas are not required to separate the numbers, I placed them above purely for readability.

### Criteria of Success

The criteria of success is based on the following:

- Shortest in terms of code size

Comment: Also can we output as a list ie `[9, 9, 9]`

Comment: @Okx no, it has to be a single number. So 3 => 9999 and cannot be [9,9,9,9].

Comment: Top of Hot Network Questions with a score of one. I'm thinking the idea about preventing HNQ when number of answers > score is a decent one.

Comment: @CAD97 meta it?

Comment: @Script47 [It was brought up on Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291249/383387) but nothing was ever done about it.

Comment: Someone should write an answer in [_99_](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47588/write-an-interpreter-for-99), although I'm not sure how to do multiply/power in that esolang. ;)

Comment: You're getting a lot of downvotes because of the overly complicated explanation for what is, essentially, either print `n+1` `9`s or print `10^n-1`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen [challenge accepted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163815/67312)

Comment: @Script47 It seems arbitrary to print N **+ 1** nines instead of just just N nines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 3 bytes

```
>9
```

Explanation:

```
>      Increment input
 9    Repeat 9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3/387yw9ypi///NwUA)

Comment: Holy moly, *3 bytes*? That's insanity.

Comment: @Script Nothing surprising. Javascript/Python takes 3 builtins, this also takes 3 builtins.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

#### Code:

```
>°<
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7tAGm///TQA)

#### Explanation:

```
>      # Increment the implicit input
 °     # Compute 10 ** (input + 1)
  <    # Decrement the result
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 11 bytes

```
(1+)+("9"*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@1/DUFtTW0PJUklL839BUWZeiUaahomm5n8A)

This is a function.

## Explanation

```
(1+)+("9"*)  Function
 1+          Anonymous function; add the input to 1
      "9"*   Anonymous function; multiply "9" by the input
    +        Function Composition; add the input to 1 then multiply "9" by this number
(  ) (    )  Brackets for order of operations
```

:o proton beats python with its function composition for once :D

Comment: Alternatives with same byte-count: `("9"*)+(+9)` or `("9"*)+(9+)`. `+(+n)` prepends, `+(n+)` appends to the string `("9"*)` which is the same as in _@HyperNeutrino_'s answer above.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh cool, thanks! I forgot that `"9"+9` worked in Proton

Answer (score 4):

## APL+WIN, <s>9</s> 5 bytes

Thanks to ngn for -3 bytes and Adám for -1 byte

Prompts for integer input:

```
1⎕/⍕9
```

Comment: Save a byte with `'9'` → `⍕9`.

Comment: and another three with `(1+⎕)⍴` -> `1⎕/`

Comment: @ngn Very clever!

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function

```
9^&.>:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WyjJOTc/OKvZ/anJGvkKagoGCoYKRgrGCiYKpgqFpxX8A)

`9^`…`]` nine raised to the power of the argument

`&.`… while both nine and the argument are under the influence of

`>:` increment

I.e. increment nine and the argument, then power, then un-increment, i.e. decrement. Effectively `((9+1)^(n+1))-1`.

Comment: Also 7 bytes for output as a string: `'9'$~>:`

Comment: @GalenIvanov Sure, but this solution is way cooler :-)

Comment: Of course, your solution is incomparably cooler. it's always a pleasure to use `&.` :)

Comment: @GalenIvanov Yes, I hope to get Under into APL next year, `⍢`.

Answer (score 4):

## [99](https://github.com/TryItOnline/99), 90 bytes

```
 999
9999 9 9
99999 99 9 9999 9
999 999 9999 9
			




99999
999 999 9
 999999 999
 9 9999
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##s7T8/1/B0tKSC4gtFYAQzADSYA6YxQXhw7mcnJxcIABWiJDkAstDeFxQzf//mwAA)

Possibly not optimal, but it was fun to write.

EDIT: looks like I was right, as [Jo King outgolfed me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163816/67312) by not incrementing the input and being smarter about the gotos.

```
 999			assign input to tri-nine
9999 9 9		assign 0 to quad-nine
99999 99 9 9999 9	assign 81 to quint-nine for printing
999 999 9999 9		increment tri-nine
			




99999			print 81/nine (the numeral nine)
999 999 9		decrement tri-nine
 999999 999		if tri-nine is zero exit program (goto outside program)
 9 9999			else goto line nine
```

Comment: Well done. Too bad the byte-count isn't 99 as well. ;p

Answer (score 4):

## [*99*](https://github.com/TryItOnline/99), 69 bytes

```
9999 9 9
99999 99 9 9999 9
 999






99999
 99 999
999 999 9
 9 9999
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##s7T8/98SCBSAkMsSwgJzwCwuEM0FAWBJLrCsJVipAkwJWDHQGAA)

Appropriate (but it's a pity that this didn't end up at 99 bytes)

#### Explanation

```
9999 9 9           9999 = 9-9
99999 99 9 9999 9  99999 = 99-9+(9-9)-9 = 9*9
 999               999 = input*9



Filler to get up to line 9


99999      Print (9*9)/9 as a number
 99 999    Jump to line 99 if 999 is 9-9
999 999 9  999 = 999 - 9
 9 9999    Jump unconditionally to line 9
```

Comment: the number `9` now just looks weird to me.

Answer (score 3):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 3 bytes

```
u╤D
```

Explanation:

```
u    Increment input
 ╤   10 ** x
  D  Decrement
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/7/00dQlLv//mwIA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```hs
f n=10*10^n-1
```

Or for string output 15 bytes, `f n='9'<$[0..n]`

Thanks to @EsolangingFruit for a byte.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz9bQIE4jT9tQU9fwf25iZp6CrUJBaUlwSZFPnoKSn4KCgn9pCVBAScHOTiE3scA3XkEjJlPXTkEDokqvOCO/XDMTJAsRUFBSeNQ2SQGsvqAoM69EQSNNIVNTUyHaQE/PNPY/AA)

Comment: `f n=10*10^n-1` saves a byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
Q10w^q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9DQoDyu8P9/YwA)

#### Explanation:

```
Q       % Grab input and increment by 1
 10     % Push 10
   w    % Swap stack
    ^   % Raise 10 to the power of input+1
     q  % Decrement by 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 4

```
*\9h
```

[Online test](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2A%5C9h&input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A15&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A15&debug=0).

#### Explanation

```
    Q  # Implicit input
   h   # Increment
*\9    # Repeat string "9" n+1 times
```

Comment: Nice, I got [`t^Th`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=t%5ETh&input=14&debug=0), also 4 bytes.

Comment: I got *p\9 with length 4. https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2ap%5C9&input=1&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0&debug=0

Comment: @NeverHopeless I see it works, but how?  e.g. with input 4, I think this translates to `print "9", 4 times`; yet 5 "9"s are a printed?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, by enabling debugging I found that there are two print functions 'Pprint' and 'imp_print' in this statement `imp_print(times(Pprint("9"),Q))`  and it is written here: https://pyth.herokuapp.com/rev-doc.txt that `p  <any>                  Print A, with no trailing newline. **Return A**.` So my understanding is that `Pprint` prints Q times and 'p' token return that character which is printed by 'imp_print' that is why it appears Q+1 times.

Comment: @NeverHopeless Makes sene - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 8

```
A?1+^1-p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/R3lA7zlC34P9/EwA)

#### Explanation

```
A         # Push 10
 ?        # Push input
  1+      # Increment input
    ^     # Raise 10 to the (input + 1)th power
     1-   # Decrement
       p  # Print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 19 bytes

[Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) does a better job than [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) ([needs eval](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7UsMUehoCgzryRNwVJVr1ih2kBPT8Ww9v///4YA)):

```sh
printf 9%.s {0..$1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/oCgzryRNwVJVr1ih2kBPT8Ww9v///4YA)

#### Alternative, 20 bytes

This works for both [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) and [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (due to [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma?tab=profile)):

```sh
echo $[10**($1+1)-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX0El2tBAS0tDxVDbUFPXMPb////GAA)

Comment: Shorter for bash: `echo $[10**($1+1)-1]`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: Oh nice, works for Zsh as well (edited it in)!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 16 bytes

```python
lambda a:"9"*-~a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRSslSSUu3LvF/QVFmXolGmoaJpuZ/AA)

Just a simple anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 18 bytes

```javascript
x=>"9".repeat(x+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1k7JUkmvKLUgNbFEo0LbUPN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoappibXfwA)

Comment: Or alternatively `n=>10**-~n-1`

Comment: Though I never specified, it would be ideal to get it a int rather than a string. Nevertheless, good answer.

Comment: @Arnauld it seems that with with your code when `n = 15` the output is `10000000000000000`.

Comment: @Script47 JS can't support numbers greater than 9007199254740991.  So, yes, it works up to **n=14**.

Comment: @Arnauld ah, right, did not know that. Thank you very much. Any ideas why it is limited as such? Meaning, was it because of technological limitations when JS first came and it hasn't changed or is it something else?

Comment: @Script47 [Here is why.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (Of course, you can manipulate numbers greater than that, but they will be rounded.)

Comment: Alternative to @Arnauld's version: `n=>"10e"+n-1`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
‘⁵*’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4xHjVu1HjXM/P//vykA)

```
‘⁵*’ - Main link. Argument: n (integer)
‘    - n+1
 ⁵*  - 10 ** (n+1)
   ’ - (10 ** (n+1)) - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
R'9→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P0jd8lHbpP///xsAAA)

```
R'9→  -- example input: 3
   →  -- increment: 4
R'9   -- replicate the character '9': ['9','9','9','9']
      -- implicitly print "9999"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```js
°Uî9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9CG0MPrLP//NwYA)

Shaved off that one byte thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)'s clever eyes. You can see the edit history for a number of 5-byte solutions.

Comment: 4 bytes: `°Uî9`

Comment: @Shaggy Nice! You should post it as an answer.

Comment: It's just a variation on your first solution so work away. Also, I have a 3 byte solution to post after lunch.

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
╵9×
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXUyNTc1OSVENw__,i=NQ__,v=2)

```
╵    increment the input
 9   push "9"
  ×  repeat the "9" input+1 times
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 48 bytes

```
({}()){({}<(((((()()()){}()){}){}){}())>[()])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6VkNTsxpI2WiAgSYIakJEayEIyLSL1tCM1aytrv3/3/C/riMA)

This uses the `-A` to enable ASCII output. Bonus round: A version without `-A`.

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 50 bytes

```
({}(())){({}<((({})(({}){}){}){})>[()])}{}({}[()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6VkNDU1OzGsiw0dAAkppgAo7sojU0YzVrgcqqa8HM//8NAQ)

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6VkNTsxpI2WhoQDggShOGojU0YzXtwGRtde3//8YA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 21 bytes

```
a00+1*0-8 9a=+*0-+1_A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83PTc1N/P8/0cBA21DLQNdCwTLRVhvI0DaMd/z/39LS8l9@QUlmfl7xf91MAA) Requires the `-i` interpreter flag.

### Explanation

A brief rundown of Momema's features:

- Its only data type is the unbounded integer. It has a double-ended tape (indexed by unbounded integers) where every number is initialized to zero.
- Strings of digits are integer literals which evaluate to themselves. Leading zeroes are parsed as their own integers.
- `+ab` evaluates to the sum of `a` and `b`.
- `-a` evaluates to the negation of `a`.
- `*a` evaluates to the value of cell `a` on the tape.
- `=a` evaluates to 0 if `a` evaluates to 0, and `=` otherwise.
- At the top level, `ab` stores `b` at cell `a` on the tape. Attempting to write a number to `-8` writes its decimal representation to STDOUT instead.
- At the top level, `[w]a` (where `[w]` is any string of lowercase letters) acts like "relative jump forward by `a` jump instructions that share the label `[w]`."
- The Momema reference implementation accepts a flag `-i`, which activates interactive mode. In interactive mode, `_[W]` (where `[W]` is any string of uppercase letters) is called a *hole* and evaluates to a number read from STDIN. However, it caches the number with its label, so if a hole with the same label is ever evaluated again it will be reused.

Knowing this, here's how you expand this program:

```
a   0                                                                                       # do {
0   (+ 1 (* 0))                                                                             #   n = n + 1
-8  9                                                                                       #   print 9
a   (= (+ (* 0) (- (+ 1 _A))))                                                              # while (n != input)
```

(This still parses, by the way; the Momema parser treats parentheses the same way as whitespace.)

---

```
a   0
```

Jumps forward by 0 `a` instructions (i.e. does nothing). This is only here to serve as a jump target later.

```
0   (+ 1 (* 0))
```

Increments the value of cell 0 (initially 0) and stores it back in cell 0.

```
-8  9
```

`-8` is memory-mapped for numeric I/O, so this outputs `9` to STDOUT.

```
a   (= (+ (* 0) (- (+ 1 _A))))
```

Compute `tape[0] - (input + 1)`. If it is zero (i.e. both sides were equal), then `=` maps the result to 0, making it a no-op. Control runs off of the end of the program. However, if it is nonzero, this is a `1`. Since there are no `a` instructions after here, it wraps around to the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king) for -1 byte

```
-[++>+[+<]>]>+<,+[->.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN1pb2047Wtsm1i7WTttGRzta107PJvb/f04A) Takes input as ASCII

Comment: Most people wouldn't begrudge you removing that leading `>`

Comment: @JoKing The next time I should have a closer look while copying from the esolang page :). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 79 bytes

```
[S S S T    S T S N
_Push_10][S N
S _Duplicate_10][S N
S _Duplicate_10][S N
S _Duplicate_10][T  N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   T   S N
_If_negative_Jump_to_Label_EXIT][S N
T   _Swap][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_2st][T    S S N
_Multiply][S N
T   _Swap][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_EXIT][T   S S S _Add][T   N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgRMIuYAQgji5OEEAwgXxFCDSnBBSAcLnVADzgJgLpAzEB6pV4Pz/3wQA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer i = STDIN as integer
Integer j = 10
Start LOOP:
  i = i - 1
  If i is negative (-1): Go to function PRINT_AND_EXIT
  j = j * 10
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function PRINT_AND_EXIT:
  j = j + i (Since i=-1 at this point, this is basically j = j - 1)
  Print j as integer
  Exit with error
```

**Example run (`n=4`):**

```
Command   Explanation                   Stack              HEAP    STDIN   STDOUT  STDERR

SSSTSTSN  Push 10                       [10]
SNS       Duplicate top (10)            [10,10]
SNS       Duplicate top (10)            [10,10,10]
SNS       Duplicate top (10)            [10,10,10,10]
TNTT      Read STDIN as integer         [10,10,10]         {10:4}  4
TTT       Retrieve                      [10,10,4]          {10:4}
NSSN      Create Label_LOOP             [10,10,4]          {10:4}
 SSSTN     Push 1                       [10,10,4,1]        {10:4}
 TSST      Subtract (4-1)               [10,10,3]          {10:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (3)            [10,10,3,3]        {10:4}
 NTTSN     If neg.: Jump to Label_EXIT  [10,10,3]          {10:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                 [10,3,10]          {10:4}
 STSSTSN   Copy 2nd                     [10,3,10,10]       {10:4}
 TSSN      Multiply (10*10)             [10,3,100]         {10:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                 [10,100,3]         {10:4}
 NSNN      Jump to Label_LOOP           [10,100,3]         {10:4}

 SSSTN     Push 1                       [10,100,3,1]       {10:4}
 TSST      Subtract (3-1)               [10,100,2]         {10:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (2)            [10,100,2,2]       {10:4}
 NTTSN     If neg.: Jump to Label_EXIT  [10,100,2]         {10:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                 [10,2,100]         {10:4}
 STSSTSN   Copy 2nd                     [10,2,100,10]      {10:4}
 TSSN      Multiply (100*10)            [10,2,1000]        {10:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                 [10,1000,2]        {10:4}
 NSNN      Jump to Label_LOOP           [10,1000,2]        {10:4}

 SSSTN     Push 1                       [10,1000,2,1]      {10:4}
 TSST      Subtract (2-1)               [10,1000,1]        {10:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (1)            [10,1000,1,1]      {10:4}
 NTTSN     If neg.: Jump to Label_EXIT  [10,1000,1]        {10:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                 [10,1,1000]        {10:4}
 STSSTSN   Copy 2nd                     [10,1,1000,10]     {10:4}
 TSSN      Multiply (1000*10)           [10,1,10000]       {10:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                 [10,10000,1]       {10:4}
 NSNN      Jump to Label_LOOP           [10,10000,1]       {10:4}

 SSSTN     Push 1                       [10,10000,1,1]     {10:4}
 TSST      Subtract (1-1)               [10,10000,0]       {10:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (0)            [10,10000,0,0]     {10:4}
 NTTSN     If neg.: Jump to Label_EXIT  [10,10000,0]       {10:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                 [10,0,10000]       {10:4}
 STSSTSN   Copy 2nd                     [10,0,10000,10]    {10:4}
 TSSN      Multiply (10000*10)          [10,0,100000]      {10:4}
 SNT       Swap top two                 [10,100000,0]      {10:4}
 NSNN      Jump to Label_LOOP           [10,100000,0]      {10:4}

 SSSTN     Push 1                       [10,100000,0,1]    {10:4}
 TSST      Subtract (0-1)               [10,100000,-1]     {10:4}
 SNS       Duplicate top (-1)           [10,100000,-1,-1]  {10:4}
 NTTSN     If neg.: Jump to Label_EXIT  [10,100000,-1]     {10:4}
NSSSN      Create Label_EXIT            [10,100000,-1]     {10:4}
TSSS       Add (10000+-1)               [10,99999]         {10:4}
TNST       Print as integer             [10]               {10:4}          99999
                                                                                   error
```

Stops program with error: No exit defined.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 7 bytes

```perl
$_=9x$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tayQiX@/3/Tf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Comment: You don't need the quotes there.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tayQiX@/3/Tf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Good spot, thx.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 26 bytes

```
{for(;a++<$1;){printf"9"}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMM6UVvbRsXQWrO6oCgzryRNyVKptvb/f0NTAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 14 bytes

`f(n)="9"^(n+1)`

That's if the result can be a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 30 bytes

```
	OUTPUT =DUPL(9,INPUT + 1)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NCQgNETB1iU0wEfDUsfTD8TTVjDU5HL1c/n/39AUAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 5 bytes

```
PR`9H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvhv6Ohu6f4/ICjB0uP/fwA)

This is a Gol><> function which takes the stack content as input.

#### Example full program & How it works

```
1AG9G
PR`9H

1AG    Register row 1 as function G
   9G  Call G with stack [9]

P      Increment
 R`9   Push char '9' that many times
    H  Print the stack content as chars and halt
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 7 bytes

```
10^(Ans+1)-1
```

Fairly straightforward...

Comment: Yeah, no idea why this got flagged.

Comment: @Ste Blame SE automatic bots. Why must  answers here have explanation?

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
qi)'9*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzBTU91S6/9/YwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)

```
&#9':_@#\-1,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X03ZUt0q3kE5RtdQ5/9/UwA)

Answer (score 1):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 16 bytes

```
@Power(10;i+1)-1
```

Simple port of my Python answer. One of the nice things about formula is that if you pass it a list it will apply the same function to each list member.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```
__=-~(_==_)
_=(__+__**-~__)**-~_+~_+_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Pt5Wt04j3tY2XpMr3lYjPl47Pl5LS7cuPl4TTGkDUfz///8NAQ)

---

#### Ungolfed

```
# implicit input stored in _
__  = -~(_==_)             # __ = -~True = 1 + True = 1 + 1 = 2
_=(__+__**-~__)**-~_+~_+_  # _  = (2 + 2 ** -~2) ** -~_ + ~_ + _ 
                                = (2 + 2**3) ** (_ + 1) - -~_ + _
                                = 10 ** (_ + 1) - (_ + 1) + _
                                = 10 ** (_ + 1) - 1
# implicit output of _
```

---

#### other 37 byte solutions

```
__=_==_
_=(-~__*-~-~-~-~__)**-~_+~_+_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Pt423tY2niveVkO3Lj5eS7cOAuPjNbWAnHhtIIr///@/IQA)

```
_=(-~(_==_)*-~-~-~-~(_==_))**-~_+~_+_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/3lZDt04j3tY2XlNLtw4CIVxNLaBAvDYQxf///98QAA)

---

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), 29 bytes

multiplies the string `'9'` by `_ + 1`

```
_=`-~-~(_==_)*-~-~(_==_)`*-~_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/3jZBt063TiPe1jZeUwvBTACy4////28IAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
×9⊕Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/19LQ8lSSUdBW1vDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU1Pz/3@D/7plOf91M/8b/jf6b/zf5L9u/n/L/5YgBMYQwhIA)

#### Explanation

```
×9     Repeat "9"
  ⊕Ｎ ++(next number as input) times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 26 bytes

```
puts [expr 10*10**$argv-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCE6taKgSMHQQAuItFQSi9LLdA1j////bwoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 30 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(n)(1-(expt 10(1+ n))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxNDkAwFEXhuVXcmLiNSBQben6aSJTiDSSiWy/O/DvDMp8h8Zx0h0tcxPejcDW0FacrKGxNW2I1X8lkdNvhRaF5vKNk8clBLwHFt1E4FKxh0aBF94MX)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 18 bytes

Just throwing out a recursive solution to the problem:

```
f=n=>n?9+f(n-1):''
```

Evaluates the expression `''+9+9+9+9...` (depending on `n`).

Because the first operand is a string, all the `+` operators are treated as concatenation instead of addition.

In my Chrome, works up to `f(11424)` before hitting a stack overflow.

```js
f=n=>n?9+f(n-1):''

for(i = 0; i < 100; i += 10) {
  console.log(f(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 25 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJReZmtoas1lbwcUsi0uKYovSi1ITSzRsNQBS2obalr//w8A)

**Code**

(Passing `$arguments` to the script)

```
<?=str_repeat(9,$argv+1);
```

**Or a recursive function, 42 Bytes**

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUSjWrU5Mz8oEMGwNNeyUlKyVLJT2QuK6hpnXt/zQNS03r/wA)

```
function f($u){echo($u<0)?"":"9".f($u-1);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Phooey](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Phooey), 11 bytes

```
&.+1[$i9-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P9fTU/bMFol01LXMPb/f1MA)

### Explanation

```
&.+1[$i9-1]
&.              take numeric input
  +1            add 1
    [   -1]     until that is zero:
     $i9        output 9s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 9 bytes

```
{N!-~_&9}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@7/aT1G3Ll7Nsva/X2pqSnG0SkFBcnosV0BRZl5JSGpxiXNicWpxdJqOgoGVqbqhaex/AA)

### Alternatives

**10 bytes:** `{"9"*t-~_}`

**13 bytes:** (pointfree) `` 9&Resize@1&`+ ``

### Explanation

```
{N!-~_&9}     
{       }     anonymous lambda taking input `_`
   -~_        input + 1
      &9      9s repeated that much (array of 9s)
 N!           cast to integer
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 24 bytes

```
func[n][loop n[prin"9"]]
```

Outputs a string

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85Oi82Oic/v0AhL7qgKDNPyVIpNvZ/UWpBamKJQq6CkQFYtEQhTSE39j8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```python
lambda i:10**-~i-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHTytBAS0u3LlPX8H9afpFChUJmnkJRYl56qoaRgaZVQVFmXolCmkaF5n8A)

Don't think it needs an explanation.

-2 with thanks to @ovs

Answer (score 0):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity), 31 bytes

```
...)...
..IE@..
.)10^).
@_+....
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09PTxOIufT0PF0dQLSmoUGcph6XQ7w2UFjv/38TAA)

#### Also 31 bytes

```
...)...
..IE)..
.@_rM..
"9"}""J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09PTxOIufT0PF01QbRDfJEvkFayVKpVUvL6/98EAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```java
n->n+=Math.pow(10,n+1)+~n
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY/PDoIwDMbvPEWPW1AC/jkRfAO4cDQe5kAcjkKgYIzBV8cJXM2SNk37@5qvLcUgtmX2mKQWXQexUPh2ABRS3t6EzCH5tQC6xgIkmwvy0MxGkyY6EqQkJIAQwYTbE7pRLOjuNfWTBf4G3YC7H5zCRd70V23k69ZQqwwq48lSahUW5wsIvhimr47yyqt78hqDSCNDTzKfz@Z/eWDhOwvfW/jBwo@2@9YHRmecvg)

This is basically a shorter version of `n->(long)Math.pow(10,n+1)-1`, because `n+=...-n` saves a byte in comparison to `(long)...`. (And combining `-n-1` to `+~n` saves a second byte in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), <s>47</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

<s>-13</s> -15 bytes thanks to [@Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

```swift
{(0...$0).map{_ in"9"}.joined()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQpmD7v1rDQE9PT8VAUy83saA6XiEzT8lSqVYvKz8zLzVFQ7P2f1p@kUImUFgBpM5EoVqhoCgzr0QjTSNTU1Oh9j8A)

Comment: [`{(0...$0).map{_ in"9"}.joined()}`](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQpmD7v1rDQE9PT8VAUy83saA6XiEzT8lSqVYvKz8zLzVFQ7P2f1p@kUImUFgBpM5EoVqhoCgzr0QjTSNTU1Oh9j8A) saves another 2 bytes. Honestly, I should sometimes [follow my own tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137931/59487).

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>34</s> <s>23</s> 20 bytes

```
X+Y:-Y is 10*10^X-1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxCoMwFEV3v@IthaR5CXngZJXOznEwi@BgS@DRhKj4@Wna6R4OnJty5PjW@xVKmZXvtIewA9k72WXWZMoNXmvgM2/AMSY4ExwR2oaFQyfNf0fZade3OP1SpwhZTFWa5qlZ2Eo4Ko9XDscmvMQPIw32QUN9/wI)

Call as `<input>+<result variable>`.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 12 bytes

```
=10^(A1+1)-1
```

Or alternatively, to better handle larger values (`>10`) for `13 bytes`

```
=REPT(9,A1+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 11 bytes

```ruby
->n{?9*-~n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2t5SS7cur/Z/QWlJsUJatEEsF5RlaBr7HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (`-lm`), 22 bytes

```c
f(n){n=pow(10,-~n)-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfBCoMwDADQs/mK4BgkYIcedqrbv0hrXaFGqZUdxH36sr3bc2ZyTjWQ8CGPdXlT1zbmI2w6e@oliku7H7Hfio/L7fUEiFJwHqIQ4wHVmv8PVF993WCgO7OFKo9lz4KthVO/LqRh2tSk@Qc)

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.

Comment: Why the `int`? Just `f(n){n=pow(10,-~n)-1;}` also works, doesn't it?

Comment: Suggest `exp10(...)` instead of `pow(10,...)`

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 15 bytes

```
Iu9)^>Os(?@.>sW
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9@z1FIzzs6/WMPeQc@uOPz/f0sA)

Expands to the following cube:

```
    I u
    9 )
^ > O s ( ? @ .
> s W . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-P`, 3 bytes

```
ò@9
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=8kA5&input=OAotUA==)

---

### Explanation

```
ò       :Range [0,input]
 @      :Pass each through a function
  9     :  Return 9
        :Implicitly join and output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

```
~)'9'*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmfp1r9v05T3VJd639erWqd9X8DLkMuIy5jLhMuUy4zLnMuCy5LLkNTAA)

Explanation:

```
~)'9'* Full program, implicit input
       Stack: '5'
~      Evaluate
       Stack: 5
 )     Increment
       Stack: 6
  '9'  Push '9'
       Stack: 6 '9'
     * Repeat
       Stack: '999999'
       Implicit output
```

### [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 7 bytes

```
~)10\?(
```

[Try this one!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmfp1r9v07T0CDGXuN/Xq1qnfV/Ay5DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy5zLgsuSy5DUwA)

Explanation:

```
~)10\?( Full program, implicit input
        Stack: '5'
~)      Evaluate and increment (as above)
        Stack: 6
  10\?  Raise 10 to that power
        Stack: 1000000
      ( Decrement
        Stack: 999999
        Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
^|Av
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%5E%7CAv&i=15&a=1)

Packed would not be any shorter.

Explanation:

```
^|Av Full program, implicit input
^    Increment
 |A  Raise ten to that power
   v Decrement
     Implicit output
```

### [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
^'9*
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%5E%279*&i=15&a=1)

```
^'9* Full program, implicit input
^    Increment
 '9* Repeat "9"
     Implicit output
```